# List of possible birth years of living humans

Tags: code-golf, date, sorting

**The Challenge**

Output a list of years that starts with the current year and ends 120 years ago. The birth year of every living human would be included in this list.

**Details**

The list should be in descending order.

Every built-in function to manipulate arrays and/or lists is allowed.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

When run this year `2016`, the output would be

`2016, 2015, ..., 1897, 1896`

When run next year `2017`, the output would be

`2017, 2016, ..., 1898, 1897`

Etc.

**Update**

- Some have asked about the format of the list. As most have guessed, it doesn't matter. Insert any separator between the numbers. Intuitively most inserted a comma or space or both, newline or output an array.
- Quasi superhumans like [Jeanne Calment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeanne_Calment) are an exception to the rule stated in my question.

Comment: Please help me understand how to improve my question. It's my first code golf question.

Comment: I recommend the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for getting feedback before posting a challenge (not just for your first challenge - most of us use it for every challenge).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the sandbox existed. Not sure though if I know now should delete my question first. Seems a legit code golf question, but I'll go to the sandbox first.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this challenge. One thing that might be worth specifying is whether the output should always start with 2016, or with the year in which it is run (will it start with 2017 if run next year?). This will affect whether it is a fixed output challenge, or needs to access the current date.

Comment: If you get lots of downvotes, it probably means something is wrong. If you just get one downvote, it doesn't necessarily mean anything. It's worth asking just in case, but sometimes a challenge gets a downvote just at random.

Comment: I think you should probably either specify a separator to use between years, or explicitly say we can use any separator.

Comment: [Jeanne Louise Calment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeanne_Calment) lived 122 years.

Comment: Lad, that was way too early of an accept.

Comment: Does the output format matter?

Comment: And you have an off-by-one besides.  You can have a 119 year old born in 1895.

Comment: Is the challenge: "Print all the numbers from `y` - 120 to `y`" or "print all the birth years of living people"? Because if someone born in 1896 is alive today, that doesn't mean that there are also still people from 1898 around.

Comment: Also, if Jeanne Louise Calment was the oldest recorded person ever, I think it's safe to say that 123 years is the upper limit. Why not go back 123 years?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Pyke, 6 bytes

```
wC7m-
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=w%C2%99C7m-)

```
w     - 121
   m- - for i in range(^):
 C7   -  current_year-i
```

(After `w`, the codepoint for 153 is present but it isn't printable)

Comment: Wow, that was a quick checkmark. Maybe wait for a Jelly answer?

Comment: Whilst I agree it was a quick checkmark, I doubt even Jelly can do it in 5

Comment: Why do you have a variable for 121? Just because it is a square number? But well done!

Comment: The `w` actually has an unprintable byte afterwards that makes it 121

Comment: What encoding does Pyke use?

Comment: @LeakyNun it's configurable, whatever the default for the server it's running on. On pyke.catbus, I set it to Windows-1252

Answer (score 11):

## Pyth, <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
-L.d3C\y
```

Works by mapping over the range `[0...120]` and subtracting every number from the current year. The range is built implicitly by using `121` as the map argument. To avoid a separating whitespace between `.d3` and `121` we get this number by converting `y` to it's codepoint.
Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman for coming up with this approach!

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-L.d3C%5Cy&debug=0)

***Old 9-byte solution:***

```
_>121S.d3
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_%3E121S.d3&debug=0)

Builds the range `[1...<current year>]` and only takes the last 121 elements of it.

Comment: You should reverse the list so that it starts with the current year

Comment: `-L...` saves a few bytes.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Missed that part, fixed. Thanks for spotting!

Comment: @Jakube Used a different approach now, but thanks for the reminder that this exists, didn't use Pyth a lot in the last time!

Comment: `-L.d3C\y` should work for 8.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Very clever, thanks! :) Gotta do more Pyth, needed way too long to understand how that works...

Answer (score 9):

## R, 34 bytes

```
(format(Sys.Date(),"%Y"):0)[1:121]
```

See [here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=oVuj9wYz&version=1) on an online interpreter.

**Edit** Could be reduced to 33 bytes by using `substr`.

```
(substr(Sys.Date(),1,4):0)[1:121]
```

but technically this solution will only work until the 9999-12-31.

Comment: This is awesome. I did not know it could typecast a string into a number when using the `:` operator...

Answer (score 8):

## BASH + coreutils, <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```
x=`date +%Y`;seq $x -1 $((x-120))
```

Comment: in your case, quotes are unneeded:  change :  `date +"%Y"` into `date +%Y`

Comment: ``x=`date +%Y`;seq $x -1 $[x-120]`` or ``seq $[x=`date +%Y`] -1 $[x-120]`` works as well.

Comment: [10 bytes shorter](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89583/11259) if you have OSX or are willing to install `jot` on Linux

Answer (score 8):

## [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) + [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), 274 bytes

```js
angular.module('x',[]).controller('x',['$scope',function(x){x.x=_.range(9,new Date().getFullYear()+1).slice(-121).reverse()}])
```

```html
<script src=//goo.gl/M5LvGe></script><script src=//goo.gl/opljJl></script><select ng-app=x ng-controller=x multiple><option ng-repeat="x in x">{{x}}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to Sp3000 and 1 byte thanks to Martin Ender*

```
et0=121,f-p
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=et0%3D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Push%20the%20current%20year%0A%20%20%20%20121%2C%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Push%20the%20range%200%2C%201%2C%20...%2C%20120%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f-%20%20%20e%23%20For%20each%20item%20in%20the%20range%2C%20subtract%20it%20from%20current%20year%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p%20%20e%23%20Print%20the%20array)

**Explanation**

```
et0=         e# Push the current year
    121,     e# Push the range 0, 1, ..., 120
        f-   e# For each item in the range, subtract it from current year
          p  e# Print the array
```

Answer (score 7):

## HP50g RPL, 97 bytes

```
120 'S' STO DATE ->STR 6 9 SUB OBJ-> 'Y' STO {} S WHILE 0 >= REPEAT Y S - + 'S' DECR END REVLIST
```

Ungolfed:

```
120
'span' STO     @ Store the span of years to cover.
DATE           @ Get the date as number 11.082016. 
→STR           @ Convert to string "11.082016".
               @ (Number format must allow all these decimal places.)
6 9 SUB        @ "11.082016" Substring for the year.
               @       ^  ^
               @  123456789
OBJ→           @ Convert string to number.
'year' STO     @ Store as the year to start at.
{} span        @ Start empty list to collect the years.
               @ Leave loop counter on the stack.
WHILE 0 ≥      @ Loop until the counter goes negative.
REPEAT
  year span -  @ E.g. on first iteration: 2016 - 120 = 1896.
  +            @ Append the year to the list on the stack.
  'span' DECR  @ Decrement loop counter and leave on stack.
END
REVLIST        @ Put list in reverse chronological order.
```

Showing a list of 2016 down to 1896:

[image: 2016 to 1896]

Comment: Edited answer to get the current year from the calculator.

Answer (score 6):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
120↑⌽⍳⊃⎕ts
```

`120↑` take 120 elements

`⌽` of the reversed

`⍳` indices until

`⊃` the first element of

`⎕TS` TimeStamp in the format [YYYY, M, D, h, m, s, t]

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=120%u2191%u233D%u2373%u2283%u2395ts&run)

---

Old version:

```apl
(⊃⎕TS)-⍳120
```

`⊃⎕TS` first element of [YYYY, M, D, h, m, s, t]

`-` minus

`⍳120` [0, 1, 2, ..., 118, 119]

Requires `⎕IO←0`, which is default on many systems.

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20%28%u2283%u2395TS%29-%u2373120&run)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

Code:

```
žg120Ý-
```

Explanation:

```
žg         # Get the current year.
  120Ý     # Create the list [0, 1, ..., 119, 120].
      -    # Substract, which leaves [year - 0, year - 1, ..., year - 120].
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xb5nMTIww50t&input=).

Answer (score 6):

## PowerShell, <strike>26</strike> 24 bytes

@TimmyD improved version:

```
0..120|%{(date).Year-$_}
```

Was:

```
($d=(date).year)..($d-120)
```

where `date` runs `Get-Date`

Comment: Blargh, should have answered earlier. That's exactly the straightforward version I had ready. Then work interfered :D A fun version would also be: `((date).year..0)[0..120]`; alas it's not shorter.

Comment: I find it interesting that date is equivalent to Get-Date when date is actually not an alias to Get-Date.  I've seen this called the "implied verb" rule and it is rarely ever documented in PowerShell literature.

Comment: @Bevo It's useful for CodeGolf, but a bit risky for any other use. See: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/778/571 and comment chain; it's both prone to name clashes and very slow.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vitsy](http://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy) + *sh <s>+ JavaScript</s>, <s>33</s> <s>26</s> <s>21</s> 18 bytes

Vitsy doesn't have native time/date retrieval, so I had to use shell and eval for this one.

Thanks to @Caleb for helping me shear off another 3 bytes!

```
'Y%+ etad',Dca*-HZ

'Y%+ etad'               Push the string 'date +"%Y"' to the stack.
          ,              Execute through shell. 
           Dca*-         Dupe n, push n - 120.
                H        Pop x, y, push range(x, y) to the stack.
                 Z       Output all stack as characters.
```

You can't try this one online, because it uses both shell AND eval.

Output is as character codes.

Comment: You should be able to trim a couple bytes off of this because you don't need the double quotes around the date format string (since there are no spaces in it); `date +%Y` works just fine.

Comment: @Caleb Perfect, thanks! Made the need for a JS eval non-existent as well.

Answer (score 5):

### R, <s>47</s> 39 bytes

```
as.double(substr(Sys.Date(),1,4))-0:120
```

If only someone invented a UTF-8 implementation of R with conveniently abbreviated frequently used system functions...

UPD: shaved off 7 (!) bytes owing to [plannapus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6741/plannapus), who suggested subrtacting a `0:120` vector rather than counting from `a` to `(a-120)` and 1 byte grâce à [user5957401](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58162/user5957401), who noticed that `double` would work as well as `numeric`. Old version:

```
a=as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(),"%Y"));a:(a-120)
```

Comment: Fiddling around with and `seq(a<-...,a-120)` can only worsen the situation.

Comment: using the type forcing command `as.double` instead of `as.numeric` will save you a byte. Similarly, if instead of formatting a date, you treat the date response as a string to pull from and use `substr(Sys.Date(),1,4)` you save another byte

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
1&Z'0:120-
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MSZaJzA6MTIwLQ&input=)

```
1&Z'      % Push first component of "clock" vector, which is year
0:120     % Literal vector [0, 1, 2, ..., 120]
-         % Subtract element-wise. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 5):

**Mathematica/Wolfram Language, 28 bytes**

```
Date[][[1]]-#&/@Range[0,120]
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You don't need to use a map here since subtraction is threaded over lists automatically. And `-Range@121+1` saves a byte over the zero-based list. And `#&@@` a byte over `[[1]]`. That said, unless stated otherwise in the challenge, all submissions have to be functions or full programs, and this code is merely a snippet/expression. The shortest fix would be making it an unnamed function by appending `&`.

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks for the feedback! I should have caught Minus being list able, minor mental lapse, but the other tips are much appreciated!

Comment: `#&@@Date[]-#&/@0~Range~120&` will save you two bytes, but then making it a function requires adding the `&` on the end (which I think yours needs anyway), so -1 byte in total.

Answer (score 5):

## 05AB1E, 9 bytes

`121FžgN-=`

[Try online](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@29oZOh2dF@6n67t//8A)

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, <s>64 62</s> 54 bytes

```
import time
n=time.gmtime()[0]
exec'print n;n-=1;'*121
```

@KarlKastor thanks for 8 bytes!

Comment: `time.gmtime().tm_year` is 3 bytes shorter

Comment: `time.gmtime()[0]` even shorter

Comment: @KarlKastor nice! Playing with the time module is like walking into a maze every time for me. So many ways to get lost

Answer (score 4):

## php, <strike>73 66 58</strike> 42 bytes

```
<?=implode(', ',range($j=date(Y),$j-120));
```

### Output:

> 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006,
>   2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995,
>   1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1989, 1988, 1987, 1986, 1985, 1984,
>   1983, 1982, 1981, 1980, 1979, 1978, 1977, 1976, 1975, 1974, 1973,
>   1972, 1971, 1970, 1969, 1968, 1967, 1966, 1965, 1964, 1963, 1962,
>   1961, 1960, 1959, 1958, 1957, 1956, 1955, 1954, 1953, 1952, 1951,
>   1950, 1949, 1948, 1947, 1946, 1945, 1944, 1943, 1942, 1941, 1940,
>   1939, 1938, 1937, 1936, 1935, 1934, 1933, 1932, 1931, 1930, 1929,
>   1928, 1927, 1926, 1925, 1924, 1923, 1922, 1921, 1920, 1919, 1918,
>   1917, 1916, 1915, 1914, 1913, 1912, 1911, 1910, 1909, 1908, 1907,
>   1906, 1905, 1904, 1903, 1902, 1901, 1900, 1899, 1898, 1897, 1896

If we don't need to separate with `,`, then <strike>58 57</strike> 41 bytes:

```
<?=implode(' ',range($j=date(Y),$j-120));
```

Thanks to insertusernamehere for saving 16 bytes

Comment: You don't really need to separate with `,`, look at many of the other answers.

Comment: It looks that way, but I'll put in two options so I can do what most are, and also what was requested

Comment: I've managed to get the comma answer down to my original non-comma answer size.  That's as much as I think I can golf it

Comment: You can remove the `<?php` tag since we allow [running with `-r` for free](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2428/53880)

Comment: Would I then count the quotes needed round it, or just the actual execution code?

Comment: Golf off *16 bytes*: `<?=implode(', ',range($j=date(Y),$j-120));`

Comment: I think you can count just the execution code, not anything needed to invoke it (such as the surrounding quotes or shell escapes to get the right string passed to the parser. But I think you do need a `print `, which is a step backwards from `<?=`.  You might look around at other PHP answers on popular questions and see about the print thing.

Comment: 37 bytes (using win-1252 encoding) `<?=join(~ß,range($j=date(Y),$j-120));`

Answer (score 4):

## PostgreSQL, 57 bytes

Who needs a `FROM` :-).  Probably shouldn't work, but it does, try it at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/10620/0)

```
select date_part('y',current_date)-generate_series(0,120)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Bash on OS X, 23

```bash
jot 121 `date +%Y` - -1
```

This will also work on Linux if you have BSD `jot` installed (e.g. `sudo apt-get install athena-jot`.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 62 bytes

```
import time
for n in range(121):print int(time.ctime()[-4:])-n
```

And at 64 bytes:

```
for n in range(121):print int(__import__("time").ctime()[-4:])-n
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, <s>55</s> <s>52</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
for(a=d=s=Date().substr(11,4);d-->s-120;)a+=" "+d
```

+9 bytes to `alert` the data (not necessary if you run this in a console).

```
for(a=d=s=Date().substr(11,4);d-->s-120;)a+=" "+d;alert(a)
```

-4 bytes if the delimiter isn't necessary.

```
for(a=d=s=Date().substr(11,4);d-->s-120;)a+=d
```

```js
for (a = d = s = Date().substr(11, 4); d --> s - 120; )
    a += " " + d;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: The `[]`s appear to be unnecessary.

Comment: @Neil: Thanks. My original solution used an array, but I hadn't thought to remove it.

Comment: You can save one byte using a `for` instead of `while` on this: `for(a=d=s=Date().substr(11,4);d-->s-120;)a+=" "+d`!

Answer (score 3):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 111 bytes

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')-LEVEL+1,', ')WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY LEVEL)FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<122;
```

Comment: I would be tempted to say the the listagg isn't required and just the set of ordered rows

Answer (score 3):

### C, <s>87</s> <s>85</s> <s>76</s> <s>74</s> 65 bytes

```
main(int i,char**v){for(i=0;i<121;printf("%d,",atoi(v[1])-i++));}
```

Ungolfed:

```
main(int i,char**v){
    for(i = 0; i < 121; printf("%d,", atoi(v[1])-i++));
}
```

My first code golf - Any pointers would be well received. Would be nice if I could cut out the argc/argv junk, but I'm not *that* skilled a C programmer. Improvements welcome.

**EDIT**: The current year is obtained from the commandline - specifically by a group of automated, well trained drinking birds.

**EDIT 2**: 85 bytes Thanks to Easterly Irk (removed spaces around arg function parameters)

**EDIT 3**: 76 bytes Thanks to anatolyg for pointing out the obvious (removed verbose argc/argv param names)

**EDIT 4**: 74 bytes Thanks to Yay295 (char**v, changed year delimiter)

**EDIT 5**: 65 bytes thanks to Yay295 and matt (re-used the variable i, removed variable x, changed while to for loop, updated printf to include atoi() read and i++)

Comment: Can't you a space? `int argc, char` -> `int argc,char`?

Comment: Replace `argc` by `c` (or better replace `int argc` by just `int`) and `argv` by `v`. Also replace `while` by `for`. The latter change requires some experience in C (but may be fun regardless).

Comment: @anatolyg oh, duh (for the argc/argv stuff). Wouldn't the 'for' loop be the same length as the while loop? for(;i>x;) vs while(i>x)?

Comment: `char*v[]` -> `char**v` saves 1 byte. You can save another by delimiting your years with a space or a comma instead of a newline.

Comment: You can make it shorter.  71 bytes. 

main(int c,char**v){int i=0;while(i<120)printf("%d,",atoi(v[1])-i++);}

Comment: @Matt: Nice, but we can go one further. `main(int i,char**v){i=0;while(i<121)printf("%d,",atoi(v[1])-i++);}`. Also, we've been off by 1.

Comment: @Yay295 - sweet! good reuse of i.

Comment: Even shorter. 65 bytes  `main(int i,char**v){for(i=0;i<121;printf("%d,",atoi(v[1])-i++));}`

Comment: 63 bytes: main(i,v)char**v;{for(i=0;i<121;printf("%d,",atoi(v[1])-i++));}

Answer (score 3):

## Processing, <s>51</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
for(int i=0;i<121;)print(year()-i+++" ");
```

## Ungolfed

```
for(int i = 0; i < 121;)
    print(year() - i++ + " ");
```

Processing is just a wrapper for Java if you didn't know, and takes most of the boilerplate away, so the obvious solution is also super short compared to a Java version.  Also opens a window for drawing graphics, but having that doesn't appear to disqualify me :)

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<121;)print(year()-i+++" ");`

Comment: I love the "+++", it looks so suspicious.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, 18 bytes

Assuming the output format doesn't matter (aside form descending order), the following program prints the last 121 years starting with the current one.

```
year(date)-(0:120)
```

It requires MATLAB version r2014a or higher. Earlier versions didn't include the `year` function.

Answer (score 3):

## **JavaScript, <s>60</s> <s>53</s> 48 Bytes**

```
f=x=>x>Date().split` `[3]-121&&(alert(x),f(x-1))
```

I used a recursive solution.

Comment: You can replace `console.log` with `alert`, and remove the last `;`.

Comment: Save 5 bytes with `f=x=>x>Date().split" "[3]-121&&(alert(x),f(x-1))`, replacing the quotation marks with backticks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 71 bytes

```go
import."time"
func f(){for t,i:=Now().Year(),0;i<120;i++{println(t-i)}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjfdM3ML8otK9JRKMnNTlbjSSvOSFdI0NKvT8osUSnQyrWz98ss1NPUiUxOLNDR1DKwzbQyNgKS2dnVBUWZeSU6eRolupmZtLcS4TWD9IOOBRnABzeGCSixYAKEB)

Prints to STDERR.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 33 bytes

```pl
say+(gmtime)[5]-$_+1900for 0..120
```

Run with `-M5.010` or `-E` :

```
perl -E 'say+(gmtime)[5]-$_+1900for 0..120'
```

Answer (score 2):

## k, 27 bytes

Output as specified

```
1@", "/:$(`year$.z.d)-!121;
```

Example:

```
k)1@", "/:$(`year$.z.d)-!121;
2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1989, 1988, 1987, 1986, 1985, 1984, 1983, 1982, 1981, 1980, 1979, 1978, 1977, 1976, 1975, 1974, 1973, 1972, 1971, 1970, 1969, 1968, 1967, 1966, 1965, 1964, 1963, 1962, 1961, 1960, 1959, 1958, 1957, 1956, 1955, 1954, 1953, 1952, 1951, 1950, 1949, 1948, 1947, 1946, 1945, 1944, 1943, 1942, 1941, 1940, 1939, 1938, 1937, 1936, 1935, 1934, 1933, 1932, 1931, 1930, 1929, 1928, 1927, 1926, 1925, 1924, 1923, 1922, 1921, 1920, 1919, 1918, 1917, 1916, 1915, 1914, 1913, 1912, 1911, 1910, 1909, 1908, 1907, 1906, 1905, 1904, 1903, 1902, 1901, 1900, 1899, 1898, 1897, 1896
```

It can be shortened more by not formatting the output and merely returning the list of integers:

```
(`year$.z.d)-!121
```

Answer (score 2):

## Fourier, 17 bytes

```
121(5d-io10ai^~i)
```

Since no output format is specified, each year is separated by a newline:

[Try it online](https://beta-decay.github.io/editor/?code=MTIxKDVkLWlvMTBhaV5-aSk)

Answer (score 2):

## jq, 46 characters

(45 characters code + 1 character command line option)

```
now|strftime("%Y")|tonumber|range(.;.-121;-1)
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -n 'now|strftime("%Y")|tonumber|range(.;.-121;-1)' | head
2016
2015
2014
2013
2012
2011
2010
2009
2008
2007
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=now|strftime(%22%25Y%22)|tonumber|range(.%3b.-121%3b-1)&j=null)

Answer (score 2):

### Vim, <s>32</s> 29 keystrokes

Thanks to [@daniero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4372/daniero) for some help on saving some keystrokes and making the output a little neater.

```
"=strftime('%Y')<Enter>pqqYp<Ctrl-x>q118@q
```

- `<Enter>` is <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `<Ctrl-x>` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

#### Explanation:

```
"                                          # Put into the register {
 =strftime('%Y')                           #   This year in YYYY form
                <Enter>                    # }
                       p                   # Paste the register
                        qq                 # Record macro q {
                          Y                #   Yank (copy) the current line
                           p               #   Paste
                            <Ctrl-x>       #   Decrment number at cursor
                                    q      # }
                                     118@q # Do macro q 118 times
```

#### Output format:

Each number is on a separate line like below.

```
2016
2015
.
.
.
1898
1897
```

Comment: OP clearly asks for a future-proof version, so only the second one answers the question. Don't you need to punch the Enter key (commonly refered to as `<CR>` in Vim context) after `:pu=strftime('%Y')`? Also, you can skip some keystrokes by using `Y` with copies the whole line. In total: `:pu=strftime('%Y')<CR>qqYp<Ctrl-x>q118@q` - 30 keystrokes

Comment: Also, you can yank from the `=` register: `"=strftime('%Y')<CR>pqqYp<Ctrl-x>q118@q` - 29 keystrokes, and it gets rid of the first empty line

Comment: If you're allowed to use shell as well then you can save five more keystrokes with the `date` utility: `:.!date +\%Y<CR>qqYp<C-x>q118@q`

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <strike>40</strike> <strike>35</strike> 33 bytes

```
while($i<121)echo date(Y)-$i++._;
```

I'm just going to pretend that error reporting is always disabled for code golfing... :)

[Edit 1: Saved 5 bytes via manatwork]

[Edit 2: Saved 2 bytes via Titus]

Comment: Forget good coding habits here. ;) Call that `date()` 121 times: `while($i<121)echo date(Y)-$i++." ";`.

Comment: @manatwork: save another two bytes by using the underscore (or any letter or 0) as separator: `while($i<121)echo date(Y)-$i++,_;` (33 bytes)

Comment: @manatwork Oh cripes how did I miss that? :)

Comment: @Titus Nice. I used the "interpret an unquoted constant as a string" thing already once here, and still totally missed this one.

Comment: It is always assumed that config is at default settings, so in PHP: E_NOTICE, E_DEPRECATED and E_STRICT are off -> You´re safe. (for different settings you have to either add the command or the string to add to config to your byte count)

Comment: OK great, the default recommended ini that ships with the source turns E_NOTICE back on. Good to know I can ignore that.

Comment: I wrote almost the exact same answer, then noticed yours on page 2 :( `for(;$i<121;)echo~ß,date(Y)-$i++;`

Comment: On second thought, you can still shave off 3 bytes (using the dodgy delim rule): `for(;$i<121;)echo$i++-date(Y);`

Answer (score 2):

## LaTeX, 129 bytes

Or, if I'm allowed to skip the document class definition & setup, and just count the package import and for loop code: **79 bytes**.

```
\documentclass{book}\usepackage{tikz}\begin{document}\foreach \n in {0,...,120}{\pgfmathint{\year\n}\pgfmathresult}\end{document}
```

Ungolfed:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {0,...,120}
{
\pgfmathint{\year-\n}\pgfmathresult}

\end{document}
```

Output (w/ free page number :) ):

[image]

Comment: LaTeX (90 bytes without "free page number"): `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\document\foreach~in{0,...,120}{ \the\numexpr\year-~}\stop`
Plain TeX (60 bytes with "free page number"): `\input tikz \foreach~in{0,...,120}{ \the\numexpr\year-~}\bye`

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>12</strike> 6 bytes

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

```
#yonKi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@69cmZ/nnfn/PwA)

#### Explanation:

```
#yonKi
#y          // # gets the char-code of y, which is 121
  o         // Create a range from [0...121]
   nKi      // At each item, perform .n(K.i()), which subtracts each item from Ki (Current year)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Minim](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Minim), 49 Bytes

Program is run as follows:

```
C:\Users\chris> minim -f golf.min
```

Golfed:

```
[]="xyear".\<1.\>[1].#<[1]--i.$<32._^!--[0].C-=4.
```

With whitespace and comments:

```
[] = "xyear".  ; Insert the string 'xyear' into memory from index 0 \
                 The 'x' character corresponds to the value '120'
\< 1.          ; Insert 1 as a system call argument \
                 This corresponds to the index in memory of the \
                 function name to call, 'year'
\> [1].        ; Call the function and insert the result at memory index 1
    #< [1]--i. ; Print memory index 1 as an integer, post-decremented
    $< 32.     ; Print a space
    _^ !--[0]. ; Skip the next statement if memory index 0, pre-decremented, is 0 
C -= 4.        ; Subtract 4 from the program counter
```

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/KakkoiiChris/Minim)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 65 bytes

`[...Array(1+- -Date().substr(11,4)).keys()].slice(-121).reverse()`

You're welcome to improve and shorten it...

Thanks to @Yay295 for the fix. I was 1 year off.

Comment: `[...Array(+Date().substr(11,4)).keys()].slice(-120).reverse()` is less!

Comment: 56 Bytes in ES5:

`s='';for(i=120;i--;)s+=new Date().getFullYear()-120+', '`

Comment: @innovati: That prints the same year over and over. If you replace the last '120' with 'i' as I expect you meant, it's still in the wrong order.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek,@eithedog: You're both off by 1. Try `[...Array(1+- -Date().substr(11,4)).keys()].slice(-121).reverse()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 67 bytes

```
from datetime import*;for i in range(121):print date.today().year-i
```

Thanks to Sp3000 for removing one byte

Comment: For future reference: In most situations, `__import__` isn't really needed, e.g. here you can do `from datetime import*` and `print date.today().year-i` instead for -1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

#### VBA, 54 bytes

In the *immediate pane*:

```
For i=0 To 120:?Year(Date)-i &IIf(i=120,"",", ");:Next
```

---

In an actual `Sub` procedure (the VBE adds whitespace and changes `?` to `Print`, but the code is per language specs without the whitespace and using the `?` shorthand nonetheless):

```
Sub A()
For i = 0 To 120: Print Year(Date) - i & IIf(i = 120, "", ", ");: Next
End Sub
```

That's 88 characters per Notepad++, with `i` being an undeclared, implicit `Variant` local variable.

Both produce the output exactly as specified in the question, comma-separated and with a space between each year:

```
2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1989, 1988, 1987, 1986, 1985, 1984, 1983, 1982, 1981, 1980, 1979, 1978, 1977, 1976, 1975, 1974, 1973, 1972, 1971, 1970, 1969, 1968, 1967, 1966, 1965, 1964, 1963, 1962, 1961, 1960, 1959, 1958, 1957, 1956, 1955, 1954, 1953, 1952, 1951, 1950, 1949, 1948, 1947, 1946, 1945, 1944, 1943, 1942, 1941, 1940, 1939, 1938, 1937, 1936, 1935, 1934, 1933, 1932, 1931, 1930, 1929, 1928, 1927, 1926, 1925, 1924, 1923, 1922, 1921, 1920, 1919, 1918, 1917, 1916, 1915, 1914, 1913, 1912, 1911, 1910, 1909, 1908, 1907, 1906, 1905, 1904, 1903, 1902, 1901, 1900, 1899, 1898, 1897, 1896
```

---

If the commas aren't a requirement (as some other answers seem to presume), then the `IIf` part can be dropped, cutting the *immediate pane* code down to **33 bytes**:

```
For i=0 To 120:?Year(Date)-i:Next
```

Answer (score 1):

### [ListSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp), 71 bytes

```
NUMB a=<c#DateTime.Now.Yearc#>
[FOREACH NUMB IN a TO a-120 AS y]
SHOW=y
```

Uses embedded c# code, *new feature!!*

Answer (score 1):

## Nim, 60 bytes

```nim
import times
for a in 0..120:echo getTime().getGmTime.year-a
```

Outputs each year on a new line. We use the `getTime` to get the current UNIX time, then convert it to UTC with `getGmTime`, get the `year` minus the counter variable, and `echo` it.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 67 bytes

```
@set/ay=%date:~-4%,z=y-120
@for /l %%i in (%y%,-1,%z%)do @echo %%i
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell 125 bytes

The imports take up a large part of the byte count

```
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Time.Calendar
main=fmap((\(x,_,_)->[x-120..x]).toGregorian.utctDay)getCurrentTime>>=print
```

Comment: I'm afraid the list is in the wrong order, the spec says current year first. Howevery we can save a few bytes: a) `import Data.Time` should be enough for all needed functions. b) use the infix version of `fmap`, i.e. `<$>`. c) `do x<-toGregorain ... ;print[x-120..x]` is shorter than the lambda. d) You can extract the year from `getZonedTime` via `read.take 4.show<$>getZonedTime`. All in all, including correct order: `import Data.Time;do y<-read.take 4.show<$>getZonedTime;print[y,y-1..y-120]`.

Answer (score 1):

## SQLite, <strike>82</strike> 80 bytes

```
with b(y)as(select strftime('%Y')union select y-1 from b limit 121)select*from b
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/2795)

(For ANSI SQL, replace the `strftime()` with `extract(year from current_date)`.)

(2 bytes saved thanks to @MickyT)

Comment: You can save yourself a couple with `select*from b` rather than `select y from b`

Answer (score 1):

## C# - DotNet core - 133 bytes

### Golfed

```
class Program{static void Main(){int x=0,y=System.DateTime.Now.Year;while(x<121){System.Console.Write($"{y-x++}"+(x<121?", ":""));}}}
```

### Ungolfed

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int x=0, y=System.DateTime.Now.Year;

        while(x<121)
        {
            System.Console.Write($"{y-x++}" + (x < 121 ? ", " : ""));
        }
    }
}
```

### Output:

[image]

I'm sure this can be improved. I don't particularly like the if statement to display or hide the trailing comma.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript: <s>68</s> <s>82</s> 59 bytes

`i=121;while(i--){x[i]=Date().substr(11,4)-i;}console.log(x)`

Comment: Will this give a proper output when run in 2017?

Comment: yes, now it will, oops :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <del>47</del> <del>40</del> 39 bytes

```
p [*0..Time.new.year].last(121).reverse
```

Thanks to @Value Ink for 7 bytes!

Ideone link: https://ideone.com/yRovUl

Comment: Some people are submitting programs where the separator is newline, so you can take out the joining operation and just `puts` it. Or use `p *<the rest>` because they're all integers

Comment: Thank you @Value Ink. Since outputting an array is allowed, I used plain `p` instead `p *<the rest>`

Answer (score 1):

## Coffeescript, 29 bytes

`->a=Date()[11..14];[a..a-120]`

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf!

Comment: Thanks! I've been lurking for a while, finally had time to start

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 54

```
import time
print(*range(time.gmtime()[0],0,-1)[:121])
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, <s>83</s> 76 bytes

```
n=>{for(n=0;n<121;)System.Console.Write(System.DateTime.Now.Year-n+++" ");};
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>66</s> <s>54</s> 51 bytes

My first foray into code golf so I'm open to suggestions for improvements.

The following will output an array of the required years.

```js
f=

_=>[...Array(121)].map((x,y)=>Date().split` `[3]-y)

console.log(f());
```

---

### History

#### 54 bytes

```
_=>Array(121).fill(Date().split` `[3]).map((x,y)=>x-y)
```

#### 66 bytes

```
(y=[Date().split` `[3]],x=121)=>{while(x--)y[x]=(y[0]-x);return y}
```

Comment: Well done this was my solution before i read any comments `_=>[...Array(121)].map((v,i)=>Date().substr(11,4)-i)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
kðt:122-r
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrw7B0OjEyMi1yIiwiIiwiIl0=)

-2 thx to @lyxal

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 12 bytes (Non-competitive)

```
{x,x-1+!120}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6qu0KnQNdRWNDQyqOXiSos2MjA0jwXTRkYQ2tAsFgDLLAnN)

K lacks any date-related functions, so this one is non-competitive.

Explanations:

```
{x,x-1+!120}  Main function. Takes x as input
       !120   Generate a range from 0 to 120 (exclusive)
     1+       +1 to each number (1..120)
   x-         x subtract to each number (x-1..x-120)
 x,           Concat x itself as the first number of the array (x,x-1..x-120)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```julia
using Dates
y=year(now())
show([y:-1:y-120;])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v7Q4My9dwSWxJLWYq9K2MjWxSCMvv1xDU5OrOANIR1da6RpaVeoaGhlYx2r@/w8A)

- -1 byte thanks to @amelies: replace `print` with `show`

Comment: `show` instead of `print` to save 1 byte

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
kOṇÞL-
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWK7P9H-5sPzzPR3dJcVJyMVQUJgsA)

##### Explanation

```python
kOṇÞL-  # Full program
kO      # Push the current year
  ṇÞ    # Compressed integer 121
    L   # Lowered range
     -  # Subtract
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```
public void possible(){
  for(int i=0;i<120;){
    System.out.println(new Date().getYear()-i++);
  }
}
```

Golfed :

```
void p(){for(int i=0;i<120;)System.out.println(new Date().getYear()-i++);}
```

1 byte off. Thanks to @LeakyNun

Comment: `void p(){for(int i=0;i<120;)System.out.println(new Date().getYear()-i++);}`

Comment: What version of Java is this? As far as I'm aware, `getYear()` gives you the year since 1900. That means that the current output would be [116, -3]. You'd have to add `+1900` (5 bytes) in order to get the correct output. Also, `Date` requires an import (`java.util.Date`), which would add to the byte count too.

Comment: @MH. is right, this code will not compile without the imports so you need to either `new java.util.Date()` or add the import. Also, why don't you shorten it further by replacing the method with a lambda expression?

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 113 bytes

```
import datetime
theYear = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(theYear.year, theYear.year-121, -1):
   print i,','
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You need to list the language you're using, and because this is a [tag:code-golf] challenge, you also need the bytecount.

Comment: This is definitely Python 2.

Comment: Thanks. How can I calculate the bytes?

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 33 bytes

```
A=right$(_D,4)┘[!A!,!A!-120,-1|?a
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```
max(getDate:seq(I,I,Ans,Ans-120,~1
```

Comment: `getDate:Ans(1` can be `max(getDate`.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 57 bytes

```
d=new Date().getYear()+1899;(d​..d-120).each{println it​}
```

**Explanation**

```
d=new Date().getYear()                               //returns how many years have passed since 1900
                      +1899;                         //adding 1900 will give us the current year, but we want the program to start one year before, so we do +1900-1=1899
                            (d..d-120)               //a range from the current year -1 to 120 years before that
                                      .each{print it}// for each element in the range, print it.
```

**Output**

```
2016
2015
2014
...
1898
1897
1896
```

Because of the 1899 trick, it starts with 2016 instead of 2017

Tested on the [Groovy Web Console](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com)

Answer (score 0):

### VBA 49 bytes

```
a=year(now):for i=a to a-120 step-1:msgbox i:next
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, <strike>75</strike> 71 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Zachary.

```
e="";for(y=(new Date).getFullYear(),i=y;i>=y-120;i--)e+=i+" ";alert(e)
```

Prints all years into a single alert.

I'm sure it could be improved.

### History

**75 bytes**

```
var e="";for(y=(new Date).getFullYear(),i=y;i>=y-120;i--)e+=i+" ";alert(e);
```

---

(Every year was in a separate alert)

```
for(y=(new Date).getFullYear(),i=y;i>=y-120;i--)alert(i);
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I'm not sure whether there exists a consensus on this, but I do not think that opening an alert for each element counts as outputting the list.

Comment: Hello. It is now in a single alert. (but with more bytes... :))

Comment: Two things, I don't think you need the `var` before `e`, and I also don't think you need a semicolon after `alert(e)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 76 bytes

```
set y [clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y]
time {puts $y;incr y -1} 121
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEoVIhOjknPzlbIS2/KDexBMYrTk3Oz0spjlXQhYqrRsZylWTmpipUF5SWFCuoVFpn5iUXAbXrGtYqGBoZ/v8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 31 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vba
For i=0To 120:?Year(Now)-i:Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 30 bytes

```factor
[ now year>> dup 120 - [a,b] ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcw7DsJADAXAq7wDQASUiZQW0dAgqiiFccxHWbwr2wjl9EtEM@XciSNbvV5O52MLpiQ6kYGYxT2b403x/NMY6UMcxSRiKfbSwCymktDVAZq/WISs7zF9CvaHHbYYaHMbMdb1TfAgnpv6Aw)

```
now     ! T{ timestamp { year 2022 } { month 10 } ... etc }
year>>  ! 2022
dup     ! 2022 2022
120     ! 2022 2022 120
-       ! 2022 1902
[a,b]   ! { 2022 2021 2020 ... 1902 }
```

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) -n, 24 bytes

```
now|gmtime[0]-range(121)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8vv7wmPbckMzc12iBWtygxLz1Vw9DIUPP//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 24 bytes

```
$=>[y:now\year y..y-120]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?LIJ0iN)

```
$=>[           ; a function
    y:now\year ; assign current year to y
    y..y-120   ; the range y down to y-120
]              ; end function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 40 bytes

```lua
for i=0,120 do print(~~os.date"%Y"-i)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/Lb9IIdPWQMfQyEAhJV@hoCgzr0Sjri6/WC8lsSRVSTVSSTdTMzUv5f9/AA)

The `~~` is used to remove a trailing `.0` from each year.

Answer (score -1):

#### Ruby, <strike>39</strike> 36 bytes

```
t=Time.new.year;t.downto(t-120).to_a
```

Old:

```
t=Time.new.year;(t-120..t).to_a.reverse
```

Should be obvious.

Comment: Where's the output?

Comment: Output is implicit. It's the return value of the last statement. Test it here: https://repl.it/CmDY/0

Comment: Output is not implicit: You can print the result, or you can return it from a function. From the [codegolf wiki](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info): `Both programs and functions may output by writing to STDOUT. Functions may also use their arguments or return value(s) for output.`

Comment: @daniero Sorry, I explained it badly. My program still holds to that definiton tho.

Comment: I'm sorry to be so strict and boring -- of course i know what you mean, but your answer is sloppy, as it doesn't *do* anything. All other answers here, as far as I can tell, either prints something or returns something.

Comment: And oh, maybe this bit of the tag wiki is more relevant: `Answers may be either full programs or functions (or equivalent).` As a full program your answer doesn't do anything.

Comment: couldn't this be made into an executable program just by putting it in a proc, i.e.

`->{Time.new.year;t.downto(t-120).to_a}` 

which comes out to only 2 more bytes

Comment: @DaneAndersen that code doesn't define `t`

Comment: Just do `p *t.downto(t-120)` :D no proc object needed