# How many countries are in the European Union?

Tags: code-golf, date

Tonight, 31 January 2020, Brexit will happen and the United Kingdom will leave the European Union, the first time that the number of EU member states will decrease.

Your job is to take a date and output the number of EU<sup>1</sup> members on that date, according to the following table:

```
| Start      | End        | Number of members 
| 0          | 1957-12-31 | 0
| 1958-01-01 | 1972-12-31 | 6
| 1973-01-01 | 1980-12-31 | 9
| 1981-01-01 | 1985-12-31 | 10
| 1986-01-01 | 1994-12-31 | 12
| 1995-01-01 | 2004-04-30 | 15
| 2004-05-01 | 2006-12-31 | 25
| 2007-01-01 | 2013-06-30 | 27
| 2013-07-01 | 2020-01-31 | 28
| 2020-02-01 | Inf        | 27
```

Input may take one of the following forms:

- your language's date format
- any ordering of integers for year, month and day with any separator (e.g. YYYYMMDD or DD/MM/YYYY)
- number of days lapsed since some epoch.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

<sub>1. or [EEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Economic_Community) before 1993</sub>

Comment: I see the Python answer is using an input as the number of days since `1957-12-31` and the JavaScript answer is taking an input in the format `yyyyMM` without the `dd`. Are these both allowed according to the "_in any reasonable format_"? Both would save bytes in my answer as well.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Number of days since some epoch is OK. `yyyyMM` is not, as it does not encode a date.

Comment: I feel like _in any reasonable format_ is not objective enough...

Comment: @LuisMendo I think it's OK. It just has to uniquely specify the day. Are you worried there is some possible loophole?

Comment: @Anush The problem is how to tell if a format qualifies as "reasonable" or not. For instance, I wouldn't have guessed that _Number of days since some epoch_ (or even _months_?) does. So a clearer specification is needed

Comment: @LuisMendo I have clarified the input format.

Comment: @RobinRyder Thanks. I have retracted my close vote

Comment: Note that the new input spec invalidates some answrs. You should notify the authors so they can fix them

Comment: @luismendo Thanks. Yes, I plan on notifying them as soon as I get back to a desktop computer.

Comment: Your data is incorrect as the European Union was founded on November 1, 1993

Comment: Looks like [I was off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114960/when-will-brexit-happen) by a year or so :/

Comment: @Rene I am also considering the EEC as the EU's predecessor.

Comment: @Robin Ryder, then you should refer to the EEC, not to the EU

Comment: * pours a 1.18L for the UK *

Comment: Should that be `-Inf` as the starting point for the first line?

Comment: @ilkkachu You don't need to be able to handle dates Before the Common Era.

Comment: First, I thought you missed the addition of the GDR to EEC, but then I realisized that the GDR was added to the Federal Republic of Germany, and still counting as one country. So your numbers are still correct.

Answer (score 12):

## Javascript, <del>85</del> 83 Bytes

```
a=d=>d<0?0:d<180?6:d<276?9:d<336?10:d<444?12:d<556?15:d<588?25:d<666?27:d<745?28:27
```

It takes an input as a float as the *months / fractions of months passed* since `1958-01-01`
(`0` for `1958-01-01T00:00:00` and a negative number for any previous date)

(Since number of days from some epoch is allowed, I assume that also a number of months is valid, as well)

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##bcvBDoIwDMbxu08CB8lW2m4SZp9lYWA0hBExvv7sjkZP3z@/po/4jsf0vO@v85bTXJZQYkjhmkYjZkij9UZYFxzLRbfvWWw9IKJY0CBSoRreC9RgZgGn4ZAE/ACuTHk78jp3a741S0NgOt@2p2/Vtx9ziH@M1Er5AA)

---

## 80 Bytes

(credits: [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld))

```
a=d=>d<0?0:d<180?6:d<276?9:d<336?10:d<444?12:d<556?15:d<588?25:27+(d>=666&d<745)
```

---

<sub>Sad to see you go, UK</sub>

Comment: Awesome Arnauld!

Comment: I have clarified what counts as a reasonable input format for dates; number of days since an epoch is allowed but not number of months. Your input format was creative! But it was a loophole, which I have now closed. Your previous version based on number of days would be fine.

Comment: since JavaScript can't compete with many other golfing languages I wanted to at least be creative. :)

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>29</s> <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 33 bytes

```
¨12βŽ₅b-‘´`<lp€¸‘Ç.¥@•¿“0p•12в<*O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0ApDo3Obju591NSapPuoYcahLQk2OQWPmtYc2gHkHW7XO7TU4VHDokP7HzXMMSgAsgyNLmyy0fL//z/a0NLUUkfBwBCEYwE)

Input is in the form `[yyyy, mm, dd]`.

Comment: The most impressive part about this answer is that you thought about using floats as input-format so the compressed integers can all be much shorter. :D

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I actually took this idea from the JS answer. I added credit to my answer.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yes it was impressive, lol

Comment: I have clarified what counts as a reasonable input format for dates; number of days since an epoch is allowed but not number of months.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>110</s> 97 bytes

```python
lambda d:ord('069:<?IKLK'[sum(d>i for i in(0,5479,8401,10227,13514,16922,17897,20270,22676))])-48
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZGxboMwEIZ3P8VJHbAjO7IPjAGVdmiWKNnaLc1AS1CRQkCEDnl6ahOSuJIX3/fd79O5uww/7QnHKv8cj0XzVRZQZm1f0kDGafb8ut5sN8Hu/NvQ8qWGqu2hhvpEJdeRSXkSScWVRDRchVpFXMUpIlcmSQ1HiUZyxNjEjO2ZiJJxu37/yHckUKmUQip7Ag72po1QKEJ3ewLpuE58btDjseMm9HkiPZ46nqh/XHtcTQ8ksS@kkS@gE1L9EFDKSNgTyqugyVzSDyH2EvAqGD9B2YnjWwIaMpfMXcBpJbeEhMwlvAt6mkHqAK4Je1L1bQNlMRyGujlA3XRtP8CCuG8q7TeB23dGrC0EvBXHb@tezjB1uaXbMoFVfgugi6boaH0aeLk8d8d6oIEIGGPk2pYDXYm76/q5Qh4qxpaOz88Q6HobAaulUynjQWanr6hT2PgH)

<sub>-13 bytes, thanks to Jonathan Allan</sub>

Takes input as number of days since `1957-12-31` (so `1958-01-01` is day `1`)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 93 bytes

```python
lambda d:b'069:<?IKLK'[sum(d>i for i in(0,5479,8401,10227,13514,16922,17897,20270,22676))]-48
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZGxbsMgEIZ3ngKpg6GCCM4GjFW3Q7NEydZuaQanjlVLcWw57pCnd8FxEiqxcN93P6ejuww/7Skeq/xrPBbNvixwme0joW328rZab9bR9vzbkPK1xlXb4xrXJyKYSoxlaSIkkwLAMBkrmTCpLQCTJrWGgQAjGIA2mtIdT9Jxs/r4zLcoklYILqQ7EcPupgyXwGN/e8LCc5WG3EDAtecmDnkqAm49T@U/rgIupwdSHQo2CQXwglUPAYRIuDuxuAoKzSX1EHSQAFfBhAnSTaxvCWDQXDJ3AaaV3BJSNJfgLqhpBqEifE3YoapvG1wWw2GomwOum67tB/yM/C@V7pew33eGnM05fi@O3869nPHU5Zfuyggv81sAeW6KjtSngZWLc3esBxLxiFKKrm05Jkt@d30/k8BiSenC8/kZhLveRTh34V1CWZS58SviHUrHPw)

<sub>-4 bytes, thanks to mypetlion</sub>

Comment: Save 13 by [avoiding the import of `bisect`](https://tio.run/##VZGxboMwEIZ3P8VJHbAjO7IPjAGVdmiWKNnaLc1AS1CRQkCEDnl6ahOSuJIX3/fd79O5uww/7QnHKv8cj0XzVRZQZm1f0kDGafb8ut5sN8Hu/NvQ8qWGqu2hhvpEJdeRSXkSScWVRDRchVpFXMUpIlcmSQ1HiUZyxNjEjO2ZiJJxu37/yHckUKmUQip7Ag72po1QKEJ3ewLpuE58btDjseMm9HkiPZ46nqh/XHtcTQ8ksS@kkS@gE1L9EFDKSNgTyqugyVzSDyH2EvAqGD9B2YnjWwIaMpfMXcBpJbeEhMwlvAt6mkHqAK4Je1L1bQNlMRyGujlA3XRtP8CCuG8q7TeB23dGrC0EvBXHb@tezjB1uaXbMoFVfgugi6boaH0aeLk8d8d6oIEIGGPk2pYDXYm76/q5Qh4qxpaOz88Q6HobAaulUynjQWanr6hT2PgH)

Comment: Python 3 port saves 4 bytes by replacing `ord('069...` with `b'069...`

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks!

Comment: @mypetlion Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>42</s> 36 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
•AÂʒë.š¡ε%ž·7í•ŽL}в.¥›O•=γ1sæΔ•₆вsè<
```

Input as number of days since 1957-12-31 (so 1957-12-30 is day `-1`; 1957-12-31 is day `0`; 1958-01-01 is day `1`; etc.)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMix8NNpyYdXq13dOGhhee2qh7dd2i7@eG1QImje31qL2zSO7T0UcMufyDf9txmw@LDy85NAbIfNbVd2FR8eIXN//@GxqaGJgA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/Rw2LHA83nZp0eLXe0YWHFp7bqnp036Ht5ofXAiWO7vWpvbBJ79DSRw27/IF823ObDYsPLzs3Bch@1NR2YVPx4RU2/3X@R@sa6hjoGOqYmphbAgkLAx0LEwNDEGGkY2hgZGQOJi10DI1NDU3ApKmOoZmlkRGYNNYxNLewNAeTFjpGBkbmBmDSUMfIyMzcDEya6xgZGxgYxAIA).

**Old 42 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer taking input in the format `yyyyMMdd`:**

```
¨¨•a3|}\§λ’Iœg½þ•ŽOΩв•32Ø•+@O•=γ1sæΔ•₆вsè<
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0IpDKx41LEo0rqmNObT83O5HDTM9j05OP7T38D6g8NG9/udWXtgEZBkbHZ4BpLQd/IGk7bnNhsWHl52bAmQ/amq7sKn48Aqb//8NLS1NDI2MDQE) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/QysOrXjUsCjRuKY25tDyc7sfNcz0PDo5/dDew/uAwkf3@p9beWETkGVsdHgGkNJ28AeStuc2GxYfXnZuCpD9qKntwqbiwyts/uv8jzY0AAJDA0MdQ0tTc0MjYzDDAipibgQVMTeGigBlICIWhjARU5iIGVTE0gQqYmkKFjEyMDAxMDE2gDBMISJmYDVAhjlUjaGxgRlYDZBhDhYBShoaQxlGIBFDiFNjAQ).

`•a3|}\§λ’Iœg½þ•ŽOΩв•32Ø•+` can alternatively be `•Me1εä~.=ΔΩ»•Ž5ãв.¥•32Ù•+` for the same byte-count: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0IpDKx41LPJNNTy39fCSOj3bc1POrTy0Gyh0dK/p4cUXNukdWgrkGBsdngmktB38gaTtuc2GxYeXnZsCZD9qaruwqfjwCpv//w0tLU0MjYwNAQ) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/QysOrXjUsMg31fDc1sNL6vRsz005t/LQbqDQ0b2mhxdf2KR3aCmQY2x0eCaQ0nbwB5K25zYbFh9edm4KkP2oqe3CpuLDK2z@6/yPNjQAAkMDQx1DS1NzQyNjMMMCKmJuBBUxN4aKAGUgIhaGMBFTmIgZVMTSBCpiaQoWMTIwMDEwMTaAMEwhImZgNUCGOVSNobGBGVgNkGEOFgFKGhpDGUYgEUOIU2MB).

**Explanation:**

```python
•AÂʒë.š¡ε%ž·7í•    # Push compressed integer 813218926689775697373196902446
  ŽL}              # Push compressed integer 5480
     в             # Convert the larger integer to base-5480 as list:
                   #  [5479,2922,1826,3287,3408,975,2373,2406]
      .¥           # Undelta it with leading 0:
                   #  [0,5479,8401,10227,13514,16922,17897,20270,22676]
        ›          # Check for each if it's larger than the (implicit) input-integer
         O         # Take the sum to get the amount of truthy values
•=γ1sæΔ•           # Push compressed integer 122116126451824
 ₆в                # Convert it to base-36 as list:
                   #  [1,7,10,11,13,16,26,28,29,28]
   sè              # Swap to get the sum, and use it to index into this list
     <             # And decrease it by 1
                   # (since a compressed integer/list cannot contain a leading 0)
                   # (after which the result is output implicitly)

¨¨                 # Remove the last two digits from the (implicit) input (the "dd")
  •a3|}\§λ’Iœg½þ•  # Push compressed integer 2722385715080006519908031109868
   ŽOΩ             # Push compressed integer 6203
      в            # Convert the larger integer to base-6203 as list:
                   #  [1,1501,2301,2801,3701,4605,4901,5507,6202]
       •32Ø•       # Push compressed integer 195800
            +      # Add it to each value in the list:
                   #  [195801,197301,198101,198601,199501,200405,200701,201307,202002]
             @     # Check for each if it's larger than or equal to the input minus "dd"
O•=γ1sæΔ•₆вsè<     # Same as above
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand how the compression works.

Answer (score 6):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), <s>972</s> 1009 bytes

My input is the date in the format specified in the test cases `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
0 0 0 * halt
* 1 _ r €
€ 9 _ r %
* 2 _ r $
$ 0 _ r £
* I 2 r ¢
% 5 _ r ^
% 6 6 r c
% 7 _ r x
% 8 _ r B
% 9 _ r i
% * _ r c
^ * 0 r c
^ 8 6 r c
^ 9 6 r c
B 0 9 r c
B 1 1 r r
B 2 1 r r
B 3 1 r r
B 4 1 r r
B 5 1 r r
B * 1 r e
r * 0 r c
e * 2 r c
x 0 6 r c
x 1 6 r c
x 2 6 r c
x * 9 r c
i 0 1 r 
i 1 1 r 
i 2 1 r 
i 3 1 r 
i 4 1 r 
i * 1 r t
t * 5 r c
 * 2 r c
£ 0 _ r 
£ 1 _ r ★
£ 2 _ r 
 0 _ r !
 * 2 r ¢
! - _ r ~
~ 0 _ r 1
1 1 2 r ☆
1 * 2 r ¢
★ 0 2 r ¢ 
★ 1 2 r ¢
★ 2 2 r ¢
★ 3 _ r &
★ * 2 r ☆
& - _ r @
@ 0 _ r 6
6 0 2 r ¢
6 1 2 r ¢
6 2 2 r ¢
6 3 2 r ¢
6 4 2 r ¢
6 5 2 r ¢
6 6 2 r ¢
6 * 2 r ☆
☆ * 8 r c
 * 5 r c
 1 1 r 
 2 1 r 
 3 1 r 
 4 _ r +
 5 2 r t
 6 2 r t
 * 2 r ¢
¢ * 7 r c
+ - _ r ¬
¬ 0 _ r 4
¬ * 2 r t
4 0 1 r t
4 1 1 r t
4 2 1 r t
4 3 1 r t
4 4 1 r t
4 * 2 r t
6 _ 6 l c
c * _ r c
c _ _ * halt
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?ede7a51c0dff0419b383aae1fb089ce0)

*Added a few bytes thanks to [Grimmy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6484/grimmy) being a bit more thorough in testing my code than I was.*

Comment: Seems like it’s all good now!

Comment: What's the point of the `` emoji and other multibyte characters? Can they be replaced with characters with lower bytecounts?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing, It's the queen's crown. All of the multibyte characters were chosen for the occassion.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 48 bytes

```
Ｉ⌕γ§ &)*,/9;<;ＬΦ⪪”)¶↶⌕βγ⦄J≦σν{:Xδp⁴E⊙≕⍘Ｈ⊙βg”⁶‹ιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsIwFET3niJ0IT8S8Se1TUPciCAILgRPUNrSBkKqTRBvHxM7i8cMPKab2qWbWxvjYzEuwKX1Aa7G9TAycg431w9fKMiW7thB6ZMuGLkPbgxTkmwYFni@rAlQcFU1yLmSZWbD/6wzVYVcIB6xSpS58xKlwLREeqtpfvQeDCNvukZvYlwFFHH/sT8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as YYYYMMDD. Explanation:

```
                 ”...”      Compressed string of YYYYMM values
                ⪪     ⁶     Split into substrings of length 6
              ＬΦ       ‹ιθ  Count those that appear before the input
   § &)*,/9;<;              Look the count up in a translation table
Ｉ⌕γ                         Subtract 32 from the ASCII code
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>158</s> 150 bytes

```python
i=int(input()[:6]);print((((((((27,28)[202002>i>201306],25)[i<200701],15)[i<200405],12)[i<199501],10)[i<198601],9)[i<198101],6)[i<197301],0)[i<195801]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY@7DoMwDEV3vgKxQCoG2yGvtvAjiIkiNQugikrt16dOSDOdc@1EN/v3eG4rhXl7LGVf1nUdfO/Xo/Hr/j4aMV71JG77K0b5kGnJipGAAGjwAwFK0FNLSoz@zqEBnFr8WweKjaKhcyrN4DSro7ksGEWfYmSUvKYsS@BqxfJZ5iZWFReEUPGIkK9VBaPuGFVCo8GiSWj5obzgOiQZkUtBThkVEHYJEUCSPVGDA0oYf8m7Pw)

Takes input as a string in `YYYYMMDD` format

Alternative Python 2 approach without imports. Simply uses nested list indexing to create the equivalent of a big `if/elif` structure.

**NB:** Posted by a British guy who is sorry to see us leave. I'm still all for the Community and working together (whether EU or here).

Comment: [Here’s some improvements](https://tio.run/##LY7NjoMwDITvPEVvxLTRjp0fEhV4kdWeukjNhaKKSuXpqaNdX/zNjCXPum/3xyLH7fE7n8ZT27ZHGcuyvjZDXwxYziEB130sVV7XZ1k2I/3ZRIFMZQoBkax0Zh98JsvoTBl8RCDrqun6/1QS2bocXSJ97wOHHz2dQIc@beb3fDO1BHWMQ58KM7jhHL1CUOgjEvcKyeEvyp7FcSPQqY5CgLBX0KpOUoWIDFHQUNUH)

Comment: Hey @Grimmy, that's well smart and different enough for you to post as your own answer. Fine by me. Same priciple, much cooler solution. I'll certainly upvote.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
“€ɓ⁴5O/ṖṪOṁṪḋg’ḃ⁽×ỵÄŻ>⁸Sị“÷ñıÐ€½µ©¡ñ‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYwxCsIwFEAv9MHkt2nSxSt08AwiSC/g1qjg0EUQtIKLo@JSsNhSuuTr4DHyLxLr9Jb33nKe56sQuLjw@vE9sH2qbOK7o@/ume/sCN@WCy7Ovt2wHejk@4a2n37Ktp35vhxDelH9rmk/DtzgGndzV6q5qALtQkBMdBIkqNgIMLFAkALRgIyUVCCTFCOQ2qQGUKCW8Pf1Dw)

A monadic link taking the zero-indexed count of days since 1958-01-01 as a integer argument and returning an integer.

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving a byte!

Comment: @RobinRyder revised to use days

Comment: `>⁸TḢị“¡©µ½€Ðıñ÷ñ‘` -> `>⁸Sị“÷ñıÐ€½µ©¡ñ‘` saves one (maybe with an off by 1 error to fix?)

Comment: Ah no, looks good, I was using wrong origin date. [(d-1,d,d+1)](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xHTWtOTn7UuMXUX//hzmkPd67yf7izEUg93NGd/qhh5sMdzY8a9x6e/nD31sMtR3fbPWrcEfxwdzdQ4@Hthzce2Xh4AtCAQ3sPbT208tDCwxsfNcz4r6tjoGOofbgdKMEFJv//jzbQUTA1MbfUUbAwMTDUUTA0MDIyB1LGpoYmQMrM0sgISJlbWAIFjQyMzIHKjYzMzM1i/wMA) :)

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 98 bytes

```
{m=$1*12+$2-23496}1,$0=m<1?0:m<181?6:m<277?9:m<337?10:m<445?12:m<557?15:m<589?25:27+(m>666&&m<746)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDBDsIgDIbvPgWHZVGnCS20pcsmz@LZ7OzB@OzYbchIQ798/EmB5/tVymeZO7gCDh3eMUTlL9w6Py8TZD/aniCzdRTJaj0EybAexEgZ0IDIDK2QNCONKMN5eTBz3y@TRL6U4m05D1YnUBIH6MKGqVnBZiU0m3yzCQ5Lh@VmNTarVC16H51V8BWpWq5ZQ2lZsMG8Z1eU3eJ29fBHrNNUjxntddsHVv4B)

Input format: `YYYY MM DD`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 95 bytes

Expects a number of days since `1957-12-31`.

```javascript
n=>[x=0,5479,2922,1826,3287,3408,975,2373,2406].map((d,i)=>x-=(n-=d)>0&&~('52012910'[i]||~1))|x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYyxbsMgFEX3fAVTAAnSxwMMDHjqX0QZrEAqRymOaqv1YOXXXTlDItnSW@65575r89v055/2PsjSpTxf4lxifRwjCGtcEBgQhfJYCY3eCW3Ai@CsQO20QAPV6fDd3BlLouWxHmVkRcbEa9jvH4xaBIVBAT22p2l6KM6ncR5yP5BIEok1OXel7275cOu@2IWxkv/IZzNkljiR5JWoCtZJhVIryjn5IL4y2XK@2y2/lhqUfB7lL/RevJHfWA43ltMrCwGMBLtCbmMhLEivET6t@R8)

This is however a bit longer than [@FabrizioCalderan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198700/58563), even if it is [fixed to use days](https://tio.run/##ZYzBbsMgDEDv/QpugQOb7QAGtNDLfiRq6LSqIlMTdZf9exZ6aKVEsvTkxzOX/t5Pp9v3z6zLOOTl3C2lSyXBsSRrOKzwBnAFAhFXthZNpQtElewDH8lrWT4IiPGvJCLHTkWyEdehiBBDdBGWOU@z6MQguiROY5nGa367jl/yLGXJv@Kzn7MclNDiuTUYLGsk3WKjlHgX3plslToc6l/1GVA/plFP9bp4Kb@rmHYVt5uKAIwGu1G8qwiqareKHtXyDw) instead of months.

Answer (score 1):

## x86 (32-bit) assembly, 43 bytes (13 bytes code + 30 bytes data)

This routine expects input in `ax` as a signed short giving number of days since 1950-01-01, and returns output in `al` (clobbering `edi` along the way).

```
    .text
    .globl eu_members
eu_members: 
    mov $.Ltbl-1, %edi
.Lloop:
    inc %edi
    scas (%edi), %ax
    jg .Lloop
    mov (%edi), %al
    ret
    .section .rodata
.Ltbl:
    .short 2921
    .byte 0
    .short 8400
    .byte 6
    .short 11322
    .byte 9
    .short 13148
    .byte 10
    .short 16435
    .byte 12
    .short 19843
    .byte 15
    .short 20818
    .byte 25
    .short 23191
    .byte 27
    .short 25597
    .byte 28
    .short 32767
    .byte 27
```

Exact opcodes of the code part (in a linked context so that the relocation of .Ltbl doesn't confuse things):

```
0804930b <eu_members>:
 804930b:       bf 49 a0 04 08          mov    $0x804a049,%edi
 8049310:       47                      inc    %edi
 8049311:       66 af                   scas   %es:(%edi),%ax
 8049313:       7f fb                   jg     8049310 <eu_members+0x5>
 8049315:       8a 07                   mov    (%edi),%al
 8049317:       c3                      ret
```

And here's the test harness I used (note that the assembly code is not PIC safe, so on Debian or Ubuntu systems you will need to pass `-no-pie` to gcc):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char eu_members_wrap(short days_since_1950_01_01) {
    unsigned char res;
    __asm__("call eu_members" : "=a"(res) : "0"(days_since_1950_01_01) : "edi", "cc");
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct tm tm;
  time_t epoch, req;
  short days_since_epoch;
  memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(tm));
  tm.tm_year = 50;
  tm.tm_mon = 0;
  tm.tm_mday = 1;
  epoch = mktime(&tm);
  memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(tm));
  tm.tm_year = atoi(argv[1]) - 1900;
  tm.tm_mon = atoi(argv[2]) - 1;
  tm.tm_mday = atoi(argv[3]);
  req = mktime(&tm);
  days_since_epoch = (((unsigned int) (req - epoch)) / (24 * 60 * 60));
  /* printf("epoch = %ld, req = %ld\n", epoch, req);
  printf("Raw number of days: %hd\n", days_since_epoch); */
  printf("EU members: %hhu\n", eu_members_wrap(days_since_epoch));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you use `lods (%edi), %al` instead of `mov    (%edi),%al`? I am not sure about assembly syntax, but the opcode should work.

Comment: No, `lods` can only read from `(%esi)`

Answer (score -3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 46 bytes

```perl
($q,%d)=split;$q--while!exists$d{$q};say$d{$q}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcprCsIwEATgq0SIoGDK7tY0CcUjeAihAQOlrwRUxKsbtynI/vlmZie/9Drng5xP@@54iVMfUitnpR730Pudf4aYouzecv608fbalDM6UwMCCuBDp20Jjfj3jmmxENcP22wmttObtSCAM3ASVGxKT4aN9ZoEWTYvVPrvOKUwDjGr4aorhAp@)

...or try like this on some decent command line:

```perl
query=19730101
data="0 0 19580101 6 19730101 9 19810101 10 19860101 12 19950101 15 20040501 25 20070101 27 20130701 28 20200201 27"
echo "$query $data" | perl -nE '($q,%d)=split;$q--while!exists$d{$q};say$d{$q}'
```

Comment: The data is supposed to be contained in the code, not passed as input.

Comment: Data is data, code is code, but sometimes code is data and data is code and E=mc²