# What's the Date?

Tags: code-golf, date

### Challenge

Weirdly, this hasn't been done yet: output the current date.

### Rules

The date format you should follow is as follows:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Where the month and day should be padded by zeroes if they are less than 10.

For example, if the program is run on the 24th May 2017, it should output

```
2017-05-24
```

The date can either be always in UTC or in the local date.

You must handle leaps years. i.e. in leap years, February has 29 days but 28 days in a normal year.

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: ... and in normal years February has 31 days of course

Comment: @edc65 I should really have known that Feb is 29 days long on leap years :P

Comment: Finally a golf where golfing languages cant perform

Comment: RIP Python needing the word `datetime` twice

Comment: In TIO, if I use `p` in Ruby it surrounds the output in quotes, but the actual date is in the right format. Is this okay?

Comment: @snail_ Do you have a link to this?

Comment: @BetaDecay here: https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@1@gEJKZm6qXl1@uV1xSlFYC5Kiruqn//w8A

Comment: @snail_ That's fine

Comment: A codegolf challenge where practical languages can beat golfing languages? Amazing!

Answer (score 12):

## [Bash](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SWJKqoK3q9v8/AA) with [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), <s>16</s> 7 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to Neil (and fergusq) (no pipe required to output)
-1 byte thanks to 12431234123412341234123 (use the built-in option with flag `-I`!)

```bash
date -I
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SWJKqoOv5//9/AA)**

Comment: Why the `echo $(...)`?

Comment: Does it not need it to output?

Comment: `date` outputs already, the output is piped to stdout. You don't need to pipe it to `echo`, which pipes it to stdout. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyWxJFVBW9Xt//@vefm6yYnJGakA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: But even if you really want to use `echo`, then at least `echo \`date +%F\``.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks, I am totally new to bash, it really is alien to me.

Comment: why not use `-I` ?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Indeed `-I` will work (note to self: rtfm). There is also an entry on the question I linked to with that! Thanks.

Comment: [According to POSIX 2018](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html), date does not support the option `-I`. So instead of "Bash", this answer should rather be titled "Any environment with GNU coreutils installed in the default path".

Answer (score 10):

## PHP, 17 bytes

```php
<?=date('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Actually, `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+hh:mm` is also an [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) formatted date and these 11 bytes: `<?=date(c);` print the whole stuff. ;)

Comment: `<?=strstr(date(c),T,1);` to give the c format a little chance

Answer (score 7):

## Bash, 15 bytes

```bash
printf '%(%F)T'
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ printf '%(%F)T'
2017-05-24
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19QlJlXkqagrqqh6qYZov7/PwA)

Comment: Even better than I found on SO, was unaware of `T`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan, it was added only in Bash 4.2 and until Bash 4.3 it required an argument to format.

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
Ks3 ¯A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@@9dbKxwaL3j//8A)

### Explanation:

```
Ks3 ¯A
K       // New Date()
 s3     // .toISOString()
    ¯A  // .slice(0,10)
```

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```
_=>new Date().toJSON().split`T`[0]
```

```js
f=

_=>new Date().toJSON().split`T`[0]

console.log(f());
```

Comment: Hmm, same length as `_=>new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)`

Answer (score 4):

## SQLite, 13 characters

```sql
select date()
```

Good boy, SQLite. Other SQL dialects usually need either `current_date` or `date(now())`.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ sqlite3 <<< 'select date()'
2017-05-24
```

Comment: MySQL has [`curdate`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp)

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 20 bytes

```
DateString@"ISODate"
```

Comment: Sometimes I come into these challenges not to see if Mathematica has a built-in, but to see what it is

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>14</s>  12 bytes

```perl6
Date.today.say
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u2/u@SWJKqV5KfklipV5xY@f//17x83eTE5IxUAA)

```perl6
now.Date.say
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u2/p@XX67nkliSqlecWPn//9e8fN3kxOSMVAA)

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 24 bytes

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"yyy-mm-dd")
```

Excel will still do a 4-digit year with only 3 `y`'s.

Comment: Google sheets will add the `")`. Excel won't. It *will* add the `)` on the end but only after prompting you so it would require additional user input and drive the score up again. 24 bytes is probably the shortest Excel answer unless we allow for regional settings using the ISO date format by default and that's [up for debate](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/209/38183).

Comment: @EngineerToast Thanks. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 10 bytes

```r
Sys.Date()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@x9cWaznkliSqqH5/z8A)

Comment: Since `sys.date` already is a function, you don't have to add the `()`, so this is only 8 bytes :)

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam not true, the () is necessary

Comment: @D.Nelson https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet `Sys.Date` is a function, so would suffice as solution. No need to explicitly call it.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam that's normally the case but I think that since the challenge is to 'output the current date in ISO-8601 format' I actually need to output it.

Comment: Well yeah, and the last line of `Sys.Date` does the outputting for you. It is similar to when you have a solution that starts with `function(x)`, you don't end that with an explicit call either. It's just how built-ins are scored.

Answer (score 2):

## jq, 19 characters

(15 characters code + 4 characters command line options)

```
now|todate[:10]
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -nr 'now|todate[:10]'
2017-05-24
```

[Try in jq‣play](https://jqplay.org/s/TtdTTXsPIO)

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 18 characters

```lua
print(os.date"%F")
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ lua -e 'print(os.date"%F")'
2017-05-24
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#@19QlJlXopFfrJeSWJKqpOqmpPn/PwA)

Answer (score 2):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 9 bytes

```
/oT\
@%;'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@fHxLD5aBqrf7/PwA)

#### Explanation

I'll leave the exact control flow as an exercise to the reader, but the linearised code that is being run in Ordinal mode is:

```
%T'T%;o@
```

And here is what it does:

```
%   Split an implicit empty string around an implicit empty string. Really doesn't
    do anything at all.
T   Push the current datetime as a string like "2017-05-24T20:53:08.150+00:00"
'T  Push "T".
%   Split the datetime string around the "T", to separate the date from the time.
;   Discard the time.
o   Output the date.
@   Terminate the program.
```

One way this might be golfable is to reuse the `%` to terminate the program in Cardinal mode with a division by zero, but the only layout I've come up with is the following:

```
\;T
\%o'
```

But here, the `%` doesn't actually terminate the program, because we push 111 (`'o`) right beforehand so there's never a division by zero.

In principle it might also be possible to reuse `%` to get rid of the `;`, since trying to split the date around the time will simply discard the time.

Answer (score 2):

## VBA, <strike>5</strike> 25 bytes

<strike>`?Date`</strike> *unpredictable, dependent on system short date settings*

```vba
?Format(Now,"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

#### Output:

```vba
2017-05-25
```

Comment: This answer is exceedingly volatile and by deafult, will not work on most computers as it depends entirely upon the user having their system short date format [under settings -> Date & Time in Win10] set to 'YYYY-MM-DD`. The default format for this is `M/D/YYYY` and thus this for the output of the `Date` function is `5/25/2017`. To correct this your answer would need to be wrapped in a `Format` call.

Comment: @TaylorScott to that end `?format(now,"yyyy-mm-dd")` using `now` is shorter than `date`

Comment: @Greedo, that is correct. This is, to my knowledge, the shortest way to achieve this goal using VBA

Comment: @TaylorScott thanks for pointing this out, I wasn't aware of the dependence on the system date settings. This date format _is_ the default on my PC and in my country in general, so I was a little overconfident here.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>26</s> 32 bytes

```java
()->java.time.LocalDate.now()+""
```

Fixed format thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: Wow, Java is actually *short*... I'd never have thought I'd see the day :D

Comment: @BetaDecay It is short, but currently not complying to standard codegolf rules. It should be a function instead of a snippet, and the required imports should be counted as well. So it should be `()->java.time.LocalDate.now().toString()` instead. Then again, you can golf `.toString()` to `+""`, so it becomes [`()->java.time.LocalDate.now()+""`](https://tinyurl.com/yaabftkw) in total (**32 bytes**).

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC 3, 29 bytes

SB has a date string built in... but it's in the wrong format! It uses slashes instead of dashes, no good. Plus, being the self-respecting BASIC it is, there is no global replace function. I guess I have to do it myself...

```
D$=DATE$D$[4]="-
D$[7]="-
?D$
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 46 bytes

```
f(X):-get_time(Y),format_time(atom(X),'%F',Y).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P00jQtNKNz21JL4kMzdVI1JTRyEtvyg3EcpPLMnPBarQUVBXdVPXUYjU1INo0QMA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>55</del> <del>53</del> 48 bytes

Binary:

```
00000000: b42a cd21 91b3 64f6 f38b c8e8 1400 8ac5  .*.!..d.........
00000010: e80f 00b0 2dcd 298a c6e8 0600 b02d cd29  ....-.)......-.)
00000020: 8ac2 d40a 0530 3050 86c4 cd29 58cd 29c3  .....00P...)X.).
```

Listing:

```
B4 2A       MOV  AH, 2AH        ; get system date: CX=year, DH=month, DL=day 
CD 21       INT  21H            ; call DOS API
91          XCHG AX, CX         ; move year in CX to AX (dividend)
B3 64       MOV  BL, 100        ; divide by 100 to separate digits of year
F6 F3       DIV  BL             ; AL = first two digits, AH = last two digits
8B C8       MOV  CX, AX         ; save AX to CX to display last two digits later 
E8 0122     CALL DISP_WORD      ; display decimal value in AL 
8A C5       MOV  AL, CH         ; move last two digits to AL 
E8 0122     CALL DISP_WORD      ; display decimal value in AL 
B0 2D       MOV  AL, '-'        ; date separator 
CD 29       INT  29H            ; fast write AL to screen
8A C6       MOV  AL, DH         ; move month in DH into AL for display 
E8 0122     CALL DISP_WORD      ; display decimal value in AL 
B0 2D       MOV  AL, '-'        ; date separator 
CD 29       INT  29H            ; fast write AL to screen 
8A C2       MOV  AL, DL         ; move day into AL and display 
        DISP_WORD: 
D4 0A       AAM                 ; convert binary to BCD 
05 3030     ADD  AX, '00'       ; convert BCD to ASCII char 
50          PUSH AX             ; save second digit for display later 
86 C4       XCHG AL, AH         ; convert endian, AL = first digit, AH = second digit 
CD 29       INT  29H            ; fast write AL to screen
58          POP  AX             ; restore digits
CD 29       INT  29H            ; fast write AL to screen 
C3          RET                 ; return to caller/DOS
```

***Output***

Standalone DOS program, run from the command line outputs current date to the screen.

[image]

Much of this program is converting binary values to ASCII for console output. This uses (abuses) the binary-to-BCD instruction (`AAM`) to create a printable ASCII version of the output.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 19 bytes

`++++.d3"-".d4"-".d5`

In Pyth `.` allows you to access a number of extra syntactic goodies. `d` contains various date options which are accessed with `.d#`, where `#` is a number 0-9. `3` is for the current year, `4` is the current month, and `5` is for the current day.

Format for the challenge wants dashes between each element of the date so we append them. Pyth using Polish notation for all math operands, thus the `++++`.

Comment: Consider adding a short explanation of your code for those who don't know Pyth. Short code-only answers (like this one) tend to be automatically flagged as low quality.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that!

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 21 bytes

```
[ now timestamp>ymd ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJyYk5qXklgEZ@il5RflJpYoZOYrWP@PVsjLL1coycxNLS5JzC2wq8xNUYj9D1Sao1BQlJlX8h8A)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 72 bytes

```
getDate→A
toString(Ans(1→B
toString(ʟA(2→C
toString(ʟA(3→D
If C<10
"0"+C→C
If D<10
"0"+D→D
B+"-"+C+"-"+D
```

This only works on a TI-84+ CE OS 5.2 and if the user has already set the time and date correctly.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>22</s> 15 bytes

```
et3<{sY0e[}%'-*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@59aYmxTXRxpkBpdq6quq/X/PwA)

-7 bytes thanks to Challenger5.

Explanation:

```
et                       Get array with [year,month,day,stuff...]
  3<                     Slice array to get [y,m,d] 
    {                    For each item do:
     s                     To string
      Y0e[                 add a 0 to the beginning of the string if it is shorter than 2 chars.
          }%             End for each
            '-*          Join the array with "-" as a separator
```

Comment: You can use `e[` (pad array) for 15 bytes: `et3<{sY0e[}%'-*`

Comment: @Challenger5 that's cool. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org/), <strike>30 bytes</strike>  <strike>24 bytes</strike>  21 bytes

-6 thanks to [Nick Clifford](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65298/nick-clifford)

-3 from looking at [snail_](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42096/snail)'s answer in Ruby

```
p Time.now.to_s("%F")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/crystal#@1@gEJKZm6qXl1@uV5IfX6yhpOqmpPn/PwA)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use `%F`. Also, nice to see Crystal on PPCG!

Comment: @Nick Clifford I saw it on tio and thought it had a cool name.

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 33 bytes

```
B=_D?_sB,-4|+@-`+_sB,2|+A+_sB,4,2
```

Explanation:

```
B=_D        Assign the system's date to B$
            This is in American mm-dd-yyyy format, so we'll need to do some reformatting
?_sB,-4|    PRINT substring B, take 4 chars from the right
 +@-`         plus the string literal "-", now A$
 +_sB,2|      plus the leftmost two chars
 +A           and A$ again
 +_sB,4,2     plus the middle part.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>53</s>  40 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to Gábor Fekete (ISO-8601 is the default format for a date object)

```python
from datetime import*
print date.today()
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59WlJ@rkJJYklqSmZuqkJlbkF9UosVVUJSZVwIW1ivJT0ms1ND8/x8A)**

#### How?

`datetime.date.today()` will return a `datetime.date` object containing the local date information.

`print` will print a string representation of that object, this will call the object's `__str__` function.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

- `date.__str__()`: For a `date` `d`, `str(d)` is equivalent to `d.isoformat()`.
- `date.isoformat()`: Return a `string` representing the date in **ISO 8601** format, `‘YYYY-MM-DD’`. For example, `date(2002, 12, 4).isoformat() == '2002-12-04'`.

Comment: `import datetime;print datetime.date.today()` this is only 43 bytes and uses datetime. Why is the even shorter version deleted?

Comment: @GáborFekete Thanks (I think you should really have posted, it's sufficiently different). The other answer was probably deleted because it did not print the correctly formatted string. I have added an explanation about why this does actually work (so long as one includes the `print`). Saved another three doing (the evil) `import*`.

Comment: I wanted to but there was an another solution which was even shorter than mine but was deleted for some reason.

Comment: ...which has now been edited to include the `print` while deleted then undeleted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>62</s> 56 bytes

```
import."time"
func f()string{return Now().String()[:10]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/go#K0hMzk5MT1XITczM48rMLcgvKtFTSsstUfoP45Rk5qYqcaWV5iUrpGloFpcUZealVxellpQW5Sn45ZdraOoFg8U0NKOtDA1ia/@DlYLM09Cs5lIAggCgdIkGULMmV@1/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [q/kdb+,](http://kx.com/download/) <s>18</s> 16 bytes

**Solution:**

```
ssr[.z.d$:].".-"
```

**Example:**

```
q)ssr[.z.d$:].".-"
"2018-01-01"
```

**Explanation:**

Take the string representation of today's date, and replace the dots with dashes.

```
ssr[string .z.d;".";"-"] / fully ungolfed solution
ssr[string .z.d;;].".-"  / partially ungolfed solution
           .z.d          / current UTC date (2018.01.01)
    string               / convert to string ("2018.01.01")
ssr[           ;;]       / string-search-replace 
                  .".-"  / the two parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 40 bytes

```
from datetime import*;print date.today()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, <s>26</s> 17 bytes

```
Date -f yyy-MM-dd
```

Thanks to @ConnorLSW for the 9 bytes.

Comment: you can save a lot here. `date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd'`

Comment: Thanks Man. I am new to Powershell. So,  I tried my luck here

Comment: @Shivaprasath V - no worries, check [this thread](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191/tips-for-golfing-in-windows-powershell/79895) for a couple of helpful posts with the more basic PS golfing tricks if you want.

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL, 46 bytes

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*

```
žgžfže)T‰J'-ý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L70o/vSju5L1Qx51LDBS1338N7//wE)

**Explanation**

```
žgžfže)         # push [year, month, day]
       T‰       # divmod each by 10
         J      # join each div and mod result together
          '-ý   # join year-month-day on "-"
```

Comment: It's a shame that `žgžfže‚т+€¦\`'-ý` doesn't work.

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L70o/vSju5L1Qx51LDBS1338N7//wE)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: The divmod trick being useful again. I'm definitely going to have to remember that ;)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```c#
_=>System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd");
```

*Saved a byte thanks to @raznagul.*

Comment: Where do I download `Sytem`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It's a custom wrapper I created around the `System` namespace because I kept doing the same typo...

Comment: You know stuff you create locally isn't allowed on PPCG unless it's published before the question is asked. :P

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Damn, next time I'll create a shorter wrapper as well...

Comment: As leading zeroes for the year are not required the format string `"yyy-MM-dd"` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 23 bytes

Prints the local time.

```
p Time.now.strftime'%F'
```

Comment: `p Time.now.to_s[0..9]`

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>25</s> 15 bytes

```matlab
datestr(now,29)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@5@SWJJaXFKkkZdfrmNkqfn/PwA)

---

The built-in function `now` returns the current system date in a weirdy MATLAB serial format.

`datestr` formats the weirdy serial format into a string of a requested format - which is in this case `'YYYY-mm-dd'`. It turns out that MATLAB has a list of predefined formats for `datestr`. ISO8601 is one of them and is represented by the number 29, which allows a saving of 10 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 84 Bytes

```
extern crate chrono;fn main(){print!("{}",chrono::Local::now().format("%Y-%m-%d"));}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Noether, 8 bytes

```
6D0 10SP
```

[**Try it here!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=NkQwIDEwU1A)

***Explanation:***

```
6  - Push the number 6 onto the stack
D  - Pop the mode number off the top of the stack and push the ISO date string (Mode 6)
0  - Push the number 0 onto the stack
10 - Push the number 10 onto the stack
S  - Pop the three items, A, B and C off the top of the stack and slice the string, A, from B to C
P  - Print the item on the top of the stack
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the following method (also for 8 bytes):

```
6D"T"^#P
```

[**Try it here!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=NkQiVCJeI1A)

***Explanation:***

```
6   - Push 6 onto the stack
D   - Pop the mode number off the top of the stack and push the ISO date string (Mode 6)
"T" - Push the string "T" onto the stack
^   - Pop two strings A and B off the stack and split A by B
#   - Pop the top item off the stack
P   - Print the item on the top of the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

#### C++14, <strike>143 bytes</strike> 139 bytes

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <time.h>
int main (){time_t t;char D[11];time(&t);strftime(D,sizeof D,"%Y-%m-%d",localtime(&t));printf("%s",D);}
```

Timtech pointed out to me that i don't need all spaces

[Test me!](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZ2NpaGlNaWNvMGc)

Comment: Can't you remove a few of those spaces?

Answer (score 1):

### Swift,  13 bytes

```
print(Date())
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 16 bytes

```
6!:0'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/oPBGaKVgbqkUCg6@ur6@KiDgA)

Answer (score 1):

## vim, 18

```
i®=strftime("%F")↵
```

where *®* and *↵* are *Ctrl-R* and *Enter*.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 15 bytes

Who needs `date`?

```sh
print -P %D{%F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/oCgzr0RBN0BB1aVa1a32/38A)

If we assume the program will only be run in current century, we can save 2 bytes:

```sh
print -P 20%D
```

Comment: "If we assume the program will only be run in current century" — This is precisely how Y2K happened…

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 12 bytes

```perl6
say now.Date
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVIhL79czyWxJPX/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
kD
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?s=?flags=&code=kD&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Uh, it's a built in constant using python's `date.today().isoformat()`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 45 bytes

```
“from datetime import*;print(date.today())”ŒV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5y0ovxchZTEktSSzNxUhczcgvyiEi3rgqLMvBINkLBeSX5KYqWGpuajhrlHJ4X9/w8A)

evaluates python code because *comedy*

Comment: [You could at least compress it](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9qZWxsef//4oCcZeG4pcaIeUPhuZnhuoc04biywqV9xpFCI8K54bmjfUR9xZNBbsivwrvFklb//w)

Comment: I am sorry, comedy is more important

Comment: +1 for comedy 10/10

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

Oddly enough, <s>I can't find an easier built-in...</s> somebody else [found it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122586/68615). ><

```python
from datetime import*
print datetime.now().isoformat()[:10]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59WlJ@rkJJYklqSmZuqkJlbkF9UosVVUJSZVwIX1svLL9fQ1Msszk/LL8pNLNHQjLYyNIj9/x8A)

Answer (score 0):

## Fourier, 33 bytes

```
|~D<10{1}{0o}Do|F5do`-`4d^F`-`3dF
```

[**Try it online!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/editor/?code=fH5EPDEwezF9ezBvfURvfEY1ZG9gLWA0ZF5GYC1gM2RG)

Uses a function which adds the leading zero... So long :P

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>104</s> <s>79</s> 61 bytes

<sup>Saved 18 bytes thanks to hvd.</sup>

```
n,b[99];f(){time(&n);strftime(b,99,"%F",gmtime(&n));puts(b);}
```

Comment: "`strftime` segfaults if you don't #include `<time.h>`." -- Not on all implementations. You could get rid of that line and save some bytes by simply choosing an implementation where it works. (Most x86-32 Linux distros probably work.)

Answer (score 0):

### SAS, 31 bytes

```
%put %sysfunc(date(),yymmdd10.);
```

Comment: Use `e8601da.` to save one byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
Z'29XO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x@lbmQZ4f///9e8fN3kxOSMVAA)

#### Explanation

```
Z'    % Push current date and time as a float
29    % Push 29
XO    % String representation of date and time with specified format.
      % Format 29 corresponds to 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 51 bytes

```
Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: You can save 7 bytes by using string interpolation - 
Console.Write($"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd}");

Comment: This is just a code snippet, you need to wrap it in a function/program. You also need to fully qualify the classes or add the appropriate `using`s.

Comment: Or look at @TheLethalCoder example on making a function that returns it rather than writing to standard output, most questions allow this.

Comment: @Chris Thanks!  I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 20 bytes

```
j\-+.d3m.[\02`.d+4d2
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%5C-%2B.d3m.%5B%5C02%60.d%2B4d2&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 26 Bytes

Anonymous VBE Immediate window function that outputs the current date in the specified format, regardless of system settings, to the VBE immediate window

```vba
?Format(Now,"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Objective-C, 27 bytes

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSDate date]);
```

Comment: Even shorter: `NSLog(@"%@",[NSDate new]);`

Answer (score 0):

## Windows batch, <s>166 144 136</s> 107 bytes

```
@set X=
@for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime')do @set X=%%x
@echo %X:~0,4%-%X:~4,2%-%X:~6,2%
```

Outputs local time

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell, 16 bytes

```
date -u %Y-%m-%d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@5@SWJKqoFuqoBqpq5qrq5ry/z8A)

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 55 bytes

```
import Data.Time
m=getCurrentTime>>=putStr.take 10.show
```

Not exactly the shortest answer (even the Java answer is shorter!)

### Explanation

```
import Data.Time                            --put the function getCurrentTime into scope
m=getCurrentTime>>=putStr.take 10.show
m=                                          --define a variable/function m
  getCurrentTime                            --get the current time wrapped in the IO type
                >>=                         --feed the current time into the following function
                                  show      --display the time as a string
                          take 10.          --take the first ten characters of that to get the date
                   putStr.                  --print it
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 39 bytes

Beats [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122602/70206) by 1 byte.

```
from datetime import*;str(date.today())
```

This won't actually work when put in a file and executed, but it does work when you paste this in a python shell. However, it works if you have this in a file and then call that file's `__main__` function, so I don't know if this is allowed by the rules. I'm going to assume that it is.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

```apl
'-'@5 8⍕1E3⊥3↑⎕TS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM9JD8lsfK/uq66g6mCxaPeqYauxo@6lho/apv4qG9qSDBIyX@wGgA)

`⎕TS` Y M D h m s ms

`3↑` take the first three

`1E3⊥` evaluate in base-1000

`⍕` make into string

`'-'@5 8` substitute a dash at positions five and eight

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 86 chars

```
(multiple-value-bind(a b c d e f)(get-decoded-time)(format t"~4a-~2,'0d-~2,'0d"f e d))
```

Good old verbose Common Lisp!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcvBCoAgDADQXxleUmgQ0Q@pmyHMlJod@3Xr0OmdXpR8tTFs6aK5CePtpTOGfJD1ECACAUNydmdF4liJCTUXdjbVs3gFNc/m8VnnaaEfk75Dzo3xAg)

Answer (score 0):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 18 bytes

```
@os.date"%Y-%m-%d"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b73yG/WC8lsSRVSTVSVzVXVzVF6X9BUWZeiUaahqbmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 17 bytes

```
$0=strftime("%F")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcC2uKQorSQzN1VDSdVNSfP/fyUlAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [jamal](http://verhas.com/peter/progs/perl/jamal/), 32 characters

```
{@format date=YEAR-0M-0D}{@date}
```

(Only interesting part is jamal's unusual date format specifiers. For example YYYY would mean YY twice, where YY is the year as in Perl, since 1900.)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jamal.pl date.jam 
2018-03-19
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 40 characters

```
\A=@subst{*\\/*\\/*=\$3-\*-\*;@date}@end
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema '\A=@subst{*\\/*\\/*=\$3-\*-\*;@date}@end'
2018-03-19
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes

```
AîKs3
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Qe5LczM=)

```
A         :10
 î        :Slice the following to that length
  K       :  Current date & time
   s3     :  Convert to ISO string
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 52 bytes

```forth
: x 0 <# # # #> ." -"type ; : f time&date 1 .r x x ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WylUKBgo2CgrgKGdgp6Sgq5SSWVBqoK1gpVCmkJJZm6qWkpiSaqCoYJeEVBxhYL1/7T/AA)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
\ x prints a dash followed by a 2-digit number with leading zeros
: x               \ start a new word definition
  0 <# # # #>     \ convert number to double-precision, then converts to a string with leading 0
  ." -"type       \ print "-" followed by the string from the previous command
;                 \ end the word definition
 
: f               \ start a new word definition
  time&date       \ forth built-in to get the components of a date/time (year on top)
  1 .r            \ print the year (with no space appended)
  x               \ print a dash, followed by the month
  x               \ print a dash, followed by the day
;                 \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```
import times
echo ($now())[0..9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEoSQzN7WYKzU5I19BQyUvv1xDUzPaQE/PMvb/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic (TI-84), 32 bytes

```
Output(1,1,sum(getDate{ᴇ6,ᴇ3,1
Output(1,5,"-
Output(1,8,"-
```

- `getDate` is a list in the form `{2021, 1, 20}`.
- the date list is multiplied by `{1e6, 1e3, 1}` and then summed, giving a single number in the form `yyyy0mm0dd`, this deals automatically with leading zeros
- `-`s are then added at the right places, giving the output `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `h`, 3 bytes

```
kQO
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UoZS7IKlpSVpuhaLswP9lxQnJRdD-QugNAA)

##### Explanation

```python
kQ   # Push a string of the current time
     # in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
  O  # Split it on spaces to get the list
     # ["YYYY-MM-DD", "HH:mm:ss"]
     # Implicit output of first item
     # ("YYYY-MM-DD")
```