# Draw an S-Chain

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

## Background

When I was younger, I was taught a method of drawing a weird "S" shape, that I (along with my classmates) found fascinating. Today, I rediscovered it, and due to its formulaic approach to drawing it, thought it could lead to an interesting challenge :P

## Drawing the "S"

The S can be drawn by following these simple steps:

First, draw 2 rows of three vertical lines like so

```
| | |

| | |
```

Next, connect the top left line with the bottom middle line and the top middle with the bottom right line to produce

```
| | |
 \ \
| | |
```

Finally, draw a top and bottom on the currently drawn image so that it ends up looking like

```
  ^
 / \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ /
  v
```

As you can see, this results in an "S" shape. When extended however (drawing it with more than 2 rows), it produces a very interesting pattern. Your task is reproduce this interesting pattern.

## Task

Given an integer where `n >= 2`, output The S with `n` rows to be made from it. Output may be returned from a function, and input may be taken in standard methods. Trailing/leading whitespace for both the overall image, as well as each line, is fine. However, leading line spaces must be consistent so that the " isn't broken. You may output as a list of lines.

## Test cases

```
input
output
---

2

  ^
 / \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ /
  v

---

8
  ^
 / \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ /
  v

---

10

  ^
 / \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ \
| | |
 \ /
  v
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins! Good luck,

Comment: Wikipedia calls the `S` the [Cool S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cool_S), and calls an infinite version of the an `S Chain`

Comment: Can we output as a list of lines?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder you may

Comment: @Stephen 10 minutes googling and this didn't come up. I'll edit the name of the question

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I searched images, that might have been it :P

Comment: I guess that leading spaces which break the shape of the S aren't allowed, right?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer yes, I'll edit that in

Comment: There are probably better UTF-8 chars to display the cool S, especially than `v` and `^`.

Comment: @EricDuminil yes, but they are most likely multi byte characters, which I'm reluctant to add as it means that languages that don't support those characters can't do the challenge as succinctly

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing: Fair point.

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
lambda k:'  ^\n / '+'\\\n| | |\n \ '*k+'/\n  v'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHbSl1BIS4mT0FfQV1bPSYmJq9GAQiBAjEK6lrZ2ur6QKZCmfr/gqLMvBKFNA0Tzf8A)

Answer (score 11):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>73</s> <s>69</s> <s>66</s> <s>64</s> 62 bytes

Two less bytes and perl-like appearance thanks to Barodus. Didn't think of using int? for nulls.

```cs
n=>$@"  ^
 / {string.Join(@"\
| | |
 \ ",new int?[++n])}/
  v"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY3BCoJAGITv@xSDdFA0hU5BaULQIerUoYMayLbKgv0L7maF@ey24aVbM8f5ZobrOVetGHlTao0n65k2pZEcnZJXHEtJcLVpJdVZgbKttWcRWJ1e2ohbuLsTX0syASYqQYV4pDiZpQ5wYYjQT0m4V5Lc1MnZG9YMOZyAxAO2vcl8nwpviOx054yr34etIq0aEZ5bacRBknArd@F5f5nllxnYMH4A)

Comment: If this was a golf of the existing C# answer, I'd never have been able to tell. Well done :-)

Comment: Can you explain what the `new string[n+1]` does? I have never seen it before.

Comment: Creates a array of empty strings AFAIK. I've used a hack with string.Join, aka join {"","","",""} with separator "\ \n | | | \n \"

Comment: @someone Woah, I never acknowledged this trick before. Really cool! (Also my bad, i though the  `new string[n+1]` was some kind of tricky string constructor and not an array declaration -.-)

Answer (score 7):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 18 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
°I-‘*"∑ūCƨΩ)¹‘@∑5n
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JUIwSS0ldTIwMTgqJTIyJXUyMjExJXUwMTZCQyV1MDFBOCV1MDNBOSUyOSVCOSV1MjAxOEAldTIyMTE1bg__,inputs=Mw__)

Uses the same strategy as [ETHproductions's Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143349/59183)

Explanation:

```
..‘           push "\|||\"
   *          repeat input times
    "..‘      push " ^ /ŗ/ v ", with ŗ replaced with POP. The reason why there's a trailing
              space is because otherwise it didn't have enough repeating characters to compress
        @∑    join with spaces
          5n  split to line lengths of 5
```

Comment: `push "|" and " "` what the heck is that builtin

Comment: @StevenHewitt those are actually two built-ins, but I joined them together (as I do with other stuff) because I don't think it's not necessary to separate stuff that gets used together soon

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 48  <s>56 59 61</s>  bytes

```python
lambda k:'  ^\n / %s/\n  v'%('\\\n| | |\n \ '*k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYjRCgIhFAV/5byI3ghs683oTy4LRmuJdRVXFoL9dxNiHmaY8m2vLJcebtzf/nN/eCSngZkFFmq1w9i0MpqZZcdgHIY@JOohV0REQfXyXMz5OJ3IlRqlmWAi0fXf1H8)

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by unescaping the lone backslashes.

Comment: @L3viathan Just updating too

Comment: [56 bytes; not sure if this is fair game](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHbSklBIS4mT0FfISZGSVtDKSavRgEIgSIxIBGtbE1tpZgiIEcfKKRQpvQ/Lb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVXDSMdC06qgKDOvRCNNI1NT0xrC1vwPAA); doesn't work on TIO

Comment: @L3viathan That is not correct. Extra ``\ \``.

Comment: On TIO: yes. In my terminal: no.

Comment: @L3viathan I'll stick with my current solution, thanks though!

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
…^
/ð"\
| | |
\ "I×…/
vJ.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOyOC79wxuUYrhqFICQK0ZByfPwdKCwPleZl17y//9GAA)

**Alternate 27 byte version**

```
'^…/ \©IF…| |û…\ \}\®R'v».c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fPe5RwzJ9hZhDKz3dgKwahZrDu4F0jEJMbcyhdUHqZYd26yX//28EAA)

**Explanation**

```
'^                             # push "^"
  …/ \©                        # push "/ \" and store a copy in register
       IF                      # input times do:
         …| |û                 # push "| | |"
              …\ \             # push "\ \"
                  }            # end loop
                   \           # discard top of stack (the extra "\ \")
                    ®R         # push "/ \" reversed = "\ /"
                      'v       # push "v"
                        »      # join stack on newlines
                         .c    # center each row
```

Comment: Your code looks a bit like an elephant to me :)

Comment: It's literally SCARY how close my answer was to yours: `'^…/ \©IF„| ûû„\ û}\®R'v).C` without looking.

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>34</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
" ^ /{ç'\²i|³1}/ v"¬¸ò5
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=IiBeIC975ydcsml8szF9LyB2Iqy48jU=&input=MyAtUg==) Outputs as an array of lines; `-R` flag added to join on newlines. (Thanks @Shaggy)

<s>First</s> Second attempt, might be improvable...

#### How it works

```
" ^ /{ ç'\²  i |³  1}/ v"¬ ¸  ò5
" ^ /{Uç'\p2 i'|p3 1}/ v"q qS ò5   Ungolfed
                                   Implicit: U = input number
        '\p2                       Repeat a backslash twice, giving "\\".
             i     1               Insert at index 1
              '|p3                   3 vertical bars. This gives "\|||\".
      Uç                           Make U copies of this string. U = 2: "\|||\\|||\"
" ^ /{              }/ v"          Insert this into this string.    " ^ /\|||\\|||\/ v"
                         q qS      Split into chars; join on spaces."  ^   / \ | | | \ \ | | | \ /   v"
                              ò5   Split into rows of length 5.    ["  ^  "," / \ ","| | |"," \ \ ","| | |"," \ / ","  v"]
                                   Joining on newlines gives "  ^  
                                                               / \ 
                                                              | | |
                                                               \ \
                                                              | | |
                                                               \ /
                                                                v"
```

Comment: Beating Charcoal and tying SOGL? Excellent work!

Comment: You can output an array of lines, by the way, so you can ditch the last 2 characters.

Comment: @Shaggy That's great, now we're winning!

Comment: We've been doing well lately :)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 60 bytes

```js
n=>`  ^
 / \\
${`| | |
 \\ \\
`.repeat(n-1)}| | |
 \\ /
  v`
```

### Test Snippet

```js
let f=
n=>`  ^
 / \\
${`| | |
 \\ \\
`.repeat(n-1)}| | |
 \\ /
  v`
;(I.oninput=_=>O.innerHTML=I.value+"\n"+f(+I.value))()
```

```html
<input id=I type=range min=2 max=15 value=2><pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: 57: `n=>'  ^\n /${' \\ \\\n| | |\n'.repeat(n).slice(2)} \\ /\n  v'` (using backticks and literal newlines)

Comment: Beat me by 1 bytes :(

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Carlos Alejo. -1 byte thanks to ASCII-only.*

```
  ^⸿ / ×\⸿| | |⸿ \ Ｎ/⸿  v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/19JQSHu0DYFfQUlLQ2lmJiYohoFIIwpUohRUNLxzCsoLfErzU1KLdLQ1FTSBworlCn9/2/yX7fsv25xDgA) Link is to verbose version. *#charcoal-verbose-obfucation*

Comment: You can save 1 byte by just calling Print (instead of adding the strings) and using `\r`: `  ^⸿ / ×\⸿| | |⸿ \ Ｉθ/⸿  v`. [Verbose version](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRENJQSEupkhBX0FJ05oLIqSloRQTE1NUowCEQKkYBSUdBefE4hKNQk1NuCIlfaCUQhlQ1///Jv91y/7rFucAAA).

Comment: Ah... I'll have to remember `\r` as the way to get newlines the sane way. Thanks!

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/19JQSEupkhBX0FJS0MpJiamqEYBCIEiMQpKOgqeeQWlJX6luUmpRRqamkr6QHGFMqX//03@65b91y3OAQA)

Comment: @ASCII-only :P -

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 82 bytes

```c
f(n){for(puts("  ^\n / \\");--n;puts("| | |\n \\ \\"));puts("| | |\n \\ /\n  v");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOi2/SKOgtKRYQ0lBIS4mT0FfISZGSdNaVzfPGiJcowCEQImYGLCMJqawPpBSKANqqv2fm5iZp6HJVc2lAARpGkaa1mAWRIsSlJemYQJk1f4HAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```perl
say"  ^
 / ".'\
| | |
 \ 'x<>."/
  v"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJJQSGOS0FfQUlPPYarRgEIuRRiFNQrbOz0lPS5FBTKlP7/NzT4l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQAAA)

*Shaved two bytes with @DomHastings' suggestion*

Comment: If you use single quotes, you don't need to escape the backslashes for -2! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 49 bytes

```
"| | |"@α;lD" \ \"@α@Z♂ii"  v"" \ /"))" / \""  ^"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/1@pRgEIlRzObbTOcVFSiFGIAbEdoh7NbMrMVFJQKFMCCeoraWoqKegDJYFCcUr//1sAAA)

Explanation:

```
"| | |"@α;lD" \ \"@α@Z♂ii"  v"" \ /"))" / \""  ^"
"| | |"@α                                          push a list containing n copies of the vertical lines
         ;lD" \ \"@α                               push a list containing n-1 copies of the diagonal connections
                    @Z♂i                           interleave
                        i                          flatten
                         "  v"" \ /"))             make the bottom
                                      " / \""  ^"  make the top
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 38 bytes

```
…| |ûU"  ^
 / \"XI<F„ \2×X}" \ /
  v"»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOyGoWaw7tDlRQU4rgU9BVilCI8bdweNcxTiDE6PD2iVkkhRkGfS0GhTOnQ7v//jQE)

```
…| |                         # Push "| |"
    û                        # Palindromize
     U                       # Store in X
      "..."X                 # Push the top three rows
            I<F      }       # One less than input times do:
               „ \           #   Push " \"
                  2×         #   Concatenate that with itself
                    X        #   Push "| | |"
                      "..."  # Push the last two rows
                           » # Join stack with newlines
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>101</s> <s>77</s> 73 bytes

<sub>Saved 24 bytes thanks to **i cri everytim**!</sub>
<sub>Saved 4 bytes thanks to **Kevin Cruijssen**!</sub>

```cs
n=>{var s="  ^\n / ";for(;n-->0;s+="\\\n| | |\n \\ ");return s+"/\n  v";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc0xC8IwEAXgvb/ikalFq@IkxHYRnHRycDAKIaYloBfIxaJof3uNuLh5b3vvgzNcGh/sYC6aGffsmXHU0Rl03p2x1Y6QcwyO2sMROrRcJIJ0uwdHe52sb2SWjuIYX1WjQTVQVT87HcCVAE6KMIWQjQ@5pLKsZ5JHlVBK0QspaVYKopDBxlsg8EhMU4dOyH6Qv89Wnthf7GQfXLQbRzZv8nlR/DWLj@mzfngD)

As per usual, string repeating in C# is a pain.

Comment: [77 bytes.](https://tio.run/##hY0xa8MwFIR3/4pDk01rO3QKqPIS6NRMHTpEDQhVNgLnCfRkk@L6t7tKunTr3XR3H5zl2oboNjsaZlyLpeBkkreYg//E0XhCySl6Gk4fMHHgKiPIevvi5C7Ny0T22VN6xC/VoYfaSHXLbCJYCeCsCS2E7EMsZV1Tp3aSH5TQWtM3svOuNUR1b9ucMAsZXZoigeW6yb@Hh0AcRte8R5/cqydX9uVTVf3L7G/MWqzbDw "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Comment: @icrieverytim Ahhh, of course, thats way better.

Comment: You can change `--n>=0` to `n-->0` and `s+="/\n  v";return s;` to `return s+"/\n  v";` to save some bytes.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 38 bytes

```
.+
$*
1
¶|||¶x\\
^
 ^¶x/\
.$
/¶ v
x?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLkOvQtpqamkPbKmJiuOK4FOKALP0YLj0VLv1D2xTKuCrsuRT@/zcGAA)

Prints a column of leading spaces and on trailing space on each line.

#### Explanation

The main byte savings come from omitting the spaces in all the literal parts and inserting them at the end. The figure is structured such that there are never two non-spaces next to each other, so if we just remove them all, we can almost fix the shape by inserting a space at every position at the end:

```
^
/\
|||
\\
|||
\/
v
```

becomes:

```
 ^ 
 / \ 
 | | | 
 \ \ 
 | | | 
 \ / 
 v
```

That's almost correct, except for indentation. The `^` and `v` are missing two spaces. That's actually easier to fix, because if we just insert an explicit space in front of each of them, that'll result in two additional spaces at the end. The lines with the slashes are trickier because they require just one additional space. To fix this, we insert a placeholder character there (`x`). When we insert the spaces at the end, we don't just insert them for every empty match, but we optionally match that `x`. That means instead of inserting a space in front of the `x`, the `x` itself gets replaced. And then there will still be an empty match right after the `x`. That means, every `x` adds exactly one space without changing anything else. So what we want to set up is this:

```
 ^
x/\
|||
x\\
|||
x\/
 v
```

which will give us the desired result. So here's the code:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert the input to unary.

```
1
¶|||¶x\\
```

Convert each `1` to two lines with `|||` and `x\\` (and a leading linefeed).

```
^
 ^¶x/\
```

Inser the first two lines with `^` and `x/\`.

```
.$
/¶ v
```

Fix the final `x\\` by turning the last `\` into `/` and appending a line with the `v`.

```
x?
```

Replace each `x` or empty match with a space.

Comment: Neat approach. I was trying to figure out a way to use join-on-spaces for my Pip solution, but it didn't quite work due to the different numbers of leading spaces on different rows.

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>21</s></sup> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
⌐èüYΩ╜yu╝√♪╪▌yº⌐▌2Σ⌠
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a98a8159eabd7975bcfb0dd8dd79a7a9dd32e4f4&i=5)

Uses ETHProductions' idea.

-1 after changing `1/` to `M` (from recursive).

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 46 bytes

```
"  ^
 / \\"
+*j[jd*\|3" \ \\"k))Q" \ /
  v
```

[Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%22++%5E%0A+%2F+%5C%5C%22%0A%2B%2aj%5BKjd%2a%5C%7C3%22+%5C+%5C%5C%22k%29%29QK%0A%22+%5C+%2F%0A++v&input=3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5&debug=0)

Comment: 36 bytes: `%"  ^\n / %s/\n  v"*Q"\\\n| | |\n \ `

Comment: [31 bytes](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25%22+%5E%0A+%2F+%25s%2F%0A++v%22%2a%22%5C%5C%5Cn%7C+%7C+%7C%0A+%5C+&input=5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 40 bytes

```
K" / \ ""  ^"Kj+b+*2+d\\b*Q]*3"| "_K"  v
```

Fairly similar to Steven Hewitt's, but developed independently.

[Try it Online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%22+%2F+%5C+%22%22++%5E%22Kj%2Bb%2B*2%2Bd%5C%5Cb*Q]*3%22|+%22_K%22++v&input=2&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
K" / \ ""  ^"Kj+b+*2+d\\b*Q]*3"| "_K"  v
K" / \ ""                                 Set K = " / \ "
        "  ^"                       "  v  Draw the end points.
             K                    _K      Draw the slants.
                         *Q]*3"| "        Draw the vertical bars...
              j+b+*2+d\\b                 ... interspersed with slants.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

Thanks Mr. Xcoder for one byte.

```
%"  ^
 / %s/
  v"*tj\|_B" \\
|
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25%22++%5E%0A+%2F+%25s%2F%0A++v%22%2atj%5C%7C_B%22+%5C%5C%0A%7C+&input=5&test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0) or [Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25%22++%5E%0A+%2F+%25s%2F%0A++v%22%2atj%5C%7C_B%22+%5C%5C%0A%7C+&input=5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0)

Comment: Very nice answer! You can bring it down to [32 bytes](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25%22++%5E%0A+%2F+%25s%2F%0A++v%22%2aQ%22%5C%5C%0A%7C+%7C+%7C%0A+%5C+&input=5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0).

Comment: [31 bytes](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25%22++%5E%0A+%2F+%25s%2F%0A++v%22%2a%22%5C%5C%0A%7C+%7C+%7C%0A+%5C+&input=5&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0), in fact.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 45 bytes

This is a pretty simple solution.

```
.+
$*
^1
  ^¶ /x
$
 \ /¶  v
1
 \x
x
 \¶| | |¶
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K/qrpHA9V9Pm0tFiyvOkEtBIe7QNgX9Ci4VLoUYBX0gW6GMCygcU8FVASQPbatRAMJD2/7/N@KyAAA)

If the art could be 1-indexed instead, it'd be a bit shorter (44 bytes):

```
.+
  ^¶ /x$0$*1
$
 \ /¶  v
1
 \x
x
 \¶| | |¶
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>45</s> <s>42</s> 33 bytes

```
"  ^
 / "."\
| | |
 \ "Xa."/
  v"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fSUEhjktBX0FJTymGq0YBCLkUYhSUIhL1lPS5FBTKlP7//28MAA)

#### Explanation

The code is really simple, though the newlines make it harder to read. Here's a better way to see the structure:

```
"prefix" . "repeated" X a . "suffix"
```

The repeated element in the S-chain is

```
   \
| | |
 \
```

Take this as a literal string and repeat it `a` times (where `a` is the first command-line argument). Then prepend the prefix:

```
  ^
 /
```

and append the suffix:

```
   /
  v
```

and print.

(I like how this ended up looking kinda like a ><> program.)

Comment: This looks like [Lumpy Space Princess](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Lumpy_Space_Princess) from Adventure Time :)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>47</s> <s>44</s> 43 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)

```
'  ^' ' / \ 'XK'| | |'XJGq:"' \'thJ]KP'  v'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X11BIU5dQV1BXyFGQT3CW71GAQjVI7zcC62U1BVi1EsyvGK9A4CqytT//zcFAA)

Comment: `'  ^' ' / \ 'XK'| | |'XJ\`' \ \'JGq@-]KP'  v'` is 44 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots), 88 bytes

```
.*$"  ^"$" / \"
/>#?)--*$"| | |"$" \ \"
*#1\ /-~$"| | |"$" \ /"$"  v"
*-{-}*[<]
\#0----/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxOzsxMyS8p/v9fT0tFSUEhTglI6ivEKHHp2ynba@rqAkVrFIAQJB4DEtdSNoxR0NetQxHXB1EKZUBZ3WrdWq1om1iuGGUDXSDQ///f0AAA)

Answer (score 2):

## bash, 67 bytes

```
printf -v a %\*s $1 \ ;echo '  ^
 / '"${a// /\\
| | |
 \\ }"'/
  v'
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##DcLBCkBAFEDR/XzFTaMppRdbv/JSQzQ2yMgG3/7onCHmZLYfy3rO1BeRUquMb1C6aUwbAXqHEAp/RxFE1T38HKq8RRAHVzCz9gM)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
->n{"  ^
 / #{"\\
| | |
 \\ "*n}/
  v"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyflmf7X9cur1pJQSGOS0FfQblaKSaGq0YBCLkUYmIUlLTyavW5FBTKlGr/F5SWFCuk5UWbxv4HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 54 bytes

```
/*/
| | |
b//b>///b/ \\\\ \\\\/  ^
 \/ \\**> \\ \/
  v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X19Ln6tGAQi5kvT1k@z0gYS@QgwQgAl9BYU4LoUYkIiWlp0CSFSfS0Gh7P9/IwA)

For input, change the number of asterisks

```
 \/ \\**> \\ \/ 
      ^^
```

Comment: How does this take input? Changing the "Input" field on TIO [does nothing](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X19Ln6tGAQi5kvT1k@z0gYS@QgwQgAl9BYU4LoUYkIiWlp0CSFSfS0Gh7P9/EwA)

Comment: I forgot about that, it takes input in unary. You change the number of asterisks in the middle, the one in the example is 2.(technically I could delete them to save 2 bytes but i dont care)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>83</s>, 57 bytes

```powershell
"  ^
 / \"
1..--$args[0]|%{"| | |
 \ \"}
"| | |
 \ /
  v"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lBIY5LQV8hRonLUE9PV1clsSi9ONogtka1WqlGAQi5FGKAkrVcCJ4@l4JCmdL///8tAA)

Per @AdmBorkBork's suggestions,

- Simplified `for` by using a number range.
- Replaced `;`'s and combined strings.
- Removed an unnecessary variable definition.

Comment: You can golf your `for` loop a lot by using [`1..--$args[0]|%{ }`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15352/42963).

Comment: Also, you can use literal newlines between the adjacent strings to save on `";"` and it's cheaper to get rid of `$s` entirely. [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lBIY5LQV8hRonLUE9PV1clsSi9ONogtka1WqlGAQi5FGKAkrVcCJ4@l4JCmdL///8tAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Slick. I like the newline save. Funny that I missed the `1..$args` opportunity. I'm not sure what the correct etiquette is on this site. Do I make changes to my answer and credit you, or do you post your solution as a separate answer?

Comment: Editing in the changes and giving credit is the proper etiquette. Welcome to PPCG.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 53 bytes

```
f n="  ^\n /"++([1..n]>>" \\\n| | |\n \\")++" /\n  v"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz1ZJQSEuJk9BX0lbWyPaUE8vL9bOTkkhJiYmr0YBCIFSMTFKmtraSgr6QLZCmdL/3MTMPAVbhYLSkuCSIp88BRWFNAWL/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>93</s> 76 bytes

```java
n->{String r="  ^\n / ";for(;n-->0;r+="\\\n| | |\n \\ ");return r+"/\n  v";}
```

Port of [*@IanH.*'s C# .NET answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143333/52210) after I golfed it a bit more.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY/NbsIwEITvPMXIJ1soP3CqZIU3KJceMUjGGGQIm8hxIiHIs6fbkmtV7e5h51tpZq92sFnTerqebpOrbdfh0wZ6LoBAycezdR7bnxX4SjHQBU4yASnN4sjD3SWbgsMWhAoTZZvnfBsrARwMoYDQ5yZKTVm2KXVcVsIYQy9wMTYGQunoUx8JcSkK1jAIPU767dD2x5odZqOhCSfcOad8@@z2sGoO@eiSv@dNn/KWUapJUu7kWv3m/ZN//MNXpZofHqdv)

Comment: It's funny how this is almost exactly identical expect for the `string` vs `var` part.

Comment: @IanH. And the `n->` vs `n=>` ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 60 bytes

```
="  ^
 / \
"&REPT("| | |
 \ \
",A1-1)&"| | |
 \ /
  v"
```

Comment: You should consider checking to see if this is a polyglot with Google Sheets

Answer (score 1):

## SpecBAS - 74 bytes

```
1 INPUT n
2  ?"  ^"'" / \"'("| | |"#13" \ \"#13)*(n-1);"| | |"'" \ /"'"  v"
```

Apostrophe moves to next line, but doesn't work inside the string being repeated, so have to use `#13` to insert line feeds in that part.

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 48 bytes

```
?@  ^`?@ / \ `[:|?@| | |`~a=b|?_fB|?@  v`\?@ \ \
```

### Explanation

```
Note that every '?' inserts a linebreak
Also note that @...` creates a string literal and assigns that to A$, B$, ... Z$
?@  ^`      print ^ prefixed with 2 spaces
?@ / \ `    print the other start bit, pre- and postfixed with spaces
[:|         FOR a = 1 to (chain-length given as cmd line param, read as 'b')
?@| | |`    PRINT the pipes
~a=b|       IF we are in the last iteration THEN
?_fB|           print the reversed of B$
                    _f...| flips a string
                    B$ holds " / \ ", which reversed is " \ / "
?@  v`          and print "  v"
\           ELSE
?@ \ \          print the connector to the next section
The final string lit, the IF and the FOR are auto-closed at EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, 109 bytes

I believe this isn't completely golfed yet.

```
@echo   ^^
@echo  / \
@for /l %%G in (2,1,%1)do @echo ^| ^| ^|&@echo  \ \
@echo ^| ^| ^|
@echo  \ /
@echo   v
```

This script just:

- Output the top of the Cool S
- Loop `n` times the chain body
- Output the bottom of the Cool S

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 bytes

Boring port of [Lynn's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143325/64159).

```
“\¶| | |¶ \ ”ẋṭ“  ^¶ / ”;“/¶  v”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yYQ9tqFIDw0DaFGIVHDXMf7up@uHMtUEJBIQ4opg8SswZy9YEchTIg5////4YGAA)

**Explanation:**

```
“\¶| | |¶ \ ”ẋṭ“  ^¶ / ”;“/¶  v”    Example input: 5
“\¶| | |¶ \ ”                       Literal string "\¶| | |¶ \ " (¶ = newline). Result: "\¶| | |¶ \ "
             ẋ                      Repeat as many times as the (implicit) input. Result: "\¶| | |¶ \ \¶| | |¶ \ \¶| | |¶ \ \¶| | |¶ \ \¶| | |¶ \ "
              ṭ                     Tack that on the end of...
               “  ^¶ / ”            ...the string "  ^¶ / ". Result: "  ^¶ / \¶| | |¶ \ \¶| | |¶ \ \¶| | |¶ \ \¶| | |¶ \ \¶| | |¶ \ "
                        ;           Append...
                         “/¶  v”    The string "/¶  v". Result: "  ^¶ / \¶| | |¶ \ \¶| | |¶ \ \¶| | |¶ \ \¶| | |¶ \ \¶| | |¶ \ /¶  v"
                                    Implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 90 bytes

```r
function(n){cat('  ^
 / \\
| | |
')
for(i in 2:n-1)cat(' \\ \\
| | |
')
cat(' \\ /
  v
')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9PI0@zOjmxRENdQSGOS0FfISaGq0YBCLnUNbnS8os0MhUy8xSMrPJ0DTUhymJiUNTABfW5FBTKgCK1/9M0LDT/AwA)

pretty lame, but this is the best we've got to work with in R.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 37 bytes

```
.*
$*
1
\¶| | |¶ \ 
^
  ^¶ / 
$
/¶  v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT4tLRYvLkCvm0LYaBSA8tE0hRoErjktBIQ7I1FfgUuHSBzIUyv7/NwIA)

I must be missing something, this is a super basic approach...

Comment: You did only outgolf Martin by 1 byte, so you probably aren't missing something

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 30 bytes

This works on the same principle as [ETHproductions's Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143349/47581), where extra spaces are added later, and the whole string is split into rows of 5 for implicit printing. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/18ppqamJkZJS0khTkFfSVtJX6FMyUFbWV0hy9Th0dRVmf//WwAA)

```
"\|||\"*" ^ /"+"/ v"@+#' j5@╪i
```

**Ungolfing**

```
            Implicit input.
"\|||\"*    Add the middle portion and multiply that by the input.
" ^ /"+     Append the top.
"/ v"@+     Append the bottom.
#           Convert into a list of strings
' j         Join with spaces.
5@╪         Split into a list of length-5 strings.
i           Flatten list onto the stack for implicit printing with newlines.
```

Comment: Nice job outgolfing Mego in his own language!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>25</s> 23 bytes

This works on the same principle as [ETHproductions's Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143349/47581), where extra spaces are added later, and the whole string is split into strings of length 5 before printing. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yYmpqamEcNcx/u6gbyFOIU9IGUvkIZUCjLu9g08v///0YA)

**Edit:** I knew there was a way to join the top and bottom of the S-chain in a golfier way. Thanks to Erik the Outgolfer for -2 bytes.

```
“\|||\”ẋ“ ^ /“/ v”jKs5Y
```

**Ungolfing**

```
                Left argument: n
“\|||\”ẋ        Repeat the middle portion n times.
“ ^ /“/ v”j     Append the top and bottom.
K               Join with spaces.
s5              Split into a list of length-5 strings.
Y               Print the strings with linefeeds.
```

Comment: `“\|||\”ẋ“ ^ /“/ v”jKs5Y`

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 71 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `A1` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
a="| | |":?"  ^":?" / \":For i=2To[A1]:?a:?" \ \":Next:?a:?" \ /":?"  v
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
↘^\¶/¶Ｇ→⁵↓⊕⊗Ｎ←⁵|¶ \↗¶\¶v/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJb88LygzPaNER0EpLiYmJk8/Jk9J05orID@nMj0/T8MKKmmqowBWq6PgmZdclJqbmleSmqLhkl@alAOkPfMKSkv8SnOTUos0NDU1gWp9UtMgupRqYvIUYmLAZkKsDC2AWRiTB7KxTB8o@f@/yX/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Comment: Funny how the [other Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143342/52210) is the same byte-count by using an completely different approach. I like yours more, though. The other is close to hard-coded, but yours is actually using Charcoal's strength.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You say strength, but that should really be printing diagonally; sadly the best I could do there was 29 bytes: `↘^\|¶/|\|¶|Ｆ⊖Ｎ↘\|\|¶|↘\|/¶|\v`

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>51 50</sup> 48 bytes

```
'  v',~'  ^','/'(0 1;_1 3)}' \ \ | | |'$~5,~1++:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYhBCoAgAATvvmKJYIuktPBi9JOoQyTRpYPQqfy6GRHDMsvs0XkMFgppkcBJGZImSjYsFHQ/a3TlTYyJ64V5MDLoqrKxFFkNusESEreF80Ksy3bAof0O@QcTHw)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 73 bytes

```
<?='  ^
 / \
'.join('
 \ \
',array_fill(0,$argv[1],'| | |')).'
 \ /
  v';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WXUEhjktBXyGGS10vKz8zT0OdSyEGxNNJLCpKrIxPy8zJ0TDQUUksSi@LNozVUa9RAEJ1TU09sEJ9LgWFMnXr////W/zLLyjJzM8r/q@bBwA)

Answer (score 1):

#### x86_16 machine code - 76 bytes

```
8B CB         MOV CX, BX
49            DEC CX
B4 09         MOV AH, 09H 
           ATAS:
BA 02 01      MOV DX, OFFSET RANTAI_S_1
CD 21         INT 21H
85 C9         TEST CX, CX
74 09         JE BAWAH   
          .LOOP:
BA 15 01      MOV DX, OFFSET RANTAI_LOOP
CD 21         INT 21H
E3 02         JCXZ BAWAH
E2 F7         LOOP .LOOP           
          BAWAH:
BA 23 01      MOV DX, OFFSET RANTAI_S_2
CD 21         INT 21H           
          EXIT:
B8 00 4C      MOV AX, 4C00H
CD 21         INT 21H 

RANTAI_S_1      DB 020H, 020H, 05EH, 00AH, 00DH, 020H, 02FH, 020H, 05CH
                DB 00AH, 00DH, 07CH, 020H, 07CH, 020H, 07CH, 00AH, 00DH
                DB 024H 

RANTAI_LOOP     DB 020H, 05CH, 020H, 05CH, 00AH, 00DH, 07CH, 020H, 07CH
                DB 020H, 07CH, 00AH, 00DH, 024H 

RANTAI_S_2      DB 020H, 05CH, 020H, 02FH, 00AH, 00DH, 020H, 020H, 076H
                DB 024H
```

Tested on DOSBox

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [CSASM v2.1.2.3](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.1.2.3), 130 bytes

By far the shortest answer I'll submit with this language. (Probably)
Hooray for builtins!

```
func main:
in ""
conv i32
pop $a
push "  ^\n / \\\n| | |\n"
push " \\ \\\n| | |\n"
push $a
push 1
sub
mul
add
push " \\ /\n  v"
add
print
ret
end
```

**Commented and ungolfed:**

```
func main:
    ; Get the input, convert it to an integer and store it in the accumulator
    in ""
    conv i32
    pop $a

    ; Push the first three rows of the chain
    push "  ^\n / \\\n| | |\n"

    ; Push the next two rows of the chain
    push " \\ \\\n| | |\n"

    ; Duplicate those two rows ($a - 1) times
    push $a
    push 1
    sub
    mul

    ; Append the duplicated rows to the first three rows
    add

    ; Push the final 2 rows
    push " \\ /\n  v"

    ; Append them
    add

    ; Print the result string on the stack
    print
    ret
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 28 bytes

```
jcjd++" ^ /"*Q"\|||\\""/ v"5
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=jcjd%2B%2B%22+%5E+%2F%22%2aQ%22%5C%7C%7C%7C%5C%5C%22%22%2F+v%225&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A8%0A10&debug=0)

Translation of [Sherlock9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47581/sherlock9)['s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/143321/draw-an-s-chain/144421#144421).

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
| | |¶\ \＊ｋ^¶/ \：↕└∔∔ｒ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JTdDJTIwJTdDJTIwJTdDJUI2JTVDJTIwJTVDJXVGRjBBJXVGRjRCJTVFJUI2LyUyMCU1QyV1RkYxQSV1MjE5NSV1MjUxNCV1MjIxNCV1MjIxNCV1RkY1Mg__,i=OA__,v=8)

---

Explanation:

```
Code                       # Explanation               # Stack visualization
#############################################################################################
                           # Stack starts with input   # <input>
| | |¶\ \                  # Push string literal       # <input>, | | |¶\ \
         ＊                # Repeat vertically n times # | | |¶\ \...| | |¶\ \
           ｋ              # Remove last line          # | | |¶\ \...| | |
             ^¶/ \         # Push string literal       # | | |¶\ \...| | |, ^¶/ \
                  ：       # Duplicate TOS             # | | |¶\ \...| | |, ^¶/ \, ^¶/ \
                    ↕      # Mirror vertically         # | | |¶\ \...| | |, ^¶/ \, \ /¶v
                     └     # Swap 2nd and 3rd in stack # ^¶/ \, | | |¶\ \...| | |, \ /¶v
                      ∔    # Add vertically            # ^¶/ \, | | |¶\ \...| | |¶\ /¶v
                       ∔   # Add vertically            # ^¶/ \¶| | |¶\ \...| | |¶\ /¶v
                        ｒ # Center each line          #   ^¶ / \¶| | |¶ \ \...| | |¶ \ /¶  v
                           # Print TOS                 #
```

`¶` represents a newline in the stack visualization.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
…\||û×" ^ /ÿ/ v"Sðý5ô»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//@KAplx8fMO7w5ciIF4gL8O/LyB2IlPDsMO9NcO0wrv//zEw)

```
…\||û×" ^ /ÿ/ v"Sðý5ô»  # full program
                     »  # split...
      " ^ /ÿ/ v"        # literal...
                        # (implicit) with ÿ replaced by...
…\||                    # literal...
    û                   # concatenated with...
…\||                    # literal...
    û                   # reversed excluding the first character...
     ×                  # repeated...
                        # implicit input...
     ×                  # times...
                  ý     # with each...
                S       # character...
                  ý     # joined by...
                 ð      # spaces...
                     »  # into rows...
                    ô   # of length...
                   5    # literal
                        # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 46 bytes

```
~['
| | |
']*' \\'2**' \\ /
  v'+
'  ^
 / \\'\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/vy5anatGAQi51GO11BViYtSNtMC0gj6XgkKZujaXuoJCHJeCPkgq5v9/IwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 24 bytes

```
`\||`∞*` ^ /`p`/ v`JṄ5ẇ⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgXFx8fGDiiJ4qYCBeIC9gcGAvIHZgSuG5hDXhuofigYsiLCIiLCIxMCJd)