# Scrabble scorer

Tags: code-golf, string, number, game, board-game

#### Challenge:

Take a string of upper or lower case letters as input (optional), and calculate the score that string would get in a game of [Scrabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble) in English.

#### Rules:

The score of each letter is as follows (use this even if there are other versions of the game):

```
1 point: E, A, I, O, N, R, T, L, S, U
2 points: D, G
3 points: B, C, M, P
4 points: F, H, V, W, Y
5 points: K
8 points: J, X
10 points: Q, Z
```

The score of a string is simply the sum of the scores of each of the letters used. You may assume that you have plenty of tiles available, so long words, and words with many of the same letters are valid input.

#### Test cases:

```
ABC       ->    7
PPCG      ->   11
STEWIE    ->    9
UGPYKXQ   ->   33
FIZZBUZZ  ->   49
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ  -> 87
```

The shortest answer in each language wins! The input and output formats are flexible, so you may take the input as an array of characters (upper or lower case) if you want.

Comment: I'm hoping to see a MATLAB/Octave solution. All my attempts were horribly long... =/

Comment: I'm hoping to see a Beatnik solution. Cuz, you know, that would be the right tool for the job.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Does 85 bytes count as horribly long?

Comment: Hasn't Mathematica a built-in for it?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Down to 73 with Octave now.

Comment: @LuisMendo Is 85 bytes horribly long compared to 50...? :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin I've been thinking of making a more complex Scrabble challenge. Unless someone else does it first I may (finally) go ahead and do that.

Comment: @manassehkatz you should definitely give it a go! I highly recommend that you post the challenge in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to get some feedback and help with it before posting it on the main site. Complex challenges are notoriously difficult to get right without any feedback.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Are we allowed to have the program fail if the input is longer than what fits on a Scrabble board (15)?

Comment: It should work for the test cases @mbomb007. You have plenty of tiles (and boards) available. You may add it as a "this would work if...", if it's an interesting/fun/short solution. :-)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Added to Sandbox - please take a look at it.

Answer (score 20):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 81

```
s/[QZ]/JD/g
s/[JX]/KB/g
s/K/FE/g
s/[FHVWY]/BE/g
s/[BCMP]/DE/g
s/[DG]/EE/g
s/./1/g
```

Output is in [unary](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5349/11259).

Reduces each letter to a combination of lower-scoring letters until all letters are 1-scorers.  Then replaces those with `1`s to give a unary count.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBDsIgEIXh/RzGiUcQGChgFWwpMIadpgfo/YON7e77X972/fS@4TtyQ6dwhd2uNPTib4@ajlEPS64NxZlCjqGhOkuZhnT4gldce78JCSFIA9NM2RIkE6ovEbRlFokZ9oMibQbr/H18PEN8TXNacqn8Aw)

Answer (score 11):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 50 bytes

```matlab
@(t)'				'/3*sum(65:90==t')'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0RTnZmTk42Zh42HWYKfmZOZmVOOGQh4eCR45NT1jbWKS3M1zEytLA1sbUvUNdX/p2moOzo5q2sqqCpAgK4diDTnAkoEBDi7I2TAEoaGIIngENdwT1eYFESHJUgi1D0g0jsiECoDljA2Bkm4eUZFOYVGRUFkwBImYB1Ay11c3dw9PL28fXz9/AMCg4JDQsPCIyIRSi3Muf4DAA)

Challenge accepted. Explanation:

```matlab
@(t)             % Define anonymous function taking a single argument t.
    ' ... '/3    % Row vector with letter scores. Corresponds to char([1 3 3 2 ...]*3). 
                 % The factor 3 was necessary to avoid a newline.

*                % Dot product (yes, * is dot product, .* is not. Go figure). Equivalent to sum of element-wise products.
     65:90       % Alphabet
          ==t'   % Broadcast equality with input string.
 sum(         )  % Sum this matrix. Gives the count of each letter in the alphabet
               ' % Transpose into column vector for dot product
```

Comment: Very clever! Using unprintables was a nice touch! :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin It's only one byte compared to `-47` but that's code-golfing for you!

Comment: Sigh. Well and truly out golfed. I hadn't realised you could use `==` like that in Octave. Doesn't work in MATLAB. Good to know.

Comment: @Sanchises Interesting. I've been using R2014b up until recently (just switched to R2017a). Haven't had a chance to explore the differences.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I don't mean to rub any salt in the wound, but the 'old' way of doing this (with `bsxfun`) is also shorter at 61 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0RTnZmTk42Zh42HWYKfmZOZmVOOGQh4eCR45NT1jbWKS3M1koor0krzNBxSC3XMTK0sDXRK1DU11f@naag7OjmrayqoKkCArh2INOcCSgQEOLsjZMAShoYgieAQ13BPV5gURIclSCLUPSDSOyIQKgOWMDYGSbh5RkU5hUZFQWTAEiZgHUDLXVzd3D08vbx9fP38AwKDgkNCw8IjIhFKLcy5/gMA "Octave – Try It Online")

Comment: WAT 50 bytes I don't even

Comment: @LuisMendo This may just be the first time I properly outgolfed you.

Comment: "properly" is an understatement for 35 bytes :-D

Comment: I had tried encoding the scores as unprintables but the newlines screwed it up! Nicely done!

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>86</s> 84 bytes

```hs
f s=length s+sum[n|x<-s,(n,y)<-zip(9:7:[1..])$words"QZ JX DG BCMP FHVWY K",x`elem`y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHLCoJAFAbgV/mRFkoqtIpEXWRkFIFtuiiCQuOFxqN4JtLo3afva0p@CSm1rsCBFFSrBrzkd5fRb/Idtk2yZ8t3vu1gbry1l61cN7cWn358snFJcbxjF2MbnRPsD9fbAyfDngohRVfMue7KlhCgFirqSQlSjDAMMIwtKbiodJJE8R8)

#### Explanation

Most letters give a score of 1 and thus we don't need to keep track of these, instead we just decrement each score (saves 1 byte on `10` as well) and then add the length of the string to the resulting score.

Thanks [@nimi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34531/nimi?tab=profile) for -2 bytes (rearanging the words and using `[1..]` instead of `[4,3..]`)!

Comment: `zip[1..]$words"DG BCMP FHVWY K . . JX . QZ"` gives another alternative with equal length

Answer (score 10):

## [Beatnik](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Beatnik), 733 bytes

Since it really had to be done, here it is.  It was a really nasty to debug and provided a few challenges.

Input must be uppercase letters only.
Output is unary (hope that is OK?)

```
J K ZZZZZZK Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZA K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZKF K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZB K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZKD K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZD K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZD K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZ K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZB K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZKA K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZKF K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZZK K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZB K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZZB K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZZKD K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZZK K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZKB K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZKF K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZZB K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZFB K A Z ZD ZB ZZZZZA K A Z ZD ZB ZZZAK K A Z ZD ZB ZZZ K A Z ZD ZB ZD K A Z ZD ZB ZKB K ZZZZKF KF K ZZZZKF KF K ZZZZKF KF K ZZZZKF KF K ZZZZKF KF K ZZZZKF KF K ZZZZKF KF K ZZZZKF KF K ZZZZKF KF K ZZZZKF KF K A ZKA ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNLMnLzP7/30vBWyEKDIC0QpSLQpQTlI8EHIGKHHFJe7vhk3XCJ4lHztsFtyRZUjglcLjQG4encXrXG7u4EynC2H2NabI3Nu1YXYZFoRsWMQzPOmJYispHcyjYQTBHuNGZDXQHMLYwUm1U5P//jk7OLq5u7h6eXt4@vn7@AYFBwSGhYeERUZEA)

General process is:

- get character from input
- subtract 65
- check if result is 0

  - if 0 jump specified amount of words.
  - otherwise subtract 1 and repeat check.
- the jump targets are push print operations followed be a loop back to beginning of program.

Ends with an error.

A more complete explanation:

```
J K ZZZZZZK Z ZD               # Get input and subtract 65
ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZA K A Z ZD # Character A - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZKF K A Z ZD  # Character B - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZB K A Z ZD   # Character C - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ K A Z ZD    # Character D - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZKD K A Z ZD   # Character E - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZD K A Z ZD     # Character F - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZZD K A Z ZD     # Character G - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZ K A Z ZD       # Character H - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZZZZB K A Z ZD      # Character I - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZKA K A Z ZD        # Character J - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZKF K A Z ZD        # Character K - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZZK K A Z ZD        # Character L - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZB K A Z ZD         # Character M - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZZB K A Z ZD         # Character N - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZZKD K A Z ZD         # Character O - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZZK K A Z ZD           # Character P - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZKB K A Z ZD             # Character Q - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZKF K A Z ZD           # Character R - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZZB K A Z ZD            # Character S - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZFB K A Z ZD            # Character T - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZZZA K A Z ZD             # Character U - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZAK K A Z ZD              # Character V - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZZZ K A Z ZD                # Character W - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZD K A Z ZD                 # Character X - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
ZB ZKB                         # Character Y - if 0 jump to print, otherwise subtract 1
K ZZZZKF KF                    # Jump Point for print 1111111111
K ZZZZKF KF                    #
K ZZZZKF KF                    # Jump Point for print 11111111
K ZZZZKF KF                    #
K ZZZZKF KF                    #
K ZZZZKF KF                    # Jump Point for print 11111
K ZZZZKF KF                    # Jump Point for print 1111
K ZZZZKF KF                    # Jump Point for print 111
K ZZZZKF KF                    # Jump Point for print 11
K ZZZZKF KF                    # Jump Point for print 1
K A ZKA ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZAAAA # Jump back to start
```

Comment: [Golfed.](https://tio.run/##dZBNCgIxDEb3c4pcJbFWnajjv7U7BRciuJr719aUYiSGUkryvRfo7X4dX49nSgwxF3uI7ud0MiqF0EP8dAko9wMCS8pDJrE8s6JaJOMUkYOxAoyVaJDivtSuBNWw4O7vErRX6qip1VbSHnOHpWFb06Kd3EUSQvtcKUoJaeKmfjZf9LxcrYfNdrc/HE/nEC9v)

Comment: @jimmy23013 very nice, you should post that one up.

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 40 bytes

```
sm+2x.e}dbc." zØÍ jÙ¹>;%OG5§"\ 1
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%2B2x.e%7Ddbc.%22%20z%11%C3%98%03%C3%8D%09j%C3%99%C2%8C%C2%99%C2%B9%3E%C2%9A%3B%C2%8C%25%01OG5%C2%83%C2%A7%22%5C%201&input=%22fizzbuzz%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
sm+2x.e}dbc." zØÍ jÙ¹>;%OG5§"\ 1
 m                              Q  For each character in the (implicit) input...
    x.e  b                     1   ... find the first index in...
          c." zØÍ jÙ¹>;%OG5§"\     ['dg','bcmp','fhvwy','k','','','jx','','qz']
       }d                          ... containing the character...
  +2                               ... 2-indexed.
s                                  Take the sum.
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>210, 204, 198, 184</s>, 170 bytes

```
({<([{}]<>(({}{}))(([][][][][])<((([]())<([][])>))((((()))))>)[](((()()())<((()))>)((())()()()()))((())()()())((()())()())[]((((())())()))(())){({}<{}>())}>{}{}<{{}}><>})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xCsRACEWv8y1yA7HYIrAHSDMhxWwRWHZJsa14dledBOIH5z/9A75@/X1M@7d/3KGMVW1jAdTUiIB1u0SMRFCYYsl9FGUJxSohVdEa1otTdEca4eHH36IzF03jCFaT8CZ5D6uaCYuR@/xs7bG05lP/Aw)

Thanks to @JoKing for saving 14 bytes!

Readable version:

```
({              # For each character

                # Push array of letter scores
                # Also adjust character to 1-indexing
        <([{}]<>
        (({}{}))    # Push 2 0s
        (([][][][][])   # 10
        <((([]())   # 4
        <([][])>    # 8
        ))      # 4,4
        ((((()))))> # 1,1,1,1
        )       # 10
        []      # Add 12 to difference
        (((()()())  # 3
        <((()))>    # 1,1
        )       # 3
        ((())()()()())) # 1, 5
        ((())()()())    # 1, 4
        ((()())()())    # 2, 4
        []      # Add 22 to difference
        ((((())())()))  # 1,2,3
        (())        # 1
        )   # Push 65-char

        {({}<{}>())} # Index character into score array
        >
        {}{}         # Add score to running total
        <{{}}><>     # Clear the stack

})               # Implicit print of total score
```

Comment: [170 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY4xCsRACEWv8y1yA7HYIrAHSDMhxWwRWHZJsa14dledBOIH5z/9A75@/X1M@7d/3KGMVW1jAdTUiIB1u0SMRFCYYsl9FGUJxSohVdEa1otTdEca4eHH36IzF03jCFaT8CZ5D6uaCYuR@/xs7bG05lP/Aw)

Comment: For a given definition of 'readable' :)

Comment: I made an edit to try and clarify the explanation, feel free to rollback if you find an issue.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
lambda x:sum(map(('ABCEIKLMNOPRSTU'+'BCDGMPQZ'*2+'FHJJKQQVWXXYZZ'*4).count,x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLCoJAGEb3PcXs/pmaWkgroSBNTc0aU/NCG7tIQl7QEezpp7HVd/jgnPbL302tiGJzE5@8uj9zNKr9UOEqbzGGnaYbtnv0Tmd2CcIIFqDpe8tjfgZzZQHmwXFc37/GSZJm8lqT1aMZak5HQkTRdIi/eo7KGk0hoMCYbskJQiO2DQmRxVI38SWZdpZpkWyoM9R2Zc3/KoXlFmiBJybiBw)

#### Shorter version, port of [DanielIndie's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162608/47120), <s>71</s> 70 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Sunny Patel</sup>

```python
lambda x:sum(int('02210313074020029000033739'[ord(c)-65])+1for c in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqrg0VyMzr0RD3cDIyNDA2NDYwNzEwMjAwMjSAAiMjc2NLdWj84tSNJI1dc1MYzW1DdPyixSSFTLzFCo0/4PYJanFJSCuuqOTs7qOekCAszuQCg5xDfd0BTJC3QMivSMCgSw3z6gop9CoKHUrLoWCIqClYK066rp26jppGiC25n8A)

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>71</strike> <strike>66</strike> <strike>63</strike> 62 bytes

- @Arnauld awesome as always reducing 7 bytes
- thanks to l4m2 for rducing by 1 byte

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s).map(x=>s="02210313074020029000033739"[x-65]-~s)|s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc5NE0JAAMbxex/DyR6YZZUctpkISS@EvDQdjGhqhLHVODR9ddExz/U3/5nnFr9iktTX6sEU5TltM9wSPJOfWZbWNAHsPa7oBs8IpiDPcxBxCIoC5CHkJdgNIRFJ1LFhJuMT8yHgTdqkLEiZp2xeXuiMpuayQgGMRTD6A8tS9F44bkCOq/qG2qM0ME@3QjOwe0RooJoRRbIXRT0Lw7g7s1A1fWmszPVmu7PsveN6Bz8If8FUBO0X)

Answer (score 7):

## Java 8, <s>75</s> <s>71</s> 70 bytes

```java
s->s.chars().map(c->"\n\n".charAt(c-65)).sum()
```

-1 byte by changing `"02210313074020029000033739".charAt(c-65)-47` to unprintables (and two `\n`) so the `-47` can be removed. Inspired by [@Sanchises' Octave answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162676/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dVFha8IwEKW2A9mvCP2UIJbauonKBHXqnNPVVad27kNW61Zn09JEQcTf3sVYBmXsSD7k3bt373IbvMfFMPLIZvWduFtMKRhinxyvAfAJ8@I1dj0wOj8FAFxos9gnn4CiOgdP/PJDGWa@C0aAgDuQ0GKDau4XjilEWoAj6BYbqiTLOUnJKVL@SpIlSV4SiYei5JUlUQW7yTjx9gYhje4CiJL6RTvafWy5dtpiH/orEHCHqY@3d4wu7tZhDM8ywK2pumGUdLNk6pWybui6UdV5mGbFrKoaC9vnZnGMDxAhUQqAfaDMC7Rwx7SIyzIopBA3VK4gMelfzpZAnhEp5lEG1WarrabcC2BZ7V4WsSedWb@TxaY9azGYj7Ngt@84ranjZFHe4b7T7T30HwdPw9GzNX6xJ9PX2XyR8rLrEH8lCn93dvxvElpQa0AtEM2FFKVap@QH)

```java
s->          // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  s.chars()  //  Loop over the characters as IntStream
   .map(c->"\n\n".charAt(c-65))
             //   Convert the character to its value
   .sum()    //   And sum it all together
```

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>90</s> 63 bytes

```r
function(W,u=utf8ToInt)sum(u('

')[u(W)-64])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNcp9S2tCTNIiTfM69Es7g0V6NUQ52RmZmJkYWJhZGDlZGZkZGZixEIWFg4WLjUNaNLNcI1dc1MYjX/p2koOTo5K2lyARlunlFRTqFRUUDefwA)

Takes input as an uppercase string. R handles unprintables and multiline strings without issues, so that's nice. Now we're almost twice the external package!

And because CRAN has so many random goodies:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + [ScrabbleScore](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ScrabbleScore/ScrabbleScore.pdf) 31 bytes

```r
ScrabbleScore::sws(scan(,""),F)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pzi5KDEpKSc1ODm/KNXKqri8WKM4OTFPQ0dJSVPHTfP/fwA)

Sadly, `sws` checks for validity by default.

Comment: Had a play with the score list and trimmed a [couple](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNcs7g0V0OjtCTNIiTfM69EQ93AyMjQwNjQ2MDcxMDIwMDI0gAIjI3NjS3VNXVNzDWjcxNLkjM0wnV8XENCXIOCNWM1/6dpJGsoOSrpKDkBsbOSpiYXWMQNyPME4igoBsmGwvmamv8B)

Comment: @MickyT nice! I played around with unprintables and re-using `utf8ToInt` instead of `match` and managed to get a few more down!

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 85 bytes

```matlab
@(x)sum([1:4 7 9]*any(reshape(char(strsplit('DG BCMP FHVWY K JX QZ')),6,1,5)==x,3)+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctbC4IwAIbh@37F7raVCNKJAqE8TTNr5nnRxRDFoIM4C/v1Jnj3vHx877zl36IvVVmW@x3qsPg80VXZLsAabG5T/vqhphAVrwuUV7xBom1E/bi3CBoEaLpHgWXHSQZccEiBzyDG0kpSpCVW1U6a45mC@xLBvaZDPBlAqU5GBaGZOOboiNDMTf0xLIcxLWJsrOFpmBaxnYN79E5n6l@CMIqTNBv2/g8)

Comment: Better than my attempts  :-) still longer than I would have thought before I tried it though... You had a very different approach to it!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Oị“ÆẠḃbṂƬɠF#ṁ²’ḃ⁵¤S
```

A monadic link accepting a list of upper-case characters which returns an integer

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9qZWxsef//T@G7i@KAnMOG4bqg4biDYuG5gsasyaBGI@G5gcKy4oCZ4biD4oG1wqRT////U1RFV0lF)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##AYEAfv9qZWxsef//T@G7i@KAnMOG4bqg4biDYuG5gsasyaBGI@G5gcKy4oCZ4biD4oG1wqRT/@G7tMW8w4fFkuG5mCTigqwkR///QUJDClBQQ0cKU1RFV0lFClVHUFlLWFEKRklaWkJVWloKQUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVldYWVo).

#### How?

```
Oị“ÆẠḃbṂƬɠF#ṁ²’ḃ⁵¤S - Link: list of characters
O                   - ordinals ('A'->65, B->66...)
                 ¤  - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
  “ÆẠḃbṂƬɠF#ṁ²’     -   literal 14011114485013321424185131
                ⁵   -   literal 10
               ḃ    -   bijective-base = [1,3,10,1,1,1,1,4,4,8,4,10,1,3,3,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1]
 ị                  - index into (1-based & modular) (vectorises)
                    -  i.e. mapping from: O P  Q R S T U V W X Y  Z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N)
                  S - sum
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 66 bytes

```hs
sum.map(\c->1+read["02210313074020029000033739"!!(fromEnum c-65)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcGxDoIwEADQXzmIA8SUHK1CGHAhxrWjiThcaivEtpgW4t9bfW@i@NLWJgP9mOLmKkfvYlTsVO@DpsctR85rFLXA9oAckXf4J0QrujzLChMWd/abA8WaY3kvk6PZQw@zX3UgtcIO4rR8oAKTpBwuX2UsPWNi10HKHw) Same approach as [DanielIndie's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162608/56433).

---

#### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>82</s> 81 bytes

```hs
sum.map(\c->1+sum(read.pure<$>lookup c(zip"DGBCMPFHVWYKJXQZ""1122223333347799")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcfBCoIwGADgV/kZHibhYBWIkB4yMopgXcrCy1gzxU3HpgQ9fMu@29dw10mlfA1p5d2kieYGVyLK6GIetpI/iZms3ASZGoZuMiDwpzVoV2zzM9sfrrf76VheHghRupyt/tZxnCQoDEOvedtDCm0/SsvFCAG4ZngDgdozlhdfUSv@cj4qc8Z@)

Answer (score 4):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 358 bytes

```
➡️s 0ls➕sa1e1i1l1n1o1r1s1t1u1d2g2b3c3m3p3f4h4v4w4y4k5j8x8q10z10ls 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDNTsJAFIX3PEUfwd/E17HttLS0tDAthVmpCw0xCAsxrpiQ4Fa3xsSX4QWcN8B7ajiJ6WK@fvfMpLk5Ki/SJChCdXB29ejs89bZxQOGFxne9pvtz@fyGMt5196JjHeZuGSrNfP9Zq1FviT8lu@HvNpdA6eAoiW0jDakFbQxTdMqWk0LgTMgpvnAORDQclpJi4ALoE@b0BrajDYALoEUuAKmtFG7FQramaMu7lEf@prLecKgvfZifgB6zi5v0WLPc/b1Bq231fnt6v/Dsgzibqor1SSqm0eJMX5tTPdGfh6qKO4n6SDLh0U5GuuqnjTT2d/bdrdf)

### Explanation:

I changed the variable names from single letters to more meaningful words, and expanded some parts of my code to hopefully make it more readable for people unfamiliar with the language. You can test the expanded program [here](https://tio.run/##ZZHNToNAEMfvfQoeofUj8XX4WOhS6FJYoOWkHmyMwfbQGk8lJOpRr8bEl@kLyBvQnVlwNFwmv/3/dz4yw0Lhc1s4rG2bavvQVLu6qcr1yFCvJ/V6PR7qn8/Nrz4ylFO@ZWaQskTRhxKUsnsxIUwQGSEnDAjnhIIwJkwIJWFK6EA4Q/QQ@zEsCOeINmFIGBG6EC4Qp4QZYU64IpxBuET0IVwhLhH7MRY46hi50Kw3d9dt8D2xRcyMcb9QLllsSqF2UKpFb/ddoduASeUYf@w1WFTieNjrUkr5Upnf@jSQXOtk3eG@6/QIhs6YQHe0tN9Um5v@@M/XcHw8rIWL/C9Gke0N1USynLOh7vKisNKiGDqquMNcb8r9WRDORbSIE5lm@XKl/8JcbXsC).

```
       define a class that takes a string
 ➡️     define a method that returns a string
  values     create int dictionary
   a1 e1 i1 l1 n1 o1 r1 s1 t1 u1 d2 g2
   b3 c3 m3 p3 f4 h4 v4 w4 y4 k5 j8 x8
   q10 z10
           ^ dictionary contains letters(keys) and their numerical values

  score 0                          declare 'score' variable and set to 0
   iterator                      transform input string to iterator
    letter iterator                 iterate over each byte in input string
     score➕score values letter    add value of each letter to score
   
  score 10     return the score as a string
 


           begin the program here
 abc     call scoring method and print the score
 ppcg     repeat with other test cases
 stewie
 fizzbuzz
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: ouch... my eyes... is there an option on golf.se to hide some specific langages? ^^

Comment: @OlivierDulac There's probably a way to prevent the browser from rendering emoji specially. They do each have standard Unicode black and white characters associated with them.

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 60 bytes

```powershell
$args|% t*y|%{$s+='02210313074020029000033739'[$_-65]-47}
$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24RlWhRKuyRrVapVjbVt3AyMjQwNjQ2MDcxMDIwMDI0gAIjI3NjS3Vo1Xidc1MY3VNzGu5VIr////v6OTs4urm7uHp5e3j6@cfEBgUHBIaFh4RGQUA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 bytes

Takes input as a lowercase list of characters.

```
•_JÊ¿ùã$Ƶ½œM•11вAIkèO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOieK/DXYf2H955eLHKsa2H9h6d7AsUNDS8sMnRM/vwCv///6PV09R1FNQzQUQVnEgCEaVIYrEA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvn/UcOieK/DXYf2H955eLHKsa2H9h6d7AsUNDS8sMmxMvvwCv//lUqH9yvo2ikc3q@k8z9aPVFdR0E9CUQkq8dyRasXgJgFED6QSAcLFoOYJSAiFUSUg4hMCBckXQpRCdNYCSKyQUQFiCgEq0mD66mCE2BrS5HEQAqRHQQkUuC2psFtyYCblQW3KgdE5IKIPBCRD3dNIYgoAhEIX4DtLIN7pQLuaqATAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 73 bytes

```matlab
@(x)sum('09977433333222211'(([~,y]=ismember(x,'QZJXKFHVWYBCMPDG'))+1)-47)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc1LC4JAFAXgfb/CTdwZKmlSmFwYpamZWWP5nGhRYdBCgl7Upr9uTi3Ks7rwncM97a/be14edFmWyyF64MutQNDVNEpVRaRXhRBAaP1qPzf68VLkxS4/o0cbAj5NPXsSJ5lh@mzsAMYtgjsqxeUBwcgwQRLBUlOSOgNx0kYFjJkO1IEQAavQSlwLagtNQOSwzEsD@ANFEWC7nBsR5/AD9bOono8t25m4U2/mzxcsWK7CKE7S7Futmn1avgE)

Uses `ismember` to map each character in the input stream `x` onto it's index in the lookup string `'QZJXKFHVWYBCMPDG'`. Any element not found will be mapped to an index of 0 (this will include the 1-point characters).

Next we add 1 to the index to make the 0's become valid 1-index references, and lookup into the string `'09977433333222211'`. This is one element longer than the first lookup string. The digits represent the point value of each element in the original string, minus 1, with the extra element being a '0' at the `beginning` .

Finally the resultant string is converted to integers by subtracting `47` (`'0'-1`), yielding the point value for each letter, and all point values are then summed.

Comment: Very clever! :)

Answer (score 3):

## C++, 95 bytes

```
char*m="02210313074020029000033739";
int f(char*p){int n=0;while(*p)n+=m[*p++-65]-47;return n;}
```

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/bdo5Ko) (not a TIO link sorry)

Explanation:

- Declares `m`, an array of the values of each letter in order, minus 1. The minus 1 is because of Q and Z: I couldn't have a two digit number in there
- Iterates through through the string `p` until we get to null character, and adds the score of the number (`*p` gives us the letter, and `-65` so we can properly index the array). Since `m` is a `char*` it converts to a `char` so we minus `48` so bring it back to 0, but add `1` since `m` is declared as one score less for each character.

<sub>I'm not an avid poster here so I hope I've done this correctly. I believe they returning `n` counts as printing the value, and that declaring a function is fine.</sub>

Comment: Very nice! The only byte you can save, is the newline: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzOvRCFNIzkjsUirQLM6sbQkXyHXVsnAyMjQwNjQ2MDcxMDIwMDI0gAIjI3NjS2VrEE68mwNrMszMnNSNYC68rRtc6O1CrS1dc1MY3VNzK2LUktKi/IU8qxr/ytn5iXnlKak2mTmF5cUpSbm2nGB9OcmZuZpaCpUc3EWl6RYWSXnl5Yo2NgAHaLk6OSspAligyVS81JyrDEVBQQ4uxNWFRziGu7pSlidm2dUlFNoVBRhlUDHubi6uXt4enn7@Pr5BwQGBYeEhoVHRGLqrf0PAA "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @movatica [Why you need `m`?](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzOvRCFNIzkjsUirQLMaxMuzNbAuz8jMSdUAiuRp2yoZGBkZGhgbGhuYmxgYGRgYWRoAgbGxubGlUrRWgba2rplprK6JuXVRaklpUZ5CnnXtf@XMvOSc0pRUm8z84pKi1MRcOy6Q0bmJmXkamgrVXJzFJSlWVsn5pSUKNjZA@5UcnZyVNEFssERqXkqONaaigABnd8KqgkNcwz1dCatz84yKcgqNiiKsEug4F1c3dw9PL28fXz//gMCg4JDQsPCISEy9tf8B)

Comment: Nice find. But it's not my post, so you should ask @Tas ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>60</s> 38 bytes

**Solution:**

```
+/1+.:'"02210313074020029000033739"65!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X1vfUFvPSl3JwMjI0MDY0NjA3MTAyMDAyNIACIyNzY0tlcxMFZUcnZxdXN3cPTy9vH18/fwDAoOCQ0LDwiMio5T@/wcA)

**Explanation:**

Index into the scores, sum up result.

```
+/1+.:'"02210313074020029000033739"65! / the solution
                                   65! / input modulo 65 to get position in A-Z
       "02210313074020029000033739"    / index into the scores (1 point lower)
    .:'                                / value (.:) each (') to convert to ints
  1+                                   / increase by 1
+/                                     / sum up
```

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, 92 bytes

```
$args|% T*y|%{$i+=switch -r($_){[DG]{2}[BCMP]{3}[FHVWY]{4}K{5}[JX]{8}[QZ]{10}default{1}}};$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24RlUhRKuyRrVaJVPbtrg8syQ5Q0G3SEMlXrM62sU9ttqoNtrJ2Tcgttq4NtrNIyw8MrbapNa72rQ22isittqiNjowKrba0KA2JTUtsTSnpNqwtrbWWiXz////jk7OAA)

Didn't notice @Add-TheNewOne's answer before writing this, but I think it's fairly different in any case.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
•Q<ß÷λv¸Ïàœ¶•IÇè>O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9vc2FiaWX//@KAolE8w5/Dt867dsK4w4/DoMWTwrbigKJJw4fDqD5P//9maXp6YnV6eg)

Explanation:

```
•Q<ß÷λv¸Ïàœ¶•           # compressed integer 30740200290000337390221031
             IÇ         # codepoints of the input
               è        # index into the digits of the large integer
                >       # increment each
                 O      # sum
```

The large integer encodes the point value of each letter. Since encoding numbers in the range 1-10 would be inconvenient, we subtract 1 so that each one fits on a single digit (this is why the `>` is needed).

Note that indexing in 05AB1E wraps around, so the first digit of the number actually corresponds to "h" ("h"'s codepoint is 104, which is 0 mod 26). This is convenient: since numbers can't start with 0, we don't want the first digit to correspond to "a".

Alternative 18-byter:

```
A•Θ¡₆öηÖ&'/α°•R‡>O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8VHDonMzDi181NR2eNu57Yenqanrn9t4aANQOOhRw0I7////o5XSlHQUlDJBRBWcSAIRpUhisQA)

`A` pushes "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz". `‡` transliterates, replacing each letter in the input with the corresponding digit in the compressed integer. `A‡` saves one byte over `IÇè`; unfortunately, this encoding puts "a" first, so we have to use `R` (reverse) to get around the issue that numbers can't start with 0.

Yet another 18-byter:

```
žW•Δÿ¦ÝZ=áí4_ø•‡>O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7wRw2Lzk05vP/QssNzo2wPLzy81iT@8A6g4KOGhXb@//9HK6Up6SgoZYKIKjiRBCJKkcRiAQ)

Same idea as above, but this one uses the obscure `žW` built-in to push "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm". `žW` is one byte longer than `A`, but it saves the `R` since "q" isn't a 1-point letter.

Answer (score 3):

## [Beatnik](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Beatnik), 379 bytes

```
K ZZZZKF ZD ZD ZD ZD ZD ZD ZD
K ZZZZZZZZA J Z ZD ZB B
K XA KD ZD ZF F ZA ZD KF KF ZD ZB B
K D Z ZD ZB B
K ZF Z ZD ZF KA ZA ZD ZD KF KF KF ZD ZB B
K A KD ZD ZF D ZA KF ZD ZB B
K ZF KD ZD ZB B
K D Z ZD ZB B
K A Z ZD ZB B
K ZF Z ZD ZB B
K D Z ZD ZF D ZA KF ZD ZB B
K Z KD ZD ZB B
K B Z ZD ZB B
K Z Z ZD ZB B
K A Z ZD ZF F ZA KF ZB Z
K K KD ZD ZB B
K B Z ZF A KF
KF
XX ZZZZZZZZZZZZZX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBLDsIwDET3PYWv4hAM1ED5E7IDiUWFxIr7p3YTVVgEy4vIM/Ms5/G8f979KyWGKMUE0f92k1UthBbiOHXgZB4QOLsIJIz6FEoBZY83CTHGEmAsiSlkcl9or0Yjatz/XYL1ldZaxVqqs5zqjnK4YsQuAlcYpNdQIx3C9JljhZTQzfycFstVy@vNttvtD8fT@XIN8TYA)

See also [MickyT's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162975/25180).

Answer (score 2):

## Japt `-x`, <s>43</s> <s>39</s> <s>35</s> 30 bytes

```
£2+`dglbcÛghvwylk¥ljx¥qz`qÊaøX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9qYXB0/3H/wqMyK2BkZ2xiY8ObZ2h2d3lsa8KlbGp4wqVxemBxw4phw7hY//8iZml6emJ1enoiCgoteA)

### 35 byte solution:

```
¬£Ò('0+#Ý03#740#È29e4+33739 g65nXc
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=rKPSKCcwKyPdMDMjgjc0MCPIMjllNCszMzczOSBnNjVuWGM=&input=IlBQQ0ciCgoteA==)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 41 bytes

```
T`BCDGJKMPQXZF\HVWY`221174229793
.
$*..
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyTBydnF3cvbNyAwIsotxiMsPDLByMjQ0NzEyMjS3NKYS49LRUtPj0vv/39HJ2eugABnd67gENdwT1euUPeASO@IQC43z6gop9CoKC6gAhdXN3cPTy9vH18//4DAoOCQ0LDwiMgoAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Like the Haskell answer, nontrivial letters are translated to 1 less than their score, and 1 is added later when the characters are converted to unary. Putting `FHVWY` last allows them all to map to a score of 3 + 1.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 36 bytes

```js
¬£2+`dg
bcmp
fhvwy
k


jx

qz`·bøX
x
```

Takes input as a lowercase string, returns a number.
Short explanation:

```js
¬£2+`dg
¬       // Split the input into chars,
 £      // then map over each char, returning
  2+`dg // 2 plus

qz`·bøX
    bøX // the char's index in
qz`·    // the hardcoded string split by newlines.
x       // And finally sum the whole thing.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9CaQ4uNtBNS0rmSknMLuNIyysorubK5uLiyKri4CqsSDm1POrwjgqvi/3@ltMyqqqTSqiolAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 60 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.sum{|c|"BDDCBECEBIFBDBBDKBBBBEEIEK"[c.ord-65].ord-65}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7daoNAEIXvfYphQGhBhZC2aQumdHW11v6YJjaJshdWVxJIk@AqpMQ8u11S0ytzbobhfHPOFNXXT5ObjT4Ue2GI6ntfpzUS27YItSjxHGITYvtEilKP@hinxqbI9Jtr1s7DoYkVgBgfiYXQLQ1gwLQjFQSWi@eoXq@lxhM69SieybprqdAN5v5shJ1Uv99SjhdFJIwi7KKuTlnye5s67pP37L@8vr0Ho4/xJPyczuYRanA7YAozeJIuINtAvVxvq1IDvtvytORZLQMKLqpVCSbk8dE10kVSCCYduQjAC1VcgipAH4KaIagQny7M/xx4ANwmQiDcA@bJciWb26o/mCl8nTW/)

A lambda, accepting input as an array of (uppercase) characters and returning an integer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF`, 50 bytes

```perl
_1DG2BCMP3FHVWY4K7JX9QZ=~/\d\D*$_/,$\+=1+$&for@F}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z/e0MXdyMnZN8DYzSMsPNLE29wrwjIwyrZOPyYlxkVLJV5fRyVG29ZQW0UtLb/Iwa22@v9/RydnF1c3dw9PL28fXz//gMCg4JDQsPCIyKh/@QUlmfl5xf91C9wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Gforth](https://www.gnu.org/software/gforth/), 109 Bytes

```
: V s" 1332142418513113:11114484:" ; : C 0 NAME 0 DO DUP C@ 65 - V DROP + C@ 48 - ROT + SWAP 1+ LOOP DROP . ;
```

Input must be uppercase:
`C PPCG 11 OK`

### Readable

```
\ String used as table with values for each letter in the alphabet
\ : follows 9 in the ASCII-table
: V
   s" 1332142418513113:11114484:"
;

: C
   0                   \ Initialize sum        ( sum               )
   NAME                \ Get the string        ( sum  c-addr count )
   0 DO                \ Start of loop         ( sum  c-addr       )
      DUP C@           \ Get letter            ( sum  c-addr char  )
      65 -             \ Calculate table index ( sum  c-addr index )
      V DROP + C@      \ Get table entry       ( sum  c-addr entry )
      48 -             \ Calculate entry value ( sum  c-addr value )
      ROT + SWAP       \ Update sum            ( sum' c-addr       )
      1+               \ Next character        ( sum' c-addr'      )
   LOOP
   DROP .              \ Drop c-addr and print result
;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvNDoJAEINfpeFKMA47mM1ykewSLspO8O8N0JuJ8P7DYC9Nv7bz97d@qve8m2rAE0sBcq4mrpl8Q47IBTIxew4FWgREHDF2194sZaSHIJ5xalDZPU1ZUO6AvYEp3y3dXp2ASlyylf/FAa1GiMRBVTc)

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), <s>78</s> 72 bytes

```c
i;f(char*s){for(i=0;*s;)i+="\n\n"[*s++-65];s=i;}
```

There are actually 26 characters in that string. See the code rendered properly and run it [here](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk0jOSOxSKtYszotv0gj09bAWqvYWjNT21aJkZmZiZGFiYWRg5WRmZGROSaPEQhYWDhYYvKUorWKtbV1zUxjrYttM61r/@cmZuZpaCpUc3EWFGXmlaRpKKmmAJXpKABZjk7OLq5u7h6eXt4@vn7@AYFBwSGhYeERkVFKmprWXLX/AQ).

Thanks to [gastropner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75886/gastropner) for golfing 6 bytes.

Ungolfed version:

```c
i; // declare a variable to store the score; it is implicitly of type int
f(char* s) { // function taking a string as argument and implicitly returning an int
    for(i = 0; // initialize the score to 0
        *s; ) // iterate over the string until we hit terminating NUL byte
        i += "\n\n"[*s++ - 65]; // this is a 26-char string containing the ASCII equivalent of each numeric scrabble value; 65 is ASCII code for 'A', mapping the alphabet onto the string
    s = i; // implicitly return the score
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 50 + 18 = 68 bytes

```cs
s=>s.Sum(c=>"02210313074020029000033739"[c-65]-47)
```

+18 bytes for `using System.Linq;`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc9da4MwFAbg@/wK8UphSmq6SekUVqfOtV3TWWfr2IVk6Qi0kXliYYz@dhdYr@u5PDzv@WDgsKblfQdCfhn5Dyh@dBdCfk8RYocawKDoF4GqlWDGqRGfxrIW0rJ184KTTrJ7UK3O3wipwn3QQxCCm3dHiwWhiT1vhMmIYH@MPYy9CdZFiE8m5jtz7m4/nLFv93rdZV7USGgO3C1bobi@hFt7y3yYRaZtT68aSqN0EOWbuMziQVakdDffrgddklXVrKiqQagfeIyT9Cl7ni@WLyu6fs03xVu53f1H0Rmd@z8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 52 bytes

```perl6
{TR/A..Z/02210313074020029000033739/.comb.sum+.ords}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZq@786JEjfUU8vSt/AyMjQwNjQ2MDcxMDIwMDI0gAIjI3NjS319ZLzc5P0iktztfXyi1KKa/9bcxUngrRrKIW6B0R6RwQqaSKEHJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fP38AwKDgkNCw8IjIqOAqv4DAA)

Maps every character to a digit, and sums them. And adds 1 for each character because there isn't a digit 10 without incurring unicode bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 91 bytes

```
{=LEN(A1)+SUM(0+("0"&MID("02210313074020029000033739",CODE(MID(A1,ROW(A:A),1)&"z")-64,1)))}
```

Explanation:

- Input is in cell `A1`
- The formula must be entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, which adds the curly brackets `{ }` to both ends.
- `MID(A1,ROW(A:A),1)` pulls out each character in turn (and a lot of empty values, too, since it's going to return as many values as there are rows in the sheet)
- `CODE(MID(~)&"z")` pulls out the ASCII value for the each character. The `&"z"` appends a `z` to the end of the `MID()` result because `CODE()` doesn't like empty inputs. The ASCII value for `z` is higher than every capital letter, though, so it's effectively ignored later.
- `MID("02210313074020029000033739",CODE(~)-64,1)` pulls out a letter from the score string based on its ASCII value adjusted down by 64 so the letters run 1-26 instead of 65-90.
- `"0"&MID(~)` prepends a zero to the `MID()` result because Excel won't let you do math with empty strings, of which there will be several.
- `0+("0"&MID(~))` turns all those strings into numbers.
- `SUM(0+("0"&MID(~)))` adds up all those strings that are now numbers.
- `LEN(A1)+SUM(~)` adds the length of the input to the sum because all the values in the score string (`02210313074020029000033739`) were adjusted down by one so they would all be one digit long.

---

There's a very similar solution in Google Sheets but it comes in at 97 bytes because `ArrayFromula()` is longer than `{}` (but at least it can handle `0 + "" = 0`).

```
=Len(A1)+ArrayFormula(Sum(0+Mid("02210313074020029000033739",Code(Mid(A1,Row(A:A),1)&"z")-64,1)))
```

Comment: Well done.  I have a Excel solution using 26 `SUBSTITUTE()`, coming in at a hefty 527 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app), 74 bytes

Of course Wolfram|Alpha supports Scrabble scoring! This is an anonymous function.

```mathematica
Plus@@(First[WolframAlpha["Scrabble "<>##,"NumberData"]]&/@Characters[#])&
```

This doesn't work on TIO.

To run, go [**here**](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app), scroll down and click "Create a New Notebook »". The code to use in the notebook is in [this TIO program](https://tio.run/##fc9dT4MwFAbge39FU5JlWwxkmYkfUcPGANl0djJko@HigBCWtNKUEn8@doqXeK6f857zclBVwUGdcujGU1QpJZo7y2KQmbUoPs2vmpUSeM7q9sPMa26BEBaaTi7Kh46wtrHtsXeSjaLxL1wwUQHFYS4hy1iB8P2jYVzibcuzQq5AAU7TkWU7FUjIVSEbaqSTUVdSvFg6OEXDo79D1z@XKSbE8f/D2s5mvQ33bhy4w/qce9vbyCfHzWE3iLWdz3vrBUmyjJJkCGt79Zeru61cz38K1pvnl@0r2b2F@@g9Phz7bW1vzt26bw) so you can copy it. Paste each function call in its own code block. If you run too many in a single block, the execution won't complete.

Note that `WolframAlpha` sends a request using the Internet. Though there are other answers on PPCG that use it, I thought you should know.

This program uses the below shorter function, but calls it on *each individual character* of the input (sending a separate [call to Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Scrabble%20fizzbuzz) each time!)

---

This only works for input up to length 15, the width of a Scrabble board. (49 bytes)

```mathematica
First[WolframAlpha["Scrabble "<>#,"NumberData"]]&
```

---

Same as above, but will display the result in a box, along with whether the input is a valid Scrabble word. (45 bytes)

```mathematica
First[WolframAlpha["Scrabble "<>#,"Result"]]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 40 bytes

```apl
+/1+⍎¨'02210313074020029000033739'[⎕A⍳⎕]
```

The same method as the K answer, index into a list of scores, add 1 to them, and sum.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97b@2vqH2o96@QyvUDYyMDA2MDY0NzE0MjAwMjCwNgMDY2NzYUj36Ud9Ux0e9m4FULEjbfwUwSONSd3RyVueC8wICnN2RuMEhruGerkgCoe4Bkd4RgeoA)

Comment: nice answer. You should post it [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/80214).

Comment: Bounty will be delivered [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211676/43319).

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) + `bc`, 54 bytes

```sh
bc<<<$#1`tr a-z 02210313074020029000033739<<<${1///+}`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/KdnGxkZF2TChpEghUbdKwcDIyNDA2NDYwNzEwMjAwMjSAAiMjc2NLUHqqg319fW1axP@//9fUJCcDgA)

## Pure [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 55 bytes

```sh
<<<$[$#1`tr a-z 02210313074020029000033739<<<${1///+}`]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGJVpF2TChpEghUbdKwcDIyNDA2NDYwNzEwMjAwMjSAAiMjc2NLUEqqw319fW1axNi////X1CQnA4A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 70 bytes

This isn't any better than [Rod's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162607/109963) (which is also 70 bytes) but it is a different approach than the other answers I see in this thread so I figured I'd submit it anyway.

```python
lambda s:sum(0xa48441111a3113158142412331>>4*(ord(c)-97)&15for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczJDoMgFAXQfb@CVZFGkyKYWpP6Jd3ggFInZKjKz1Ps29xzk5snD9MvM/H89fYjm6qGAV1oO0X3ndGcUhyOEYwJznJMU4pTQnBZ0lu0qCaqUfJ8oCvO@KJADcQMNPKnTavNWSGrahhDKesuhDbtJtoA28lj2NcgLpyrrHOBYdq0vOvFZxineZGr0sZ@t/1wsLgAqcRsovNvDJMSxvxvhPwP)

## Shorter version, 68 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to xnor, now making this better than the previous Python answer!

```python
lambda s:sum(0xa48441111a3113158142412331>>ord(c)%97*4&15for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxNDoMgFATgfU/BpkUamxTB1JrUk3SDKEr9AQWqcnmLfZv5Jpk8vdlWjWQXr/fes6GsGDC5cUN0XxnNKMXhGMGY4DTDNKE4IQQXhZqriKPz83GlF5wKNQMO5AgM2g/b2tijQlZyGEOteRPC2HqRdYBr9NatU5CQ3pfO@8AwrWrRtPLT9cOo9DQb677LunmYn4Ce5Wij428MbwWMxd8I7T8)

Comment: Welcome! It looks like you can shave a byte by distributing the `4*`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBDoMgFATQfU/BqmijSRFMiEk9STeIoFQFFKzK5S32b@ZNMvn28L3R@JSv9zmyqWkZcJVbp@S5M0IJQfEYRgijkiJSEFRgjOqaPMzSJjzNMaV3VEqzAA6UBi49L3vh/FUhazjMoLW8i@G82JSIWDt7DPscJVUIzRpCZJy2Qna9@gzjpI2dF@fX77YfAVY3YBelfXL9zWBew0z@nabnDw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Or, better, replace the subtraction with a mod: [TIO](https://tio.run/##HcxNDoMgFATgfU/BpkUamxTB1JrUk3SDKEr9AQWqcnmLfZv5Jpk8vdlWjWQXr/fes6GsGDC5cUN0XxnNKMXhGMGY4DTDNKE4IQQXhZqriKPz83GlF5wKNQMO5AgM2g/b2tijQlZyGEOteRPC2HqRdYBr9NatU5CQ3pfO@8AwrWrRtPLT9cOo9DQb677LunmYn4Ce5Wij428MbwWMxd8I7T8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor That's a couple good ideas. I'm sometimes too shy of order of operations when golfing! (And I entirely missed the idea of mod)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 69 bytes

Takes input as an array of characters.

```javascript
s=>s.map(c=>t-=~'9200204703130122093733'[parseInt(c,36)*25%26],t=0)|t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdC7DoIwAIXh3acgTYxgtJRWRYaaeEHEK17wUuJAEI1GgdjGyfjq6OBYPfuXPzmX8BHy6H7ORDVJD3F@pDmnLQ5vYaZGtCWq9FWyMEIY1UxEDIIMjJFFTEJKQRbeeewmQo0qpKGVcb2IG/uKoEh7ijxKE55eY3hNT@pRDSCEoN3pAkW@vaYpuq4oZkHiPK/rgL/OMGRuubI3rg3@9SyZ8x1vN9rOwW9HiMz1XcY6PmPgp6tJe59fenbfGbjD0XgynXnzxXLlrzfbHQNf1zTzNw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash + GNU utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 64

```bash
sed -es/[{QZ]/JD,JX]/KB,K]/FE,FHVWY]/BE,BCMP]/DE,DG]/EE}/g|wc -c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpJCsIwFADQfU7xEd2l5ACCYNqfjmpq52gW2sYBxEoruFDPXt0Ibh9vv@tPw@N0vhjozK6ZQtOSW3e@3g8wmvRgzWAE4zXKqPrjH8ELtkNvGrBMzzbPWGkWODQoNQs5DTUTSIWXF5VmHCm3F1IzB6njaob4ZsfXowarHpr2aoY5t4mUtkuSFAsfSebKKixjInyleKYU@QYHhev5QRgtlisZr5M0y4uyUuQD)

Input read from STDIN.  Uses a brace expansion to generate sed expressions equivalent to those in my [sed answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162626/11259).

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 55 bytes

```perl6
{sum .map:{:36<Z3P8JOBRZ4X1FBXLWSVL>+>(.ord*4-260)%16}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrLCoJAFADQX7mbQoskU4YwExpTMy3H9zg7e7hqUJQWIn771Fmf7t1/kOAjLBs4imn4clB43RmToSGTaWR/jXDCdKq6mIZlWoTW2pKUtn@t9M0ObeWFiuZZDPUIjaQ8W/6QoWl7ME/YBkJsD9LMKX0Hco9UAY3B9RnDOWPwD2fH9S7@NQhv94jESZrlRUkrZh3EDw)

Takes an array of characters. Uses a 4-bit lookup table encoded in base-36.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF`, 73 bytes

```perl
$\+=(1,3,3,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1,1,3,10,(1)x4,4,4,8,4,10)[-65+ord]for@F}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWw1DHGAiNdAx1TICkCZC20DHVAYkaQkgDHQ1DzQoTHRC0ACkw0IzWNTPVzi9KiU3LL3Jwq63@/9/NMyrKKTQq6l9@QUlmfl7xf90CNwA)

Comment: Managed to save a few using `=~/./g`, but can't get it down as far as [@nwellnhof's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162636/9365)... [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWw0DHyMjQwNjQ2MDcxMDIwMDI0gAIjI3NjS1t6/T19NM1o3XNTLXzi1JitQ3T8osc3Gqr//9384yKcgqNivqXX1CSmZ9X/F@3wO2/rm9SZnpeaS4A "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: My Perl6 solution is pretty similar to this, I opted to use value-1 thus only needing 0-9 which are single digits and then split `022103...`

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 97 bytes

```
func[s][t: :to-integer n: 0 foreach c s[n: n - 47 + t pick{02210313074020029000033739}t c - 64]n]
```

Takes a string as input.

### Explanation of the ungolfed solution:

```
f: func[s][
    n: 0                  ; n will store the sum
    foreach c s [         ; for each character in the argument 
        n: n - 47 + to-integer pick {02210313074020029000033739} to-integer c - 64
                          ; find its offset from "A" (to-integer c - 64)
                          ; use this as an index in the string with scores (pick {...} ...)
                          ; to extract the score and convert it to an integer 
                          ; increase it with 1 and add it to the sum    
    ]
    n                     ; return the sum 
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxLC4JAFEb3/YqL2xBujiS5y1Ize/jsMYOL0LEkmGKaVtFvt1mF3@4c@I7kTZ/xhlWj1u3bt6jZq2LKBVc9zE4ofuUShAsI7UPyS32DGl5MCwEm2A6MQcGzq@8ftKwJkglBx0YL0ZqhHiEOmX2V/pgwtStR9U@po9CCMfcWxuhPSbIIB5gX/jHyB6IMk3N8SgcmiCj1SkoHSieXfhCuonW82e72SZrlRXk4ns7U6H8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
1+("3V1S1QFRU1SMQ12W7"FB36)@A_MSa
```

Takes input in lowercase as a command-line argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@F/931BbQ8k4zDDYMNAtKNQw2DfQ0CjcXMnNydhM08Ex3jc48X@tgq9CNJeCUmJSshKQKihITgfRxSWp5ZmpIFZpekFldkUhiJmWWVWVVFpVpQRRn5Kalp6RmZWdk5uXX1BYVFxSWlZeUQmUjf3/Xzfnv6OTMwA)

#### Explanation

We map a function to each character of the command-line argument `a` and sum the results using `MS`.

In the function, we convert the argument `_` to its ASCII code using `A`, and then use that to index into the magic number `30740200290000337390221031`. With cyclic indexing, this maps `a` -> `0`, `b` -> `2`, ... , `z` -> `9` (one less than the Scrabble score). We then add `1` to get the correct score of each letter.

We save one byte by encoding the number in base 36 (the highest base Pip's builtin base conversion can handle) as the string `"3V1S1QFRU1SMQ12W7"` and then converting it from base 36 to decimal using `FB`.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>87</s> <s>85</s> 78 bytes

```
INPUT S$WHILE""<S$S=S+VAL(@2210313074020029000033739[ASC(POP(S$))-65])+1WEND?S
```

Old method:

```
INPUT S$WHILE""<S$S=S+(INSTR(@DG+@___BCMP_FHVWYK*2+"JX"*4+@QZ,POP(S$))+4)DIV 5+1WEND?S
```

Answer (score 1):

## Go, <del>96</del> 94 bytes

```
func(i string){a,s:=`

`,0;for _,c:=range i{s+=int(a[c-65])};print(s)}
```

Go allows any byte sequence in a raw string, except `\r` and `` ` ``, this saves about 3 bytes off the total.

This is just a remix of existing solutions in other languages, so no real new innovation here.

Edit: I missed the memo where we dont have to name our functions

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/NTsJAFAXgDB0TOk8xYdWJNUhQUUgXgqVU/ClCBWqMTBrbTNCBTMFN02evl@6s9O7O4jsnN97kWx6uefxJv7mQ5IcrGtFoL0ND0GSnhIyZlf/NKTeTrrVCmlZDuIZR/QRpCGkEwWFcx2RlnveijaIfZti1FJdQLtLk1BJyZ/C38Ozq8p1lva065IRlRX0xbzCaEj0yGrf9QYPRims29Q7RC/4FpACeN3AqBYBWqyymM3vu2hUGxE0Z@I63HC8mxwWAdrsshm4Q9P0gOEpAXPzbgL/v7KEzcu/HD49Pz97kZTrzX@eL5aEDxHWHZCT/BQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell with amazing 297 Bytes

Any idea to make the script shorter?

```
$1=read-Host
$s=0
$l=$1.ToCharArray()
$l|%{switch($_){{'E','A','I','O','N','R','T','L','S','U'-contains$_}{$s+=1}{'D','G'-contains$_}{$s+=2}{'B','C','M','P'-contains$_}{$s+=3}{'F','H','V','W','Y'-contains$_}{$s+=4}{'J','X'-contains$_}{$s+=8}{'Q','Z'-contains$_}{$s+=10}{'K'-contains$_}{$s+=5}}}
$s
```

Comment: You can remove the string `$s=0`. The `-in` is sorter than `-contains`. switch can returns a value `$s+=$(switch($_){...{1}...{2}... ...{5}})`. and etc :) [Welcome!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191/tips-for-golfing-in-powershell)

Comment: Thank you :D !!! I'm not very experienced in Code golfing so can you explain me what you did in your Code?

Comment: Step 1: obvious thing [240 bytes](https://tio.run/##Nc05C8JAEIbhPr9jJYoHnmCTIolX1Ki5jyYEESMEI7uCSNzfvn7FbvE078wwr@Zzo6y61bUQpDZISe9sFDZ2VVKT0vLb7Wmk/nVa9nm8r1WXFL22JcXw8dTX@kA3wYEznMCHEI4QQKTzlrC@MeHyaIW4lXGqooVogwsXOZyp4QZxBzEkkMmFuVrYI6YyLlX0EHP1fKzqQZYF51wjTAhhWvZqvdnunP3h6J7OF88PwihO0iz/Aw "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Step 2: big case to default [195 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcpLC4JAGIXhfb9jQqULXaFNCy@paZaWeduIlKUgFTOGhM1vnz5oXLyb55zXs8kxKfKqYgxl@E7G/lMtMixjnH1E6dtvSVPWl0JEqdS2KB2VD0EThoIh0BaRwXpGOSqAKuRALh/n3agDmlAAhVDMD4vuYAFGHFcdeoAJx@mkU5vLkl7zW/au6v9OKe0hwhiTFVXb6Ia5teydsz@43vHkn4MwipMf "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Step 3: to take out repeating code [171 bytes](https://tio.run/##Ncm5DoJAFIXh3ucYA8Ql4pLYWLAICKKgyNYQoigkRMwMhphxnn28hRR/cb7zaroCk7Koa85Rjh9kGjRamWMF4/wjSt8hRWS0IV3VXksRZRKlKJtUT0EXxoIpMDpnf1ABNMiFPDgW/WEAWFAIRVAC57I/bYAYYN2DD5ACyLNeHFgrdivu@btuqcwYGyDCOVdUTd8aprWznb17OHr@6RxcwihO0h8 "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Step 4: replace `.ToCharArray()` [with shortcut](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/80745) [163 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24RlWhRKuyRrVapVjbtrg8syQ5Q0MlXrO6WiVeNzNP3UVdR91dvbbaqBYq4AQUcAZiXyAOAEoYwyTcgAIeQBwGxOFAHAmUNIFJegEFIoACFjCBQKBAFFDA0AAm4g3kmdampKYlluaUVBvW1tZyqRT////f0cnZxdXN3cPTy9vH188/IDAoOCQ0LDwiMgoA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Step 5: use switch with regexp instead long expressions with char array [92 bytes from Gabriel Mills](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180689/80745) :)

Comment: I will be happy to delete my answer if and when you choose to implement my 92 byte strategy, as @mazzy mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

## x86-machine code, IBM PC DOS, 37 bytes

```
00000000: bb18 0133 d2ac 2c41 d0e8 9cd7 d410 9d72  ...3..,A.......r
00000010: 0286 e002 d0e2 eec3 1332 1424 1851 3113  .........2.$.Q1.
00000020: a111 1448 4a                             ...HJ
```

Listing:

```
BB 0118     MOV  BX, OFFSET TBL     ; load score table into BX 
33 D2       XOR  DX, DX             ; clear letter count 
        LOOP_LETTER: 
AC          LODSB                   ; load next char from DS:SI into AL, advance SI 
2C 41       SUB  AL, 'A'            ; convert letter to zero-based index 
D0 E8       SHR  AL, 1              ; divide index by 2, set CF if odd index 
9C          PUSHF                   ; save CF 
D7          XLAT                    ; AL = packed score byte 
D4 10       AAM  16                 ; unpack nibbles into AH/AL (clobbers CF though) 
9D          POPF                    ; restore CF
72 02       JC   ODD                ; if odd index, use low nibble 
86 E0       XCHG AH, AL             ; otherwise is even, use high nibble 
        ODD: 
02 D0       ADD  DL, AL             ; add tile to score
E2 EE       LOOP LOOP_LETTER        ; loop through all letters
C3          RET                     ; return to caller
        TBL:
            DB 013H,032H,014H,024H,018H,051H,031H,013H,0A1H,011H,014H,048H,04AH
```

[Try it online!](http://twt86.co?c=voAArYjBSegUAInQ1AoFMDCA%2FDB0BobgzSmG4M0puzYBMdKsLEHQ6JzX1BCdcgKG4ADC4u7DEzIUJBhRMROhERRISg%3D%3D)

*Note: using link above, re-run with input on command line like `ASM ABC`, etc.*

As a callable function, input string at `[SI]`, length in `CX`. Output to `DX`.

**Explanation**

Uses a score table of 4-bit nibbles for each tile's score. Loops through the input string and converts each letter to a zero-based index. Each index is divided by two to find the corresponding byte in the table. The low nibble is added if the index is odd, otherwise the high nibble is added if the index is even.

**Test Program I/O**

[image]

Comment: Use a different `BX` so no need to `sub al, 'A'`

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>386</s> 382 bytes

```
->,[>>,]->+>>+++>>+++>>++>>+>>++++>>++>>++++>>+>>++++++++>>+++++>>+>>+++>>+>>+>>+++>>++++++++++>>+>>+>>+>>+>>++++>>++++>>++++++++>>++++>>+++++++++++[-<<+]->+[->++++++++[<-------->-]<-[[->+]>>-<+[-<+]->]+[->+]->[->+>[>>]>++[-<+]->]>[-<+>]<<+<[<<]>-<+[-<+]>>->+]>[>>]>>+[[-]<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->[-]>>+>+<<<]]]]]]]]]<]>>[>]++++++[-<++++++++>]>>]<<<[.[-]<<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU9BCgIxDHxQNr4gzMGD4AO8NOSgC4IIHgTfXyfrblvBi6Ek6WQySS7P8@1xfc33WhWTA1MoBBDpDiuwfWSANnjAPrFLdNb4RL78rz/N1UxyI9cGu@lq0DD1LAWgluwkx8JmkgG8KSCthkwQlDU3i9ZGgZRZ2BznlM72fxx78jYx6m7GCdSMdk27lTiXMN/lJDbUejiWsj@V8gY)

Pretty much ungolfed, but first brainfuck code for this question. This code can only handle uppercase letters. Any other symbol will lead to an endless loop. Also the maximum score depends on the used bf-interpreter. On tio.run this can handle scores up to 254.

```
points:
abcde fghij klmno pqrst uvwxyz
13321 42418 51311 3x111 14484x (x = 10)

tape:
[input], 0, [points table], 0, 0, score
input: current letter marker (0 or neg 1), current letter
points table: check letter marker (0 or neg 1), points

code:
-           set current letter marker
>,[>>,]     input characters

->          set check letter marker
            fill points table
+>>+++>>+++>>++>>+>>
++++>>++>>++++>>+>>++++++++>>
+++++>>+>>+++>>+>>+>>
+++>>++++++++++>>+>>+>>+>>
+>>++++>>++++>>++++++++>>++++>>++++++++++

+[-<<+]->                   go to first input letter
+                           bugfix: intersecting pointers
[                       main loop
  -                         bugfix: intersecting pointers
  >++++++++[<-------->-]<-  subtract 65 from current letter (ASCII A)
  [                         check loop: mark the entry in points table that's related to the current letter
    [->+]                   decrease letter and go to check letter marker
    >>-                     set new check letter marker
    <+[-<+]-                go back to current letter marker
    >                       go to current letter
  ]
                            the related points entry is found so we need to add the points to the score
  +[->+]->                  go to related points entry
  [                     addition loop
    ->+                     decrease points entry and save points to temporary cell
    >[>>]>+                 go to score and add 1
    +[-<+]->                go back to related points entry
  ]
  >[-<+>]                   move points back from temp cell
  <<+                       delete "check letter marker"
  <[<<]>-                   set "check letter marker" at A
  <+[-<+]                   go to current letter marker
  >>-                       set new current letter marker
  >                         next input letter
  +                         exit loop if cell pointer is at "check letter marker" position
]

>[>>]>                      go to score
                            number printing routine from esolangs
>+[[-]<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->+<[->[-]>>+>+<<<]]]]]]]]]<]>>[>]++++++[-<++++++++>]>>]<<<[.[-]<<<]
```

if unary output is allowed then this <s>297</s> 293 bytes code can be used:

```
->,[>>,]->+>>+++>>+++>>++>>+>>++++>>++>>++++>>+>>++++++++>>+++++>>+>>+++>>+>>+>>+++>>++++++++++>>+>>+>>+>>+>>++++>>++++>>++++++++>>++++>>+++++++++++[-<<+]->+[->++++++++[<-------->-]<-[[->+]>>-<+[-<+]->]+[->+]->[->+>[>>]>++[-<+]->]>[-<+>]<<+<[<<]>-<+[-<+]>>->+]>[>>]<+++++++[>+++++++<-]>>[-<.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9LCkIxDDxQXjzBMAsXggdw05CFPhBEcCF4/pro60cwlHxmppP28jzfHtfXeq9VuRi5uFJIkZG4AW2QCWrwhH3rsBiq@Yj85H9zhCkg@SLTDht0C6pDLSknFalOsX/U0WRh/MkpnWM29LCFAd6vhUHapBptUVsJDTpUO3qth2Mp@1Mpbw)

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 224 bytes

```
	V =ARRAY(10,0)
	V<1> ='EAIONRTLSU'
	V<2> ='DG'
	V<3> ='BCMP'
	V<5> ='FHVWY'
	V<8> ='JX'
	V<10> ='QZ'
	I =INPUT
N	S =I
	X =LT(X,10) X + 1	:F(O)
R	S ANY(V<X>) =	:S(R)
	O =O + X * (SIZE(I) - SIZE(S))
	I =S	:(N)
O	OUTPUT =O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7LjsIgFIbX8BRnJzhOUrwkk0ZM0LaKtlCBIu1y1kYXvn8qsPu@/1w/r/f/@7mdZ@SBC2PESFixKihGfs8OwBe1kFoZ19phkbJ1yqpz5k3i46nrs@2SNRf/GLP@Jb2GzKxIcp@iSOBS9YPDCtmIGAXgrSNhxQoKAX6AobIhmmIT60KNxO/DgQJHpSUmfqWB69gVYAnEyqkmksIvZLKU5v0WlURRrJEeXLwUB3CtqnkWx1NVN@eLvN7aTun@bqwb/COM0xc)

*Very* naive approach. Stores the letters in an `ARRAY` with indices equal to the scores. It tries to match `0` for point values that don't exist, which ends in a score of 0.

```
	V =ARRAY(10,0)			;* set up value array of 10 values with contents all 0
	V<1> ='EAIONRTLSU'		;* set contents at appropriate indices
	V<2> ='DG'
	V<3> ='BCMP'
	V<5> ='FHVWY'
	V<8> ='JX'
	V<10> ='QZ'
	I =INPUT			;* read input
N	S =I				;* begin Next iteration
	X =LT(X,10)	X + 1	:F(O)	;* increment X or GOTO output
R	S ANY(V<X>) =	:S(R)		;* replace ANY letters in V<X> with nothing
	O =O + X * (SIZE(I) - SIZE(S))	;* add to the score
	I =S	:(N)			;* set I to S and goto N
O	OUTPUT =O
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>187</s> <s>184</s> <s>156</s> 154 bytes

```
listen to W
cut W in S
cut W
while W
roll W in X
P's 1
cut "DG1BCMP1FHVWY1K111JX11QZ" in T
while T
roll T in L
let P be+L's 1
let S be+L's X and P


say S
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Abuses a nice little feature in Rockstar whereby the variable (`S` in this case) an array is assigned to can be used to reference both the array (e.g., `S at index`) or, by itself, the length of the array. So, by `cut`ting the input `W`ord into the array `S` we, straight away, have a base score of 1 point per letter.

```
listen to W        :Read input into variable W
cut W in S         :Split W into variable S (our score)
cut W              :Split W
while W            :While W is not empty
roll W in X        :  Pop first element of W into variable X
P's 1              :  Initialise P as 1 (base score for each tile)
cut "..." in T     :  Split "DG1BCMP1FHVWY1K111JX11QZ" into variable T
while T            :  While T is not empty
roll T in L        :    Pop first element of T into variable L
let P be+          :    Increment P by
  L's 1            :      Is L equal to 1?
let S be           :    Increment S by
  L's X            :      Is L equal to X?
  and P            :      Logical AND with P
                   :  End while loop
                   :End while loop
say S              :Output S
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ä⁻»yŒṄȦẏÄb¶Ỵɓæ»11Bsi
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhY3VQ-3PGrcfWh35dFJD3e2nFj2cFf_4ZakQ9se7t5ycvLhZYd2Gxo6FWcuKU5KLoZqWbDCzTMqyik0KgrCBwA)

##### Explanation

```python
Ä⁻»yŒṄȦẏÄb¶Ỵɓæ»11Bsi  # Implicit input
Ä⁻                    # Convert input to 0-based indices in alphabet
  »yŒṄȦẏÄb¶Ỵɓæ»       # Compressed integer 140755590392038037755694497
               11B    # Converted to base 11 as a list:
                      # [1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10]
                      # (A, B, C, D, E, ...)
                  si  # Index into the list
                      # Implicit output of the sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `rs`, 20 bytes

```
øA11»⟑↑Gp→₃ꜝ¬∑"Ż¶»τİ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJycyIsIiIsIsO4QTExwrvin5HihpFHcOKGkuKCg+qcncKs4oiRXCLFu8K2wrvPhMSwIiwiIiwicHBjZyJd)

port of thunno 2 answer but I needed an extra byte for the compressed number since vyxal cant zero index letters to numbers

Comment: [flagless 20](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLDuEHCu1jih6fqnJ3CozThuYVv4oG9x49eyK7Cu2bigLokxLDiiJEiLCIiLCJwcGNnIl0=)

Answer (score 0):

### Visual Basic for Applications, 117 bytes

```
s=inputbox(u):for i=1to 16:s=replace(s,mid("DGBCMPFHVWYKJXQZ",i,1),space(mid("1122223333347799",i,1)+1)):next:?len(s)
```

Run in immediate (debug) window.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 74 bytes

```php
while($c=$argn[$i++])$s+=1+_02210313074020029000033739[ord($c)&31];echo$s;
```

case insensitive. Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b4a756e1de03210acd5b1f2bca2428977ca639a1).

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 48 + 18 = 66 bytes

```cs
s=>s.Sum(c=>"!#C²!$1$$XhQJ"[c%13]-16>>c%2*4&15)
```

+18 bytes is for `using System.Linq;`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv1fWpyZl64QXFlckpqr55OZV2jNxZWck1hcrBDAVc1VXJJYkpmsUJafmaLgm5iZp6EJFIQqdivNS7YpLikC6tfJzCuxS7P9X2xrV6wXXJqrkWxrp6So7Hxok6KKoYpKREagl1J0sqqhcayuoZmdXbKqkZaJmqGp5n@gZVDTnPPzivNzUvXCizJLUoHuSNVI01BydHJW0tS0xqsmIMDZnaCi4BDXcE9XgspC3QMivSMCCapz84yKcgqNiiKoEOgBF1c3dw9PL28fXz//gMCg4JDQsPCISIhWrlqu2v8A)

Comment: Isnt the function signature part of the code?

Comment: @KristofferSall-Storgaard I'm not actually sure on the code golf rules since I don't post often. I just mimicked TheLethalCoder's setup and tried to save a few bytes.

Comment: I was wrong. It would appear we dont need to name the functions

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 106 bytes

Accepting uppercase characters.

Inserted a line break to make this readable:

```sql
DECLARE @ varchar(max)='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

WHILE'='<@
SET
@=stuff(@,1,1,'')+'-~'+substring('02210313074020029000033739',ascii(@)-64,1)
EXEC('print'+@)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 49 bytes

```
!x=sum(i->b"\1\3\3\2\1\4\2\4\1\b\5\1\3\1\1\3\n\1\1\1\1\4\4\b\4\n"[i-'@'],x)
```

(the special characters are escaped here for clarity)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxBT8IwGMbxlNWE9FN0XOiS7bBAghy6IDjmRHEIE5gxpkJNamZZ2pHs28@aavR/eA@/PHk/zqVgYdO2bkP1@ZOIIHrrAcfpANiBoHsBHAAcBEwQdiHqPYugP@m/@I3Xvp8UFlhIrDg7lkJyTTyETcx/9Q@YYl2VoibCIjdQMaU5SWXtHyxWSsi6lITRyChxmWd9wrTmqsYuw5Rijrg8tlfTGbYF0fcdoSybJf8kDNF6E2/T@G8zRnmS7Re71a8MBmieFsU0L4ofGY6R@Xwdz5Ob9HZxd798yFaP603@tN3t7eZy9AU)