# Draw the prime race tracks

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, primes

Odd prime numbers are either in the form of `4k+1` or `4k+3` where `k` is a non-negative integer. If we divide the set of odd prime numbers into two such groups like this:

```
4k+3  |   3     7  11          19  23      31          43  47      59      67  71    
      |
4k+1  |      5         13  17          29      37  41          53      61          73
```

we can see that the two groups are kind of *racing* with each other. Sometimes the so-called 'upper' group wins and sometimes the 'lower' one is on track. In fact, [Chebyshev discovered that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias) in this race, the upper group wins slightly more often.

### The problem

Let's assume that we are interested in knowing the shape of this race track up to a certain number. Something like this:

[image: prime race track]

The upper and lower horizontal lines indicate that the next prime stays in the same group, while the slanted lines indicate a 'jump' from one group to the other.

Now assume that the underline character `_` represents a lower horizontal line and the overline character `‾` (U+203E) represents an upper one. The slanted lines are represented by slash `/` or backslash `\` characters.

### Challenge

Write a program or function that gets a number `N` as input, and draws this prime race track up to `N`, in a *kind of* ASCII-art-form described as above (Well, it's not an actual ASCII-art since it would contain a non-ASCII character).

### Rules

- `N` is an integer and not necessarily a prime number. Draw the race path for the primes up to, (and maybe including) `N`.
- For a valid `N` as input, the output shall only be composed of these four characters `‾_/\`. No other character, space or separator is allowed (except maybe at the end of output).
- The output can either be in a text file or stdout or wherever supports displaying those characters. But an actual plot (like the blue figure above) is not desired.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Examples

Here is a list of possible inputs and their acceptable outputs.

```
N < 5        no output or maybe an error message whatsoever
N = 5        \
N = 20       \/‾\_/
N = 100      \/‾\_/‾\/\_/‾\/\/‾\/‾\_
```

### Trivia

The resulting plots of this challenge may actually resemble the *derivative* of the plots shown in [there](https://www.makethebrainhappy.com/2018/10/chebyshev-bias.html).

Comment: Do we really have to use a non-ASCII character? Can we replace `‾` by `-`?

Comment: @LuisMendo Don't you agree that it would be ugly?

Comment: Yes, `-` is uglier than `‾` in this context. But to me it's even worse to require a non-ASCII character, especially for ASCII-art

Comment: @LuisMendo What's your suggestion? Should I change the rules? By the way, this is why I said **_kind of_** ASCII-art-form and wasn't implying an actual ASCII-art.

Comment: Did you just downvote? Dude...

Comment: No, I didn't. But I was tempted

Comment: I would have allowed `-` as a alternative to `‾` (answerer's choice), or maybe I'd have required graphical output (however, it's not advised to allow both ASCII-art and graphical output in the same challenge). Requiring Unicode rules out some languages

Comment: Something you might not be aware of is that [challenges about primes have been way overdone](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14580/20260) over the course of this site. So, while I think the ASCII art visualization based on modulus is a nice idea for a challenge, the fact that a solution needs to start with either generating primes or calling a primes built-in means that writing a solution will feel somewhat samey to many past challenges.

Comment: To follow with my previous comment, something like `\/ \ / \/\ / \/\/ \/ \ `  (space instead of `_` or `‾`)  looks quite nice to me. But I guess it's too late to change now, as there are two answers

Comment: @xnor I am already thinking about writing an answer in C# and I think a creative way is possible to circumvent the prime built-in problem by noticing that all primes up to a certain number are needed. So I might be able to just check the integer remainder along a saved list. Just a vague idea. I'll give it a try

Comment: As others have mentioned, I would indeed advice to use `-` or `~` instead of `‾`. [Here another challenge using those same characters where the same is done.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181708/would-this-string-work-as-string) The main reason to allow this is to open up the challenge to more languages, because there are quite a few languages that can't even use non-ASCII characters, so they would be unable to complete just because of that single character in an otherwise good challenge.

Comment: `^` might also be a decent-looking alternative.

Comment: To follow @xnor's comment, this seems like a chameleon challenge to me.  If your language doesn't already have a built-in to find primes, most of the code is going to be spent calculating that rather than the output.

Comment: Mathematical remark ([further reading if desired](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/PNR.pdf)): we believe that the upper group wins not *slightly* more often, but in fact about 99.59% of the time.

Comment: Downvoted because it's impossible without Unicode, and because the main part of the challenge is seeing if the number is prime or not.

Comment: @S.S.Anne they will also need to determine if the number is odd. Eat it

Comment: @polfosol Determining if the number is odd is trivial compared to determining if a number is prime. The easiest solution for determining if a number is odd is a modulo by 2, while determining if the number is prime without a builtin at least consists of computing the square of a factorial modulo n. I will not "Eat it" kind sir, thank you for the offer.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>31</s> <s>26</s> 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
…\/_ŽW ç«ÀIÅP¦4%üeè
```

-5 bytes by taking inspiration from [*@HyperNeutrino*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203541/52210).
-7 bytes thanks to *@Grimmy*.

Outputs as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//@KAplwvX8W9VyDDp8Krw4BJw4VQwqY0JcO8ZcOo/0r/NTAw) (the `J` in the footer is to join the list together to pretty-print it).

**Explanation:**

```python
…\/_                 # Push the string "\/_"
    ŽW               # Push compressed integer 8254
       ç             # Convert it to a character with this codepoint: "‾"
        «            # Append it to the earlier string: "\/_‾"
         À           # And rotate it once to the left: "/_‾\"
          IÅP        # Push a list of all primes <= the input-integer
                     #  i.e. 50 → [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47]
             ¦       # Remove the first value
                     #  → [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47]
              4%     # Take modulo-4 on each value
                     #  → [3,1,3,3,1,1,3,3,1,3,1,1,3,3]
                ü    # For each overlapping pair:
                     #  → [[3,1],[1,3],[3,3],[3,1],[1,1],[1,3],[3,3],[3,1],[1,3],[3,1],[1,1],[1,3],[3,3]]
                 e   #  Get the number of permutations; short for ⌊a!/|a-b|!⌋
                     #   → [3,0,6,3,1,0,6,3,0,3,1,0,6]
                  è  # And index each into the earlier created string
                     # (0-based and with wraparound, so the 6 is index 2 in this case)
                     #  → ["\","/","‾","\","_","/","‾","\","/","\","_","/","‾"]
                     # (after which the result is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integer?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `ŽW`  is `8254`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2 (IronPython)](http://ironpython.net), 87 bytes

I'm using IronPython here to display the unicode character `‾`, since Python can't print it.

```python
P=a=b=1
s=''
exec"if P%a:s+='\/‾_'[b%4/2-a%4];b=a\nP*=a*a;a+=1\n"*input()
print s[2:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9LNLMrP@6@skJyfkpmXbqVQWpKma/E/wDbRNsnWkKvYVl2dK7UiNVkpM00hQDXRqljbVj1G/1HDvnj16CRVE30j3URVk1jrJNvEmLwALdtErUTrRG1bw5g8Ja3MvILSEg1NroKizLwSheJoI6vY//8NDQwA)

### Explanation

The idea of calculating primes comes from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27022/88546), which uses Wilson's theorem. To figure out which character to print, we use the following formula: \$ \frac{b \bmod 4} 2 - a \bmod 4 \$, where \$ a \$ and \$ b \$ represent the current and previous prime numbers. Here is a table to show how this works:

```python
 a mod 4 | b mod 4 | a'/2-b'
---------+---------+---------
    1    |    1    |   -1
    1    |    3    |   -3
    3    |    1    |    0
    3    |    3    |   -2
```

And in Python negative indices wrap around to the end of the string, so each index maps to its own character.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 102 bytes

TIO doesn't display U+203E...

```
""<>(Partition[Prime@Range[2,PrimePi@#]~Mod~4,2,1]/.{{3,1}->"\\",{3,3}->"‾",{1,1}->"_",{1,3}->"/"})&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X0nJxk4jILGoJLMkMz8vOqAoMzfVISgxLz012kgHzAvIdFCOrfPNT6kz0THSMYzV16uuNtYxrNW1U4qJUdIBso1B7EcN@4AcQ4hEPJgJFtdXqtVU@w80Ka9EwSE92jSWC842MkDiGBoYxP7/DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 50 bytes

```
1('/^\_'{~[:(+_1&|.*1&=)1+2*@-/\4&|)@}.(#~1&p:)@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DTXU9eNi4tWr66KtNLTjDdVq9LQM1Ww1DbWNtBx09WNM1Go0HWr1NJTrDNUKrDQdMvX@a3KlJmfkK6jHqCvYKqQpmMG4IHP01RV0rYCCRoYoonEx@lASRIDsgygzNDD8DwA)

Had to replace `‾` with `^` because the formatting on TIO screws up otherwise.

This uses < N convention.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
ÆRḊ%4ḄƝṣ9ị“\/_”j⁽ø¤Ọ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//w4ZS4biKJTThuITGneG5oznhu4vigJxcL1/igJ1q4oG9w7jCpOG7jP///zEwMA)

-3 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

## Explanation

```
ÆRḊ%4ḄƝṣ9ị“\/_”j⁽ø¤Ọ  Main Link
ÆR                    Primes up to N
  Ḋ                   All but the first (3, 5, 7, 11, ...)
   %4                 Modulo 4
     ḄƝ               Convert each pair (overlapping run of 2) to binary (even though the digits are 1 and 3, this still works because it's just 2 x first digit + second digit) - 1,1: 3; 1,3: 5; 3,1: 7; 3,3: 9
       ṣ9             Split on 9 (the upper bar)
         ị“\/_”       Index into "\/_" (3 is _, 5 wraps around to /, 7 wraps around twice to \)
               j⁽ø¤   Join on 8254
                   Ọ  Convert from char code to character; doesn't affect characters, only the 8254s
```

Comment: `8254` can be written as `⁽ø¤` ([converter](https://tio.run/#jelly#@x9vbmpweKK1w6OGuY8a9x7aanBk/6GtQFbF0T1B2ie2pzoc2mrP9XBHs5GpwcPd3YdneHFpmxlZAPW0I/QcngjXEg@kK5MhuriOdD1q3PNwx7wTyx/uXHBo65H9////NzYCmgQA) - link also in the tutorial on the wiki)

Comment: You can also avoid testing for less than three [like this](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//w4ZS4biKJTThuITGneG5oznhu4vigJxcL1/igJ1q4oG9w7jCpOG7jP///zEwMA).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh, that's clever. Also thanks, I keep forgetting about that thing lol.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 86 bytes

```javascript
n=>(g=x=>x>n?'':['\\_/‾'[(P=n=>n%--d?P(n):d<2)(d=x)&&(q==(q=x%4))|q&2]]+g(x+1))(q=4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZckxDoIwFIDh3XvQvhdShQYX4itXYAdiCIUGQ1oRYzo4eDIP40VqV@PwL99/6R/9Ntzm611Yp8cwUbCkwJAn5ZWtOC8b3rbnw@f15g3UFK9NhNBVDRZLfZIImjwyBitRzCcF4nNlsutSAz7NEaMWGAZnN7eM@8UZmOCIuPsVmf1RnkULXw)

#### Commented

```javascript
n => (                  // n = input
  g = x =>              // g is a recursive function taking the current integer x
    x > n ?             // if x is greater than n:
      ''                //   stop recursion
    :                   // else:
      [                 //   make sure to turn undefined into an empty string
        '\\_/‾'[        //     pick the relevant character:
          ( P = n =>    //       P is a helper function taking n:
              n % --d ? //         decrement d; if d does not divide n:
                P(n)    //           try again until it does
              :         //         else:
                d < 2   //           return true if d = 1 (i.e. n is prime)
          )(d = x)      //       initial call to P with n = d = x
          &&            //       if x is not prime, ['\\_/‾'[false]] ~> empty string
          (             //       if x is prime:
            q ==        //         yield 1 if q is equal to ...
            (q = x % 4) //         ... the new value of q which is x mod 4
          ) | q & 2     //         bitwise OR with q & 2 for the direction
        ]               //     end of character lookup
      ] + g(x + 1)      //   add the result of a recursive call with x + 1
)(q = 4)                // initial call to g with x = q = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>105 103 96 89</s> 88 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=3,j=5,t=24:n//j*" "and"\/‾_"[i%4//2-j%4]*(P:=t%j>0)+f(n,[i,j][P],j+1,t*j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9RioMwEIbfPcUQELSNjbUWFml6hr6rBJdWNqHGEPNSSmFPtofZi7iJUsmWfVgImZn83/yZUTfz0cvdm9Lj2NJr072fG5CY0x0WdI8NzfJCEiJWCFAjz6gi359fDJU8zAnJEhHm9So6FdSE4pjG6zaSuORY1OWpxmK9xWYl4pF3qtcGhtsQtL2GK5cX4NLVm8GcuSwCsH9CIweg0DUqGoy2iuYKT/BmUFduIpQcURxbVlusjbg0kZxqpV3eorssDvkDkiPcdXHI9g8o75alzvlRo3jcAjg12M@xCrJ0TtxWFSPBNk392t1kiXOYFAf@j2S/gKf0ZOdj81mbkuWB@TZsaWZe5x8WpHrpJS9DPBucJVsG8hDPlPm7/AA)

*-1 byte thanks to @xnor!*

#### Explanation:

This is a recursive function that increases `j` from `5` to `n`. If `j` is prime,  the function compares it to the previous prime `i` to determine the race track character.

The following expression evaluates to `1` or `0` depending on whether `j` is prime or not:

```python
t%j>0
```

where `t` is `factorial(j-1)`. This uses [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), taken from [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/27022/92237) on another prime problem.

Given 2 consecutive prime `i` and `j`, the following code determines the character (shamelessly stolen from [@dingledooper's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203517/92237)):

```python
"\/‾_"[i%4//2-j%4]
```

Comment: A one-byte shorter way to handle the base case here is `n//j*"?"and`.

Comment: Thanks @xnor! I tried that before and somehow confused myself into thinking that it doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 65 bytes

```
.+
$*
1
_1$`
^.{6}|_(11+)\1+(?!1)|1111|1(1?)
$2
_1
/1
1/
‾
1_
\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLkCveUCWBK06v2qy2Jl7D0FBbM8ZQW8Ne0VCzxhAIagw1DO01uVSMgOq49A25DPW5HjXs4zKM54r5/9/QwAAA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert `N` to unary.

```
1
_1$`
```

Count up to `N`, using `_` to separate the unary values, thus assuming all odd primes have a remainder of 1 (modulo 4) by default.

```
^.{6}|_(11+)\1+(?!1)|1111|1(1?)
$2
```

Delete `1`, `2` and their separators; delete all composite numbers and their separators; reduce the odd primes modulo 4, and identify the primes with a remainder of 3 (modulo 4).

```
_1
/1
```

Still assuming that the prime previous to a prime with a remainder with 3 has a remainder of 1, change the `_` to a `/`.

```
1/
‾
```

But if it turns out that the previous prime also has a remainder of 3, then change the `/` to a `‾`.

```
1_
\
```

Any remaining primes with a remainder of 3 must have a next prime with a remainder of 1, so change the `_` to a `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 118 bytes

Erlang doesn't support negative indices so I had to do my own. (Also it doesn't display `‾`, so it's replaced with `^`.)

```erlang
p([_])->[];p([H|T])->[lists:nth(H rem 4+1rem(hd(T)rem 4),"_/\\^")|p([A||A<-T,A rem H>0])];p(X)->tl(p(lists:seq(2,X))).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYyxDoIwEIZ3nqJhuosFgeiChoSNB2AgASREqzQpFdsmLn33WnExMfGWuy//fx9TYpS3iOmz4otxgVugHXqMirY/@LOy9QqCa6NzaSaoiGIz2W1Sv2C6QI0rIw2HbdedQrT@rbS2PEY1LddyVSQ9vnWNVxkBC3x0mj0gow0ixm4euYQBSVQExA@/59en4ob58h6RepYCkP6EWfIvTZOvOHYv)

## Replaced formula

```erlang
  a % 4  |  b % 4  | a + 1%b
---------+---------+---------
    1    |    1    |   1
    1    |    3    |   2
    3    |    1    |   3
    3    |    3    |   4
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 26 bytes

```
J'¯†!"¦/_"x9ẊoB2em%4t↑İp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9odXNr//9KJ8Kv4oCgISLCpi9fIng54bqKb0IyZW0lNHTihpHEsHD///8)