# Is this continuous terrain? Part II

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, pattern-matching

*Caves and Cliffs edition*

[Part 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241136/is-this-continuous-terrain), [Very related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181708/would-this-string-work-as-string?noredirect=1&lq=1)

You're given a piece of ASCII art representing a piece of land, like so:

```
   /‾\         _ __ 
__/ _/         \‾
  _/  __/‾\     |
 /   /     ‾\   |  
 \_/‾        \_/
```

But unlike in the previous challenge, the terrain is mountainous, with caves and cliffs, and can turn back on itself. Also, a new character is introduced, `|`, which can connect to any of its four corners.

Since an overline (`‾`) is not ASCII, you can use a `~` or `-` instead.

Your challenge is still to determine if it is connected by the lines of the characters such that a single line connects them all without backtracking or crossing itself. For example, the above can be traced like so:

[image]

To clarify the connections:

- `_` can only connect on the bottom on either side
- `‾` (or `~` or `-`) can only connect on the top on either side
- `/` can only connect on the top right and bottom left
- `\` can only connect on the top left and bottom right
- `|` can connect on all four corners, but not to anything that connects to more than one corner. `|` must have a single connection above itself and a single connection below.

That one's a bit confusing, so the following are legal:

```
|
 \

|
\

 _
|_

‾|
/
```

And the following aren't:

```
|
‾
_
|

||
```

It doesn't matter where the connections start and end as long as they're all connected. Note that one line's bottom is the next line's top, so stuff like this is allowed:

```
_
 ‾

\
 \

 _
/

\
 ‾
```

You can assume input will only contain those characters plus spaces and newlines, and will contain at least one non-space character per column.

Input can be taken as ASCII art, an array of rows, a character matrix, etc.

### Testcases

Separated by double newline.

Truthy:

```
\
 \

\_
  \ /\/\_
   ‾     \

/\
  \/

\_
  ‾\

   /‾\
__/   ‾\_
         \_/‾\
              \

   /‾\         _ __
__/ _/         \‾  
  _/  __/‾\     |  
 /   /     ‾\   |  
 \_/‾        \_/   

/‾\
\ /
/ \

____   _
 ___| | |
|  ___| |
| |___  |
|___  | |
 ___| | |
|_____| |

 _
/ \  _
| |_|

 _
|_\
```

Falsy:

```
/
 \


//

 ‾‾
/  \

‾
 _

\____/
      /‾‾‾\

\_
/

| |
‾‾‾

|_|
| |
```

Comment: So self-intersections, nested regions, etc, are all allowed?  So long as there is a path from each cell to every other cell?  For example: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7Uis4SLS0FBQV9XNwZI68frxyiAGEBSX0EfJBMTH6/P9f8/AA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: Hmm... based on some of the falsy examples that must be falsy.  is the rule that your single connected line tracing it is not allowed to backtrack?

Comment: @Jonah No self-intersections, yes the line can't backtrack.

Comment: What if there is an input that has a continuous line and a disconnected (but continuous) loop? Is it continuous?

Comment: @AnttiP Example?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8TjYVgb8

Comment: @AnttiP No, that's not continuous as a single line has to be able to connect them all.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 190 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υιＦυ«⸿Ｆι«Ｍ³→Ｆ№\|/κＰ|@#≡κ_Ｐ^²‾ＰV²/Ｐ/²\Ｐ\²»⸿⸿»Ｊ⁰¦⁰Ｆυ«⸿Ｆι«Ｍ³→≡κ|Ｆ⁸¿‹ ⊟ＫＤ³✳λＰ✳λ²»⸿⸿»ＵＭＫＡ⎇⁼#ιψι≔⟦⟧θＦ×³ＬυＦ×³⊕⌈ＥυＬκ«Ｊκι≔ＬΦＫＭ‹ λη¿∧‹ ＫＫ›²η⊞θ⟦ικη⟧»¿∨⁻²Ｌθ⊙θ⊖⊟ι⎚«≔⊟θηＪ⊟η⊟ηＷ⌕ＡＥＫＭ‹ κ¹✳⁻³⊟ιψ¿⊖ＬＫＡ⎚«⎚¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVPbjpswEH2GrxixL0aiYi8vVfrSKNuttlrUqM3bskWIeIOFMWAg22gTqV/Wj@mPUI9tclOrPtRCIpkzMz7nzJDlqcyqlA/DS844BXIv6r772kkmVsT3Yd63OekDYP4797mSQHofXl1nrvCOeLH0VNzRANOAE1VrSm4CmHxhq7xD1MCzqtcV8Tb0AihU66jnHat1o8k2AO/9hW7mtC@sy3IghWmYpS0FL/EmJwXfArjW2Qb@9ePnWcL6NCE8g8NTOI7P8HjEdy4@e71G8c791Jf1oiKXAVz@hzN/lLpVVHTdWx/YM5AH2rbEA@XavKrJnNLilkmadawS2O7wh/t4jmUcY/8QFKX1rCrLVCz1FVPOiSpZUClSuSEfmj7lisWFh6sQwAZfqm7atmwlyONTAM3ow4KVtEVmD1SsOrU9SOoUuReZpCUVHV2SKP3Oyr5U7xoXzRYVvhGjbLFWF2YJHXulzbtjvKNSU46qSlIkfTAMHQkgxzJ0cqrEHbmpagjiHyVNsck1ptqVbwJ4ZGpPVehJ@4P1nyWJmOhbzLT3N9hgKjZYcEsPqnBUzEiYcZpKoppQrsb7uleAKc1Iz4rEWO6bSedosGM/yzsmljgTdOkvYgukcoUCzmZvON@YrgyzNqMjx5Stov30T7g7I3nnELJLdIW/d@5uGAAgVF9iDONJIEncJAlBPeOJVQaACzqmsH3BFqOYZ3JtXEdjnbbvoLu5w5s1/w0) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated strings and outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for continuous, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Input the terrain.

```
Ｆυ«
```

Loop over the rows of the terrain.

```
⸿
```

Start each row on a new line. This is because we'll be drawing above the current line, so we want the actual drawing to start at row `0`.

```
Ｆι«
```

Loop over each character of the row.

```
Ｍ³→
```

Space the characters 3 apart. (This should be one before and two after, but unfortunately `Switch` makes doing that less golfy.)

```
Ｆ№\|/κ
```

If the current character is a `\`, `|` or `/`, then...

```
Ｐ|@#
```

... output a marker in case the character above or below is a `|`.

```
≡κ
```

Switch on the current character.

```
_Ｐ^²
```

If it's a `_` then write to the centre and the bottom left and bottom right corners of this `3×3` square.

```
‾ＰV²
```

If it's a `‾` then write to the centre and the top left and top right corners.

```
/Ｐ/²
```

If it's a `/` then draw from the bottom left to the top right.

```
\Ｐ\²
```

If it's a `\` then draw from the top left to the bottom right.

```
»⸿⸿
```

Add another two rows so that each row is spaced 3 apart vertically as well.

```
»Ｊ⁰¦⁰
```

Jump back to the beginning.

```
Ｆυ«⸿Ｆι«Ｍ³→
```

Loop through the rows and columns as before.

```
≡κ|
```

This time, only process `|` characters.

```
Ｆ⁸
```

Check all 8 directions. (Actually directions `0` and `4` are useless, but it's easier to include them.)

```
¿‹ ⊟ＫＤ³✳λ
```

See if there's a `\`, `|` or `/` in that direction.

```
Ｐ✳λ²
```

If so then draw a connection to it.

```
»⸿⸿
```

Finish processing each row.

```
»ＵＭＫＡ⎇⁼#ιψι
```

Remove any unused `#`s.

```
≔⟦⟧θ
```

Start collecting points that do not have two neighbours.

```
Ｆ×³ＬυＦ×³⊕⌈ＥυＬκ«Ｊκι
```

Loop over each cell of the canvas, taking into account that it's offset by `2` characters to the right.

```
≔ＬΦＫＭ‹ λη
```

Get the number of neighbours of this cell.

```
¿∧‹ ＫＫ›²η
```

If this cell is not empty and does not have two neighbours, then...

```
⊞θ⟦ικη⟧
```

... add it to the list.

```
»¿∨⁻²Ｌθ⊙θ⊖⊟ι
```

If there aren't exactly two points with exactly one neighbour each, then...

```
⎚«
```

... simply clear the canvas, otherwise:

```
≔⊟θηＪ⊟η⊟η
```

Jump to one of the two ends.

```
Ｗ⌕ＡＥＫＭ‹ κ¹
```

While there is an adjacent character...

```
✳⁻³⊟ιψ
```

... erase the current character and move in that direction.

```
¿⊖ＬＫＡ
```

If there is more than one character left, then...

```
⎚
```

... simply clear the canvas, otherwise...

```
«⎚¹
```

... clear the canvas and output success.