# Display percent battery remaining

Tags: code-golf

#### Display the remaining battery charge, as a percentage of maximum charge

Remember if you can't run your code on a phone, calculator, etc, you can probably install your environment on a laptop at least. If you absolutely can't run on a device that has a battery, then unfortunately your language isn't eligible since you have no useful value to print.

You must display the results on the screen. This is theoretically supposed to be a handy utility for the user to check the battery. Writing battery percent to a file is too clunky, requiring the user to then check the file. Displaying on-screen is therefore a part of the specification that can't be overridden by default IO. That said, you can assume nothing is preventing things like STDOUT from being displayed on screen in the usual way.

If the battery percent is already displayed on screen all the time by the OS, like on many phones, that does not mean you've got a zero-byte solution. You must assume that built-in display doesn't exist, and display the battery percent again somewhere else.

Edit: The output format is being opened up. You are free to display as little as just the digits of the percent, or the digits with some extra output as well.

Edit2: The digits representing the percent must appear in a known location within the output, not more than 50 lines from the end of the output, and that location shouldn't change between invocations. The digits representing the percent must be separated from other output by at least one non-digit character on each side.

For reference here is the old output format from before the change:

`Remaining battery is ddd%`
or
`Remaining battery is ddd percent`

Comment: This is a uniqueish challenge because the language chosen depends largely on the environment and the best golf is going to rely greatly on the api presented in that environment. Not sure if that's good or bad, ha

Comment: Turns out javascript has (had) the Battery Status API for this (currently available in chrome).

Comment: What if the program writes the percent to a file and then opens the file to display it?

Comment: What is battery percentage defined as?  I'm not really familiar with how the hardware works but I was always under the impression that battery percentage was some kind of hueristic in terms of predicted use.

Comment: Why is the output format so strict?

Comment: @WW I think I've heard of phones displaying that as the 'percent'. They shouldn't, of course, that's just misleading and condescending to the user. But short of asking people to golf a new hardware-level device driver, I'm willing to accept any % that the OS or system-level API gives.

Comment: @Okx Poke pointed out that if output doesn't have to be formatted, some solutions will simply be the relevant API call and nothing else, and the winner might simply be who has the shorter API call. I'm open to suggestions on the particular formatting required, though.

Comment: @mbomb007 I suppose that's alright. Displaying on screen is required, but any way you do that is allowed.

Comment: @WW https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/144914/how-does-a-smart-phone-measure-the-battery-power --> if I understood correctly, it has nothing to do with usage.

Comment: @JaredK Can we assume that the battery has 100% capacity? (i.e., it's a new battery)

Comment: Also: Does the output need to be zero left-padded?

Comment: @user202729 no it must check the current current battery charge, whatever it may be. And no, it doesn't need padding.

Comment: @JaredK I can't see how does the strict output makes the challenge better. Even Poke didn't claim the simple calls were problematic, and we do have a few catalogue challenges here. As I see the answers, it simply adds a printing command with the aforementioned text for each, which looks a bit like a clutter over the basic solution. That said, the original task is pretty good as a challenge on this site IMO.

Comment: @Uriel Good points. I think we can open up the output format and let this be a catalog challenge.

Comment: @JaredK Could you update the challenge then? Rules made in the comments don't count.

Comment: @user202729 That electronics.SE answer is about the internal measurement, but what's exposed to the user is often a doctored number - Li-ion batteries drain faster the more charge they have (or is it the other way around?), but the device (usually) adjusts for that to show a somewhat linear change in battery percentage since that feels more predictable to us users.

Comment: @sundar That's not really a problem. The real problem is that it's hard to tell whether an answer is correct (display the "original" number, not the "edited" one)

Comment: You should require the output to be consistent, with the only thing that changes is the number indicating the charge percentage.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is getting so much flak. I think it's a great question bringing a bit of diversity to the site.

Answer (score 43):

## Bash, <s>70</s> <s>67</s> <s>50</s> <s>46</s> <s>43</s> 16 bytes

```
`</*/*/*/B*/c*y`
```

Outputs: `<battery 0-100>: command not found`

Reads the file `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/capacity`.

Tested using Ubuntu 18.04 on a LENOVO ideapad 500.

Takes a while (since it searches the entire filesystem) - but it saves a byte!

#### Old answer:

```
echo Remaining battery is `</*/*/*/B*/c*y`%
```

Comment: _Takes a while (since it searches the entire filesystem) - but it saves a byte!_ - that's code golf for you!

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure if it can be guaranteed that there isn't a file called `/so/apes/yadayada/Brunch/calamity`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I'm told I can assume a fresh install.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I'm so glad Brunch is served before the world ends.

Comment: Why do you need the `B`? It works for me without it (not 18.04 though).

Comment: @Ruslan Without it, it outputs: `-bash: /*/*/*/*/c*y: ambiguous redirect`. Though I am not using a clean install.

Comment: @Okx Considering the rule change, why not do `cat /*/*/*/*/*`? Sure, it might print a huge chunk of files on the system and take forever, but the battery string is there. Somewhere. Eventually.

Comment: @algmyr That's bending the rules quite a bit, and I doubt it will even be consistent output.

Comment: _"You are free to display as little as just the digits of the percent, or as much output as you would like."_
Who says we need consistent output? Also, isn't bending (but not breaking) the rules in the spirit of code golf?

Comment: @algmyr At that point I might as well do `echo {0.100}`

Comment: @Okx That is exactly why I dislike the change of rules. It allows solutions that doesn't follow the spirit of the challenge.

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript (browser), <s>78</s> <s>77</s> 50 bytes

(-1 byte thanks to [Benoit Esnard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38454/benoit-esnard))

(-27 bytes since the output format is flexible now)

```js
navigator.getBattery().then(b=>alert(b.level*100))
```

## JavaScript (browser), 46 bytes, by returning a promise

(Suggested by [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy), requires a header and footer)

```js
f=
_=>navigator.getBattery().then(b=>b.level*100)
f().then(alert)
```

---

**Note:** Only works on Google Chrome >= 38 (desktop and Android) or any other browser that supports [Battery API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API). FireFox has removed this API due to privacy concerns.

**Example on Android (old output format):**

[image]

**Example on a Windows laptop (old output format):**

[image]

Comment: You can save one byte by using ES6 string templates: `\`Remaining battery is ${b.level*100}%\``

Comment: @Benoit Esnard: Nice idea! Thanks ...

Comment: I never realised you can get a user's battery level in a webpage. I can't think of when that feature would actually be useful to a user though.

Comment: @numbermaniac Back in the days, PoC featured websites that included a low-power mode based on the battery level of the device. Too bad they didn't think all of this could also be used to [track you](https://amiunique.org/fp) without the need of cookies.

Comment: @numbermaniac: One of the usages is to auto save a form when user's battery is low. But there can be many misuses for it and that is why FireFox has removed it.

Comment: [You can return a promise from a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12327/58974) so you could save a few bytes with `_=>navigator.getBattery().then(b=>'Remaining battery is ${b.level*100}%')` (replacing single quotes with backticks), which you would then call with `f().then(console.log)`.

Comment: @Shaggy: The questions specifies that "You must display the results on the screen." and later on they say it cannot be overridden by default IO. That is why I used an alert.

Comment: If you have your browser's console ope or you use (e.g.) [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yuqoqizewe/edit?js,console), it will be displayed on screen ;) Or, if you prefer, just replace `console.log` in my code above with `alert`.

Comment: @AlexisFacques Wow, I didn't realize I could be fingerprinted basically just by my Flash plugin--thanks for the informative link!

Answer (score 12):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 28 bytes

-26 (!) thanks to AdmBorkBork. Previous version -3 thanks to colsw.

```powershell
((gwmi win32_battery)|% e*g)
```

[image]

`gwmi` is short for `Get-WmiObject`

`|%` takes the pattern `e*g` and finds the only matching property; `estimatedChargeRemaining`

Comment: Using [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/42963), you can golf down the lengthy property name -- `((gwmi win32_battery)|% e*g)`.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Thank you again. As you can tell, I'm not a Powershell golfer (or even user). Just used a bit of Google-fu…

Comment: If the device has more than one battery, it displays something like `Remaining battery is 98 96%`

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev OP sounds like we may choose an appropriate device.

Comment: Change `"abc"+(def)+"ghi"` to `"abc$(def)ghi"` to save some more.

Comment: @Adám only 10 more bytes and we beat bash! I'm not exactly hopeful.

Comment: You can now update this to remove the text "Remaining battery is ... %"

Comment: @immibis Thanks. Done.

Comment: Well it seems I've [172% left](https://i.imgur.com/ItqmChF.png). Nice.

Answer (score 10):

## Bash+acpi, <s>43</s> 4 bytes

### New rules

```
acpi
```

output on form

```
Battery 0: Charging, 92%, 00:05:37 until charged
```

not sure if the rule change makes things more interesting, couldn't you dump any text that contains all strings 0 to 100 which would be valid output? Seems to lose the original intent if so.

### Old rules

```
set `acpi`;echo Remaining battery is ${4%,}
```

output on form

```
Remaining battery is 92%
```

Don't ask me why set works like this, but it does.

Comment: What did you test this on? Ubuntu or similar I'm guessing? It doesn't work on Mac, for example.

Comment: Works on fedora, but it depends heavily on the syntax of the output (what is it on mac for reference? @numbermaniac )?

Comment: I assume it's the one available for most linux distros. Is the acpi output format different on mac perhaps (is acpi even available there)?

Comment: @Wilf `acpi` simply isn't there on Mac it seems.

Comment: It can to be installed separately on some linux distros, mac likely has its own built in equivalent drivers and commands.

Comment: Dumping all digits 0-100 would be [hard-coding the output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1063/69304) I think.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/), 80 bytes

```python
import psutil
print(f"Remaining battery is {psutil.sensors_battery().percent}%")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcoxCoAwDADA3VcUQWiXLv7ED0iVqAGbhiQORXx7HXS@42pHobE1zFzEHOtleHYsSOa3foKckJB2tyQzkOpQ3f2lqEBaROeffIgMsgLZM/ShtRc)

If the machine has no battery (like on TIO), the program will throw an error, because `psutil.sensors_battery()` returns `None`.

This requires Python 3.6 for [string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Comment: Idk. It's included on TIO. I'll include a link to the module.

Comment: I Googled and found the same library but my Python 2 answer was not as smart as yours with string interpolation. Note to self: must get into Python 3.6 and answer faster. +1

Answer (score 5):

## C (win32, gcc i686-w64-mingw32), 78 bytes

```c
#include<windows.h>
main(s){GetSystemPowerStatus(&s);printf("%hhu",s>>16);}
```

Abuses the win32 API by letting `GetSystemPowerStatus()` write "somewhere" on the stack, the interesting member is in the third byte, according to the [`SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS` struct](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/api/winbase/ns-winbase-_system_power_status).

Unfortunately, the `#include` seems to be needed, probably because of calling conventions.

Example output:

```
> bat.exe
90
```

Displays `255` on systems without a battery.

Comment: What happens if you omit the include?

Comment: @Ruslan the linker doesn't find the symbol in `kernel32.dll`. That's why I **think** it's the calling convention, win32 API functions don't use the "standard" `cdecl`. So even if I could trick the linker somehow, the code probably wouldn't work anyways.

Comment: Did you try compiling with `/Gz` (default to `__stdcall`)?

Comment: @Neil no, does gcc/mingw have a similar option or do I have to use msvc for that? And wouldn't that break the `printf()` without a prototype?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read your header carefully enough. I think the mingw version is `-mrtd`, but I don't know what would happen to `printf()`; maybe there's a shorter include for it?

Answer (score 4):

## Excel VBA, 150 bytes

Restricted to 32-Bit Windows Installs of office, because the windows Kernel32 call is not 64-bit pointer safe.

Outputs to the cell `A1` on the ActiveSheet.

```vb
Declare Sub GetSystemPowerStatus Lib"kernel32"(f As t)
Type t
i As Integer
b As Byte
End Type
Sub d
Dim e As t
GetSystemPowerStatus e
[A1]=e.b
End Sub
```

-26 bytes thanks to flexible output

-7 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) for using an Int instead of 2 bytes

Comment: Not 64-bit pointer safe? What? That's ridiculous, Microsoft.

Comment: @immibis it has do do with a difference between the versions - if you are using a 64 bit install of Office then the call just changes to be `Declare PtrSafe Sub GetSystemPowerStatus Lib"kernel32"(f As t)`

Comment: Can you not use a byte array instead of a structure?

Comment: @Neil - unfortunately not, the Lib call assigns f to a pointer of the [`_SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS` structure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/ns-winbase-_system_power_status), which holds both byte and dword values, meaning that, in this case, the structure has to be emulated from within vba, and a byte array cannot be used.

Comment: If you can't use an array, can you not at least use a two-byte type as your padding instead of two single bytes?

Comment: @Neil - I hadn't even considered that - and it works fantastically! Great suggestion

Answer (score 3):

## [QPython for Android](http://www.qpython.org/index.html), 133 bytes

```
from androidhelper import*
d=Android()
d.batteryStartMonitoring()
d.dialogCreateAlert(str(d.batteryGetLevel()[1])+"%")
d.dialogShow()
```

[image: Code screen]

[image: Output screen]

The `+"%"` isn't strictly necessary since it uses the newer more flexible output format anyway, but it makes for slightly nicer output at just +4 bytes.

Comment: [`d.notify` (create notification alert) would have been much shorter than creating and displaying the dialog, but for some reason it doesn't work, at least on my device (possibly, it hasn't been updated for newer Android APIs).]

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##JcjRCoMgFADQd79CAtG7Saw2thj4sO9oIZFGYqncJLavdw87jyd98xJDW8qMcaNjMBidWeyaLFK3pYj5RIx6/V8A8arSoPeMQkPfDHDmjIOGiswR6UFdoNeLvD9ke5Nd9/TK12jTOk5WcM0lfwdTs11wZhwKA/0xyAaI/diJ@lJ@) works for 130 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Emacs Lisp, 9 bytes

```
(battery)
```

Shows current battery status in mini-buffer at the bottom (or to stdout when using `--batch`) in format such as: `Power N/A, battery Unknown (99.1% load, remaining time N/A)`.

Should work on Windows, OSX, BSD , and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 60 bytes

```
Ox`nàÀÓ&.getBÂjry().È(x=>O.q("Rà@°á ßMy  "+L*x.¤vel+"%"))
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=T3hgbuDA0yYuZ2V0QsJqcnkoKS7IASh4PT5PLnEoIlLgQLDhIN9NgHkgiSAiK0wqeC6kdmVsKyIlIikp&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 546 bytes (Windows XP or Higher)

The powercfg utility came into play for WindowsXP, I have no idea what utilities were available prior to this. I must also be run as administrator. This is god-awful and I didn't make an extreme golfing attempt...

```
import java.io.*;import java.util.Scanner;public class J {public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powercfg energy");p.waitFor();Scanner s=new Scanner(new File("C:\\windows\\system32\\energy-report.html"));String x;double a=0,b=0;while(s.hasNextLine()){x=s.nextLine();if(x.contains("Design Capacity")){s.nextLine();b=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().replaceAll("\\D+",""));}else if(x.contains("Last Full Charge")){s.nextLine();a=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().replaceAll("\\D+",""));}}System.out.print(a/b*100);}}
```

Formatted / commented...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class J {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powercfg energy"); // Run CMD sys32 app.
        p.waitFor();                                              // Wait for it.
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(
                "C:\\windows\\system32\\energy-report.html"));    // Read output.
        String x;
        double a = 0, b = 0;
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            x = s.nextLine();
            if (x.contains("Design Capacity")) {                   // Find max capacity.
                s.nextLine();
                b = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
            } else if (x.contains("Last Full Charge")) {           // Find current capacity.
                s.nextLine();
                a = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
            }
        }
        System.out.print(a / b * 100); // Calculate %.
    }
}
```

Honestly I was more interested to see if it was even possible in Java.

Comment: Having to call an external command like that, then read the results of the external command from a file... then having to calculate the percentage yourself. And so verbose. It's awful I love it. I'm glad people try these things in ill-suited languages it's so fun. +1

Comment: @JaredK I enjoy Java "golfing", but only on questions where people think, "oh god no, what moron would ever try this in Java? It just wouldn't make sense." Sort of ironic.

Comment: Sometimes I think Java ought to get a golfing version like how Japt was made for golfing Javascript.

Comment: @JaredK look into Groovy or Clojure, could probably turn this into a 100 byte groovy answer if I tried super hard.

Comment: @JaredK here's an approximation of this same answer in groovy: `{Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powercfg energy").waitFor();x=new XMLSlurper(new File("C:\\windows\\system32\\energy-report.html"));x.html.table.tr[#].span[0] as int/x.html.table.tr[#].span[0] as int}`