# Rest of the path

Tags: code-golf, file-system

Consider this file path:

```
C:/Users/Martin/Desktop/BackupFiles/PC1/images/cars/new.png
```

Your goal is to write a program that will return the file path starting from the folder after the last folder that contains a number till the filename. So, for the above file path, the program should return `images/cars/new.png`.

One or more of the folder names may also contain spaces:

```
C:/Users/User1/Documents/Books/eBooks/PM2.4/ref/Project Management.pdf
```

should return `ref/Project Management.pdf`.

Also this filepath:

```
C:/Users/John/Videos/YouTube/3D/Animations/52.Tricky.Maneuvers/video234.png
```

should return `video234.png`.

Your answer should work with the above given three examples and all other examples that match the criteria described here.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the lowest number of bytes yields victory.

I am new to the site, so feel free to modify my post and/or add relevant tags.

Comment: @Stephen "challenge proposer".

Comment: Suggested test case: `C:/Users/User1a/Documents/foo.pdf`. (Can you confirm that the expected output is `Documents/foo.pdf` in that case?) And welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Sorry @Stephen, I forgot to mention that. As per the example given, you should start from the last folder that contains a number in its name. I will also modify the question so that there are three examples.

Comment: Do we have to support some weird Unicode characters like `߈` ("NKO DIGIT EIGHT") and would it be considered a number?

Comment: What if the "part" after the last folder with a digit is the file name not a folder? (example `C:\a1\a.pdf`)

Comment: No, numbers are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 0.

Comment: `C:\a1\a.pdf` should return `a.pdf`.

Comment: Yes @arnuld, this is the required output from your path.

Comment: @WaisKamal are backslashes considered legitimate path separators?

Comment: I'm not clear on why the third test case is supposed to return `Animations/52.Tricky.Maneuvers/video234.png` as opposed to `video234.png`. Why does the folder `52.Tricky.Maneuvers` not count as " the last folder that contains a number"?

Comment: I agree with @mypetlion. `52.Tricky.Maneuvers` contains a digit, so shouldn't it output `video234.png` instead? And if you mean by "_starting from the folder after the last folder that contains a number till the filename_" that there should always be at least one folder (regardless if it contains digits) before the file-path, doesn't that mean that `C:\a1\a.pdf` should output `C:\a1\a.pdf`?..

Comment: `As per the example given, you should start from the last folder that contains a number in its name..` This is not what your third example suggests. However, this is what your second example does. So, what's the correct one?

Comment: @mypetlion (challenge fixed)

Comment: Um, does our code need to work with something else than the provided three examples? "Your answer should work with the above given three examples." If it should only work for the three examples, that's highly discouraged.

Comment: These are just examples, so the answer must work as specified in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 9 bytes

```
.*\d.*?/
```

Regex is ported from [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172191/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XY8/iwIxEMV7P4W1RR7Z1cbmOF0shIUtVDi4JmZHL7eaWfJH8dPvJYge2swMzPzevOcoGKvkMIjJdysmHxgNw3KOrSfnUSuXtqjId4F7LJTuYr8yJ/JolhLmrI5p1CqdWrqK3h5HTzZXiYp1PJMNHgvmzoPurakLMYWjAxrHv6TDuFY2ieVT0beHf5k1/1jsTEvs8cVxE/eEssKnTc@DYesxK8TGGd3dRNKgeMnUJQNFOX219BqnfMtTvOeRD1pJqOzqDw)

**Explanation:**

```python
.*\d.*?/    # Main regex:
.*          #  Zero or more characters (as much as possible)
  \d        #  Followed by a digit
    .*?     #  Followed by zero or more optional characters (as few as possible)
       /    #  Followed by a slash

            # Replace the match with:
            #  Nothing (so basically remove that leading part)
```

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @tsh*

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/.*\d.*?\//,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY4xb8IwEIX3/opuSVDxiUAXJFoBUYdKkTLQSpVYjHMJJsFn@exU/PrgqF3b5d4N7/v0LnKQrJy2fm6oxrHZjLx5YeHQ9lJhCmJ2rMXs9QjwlCTZqMgw9Sh6atMmTfZr@GB0DKV0XhsokDtPFnZSdcG@6R4Zqv0C9FW28VUyVg1@C2vaJMse/rJNdwEFqXBF4xl2RB0D/kRV5mIFDhuoHF1Q@cdSmqifqsLWzX/idzob@NQ1EsMXhUM4ISwL2Jo40OsIwXMuDk6r7iaiFcMwUcME5MvV7@zxDg)

#### How?

```
                                             /.*\d.*?\//
                                              \/\/\_/\/
                                              | |  | |
match the longest possible string (greedy) ---+ |  | |
match a digit ----------------------------------+  | |
match the shortest possible string (lazy) ---------+ |
match a slash ---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: So, why not `s=>s.replace(/.*\d.*?\//,'')`?

Comment: @tsh Because I didn't realize it would be 1 byte shorter. :p Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 8 bytes

```
*<D>*\/=
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema '*<D>*\/=' <<< 'C:/Users/Martin/Desktop/BackupFiles/PC1/images/cars/new.png'
images/cars/new.png

bash-4.4$ gema '*<D>*\/=' <<< 'C:/Users/User1/Documents/Books/eBooks/PM2.4/ref/Project Management.pdf'
ref/Project Management.pdf

bash-4.4$ gema '*<D>*\/=' <<< 'C:/Users/John/Videos/YouTube/3D/Animations/52.Tricky.Maneuvers/video234.png'
video234.png
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/X8vGxU4rRt/2/39nK/3Q4tSiYn3fxKKSzDx9l9Ti7JL8An2nxOTs0gK3zJzUYv0AZ0P9zNzEdCAzORGoNC@1XK8gLx0A)

Comment: Can you please add a [Try It Online](https://tio.run/) link? I am not familiar with Gema.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately there is no Gema or GeL interpreter on TIO. ☹

Comment: [Requested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46771946#46771946).

Comment: Might have better luck if you ask @pxeger to add it to https://ato.pxeger.com

Answer (score 4):

## sed, 17 bytes

```
s:.*[0-9][^/]*/::
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PYyxCoMwGIT3PkVnwVwtXZpRpVvApZNYCPFXrJqE/JE@fqoUutx3w3fH1Oej3VJiKbL2kt@79oUug5QpVRJPpsBQOsTJoiaeo/MotZk3/5gWYjRVgWnV416N3lVLH@HtePpvjyxQO7OtZCOjdG5m0A@NuoobAg1ognuTiWel7X52qML3wxc).

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'/©¡RćUηí®ýʒþd_}®«õš¤X«
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AW0Akv9vc2FiaWX//ycvwqnCoVLEh1XOt8Otwq7DvcqSw75kX33CrsKrw7XFocKkWMKr//9DOi9Vc2Vycy9NYXJ0aW4vRGVza3RvcDMvQmFja3VwRmlsZXMvUEMwL2ltYWdlcy9jYXJzL25ldzEucG5n) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3lf3X9QysPLQw60h56bvvhtYfWHd57atLhfSnxtYfWHVp9eOvRhYeWRBxa/V/nv7OVfmhxalGxvm9iUUlmnr5LanF2SX6BvlNicnZpgVtmTmqxfoCzoX5mbmI6kJmcCFSal1quV5CXzgXXCyIN9V3yk0tzU/NKivWd8vOzi/VTIVSAr5GeiX5Rapp@QFF@VmpyiYJvYh7QMJBSvYKUNIQxXvkZefphmSmp@cX6kfmlIaVJqfrGLvqOeUDLSzLz84r1TY30Qooyk7Mr9YBmpJaWgXSVgTQYGZvAnJRoqJ@Iai6q14zR/GaA7jdDkEkA).

05AB1E has no regexes, so this is not the kind of challenge it will do very good, in comparison to non-verbose languages that have a strength in regexes like Retina or Pyth.
Can probably still be golfed by at least a few bytes, though.

**Explanation:**

```
'/              # Push a "/"
  ©             # Store it in the register (without popping)
   ¡            # Split the (implicit) input on slashes
                #  i.e. "C:/Desktop3/Stuff/F0/images/new1.png"
                #   → ["C:","Desktop3","Stuff","F0","images","new1.png"]
    R           # Reverse this list
                #  i.e. ["C:","Desktop3","Stuff","F0","images","new1.png"]
                #   → ["new1.png","images","F0","Stuff","Desktop3","C:"]
     ć          # Head extracted
                #  i.e. ["new1.png","images","F0","Stuff","Desktop3","C:"]
                #   → ["images","F0","Stuff","Desktop3","C:"] and "new1.png"
      U         # Pop the extracted head, and store it in variable `X`
       η        # Take the prefixes of the list
                #  i.e. ["images","F0","Stuff","Desktop3","C:"]
                #   → [["images"],["images","F0"],["images","F0","Stuff"],["images","F0","Stuff","Desktop3"],["images","F0","Stuff","Desktop3","C:"]]
        í       # Reverse each inner list again
                #  i.e. [["images"],["images","F0"],["images","F0","Stuff"],["images","F0","Stuff","Desktop3"],["images","F0","Stuff","Desktop3","C:"]]
                #   → [["images"],["F0","images"],["Stuff","F0","images"],["Desktop3","Stuff","F0","images"],["C:","Desktop3","Stuff","F0","images"]]
         ®ý     # And join them by slashes
                #  i.e. [["images"],["F0","images"],["Stuff","F0","images"],["Desktop3","Stuff","F0","images"],["C:","Desktop3","Stuff","F0","images"]]
                #   → ["images","F0/images","Stuff/F0/images","Desktop3/Stuff/F0/images","C:/Desktop3/Stuff/F0/images"]
ʒ   }           # Now filter this list by:
 þ              #  Leave only the digits of this suffix
                #   i.e. "images" → ""
                #   i.e. "Stuff/F0/images" → 0
  d             #  Check if its >= 0
                #   i.e. "" → 0 (falsey)
                #   i.e. 0 → 1 (truthy)
   _            #  Inverse the boolean (0→1; 1→0)
     ®«         # Append a slash to each remaining suffix
                #  i.e. ["images"] → ["images/"]
       õš       # Prepend an empty string as list
                # (work-around when there are no valid suffices left)
                #  i.e. [] → [""]
                #  i.e. ["images/"] → ["","images/"]
         ¤      # Take the last suffix
                #  i.e. ["","images/"] → "images/"
          X«    # Append variable `X` (and implicitly output the result)
                #  i.e. "images/" and "new1.png" → "images/new1.png"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/powershell-scripting) <strike>42</strike> <strike>39</strike> <strike>45</strike> <strike>30</strike> 26 bytes

Find the last decimal before a /, fetch all after the slash as the new path

```
($args-split'.*\d.*?/')[1]
```

[Try it out!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0MlsSi9WLe4ICezRF1PKyZFT8teX10z2jD2////6s5W@qHFQLX6XvkZefphmSmp@cX6kfmlIaVJqfrGLvqOeZm5iSWZ@XnF@qZGeiFFmcnZlXq@iXmppWUgXWUgDUbGJnoFeenqAA)

- many bytes by tips from @mazzy
- 1 byte by removing non-required regex escape
- 4 bytes as the regex with -split didn't require a group
- added greedy decimal search

Comment: Great! I think `$args` is better then `param($f)$f`

Comment: Completely right, although using $args within an expression always seems to return the original value, powershell might think of it as an array with ToString() or something. Works fine with indexer though.

Comment: "$args". Welcome to [Tips for golfing in PowerShell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191/tips-for-golfing-in-powershell)

Comment: The script return 2 values: $true/$false from -match expression and match string. I think `should return the file path` means the file path only. I beleave it can be golfed more.

Comment: Included both solutions. Up to @Wais Kamal which output matches the criteria.

Comment: `$v=` is shorter then `>$null` :) and try a `-split` instead `-match`.

Comment: split had a lot of additional perks :)

Comment: Cool! and... fatality... Finish it! `($args-split'.*\d.*?/')[1]` :)

Comment: port of Javascript by @tsh `$args-replace'.*\d.*?/'`. Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 26 bytes

```java
s->s.split(".*\\d.*?/")[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNSwMxEIbv/RXDQqFb1gz98FK1opYehEKhVRDtIe5ma7q7ScgklSL97TW7W3rRQzIZ8s7D8Oz4nl/tsuIkK6Otg13omXeyZLlXqZNasf5NJy05ESy4VPDTATD@s5QpkOMulL2WGVThr7dyVqrt@wa43VLcRAHmZ85t@5u0ZQo53J3oakqMTCldL2L9j4@M9e8xit8Hm9NNM3whOkGO4O7MBIieJvhCwhIuuHVS4UxQ4bTBR54W3sxlKQiXTwOUFd@GZ8pDVIlvZtQ2Sv5A6nuAM536SihH@Kh1QSjaslwM2RityHFp9U6kLphQgVpHmcnyf3jP@kvhq8yEJnzTfu0/BY5m@KDCOrUMwushW1uZFgcWYMLv66l9PTAcjZslG@ax1ZBre5bbiJi0OuKLjdWBnKiY9mGfkHJ5L@oGW1PoUldFSRNPIGfcmPLQq7s4bsnHTn2Op18)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 22 bytes

```ruby
->s{s=~/.*\d.*?\//;$'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BSwMxFITv/ooehIWCGbqtl0oV28WDsLCHWhDrIc2@rXFtEvKSShH96zFLT@JlZg4zH@Pj7pS6Rbq65S9e/ECMt60Y322Bm8viO7lR91Ks5nhi8oxa@qANKuI@WIelVH10D/qDGM1qAn2Q@xyVzFVDn8KZffF68Rcx6ASVVfFAJjCW1vYMOltTl2IGTx0ab99JhVEtTWYOVeHa7h/t0b4ZbHRLlvFs4zruCNMK9yZfCdoaxnUp1l6r/iQyiuJxWB2HQTmdnQ@m9As)

Same trick as Arnauld and everybody else after him.

Comment: +1 for TIL about `$'`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
”/ɓṣṖf€ØDTṀ‘ṫ@ṣj
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which returns a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw1z9k5Mf7lz8cOe0tEdNaw7PcAl5uLPhUcOMhztXOwDFs/7//@9spR9anFpUrO@bWFSSmafvklqcXZJfYKzvlJicXVrglpmTWqwf4Gykn5mbmA5kJicC1eallhvqFeSlAwA)**

#### How?

```
”/ɓṣṖf€ØDTṀ‘ṫ@ṣj - Link: list of characters X
”/               - literal '/' character
  ɓ              - start a new dyadic chain with swapped arguments - i.e. f(X,'/')
   ṣ             - split (X) at ('/')
    Ṗ            - pop (removes the rightmost)
       ØD        - yield digit characters
      €          - for each: (of the parts of X after the split & pop)
     f           -   filter keep (digit characters)
         T       - truthy indices (1-indexed indices of parts containing any digit(s))
          Ṁ      - maximum (rightmost, zero if not found)
           ‘     - increment
              ṣ  - split (X) at ('/') (...again)
             @   - with swapped arguments:
            ṫ    -   tail (the split X) from index (the incremented maximum...)
               j - join with ('/')
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 74 bytes

```python
r='';k=1
for c in input():
 r+=c;k-=c.isdigit()
 if'/'==c:r*=k;k=1
print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5NT8MwDIbv@RVRL4UharUbl045sFUckCr1MJA4ltTtQlgc5WOwX1/ScQDJsi3rfR7ZXsKRTDVLGpALnmXZ7ESeb7Uo2UiOS65MKhvDzW3NuLsTcqvvhSyUH9Sk0pVxNeaQCyFrtxL6SlqnTOBuTjrG8BslX/yr9Zzta3jx6Dy0vQvKQINeB7Kw66WO9kl9ooduX4I69VNaZZ@iBr8Ka6aM/dFLL6EhGU9ogocdkfaAv6Nrq2IDDkfoHH2gDLztTdIt0cIO43/RMx0NvKoBycMbxUN8R1g38GjSA0GR8fBQFQenpL4UyYLxvFDnBajWm@tbPw)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
lambda n:re.sub(".*\d.*?/","",n)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY49a8MwFEV3/wqhyTZBj9jpEgilielQMHhIC4UssvycqI6fhD7S5te7dju0y7tvuOdw7T1cDBWTMh2yHeOcJ/3uNF3l2HaS0dah8LFNuchPncgfga84X1GW6NEaF5jDyTpNgfWpJhtDmmXJ4kjwCxVbpHk58cMWXj06D7V0QRNU6IdgLOylGqJ91lf00BzWoEd5nl8l5yrhp7B05skfvdw1VEbFESl42BszeMDfaOpCbMBhD40zH6gCqyXNuqUqbNf/F72YC8Gb7tB4eDfxGFuEsoInmgcEbcjDQyGOTqvhLmYLxttC3RagKDc/s74B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 79 bytes

```
func[s][d: charset"0123456789"parse s[any[to d thru"/"]copy t to end(print t)]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDJTsMwEL33Kyyf4JIhacuSG23EASlShAoSinIw9qQxoWPLS1G@PjhwoZdZnuYtGodqfkHVdqu@nPtIsvVdq0omB@E8Bn6TF@vN9vbu/oHbBWG@FTS1wTDFwuAiB95JYycWWMKQ1JV1mtJy3XVzz/i@hFePzkMtXNAEFfoxGAs7Icdon/QXemj2OeiTOKZRJg8g/M4sHfnqP3@pOVRGxhNS8LAzZvSAf62pi2wDDntonPlEGVgtKAkup5lV/aXUsxkI3rRC4@HdxEP8QFhX8EgpRNCGPGyL7OC0HKcs6WA8L6zzQkjP@I02/wA)

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, 14 bytes

The same regex solution that everybody else is using:

```
:z"^.*\d.*?/""

:                     regex replace
 z                    in the input() string
  "^.*\d.*?/"         the file path up until the last path with a number
             "        with an empty string (Pyth terminates this string at end of program)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
a@`\d.*?/`$'
```

Takes input as a command-line argument. Verify all test cases: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5NawIxFEX3/opBCoVCc3HUjZu2OnRRGJiFLUgtmGaeNh3NC/mwiPS3pxnc1M27b3HP4Vpt0znJx826FXcP2Nzcpt@iLt4HxXAxw6sn51FLF7RBRb4LbDGXqov2We/Jo1mMoA9yl18lc9XQj7BmN/yP93eEilU8kAkec@bOgy7R1KWYwNEWjeNvUqGopcm@vipsu70yvfCXwZtuiT1WHJfxkzCu8GTyhKDZeExLsXRadSeRNRSPPXXsgXI8uQz7SOl@/wc)

#### Explanation

Does ***not*** use the same regex as everyone else! (Well, okay, it's pretty similar.)

```
a             1st command-line argument
  `\d.*?/`    Regex matching a digit, as few characters as possible, and then a slash
 @            Find all matches
          $'  Special variable: the portion of the string after the last match
              Autoprint
```

---

The shortest solutions using the standard regex were all 13 bytes:

```
aRM`.*\d.*?/`   Remove
a|>`.*\d.*?/`   Left-strip
aR`.*\d.*?/`x   Replace with empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab, 68 bytes

```
function[r]=f(s),[~,b]=regexp(s,'/[^/;]+\d[^/;]+/');r=s(b+1:end);end
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BC4IwGEB/zjYUP9K6ODxEnYJuFoQZqPu0EW2yz0ld@usr6fLe6fFsNzUzhtB7003amsrVRc9JxNUnbuvC4YCvkVPMoLqBrKOr@huYkK4g3karHI0S8oegNI2852yXw4nQERzs3cBZK7QEF@tL3yJke9ga/WyWG8EmTUqnu8c7OTYG/bxU8xKk2ToZzcCEkOEL)

Comment: `disp(f('C:/Users/John/Videos/YouTube/3D/Animations/52/video234.png'));`  output an empty string due to `+` in regex.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP 4 (42 chars)

Given *$argv[1]*, it will [silence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) the [**end**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)'s “*Only variables should be [passed by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)*” notice.

```php
echo@end(preg_split(';\d.*?/;',$argv[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>103</s> <s>100</s> 88 bytes

```c
*a(b,l)char*b;{for(b+=l;!isdigit(*b);b--);for(;*b-47&&*b;b++);for(;*b-47;b--);return b;}
```

[Try online!](https://tio.run/##VY5NS8NAEIbP5lfEFkqSNhlaK4JRIUnxIBR6qILH3c0kXZPuhv2oSOlvj4mhWi8zwzPvPAwLS8baNiAendU@2xEV0PhYSOXR6WMdX3Od85IbL6B@TMPQj/tVHNBweTeZdFE6nV6yIaPQWCVcGp/acY4FF@gm7ii7h1eNSsOaKMMFrFBXRjaQElbZ5pnXqGGTzYHvSdmNjHRRgZ9RI8qRc/akF56@zmElmd2jMBpSKSsNOLTNehEtQWEBGyU/kBl3TUQn7qNRkxd/yuxC@SJ3At54jlLDu7RbSxFuVpCI7inDpdBwu4i2irPqK@p8aA/91aE/WNwsh1edMRestjm6D9ooLspo9@RC0M01igCcPeHC84/OVWON9oiXzIaVl/i@H//i9IzTfzg74@wHn9pv)

-22 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

Note: the function may have undefined behavior if the string doesn't contain a number and a "/" character!

### Ungolfed version

```c
*a(b,l)char*b; /* b:the string, l:the length of the string */
{
    for(b += l; !isdigit(*b); b--); /* start from the end of the string and decrement pointer until a number is found */
    for(; *b-47 && *b; b++); /*increment pointer until '/' (ascii value 47) is found*/
    for(; *b-47; b--); /* decrement pointer until '/' is found */
    return b;
}
```

Comment: [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY5NS8NAEIbP5lfEFkqSNhlaK4JRIUnxIBR6qILH3c0kXZPuhv2oSOlvj4mhWi8zwzPvPAwLS8baNiAendU@2xEV0PhYSOXR6WMdX3Od85IbL6B@TMPQj/tVHNBweTeZdFE6nV6yIaPQWCVcGp/acY4FF@gm7ii7h1eNSsOaKMMFrFBXRjaQElbZ5pnXqGGTzYHvSdmNjHRRgZ9RI8qRc/akF56@zmElmd2jMBpSKSsNOLTNehEtQWEBGyU/kBl3TUQn7qNRkxd/yuxC@SJ3At54jlLDu7RbSxFuVpCI7inDpdBwu4i2irPqK@p8aA/91aE/WNwsh1edMRestjm6D9ooLspo9@RC0M01igCcPeHC84/OVWON9oiXzIaVl/i@H//i9IzTfzg74@wHn9pv "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 13 bytes

*12 bytes for code; +1 for -p switch*

```perl
s!.*\d.*?/!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BawIxFITv/RXdq2AGV730UqqLB2FhD7Yg9JJmnxpX80JeYumfb8y2UOhl3hzmmzeewmWZs1Rq8t6ryTOqKuf1E16FgqDVIVqHhmSI7LHSZkh@Yy8k6NYz2Ks@Fmt0iTr6VN4dH/7YLZ8c3mxPLNhz2qUPwrzBiytUtOwEy1rtgjXDl2q1o3QbqdsI1PPF/65RZ2jYpCu5KFgxDwL6PV1bqwUCHdAFPpOJj6WuDBujyveHb/Y///LU3wE)

I solemnly swear I came up with my own solution before reading other answers.