# How fast am I vrooooming?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, counting

## Introduction

My car speedometer was hacked! Instead of showing me how fast i'm driving, it just shows: "Vroooom!" Please help me know how fast i'm going.

## Challenge

Take a string as input, and check if it matches the regex `/^[Vv]ro*m!$/m`. In English that means any line of the string must start with a capital or lowercase `v`, then a lowercase `r`, then any amount (including zero) of the lowercase letter `o`, then the exact string `m!`. There may be other lines, but the Vroom string must be on it's own line.

If you find a match, then you must count the amount of `o`'s in the Vroom string and output it. If you don't find a match however, you should output any default value that can't be outputted otherwise (like `-1` or an empty string)

## Reminders

- I/O is in [any reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are banned
- Submission may be a full program or function
- Input is guaranteed to only have 1 Vroom string

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the [shortest code](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10145/how-to-count-bytes-faq) in bytes wins. **However**, I will not mark any answer as accepted.

## Test cases

**Input**

```
Vrom!
```

**Output** `1`

**Input**

```
vrooooooom!
```

**Output** `7`

**Input**

```
Hello, Vroom!
```

**Output** `(none)`

**Input**

```
Foo bar boo baz
Vrooom!
hi
```

**Output** `3`

**Input**

```
Vrm!ooo
```

**Output** `(none)`

**Input**

```
PPCG puzzlers pie
```

**Output** `(none)`

**Input**

```
hallo
vROOOm!
```

**Output** `(none)`

Answer (score 8):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 20 bytes

`-nr` options required at the command-line.

```
s/^[Vv]r(o*)m!$/\1/p
```

This outputs the speed in [unary](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5349/11259) as the number of `o`s.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WD8uOqwstkgjX0szV1FFP8ZQv@D/f7f8fIWkxCKFJDBdxRVWlJ@fn6vIlZH5L7@gJDM/r/i/bl4RAA)

Comment: Can't tell `Vrm!` from `Vram!`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>56</s> 53 bytes

```python
lambda x:len(re.search('^[Vv]r(o*)m!$',x,8).group(1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcmxCsIwEADQvV9xDULvpBR0EsHVT@giCommJtDkwjWV6s/H0ukNL32z43gsPiSWDGLLcBl1MC8Ny3m0EcV2k9XydNg8bv3nLsh7CvWuaZf2RN1beE54ICpJfMwwoFLqygxGC5jNX9ULM4e6cn5NKn8)

Basic regex and grouping, uses re.MULTILINE flag (which has a value of 8) and re.search to ensure it works for multiline inputs. Raises an exception when no match is found. Thanks to @ovs for the -3 bytes from `(re.M == 8)` tip.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I reformatted your answer to make it appear a bit nicer, if you're unhappy with my edit you can always roll back. Btw. I suggest to link to something like [tio.run](https://tio.run) such that people can easily test your answer.

Comment: `re.M` has the value `8`, so can just use `re.search(regex,x,8)`

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>62 60 58</s> 44 bytes

```r
nchar(grep("^[Vv]ro*m!$",readLines(),v=T))-4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py85I7FII70otUBDKS46rCy2KF8rV1FFSacoNTHFJzMvtVhDU6fMNkRTU9fkv1t@vkJSYpFCEpiu4gorys/Pz1Xkysj8DwA)

@Giuseppe with 14 bytes golfed.

Original approach with explanation:

```r
function(x)attr(el(regexec("(?m)[Vv]r(o*)m!$",x,,T)),"m")[2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCM7GkpEgjNUejKDU9tSI1WUNJwz5XMzqsLLZII19LM1dRRUmnQkcnRFNTRylXSTPaKPZ/moZSWFE@EOQqKmlygXmJCCaM5ZGak5Ovo8AFUQpWzRWeX5STApT/DwA)

R has seven pattern matching functions. The more commonly used ones are `grep`, `grepl`, and `sub`, but here's a nice use for `regexec`.

`regexec` gives you a bunch of things, one of which is the length of any captured substring, in this case the `(o*)` part of the multiline regex.

The `attr(el .... "m")[2]` stuff is a golfy way to get the desired number.

Returns `NA` if there is no match.

Comment: [58 bytes with a different approach](https://tio.run/##PYwxD4IwEIX3/oqjOlBTNlbjYKJuEGNYjAOYYpvQllwpJvz5WhC95d19793D0O5D681zUNakjpmnrDFqti6@SWl60OxejQ@0O51sKaeUO85vjGV52ACKwaNxkOXwlsJAhdZqUA60ck6ZFyFtSiPUCWXLPsbAMn9yEV1n@ffzx07WQlMjNItOZDajS6RaAxXqJKL1KsvjGXo/TZ1AB70SK5d1rCbjtSiKuTp8AA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: I have a 44 byte approach... Not gonna post it unless you want me to.

Comment: @Giuseppe not sure why not? Especially if it's fundamentally different.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
a=>(l=/[Vv]r(o*)m!/.exec(a))&&l[1].length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1k4jx1Y/OqwstkgjX0szV1FfL7UiNVkjUVNTTS0n2jBWLyc1L70k439yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaaRoJbfr5CUmKRQhKYruIqK8rPz89V5MrITNDUtP4PAA)

Comment: This fails for `vroooooooooooom!x\nvrom!`

Comment: Seeing as we're allowed exit with an error if no match is found, you could do [this](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1k4/LjqsLLZII19LM1dRRT9XL7UiNVkjUTPaMFZPISc1L70k439yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaaRkJZUT4SyFWs4AKK5ComaGr@BwA) for -3 bytes, fixing the problem @BMO mentioned above in the process.

Comment: Uncrossed-out 41 is definitely still 41

Comment: @Shaggy What's the space in `[1]. length` for?

Comment: @l4m2, a typo! I didn't spot it on my phone 'cause `length` was breaking to a newline anyway.

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, <s>62</s> <s>58</s> <s>53</s> 48 bytes bytes

```powershell
"$($args|sls '(?m-i)^[Vv]ro*m!$'|% M*)".Length-4
```

returns numbers of `o` in a first `Vroom!`, or -4 if `Vroom!` not found.

Notes:

- `sls` is alias for [Select-String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String);
- `(?m-i)` inside regexp means:

  - Use multiline mode. `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a line, instead of the beginning and end of a string.
  - Use case-sensitive matching
- `|% M*` is [shortcut](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/80745) for the property `Matches`, which gives a first match because we don't use `-AllMatches` parameter.

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

"$($args|sls '(?m-i)^[Vv]ro*m!$'|% M*)".Length-4

}

@(
,('Vrom!',1)
,('vrooooooom!',7)
,('Hello, Vroom!',-4)
,('Foo bar boo baz
Vrooom!
hi',3)
,('Vrm!ooo',-4)
,('PPCG puzzlers pie',-4)
,('hallo
vROOOm!',-4)
,('
Vrooom!
Vrooooom!
',3)        # undefined behavior.
,('vrm!',0) # :)
) | % {
    $n,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $n
    "$($result-eq$expected): $result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: 1
True: 7
True: -4
True: 3
True: -4
True: -4
True: -4
True: 3
True: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>99</s> 82 bytes

```
I	INPUT POS(0) ('V' | 'v') 'r' ARBNO('o') @X 'm!' RPOS(0)	:F(I)
	OUTPUT =X - 2
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/35PT0y8gNEQhwD9Yw0BTQUM9TF2hRkG9TF1TQb1IXcExyMnPX0M9H8h1iFBQz1VUVwiCKOW0ctPw1OTi9A8NAem3jVDQVTDicvVz@f/fLT9fISmxSCEJTFdxhRXlg0CuIldGJgA)

Pretty direct SNOBOL translation of the spec, reads each line until it finds one that matches `^[Vv]ro*m!$`, then outputs the length of the `o*` bit.

Enters an infinite loop if no `Vroom!` can be found.

Comment: Is all that whitespace necessary? Wow.

Comment: @FireCubez yep, that's what you get with a 50+ year-old language: weird whitespace requirements. It uses space/tab as concatenation and you must surround operators with whitespace as well.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 83 bytes

```powershell
($args-split"`n"|%{if(($x=[regex]::Match($_,"^[Vv]ro*m!$")).success){$x}}).length-4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcWxDoIwEADQna@ApobWCJMTiaubKwtBLU2lTQpH7qo2It9eE9/yFngbJGu8T0lwhSNVtHgX2H1m393qHkLweOrQjCb2TXNRQVvBbwd27dpXj7CfCs6krOmptSGSK4/bJmtv5jHY6phSKs8A@aAwH/5/shYBYCoy68of)

`-split`s the input `$args` on `` `n ``ewlines, pipes those into a for loop. Each iteration, we check whether our `[regex]::Match` is a `.success` or not. If so, we leave `$x` (the regex results object) on the pipeline. Outside the loop, we take the `.length` property -- if it's the regex results object, this is the length of the match (e.g., "Vroom!" would be 6); if it's not a regex results object, the length is zero. We then subtract `4` to remove the counts for the `Vrm!` and leave that on the pipeline. Output is implicit. Outputs a `-4` if no match is found.

Comment: `sls "^[Vv]ro*m!$"`?

Comment: @mazzy How would that work for multiline input? Your only input is one string, and so `sls` will give back `('','Vroom!','')` for example.

Comment: it's not completed solution. I mean, you can try `sls` instead `[regex]::Match`

Comment: @mazzy Maybe you should post it as a separate solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 21 bytes

```
L$m`^[Vv]r(o*)m!$
$.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/30clNyEuOqwstkgjX0szV1GFS0UPKOyWn6@QlFikkASmq7jCivLz83MVuTIyAQ) Explanation: `L` lists matches, so if the regex fails to match then output is empty. `$` causes the result to be the substitution rather than the match. `m` makes it a multiline match (the equivalent to the trailing `m` in the question). The `.` in the substitution makes it output the length of the capture in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 26 bytes

```perl6
{-!/^^[V|v]r(o)*m\!$$/+$0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WldRPy4uOqymLLZII19TKzdGUUVFX1vFoPZ/cWKlQpqGSrymQlp@EZdSWn5@TF5ZUX5@rmJMXlJikZIOl1JZUa4iiA4DCoMBhAtUlav0HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>188</strike> 183 bytes

Why use regexes when you can use a state machine instead? :-)

```c
a,b;f(char*s){for(a=b=0;a<5;s++){!a&*s==86|*s=='v'?a++:a==1&*s=='r'?a++:a==2?*s-'o'?*s-'m'?0:a++:b++:a==3&*s==33?a++:!*s&a==4?a++:*s-10?(a=-1):a-4?(a=0):a++;if(!*s)break;}s=a<5?-1:b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPbjtowEH33VxiqJXYuVbJsqxVZNw/V0lZCZVWpfQEekpCA1VxQ7ERaaL6djhPMpVUbgew553g8ZyaJnU0cH9/wIs7qdYKfhFzz8u32A7qGKl5s/sTWGY8AO4Z25Kck3oaVKeghLSsSsoi5fvj0zheWRQ@DcGQKxh7f/1KL0RhBaFmTkDGvw43qDNwHpnCM0uiW3AjciSKinhx36vG4Ew9MMQLsoQtA7bkBXOt4dBI6D2rrUnXW5ykBKY2qJPzpt4JBUYHjTSK/PaqKsblJZF5nkpPpl9kzNlOKDwjjnhM2jm0c1eni0V2xg9v6QPFCKigu60LaGFpz2gGWJQUTfJ@UKYGI@gjkqh@Cff0@m13ETJ@HLmESsxSKiElK6YA9z6d@XwLc1KXphaxPrymMBQNLWVbGRFwSW73K8qivZbIq4t0rEdZNpbrca12f4XTRGV9oZsWMpWto/MpBh7TohC40Y1krFitSUVdWtIV/Gug32sL/DPT5TrrFXzkuFbdqElUi66rAwkcQqinmIS9IU/L1zczZ@Y1QX0JBbWzClWYN/0bPn59HK5nwsYQpSlbT0YhAA@@pttiwvHfoWYQzQmoGNcKPQMLhslgWQ0qD2pETwKDnRFJ4bm03NgYxP6HNgl@PYQefpUzJ8E5ghu/WkM/GcCAljU6TVkkCkR5DFwoI2@OPqswHCDVV2T8q@JxAtTYGqgunZYkj6EnUrXukcEVsOYJ9PoAIoZeXj5/wrt7vs6QSeMcThLbKNGq@zefzfPAb)

Comment: [147](https://tio.run/##XVDbitswEH3XVzgpG0uWXOxNW4K1U4ML275lWUNfsnmQHacRxBck2dBkt7@ejhIoS3VhdM7ozBypjn/V9eWDbofeuAfrdrr/ePh6UaKSe1oflIksO@97QxVUkEj18HmxoIqDeo1svPqyWGAIpzBXceqZ0PjjPe6lh8tlHtlXFX/CEKdJ/kdlHsQqS6/TK/oQkwBhG2YzzivPi8hyziSTFrBhHqdZJd8urdId1exMbrZEtVklWzi/SaI7FxSilMQbtVBCgVZNo3Y0EQstUiarTcH5FjQrAFZJbgGzx2NfUytKvkqZsM7Uw29qeSkqRJuSg6@OhbJEkuI/RcHT26ViCzOUdv@0omBe4I1cbTqwIhpFNEknHYz5yO@zhJFggvZWLuVUA6UjYBlc1In5S/fSzRnLx9hlSB2bjjqGQ6Bso991nIQT2tODwS/Y0/mdDSC426FcTGJPJ8bw336avp0RMpn@Njz40WBzEWDqCh/7PqiUCaprPBHP@8RBEzy3M0SEPD19@x4M4@l0bIwNBt0QcvBvINPzer1uZ38B "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
∞╠mQ╛3mQ->n▀÷↕┐ò
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=eccc6d51be336d512d3e6edff612bf95&i=Vrom%21%0A%0Avrooooooom%21%0A%0AHello,+Vroom%21%0A%0AFoo+bar+boo+baz%0AVrooom%21%0Ahi%0A%0AVrm%21ooo%0A%0APPCG+puzzlers+pie&a=1&m=1)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 bytes

```
fè`^[Vv]*m!$` ®èo
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ZuhgXltWdl2eKm0hJGAgruhv&input=W1siVnJvbSEiXSwKWyJ2cm9vb29vb29tISJdLApbIkhlbGxvLCBWcm9vbSEiXSwKWyJGb28gYmFyIGJvbyBiYXoiLCJWcm9vb20hIiwiaGkiXSwKWyJWcm0hb29vIl0sClsiUFBDRyBwdXp6bGVycyBwaWUiXSwKWyJoYWxsbyIsInZST09PbSEiXV0KLVFt)

Saved a byte by taking input as an array of lines.

Includes an unprintable character between `]` and `*`.

Explanation:

```
fè                   Get the line(s) that match
  `^[Vv]*m!$`          The provided RegEx with a little compression
              ®èo    Count the number of "o" in that line if it exists
```

Comment: [19 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=t2boYF5bVnZdniptISRgIK7obw==&input=WyJWcm9tISIsCiJ2cm9vb29vb29tISIsCiJIZWxsbywgVnJvb20hIiwKIkZvbyBiYXIgYm9vIGJhegpWcm9vb20hCmhpIiwKIlZybSFvb28iLAoiUFBDRyBwdXp6bGVycyBwaWUiLAoiaGFsbG8KdlJPT09tISJdCi1RbQ==)

Comment: [Also 19 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ZmBeW1Z2XZ4qbSEkYCdtIK7obw==&input=WyJWcm9tISIsCiJ2cm9vb29vb29tISIsCiJIZWxsbywgVnJvb20hIiwKIkZvbyBiYXIgYm9vIGJhegpWcm9vb20hCmhpIiwKIlZybSFvb28iLAoiUFBDRyBwdXp6bGVycyBwaWUiLAoiaGFsbG8KdlJPT09tISJdCi1RbQ==)

Comment: Actually, as input can be an array of lines, you can knock the first byte off my first comment above.

Comment: @Shaggy I can't find anywhere in the question that specifies that input can be an array of lines, and it doesn't seem to be listed in the default I/O methods that a multiline string can be taken as an array of lines. It seems likely to be reasonable, but I'll wait for confirmation first.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>75</s> <s>71</s> 69 bytes

```hs
f s=[length n-2|r<-lines s,n<-scanr(:)"m!"$'o'<$r,v<-"Vv",r==v:'r':n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcWxCsMgEADQPV9xEcEWtENH0bWfkKV0MMFUqbmDUyyU/ruFvuWlUF@xlDF2qP5eIj5bAjTXLztTMsYKVaMzdQvIJ3sWxyykIuUk6@6MWLrQ7H23ipXFxzhCRvCQsUUOWwMJNdEbLrCPGxGsgWH9/5kWJqJjnlL@AQ)

No regex. Instead builds all valid `Vrooom!`-strings up to a sufficient length and compares the lines of the input against them, collecting the number of `o`s in a list. Thus for invalid inputs an empty list is returned.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>138</strike> 124 bytes

Here's the boring regex way.

```c
#include<regex.h>
f(char*s){regmatch_t m[9];regcomp(m+2,"^[Vv]r(o*)m!$",5);s=regexec(m+2,s,2,m,0)?-1:m[1].rm_eo-m[1].rm_so;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVNdb9owFH33rzBsbW0SKkCatDX1@jCVbhIa1aT1JbAKjAOW4hjZTrSB@O3sOsF8bNoiEL7nHB/f4xt4d8n5/o0seF4uBL63biH17eojOoeMLJZ/YotczgE7br03Yil@elVG@GpmOpZuAVIzx1evDqv0wzSBmmu1JioaxO0f6Us1NUR3qGq9bcfvaGJZ7SF4LbDxIFZxjz50@3cq7U9vjXoVuhuWVie7vT8Id5bCqTJ3kgy/jB5xJ6N4izBuOBtjHuN5maXve1O27e0SoGThPMR1WbgYQ77DCrBcFMzKjdAZgYomCOSZNsSyr99Ho5OYhf2sl2DCWQZNcJJR2mKP42HStAAn1TaNkDX2gcLY553luebEnoyjRhX1aRJkzhR8/YvY6KLT0O65rnE4HHTE08BM2c2kdxPwswQ1skMHNA1MFE0Z96SnzqKECP8M0CxChP8FaPwOuvQvj1PHOz8JI1xpCmwTBKWfoprJglRaLi5mzo5vhH@dCxrjDhzZKeFbhfnL42gdswl2MEXHSnp9TeACBzRErJhqEvYjIhkhJYMe4UPAsD0pJkWb0oey6@4AgzsnjsJzGbuKMYjlAa1SeT6GNfy3XEbaVxYzfLUAvxjDhoxUwSYzQkAVxlCXFsrd/sVo1UKoMrp5fPFZQLcxBqouh1rjOdzJvP7dII97YiURrFULKoSenz894XW52eTCWLyWAqGVD42qb@PxWLV@Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>104</s> 100 bytes

```c
s;main(c,n){for(;gets(&s);sscanf(&s,"v%*[o]%nm%c%c",&n,&c,&c)-1||c-33?:printf("%d",n-2))s=s-768|32;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBC4JAFITv71eswoobu4cSKpLoEFQ3pUOX6KAvLcHdlV3zYPbbba3hwcz3BgbFA3EcbSyzSoXIFXuX2oTxo2htGFgWW4uZKl3kfkdnV32jSlKk6PNA8QDdMTEfBhRRtNs0plJtGfr07nMlFozZrRWr5XqIFvFnHC9GSw@gM/qvCU5FXWtOXPXDg9YkzwzJf97D9J@KZwUuS88RQJruj6R59X1dGEuaqgB4Zm4GunOSJNL7Ag)

Output the `n` for each valid line, exactly in the requirement(nothing if no valid line, the `n` if exactly one)

```c
int s; // Use as a char[]
main(c){
  while(gets(&s)) {
    s=s-768|32; // byte 0: 'V'=>'v'; byte 1: 'r'=>'o', 'o'=>'l'
    if (sscanf(&s,"v%[o]m%c%c",&s,&c,&c)==2 && c=='!') {
    // The last '%c' get nothing if it's EndOfLine
      printf("%d",strlen(&s)-1))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's so funny that the regex answer is longer than this

Comment: @WindmillCookies GCC need extra code to support regex

Comment: hmm. seems like names related to regexes are extremely long

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 28 bytes

```
IJjb.nm:rd0"^vro*m!$"1.z/J\o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/39MrK0kvL9eqKMVAKa6sKF8rV1FFyVCvSt8rJv///@T8lFSF9PycNK6wovz8/FxFrozUnJx8AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 20 bytes

```
/R\o:#"^Vro*m!$"1cQb
```

Outputs as a list containing only the number of 'o's, or an empty list if there's no Vroom.
[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FR%5Co%3A%23%22%5EVro%2Am%21%24%221cQb&input=%22Foo%20bar%20boo%20baz%5CnVrooom%21%5Cnhi%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
/R\o:#"^Vro*m!$"1cQb
                 cQb  Split on newlines.
    :#"^Vro*m!$"1     Filter the ones that match the regex.
/R\o                  Count the `o`s in each remaining element.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>134</strike> 122 bytes

```cs
for(var a="";a!=null;a=Console.ReadLine())if(new Regex(@"^[Vv]ro*m!$").Match(a).Success)Console.Write(a.Count(x=>x=='o'));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NagIxFIX3fYo7g2AiNC8QUirSnW6q2EVp4RKvNpDJbfMzRsRnn2ZTkJ7dOXC@z6ZHy5Gmklw4wfaSMg0a7ptau/Dzb9pRzeqVTsVjfKnfkVJyHJJ@sB5TgiVcIWXMzsLI7gAbdEFIuE5HjmLECGj6XmNnQvFeo1m1L3tqRDw0Gwkp3VEEOkNzUBXP/ef7fvyIvBi6WS/VBrP9EijVtljb3PIP8BZdJoFqxSVkUc1TNWbOcyn1dLtN@8j3Gbpf)

*-12 bytes: moved* `null` *check into* `for` *loop and removed brackets*

Ungolfed:

```cs
for(var a = ""; a != null; a = Console.ReadLine())  // initialize a, and while a isn't null, set to new line from console
    if(new Regex(@"^[Vv]ro*m!$")                        // set regex
                        .Match(a).Success)              // check if the line from the console matches
        Console.Write(a.Count(x => x == 'o'));              // write the number of 'o's to the console
```

Comment: **-10 bytes** with C# 6's [null-coalescing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) and [conditional](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) operators, also unnecessary `{}` when using just one statement in the `for` loop: `for(var a="";;a=Console.ReadLine())Console.WriteLine(new Regex(@"^[Vv]ro*m!$").Match(a??"").Success?a.Count(x =>x=='o'):-1);`

Comment: Also, this needs `using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`, not sure if this is important lol

Comment: The code you provided doesn't actually work, as it will not only output a `-1` for every line that it doesn't work on, but it will output `-1`s forever as there is no check for `null`.

Comment: No, it won't. `a = Console.ReadLine()` makes the loop, so each time you're requesting input for the loop to go on, if there is no input, the loop is just waiting, not printing `-1` forever

Comment: [Proof of concept.](https://tio.run/##XY5PSwMxEMXvfoppEJoIXfDaEFcp3uzFSj2IwpCONbCb0Ux2jZR@9m0QhOK7vR@8P14WnhNNg4S4h82PZOotnLvmIcSvf@iJSm4eaT90mO7LZyKRwFHshe9QBO7gAJIxBw8jhx2sMURt4DC9c9IjJkCnlLXoVjXEHdUq3NUZ0sb8oecUMv2ySN9Qt6joW/X2sh1fE1/1s0tlmjVm/6GxbVU1m8H7@qPFZsVDzLqAuynOzXlulotrY6fjcdomPlc/OwE "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online") Even if it did work as you said, a never-ending loop is not ideal behavior.

Regardless, I've moved the null check into the for loop, which removes the brackets (and makes the code shorter than your suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 21 bytes

```
a~,`^[Vv]r(o*)m!$`#$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/sU4nIS46rCy2SCNfSzNXUSVBWcXw////YUW5ivn5@VxlQfn5uYpcZUVADpABAA)

Match regex `^[Vv]r(o*)m!$` in multiline mode; output length of capture group.

Answer (score 0):

### C++, MSVC, <s>164</s> 159 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to Zacharý

It compiles even with the `regex` header only

```cpp
#include<regex>
using namespace std;int f(vector<string>i){smatch m;for(auto&e:i)if(regex_match(e,m,regex("^[Vv]ro*m!$")))return m[0].str().size()-4;return-1;}
```

Tests :

```cpp
std::cout << "Vrom!" << " -> " << f({ "Vrom!" }) << '\n';
std::cout << "vrooooooom!" << " -> " << f({ "vrooooooom!" }) << '\n';
std::cout << "Hello, Vroom!" << " -> " << f({ "Hello, Vroom!" }) << '\n';
std::cout << "Foo bar boo baz \\n Vrooom! \\n hi" << " -> " << f({ "Foo bar boo baz", "Vrooom!", "hi" }) << '\n';
std::cout << "Vrm!ooo" << " -> " << f({ "Vrm!ooo" }) << '\n';
std::cout << "PPCG puzzlers pie" << " -> " << f({ "PPCG puzzlers pie" }) << '\n';
std::cout << "hallo \\n vROOOm!" << " -> " << f({ "hallo", "vROOOm!" }) << '\n';
```

Comment: I think `using namespace std;` would save a few bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [sfk](http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html), 94 bytes

```
xex -i -case "_[lstart][char of Vv]r[chars of o]m![lend]_[part 4]o_" +linelen +calc "#text-1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsMgEEX3OcWPXQYXhZ6hR8hGBjF2QqQmU1SC9PLWZvV4j8/P67u1yhU6QHuXGcqamItLhYzfXIKsmE9Kl@S/Ce2jiXy8yJpP3@FBYhWmGA7uGZN30UPdCtei7wqtPUWw9Kvl4neYk@zjsIUf)

Gives `-1` when you're not vrooming.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, <strike>90</strike> <strike>73</strike> 61 bytes

```
_=>_.replace(/^[Vv]r(o*)m!$|[^\1]/mg,(m,a)=>a||'').length||-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLCoMwEEX3fkWEgknxgR9gN4V2qXThxvqINj5K4ki0UiT/bq2IeDcz99yZ@6Yj7QvZdIPVwovNpTen3iW1Jes4LRh2kigcY4nhTIR@UlHydGNHVCYWJiXehSplGMTmrK2GWinLnQtoe@DM5lDhEmejhIOE/tUWIvSMmGhJw8O@X@7kBoByKlG@zkkL5ZpqdbO/C31BmwuC6x11n2niTPaoa9jGa8o5aOPD9/1/NZl/)

Replace characters that are not captured at `(o*)` with empty string, return `length` of string containing only `"o"` or `-1` if resulting string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>28</s> 29 bytes

```ruby
p$_[/^[vV]r(o*)m!$/].count ?o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AlPlo/LrosLLZII19LM1dRRT9WLzm/NK9EwT7///@wovxcRa6yIjCRnw/ieKTm5OTrKIC4QF5YkL@v4r/8gpLM/Lzi/7p5AA)

Multi-line strings require three more bytes. I'm not sure if that's a hard requirement. If so, I'll update this.

```ruby
->l{l[/^[Vv]r(o*)m!$/].count ?o}
```

Comment: How can you test multi-line strings?

Comment: Fail on `VROM!`

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 104 bytes

```
func[s][n:""if parse/case s[opt[thru"^/"]["V"|"v"]"r"copy n any"o""m!"opt["^/"to end]][print length? n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY0xb4MwFIR3/4rHzY2yZ@lQKc1GlIHFciUHngsS2NazQQptfzuBZkxuueG@uxNulgs32ih3WNzoa52M9gegcxStJN7XNjElHWLWuZURX3sYjQq/mGAgqEO8kSfrbwjAUGAjNyoHYt8Yo6N0PlPP/ju37@SNWRwRJgkPrRX1QLDbBOUIJ@778EaVvM5/jiHQ1Qpd/31WG7iSqu3@nscqGYo1Bj3vtHb9UdOlLMuheFE9nz8@KY7z3LMkih1DLXc)

A straightforward solution. Red's `parse` is cool and readable, but too long compared to regex

```
Red []
f: func [ s ] [
    n: ""
    if parse/case s [
             opt [ thru newline ]
             [ "V" | "v" ]
             "r"
             copy n any "o"
             "m!"
             opt [ newline to end ]
    ] [ print length? n ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 35  bytes

```
(]{~0<{.)(1{'^[Vv]r(o*)m!'rxmatch])
```

Returns negative 1 if the pattern doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 32 bytes

```
->n{n=~/^[Vv]r(o*)m!$/m;$1.size}
```

Matches the string to the regex, then uses Ruby's magic regex group variables to get the first group's size.

Call it like so:

```
x=->n{n=~/^[Vv]r(o*)m!$/m;$1.size}
x["Vrooooooooooooooooooooom!"] # returns 21
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 90 bytes

```clj
#(do(def a(clojure.string/replace % #"(?ms).*^[Vv]r(o*)m!$.*""$1"))(if(= a %)-1(count a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchBCoAgEADAr2ymsCtk@IDoF12iQNSiqAy1vm@H5jj2CPsTfSk1uoDOL2DQ/qdSjtu1ttHfh7EeBNQM@zORkvM4vFPEIOmsuJKMcc2IcFuwAwOCGo02PFcGQ0SlfA)

This anonymous function returns the number of "o"s in the vroom string, or -1 if there is no valid vroom string.

#### Readable version

```clj
(fn [s]
  (def a (clojure.string/replace s #"(?ms).*^[Vv]r(o*)m!$.*" "$1"))
  (if (= a s) -1 (count a)))
```

#### Explanation

```clj
#"(?ms).*^[Vv]r(o*)m!$.*" ; This regex matches any string that contains a valid vroom string. The first capturing group contains only the "o"s in the vroom string
(clojure.string/replace s #"(?ms).*^[Vv]r(o*)m!$.*" "$1") ; Replaces a match of the above regex with its first capturing group. The resulting string is stored in the variable a
(if (= a s) -1 (count a))) ; a equals s if and only if there is no valid vroom string, so if a equal s we return -1. If there is a valid vroom string, a contains only the "o"s from the vroom string, so we return the length of a
```

Answer (score 0):

## perl -nE, 35 bytes

```
$s=length$1if/^[Vv]r(o*)m!$/}{say$s
```

This uses the *Eskimo greeting* (`}{`) which abuses the a quick on how the `-n` option is dealt with by perl.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 109 bytes

```java
s->{int r=-1;for(var l:s.split("\n"))r=l.matches("[Vv]ro*m\\!")?l.replaceAll("[^o]","").length():r;return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lVA9b8IwEN35FYenuIJIXYloVVVquxRQkbIQKjnBEFPHjs4moqD89vQSGLpUpB5s@fye38deVGK833w1mRbOwbtQ5jwAUMZL3IpMwqy9dgPIgqVHZXbgeETDekCb88KrDGZgYNq48cO5BeJ0fB9tLQaVQNATF7pSKx@wxDDOcarDQvgsly5gq7hao70rkmTI@KMOUZaaVJ@0prdPu2Yjxniopdn5POATjFD6AxrAqG6iVr88pJr0rzYqqzZQUIar09UaBL8EWH47L4vQHnxY0pPXJjBhFrAYbUHaXaK/URXay@qBfZNa2xHQx33QL9ZCSjWl3XlKTMsjYmJydZMcYzEk9E3cYvH8SlWdTlqig1LJm4xcUIjEVB/z@bxHiiNBsTV97OFZ/Kfwa@udQJ8@4@p37/Wgbn4A)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                             // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  int r=-1;                      //  Result-integer, starting at -1
  for(var l:s.split("\n"))       //  Loop over the lines:
    r=l.matches("[Vv]ro*m\\!")?  //   If the current line matches the regex:
       l.replaceAll("[^o]","").length()
                                 //    Change `r` to the amount of "o"'s in it
      :                          //   Else:
       r;                        //    Leave the result `r` unchanged
  return r;}                     //  Return the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>39</s> 37 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
|ʒć„VvsåsÁÁD…m!rÅ?s¦¦¦Ù'oså)P}Dgi`'o¢
```

Although 05AB1E is a golfing languages, regex-based challenges are definitely not its strong suite, since it has no regex-builtins.

Outputs `[]` if no match was found.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/5tSkI@2PGuaFlRUfXlp8uPFwo8ujhmW5ikWHW@2LDy0DwcMz1fOBkpoBtS7pmQnq@YcW/f/vlp@vkJRYpJAEpqu4yoryE0EwVxHIBOrOBzPygQDICCtKTATLBPn7KnJlZAIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/U5OOtD9qmBdWVnx4afHhxsONLo8aluUqFh1utS8@tAwED89UzwdKagbUuqRnJqjnH1r0v1bnf3S0UlhRfq6iUqyOQrRSWVE@BMAEPFJzcvJ1FIBK4EJu@fkKSYlFCklgukpJB2QAWFpHKSMToiasKFcRKAbhBAQ4uysUlFZV5aQWFSsUZKZChDMSgUYD9ZQF@fv7@8IdgNsaoOMSQRBsE0hhUT6UmQ@zP6woMREqHwQyE@EiuPrYWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
|              # Get the input split by newlines
 ʒ             # Filter it by:
  ć            #  Head extracted: Pop and push the remainder and head-character
               #   i.e. "vrm!" → "rm!" and "v"
               #   i.e. "Vroaom!" → "roaom!" and "V"
   „Vvså       #  Is this head character in the string "Vv"?
               #   i.e. "v" → 1 (truthy)
               #   i.e. "V" → 1 (truthy)
  s            #  Swap so the remainder is at the top of the stack again
   ÁÁ          #  Rotate it twice to the right
               #   i.e. "rm!" → "m!r"
               #   i.e. "roaom!" → "m!roao"
     D         #  Duplicate it
      …m!rÅ?   #  Does the rotated remainder start with "m!r"?
               #   i.e. "m!r" → 1 (truthy)
               #   i.e. "m!roao" → 1 (truthy)
  s¦¦¦         #  Remove the first three characters from the duplicated rotated remainder
               #   i.e. "m!r" → ""
               #   i.e. "m!roao" → "oao"
      Ù        #  Uniquify, leaving only distinct characters
               #   i.e. "" → ""
               #   i.e. "oao" → "oa"
       'oså   '#  Is this uniquified string in the string "o"?
               #   i.e. "" → 1 (truthy)
               #   i.e. "oa" → 0 (falsey)
  )P           #  Check if all three checks above are truthy
               #   i.e. [1,1,1] → 1 (truthy)
               #   i.e. [1,1,0] → 0 (falsey)
 }             # Close the filter
  D            # After the filter, duplicate the list
   gi          # If its length is 1:
               #   i.e. ["vrm!"] → 1 (truthy)
               #   i.e. [] → 0 (falsey)
     `         #  Push the value in this list to the stack
               #   i.e. ["vrm!"] → "vrm!"
      'o¢     '#  And count the amount of "o" in it (and output implicitly)
               #   i.e. "vrm!" → 0
               # (Implicit else:)
               #  (Implicitly output the duplicated empty list)
               #   i.e. []
```

Answer (score 0):

### 16-bit x86 assembly code, 35 bytes

```
l1: lodsb          ;fetch a byte
    cbw            ;zero AH to allow returning 0
    cwd            ;zero counter
l2: and   al, 0dfh ;lower- to upper-case
    je    l4       ;exit if end of string
    cmp   al, 'V'
    jne   l1
    lodsb          ;fetch a byte
    cmp   al, 'r'
    jne   l2       ;if not 'r', branch to try 'v' or 'V' instead
l3: lodsb          ;fetch a byte
    test  al, al
    je    l4       ;exit if end of string
    inc   dx       ;speculatively count 'o's
    cmp   al, 'o'
    je    l3       ;loop while 'o'
    lodsw          ;fetch two bytes
    dec   si       ;align pointer as though only one byte fetched
                   ;in case of mismatch at the end
    cmp   ax, '!m' ;Intel backwards ordering
    jne   l2       ;loop while not matching complete string
    xchg  dx, ax   ;return count only if match
l4: ret
```

Accepts a pointer to the string in si, returns the count (or 0) in ax.

Comment: Can't tell `vrm!` from `foo`?

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 55 bytes

```
{Regex("^[Vv]ro*m!\$").find(it)?.value?.count{it=='o'}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7NCoMwEITvPsUaCiaF@gBCmnOhpxa89AekRlmqGwmrFCTPnkbnNswM33wdD0hxaQZYvHNjBfLOHqlXcDrDhdiAjuvN9vYnxftRLy/vjmP@PAhVdkitRFamTPPZmvLjZuIVWevCFSHEbiYYGySpYM0gacMgTaDB26a9ItkUmQqE2OMpgVnuP2SqKZWFWG8u/wM)