# Tips for golfing in Dart

Tags: code-golf, tips

[Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/) is an object oriented programming language borrowing from both Java and Javascript. What general tips do you have for golfing in Dart? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to Dart (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

If a tip is similar to Java/JS, please link to the answer in the original language's thread as well if you can.

Taken mostly from [Joey's Tips for Powershell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/191/64722)

Answer (score 3):

**Variable declaration**

Regular variable declaration takes 4 bytes (`var`) + 2 bytes/variable (`i,`).
You can declare variables as optional named parameters for your function and shave a few bytes.

```
f(){var i,j,k;} //Takes 15 bytes
g({i,j,k}){}  //Takes 12 bytes
```

Note: This doesn't work for non-constant values, for example:

```
f({i=List}){}  //Works
g({i=[]}){}  //Doesn't work

f({i=0,j=0}){}  //Works
g({i=0,j=i}){}  //Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3):

**Implicit parameter passing**

In some cases where Dart expects a function to be declared, you can code the function elsewhere, and then just pass its name. Dart will take care of passing the value automatically. Let me illustrate :

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5].forEach((i) => print(i)); //Using a lambda
[0,1,2,3,4,5].forEach(print); //Using implicit parameter passing since print() expects a similar parameter
```

You can also use your own functions

```
f(List i){
    i.forEach(print); //Prints each number on a new line
}

[[0,1], [1,2]].forEach(f); //Prints 0 \n 1 \n 1 \n 2\n
```

If you know a lambda might be used in multiple places, for example a `map()`, it can be useful to make it its own function and pass it that way instead of declaring it multiple times.

Comment: Is this not just a consequence of first-class functions? (I don't know Dart)

Comment: Looks like it's the case. I didn't know this was more widely spread https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#functions-as-first-class-objects

Answer (score 2):

**String conversion and concatenation**

Dart doesn't allow for concatenation for types other than String and doesn't implicitly convert to String like C# does for example.

It however includes a very useful way to concatenate variables without needing to use any addition operator or explicitly casting to String (using the `.toString()` method).

```
var i=0,j=1,k=2;
var s0='$j'; //'1'
var s1='$i$j$k'; //'012'
var s2='i=$i'; //'i=0'
```

You can also perform operations directly in the `${}` section and save a few temporary variable declarations.

```
var i=0,j=1,k=2;
var s='${i+j+k}'; //'3'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Creating range of consecutive integers**

If you want to create a list of integers from start and end values, you can use below options:

```dart
final int s = 0; // start value
final int e = 5; // end value

List.generate(e-s,(i)=>i+s);  // 28 bytes
List.generate(e,(i)=>i);      // 24 bytes, if start is guaranteed to be zero
[for(int i=s;i<e;i++)i];      // 24 bytes
[for(int i=s;i<e;]i++];       // 23 bytes
[for(int i=s;i<e;]++i];       // 23 bytes, if start is exclusive
[for(;s<e;)s++];              // 16 bytes, if start can be changed in-place
```

Answer (score 0):

**Return inside loops**

Let's suppose in your code there is a return inside a loop. You can use the following idiom to reduce bytes:

```dart
// indexOf method
f(v,x,[i=0]){for(;i<v.length;i++)if(v[i]==x)return i;return-1;}   // 63 bytes
f(v,x)=>([i=0]){for(;i<v.length;i++)if(v[i]==x)return i;}()??-1;  // 64 bytes
f(v,x)=>(i){for(;i<v.length;i++)if(v[i]==x)return i;}(0)??-1;     // 61 bytes
```

The more variables to be initialized, the more bytes can be reduced.

```dart
// "index of integral"
g(v,x,[s=0,i=0]){for(;i<v.length;i++){s+=v[i];if(s>=x)return i;}return-1};  // 74 bytes
g(v,x)=>(s,i){for(;i<v.length;i++){s+=v[i];if(s>=x)return i;}(0,0)??-1;     // 71 bytes
```