# Count rotary dial pulses in a phone number (including letters)

Tags: code-golf, number

In your grandparents' day, dialing a phone number was done with a [rotary dial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_dial) like this:

[image]

To dial each digit, put your finger in the corresponding hole, pull it over to the finger stop, and release it.  A mechanism will cause the dial to spin back to its resting position, and the phone will disconnect and reconnect a circuit a specified number of times, making audible clicks.

Dialing the digit *N* requires *N* such “pulses”, except for N=0 which is ten pulses.

Rotary phones have the property that large digits (8, 9, 0) take longer to dial than small digits (1, 2, 3).  This was an important consideration in drawing up early area code maps, and why New York City with its heavy population (and phone line) density got [212](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_codes_212,_646,_and_332) (only 5 pulses), while while [907](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_code_907) (26 pulses) went to sparsely-inhabited Alaska.  Of course, this all became irrelevant when touch-tone dialing became popular.

## The challenge

Write, in as few bytes as possible, a program or function that takes as input a string (or sequence of characters) containing a telephone number, and outputs its number of rotary dial pulses.  These are to be counted as follows:

### Digits

- Digits 1-9 count as that number of pulses.
- Digit 0 counts as 10 pulses.

### Letters

Note that digits 2-9 on the dial have letters of the Latin alphabet associated with them.  These were originally intended for [named exchanges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_exchange_names), but were latter re-appropriated for [phonewords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneword), and for text message input systems.

You must support having letters in your phone numbers, using the [E.161](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.161) assignment of letters to digits:

- A, B, C = 2
- D, E, F = 3
- G, H, I = 4
- J, K, L = 5
- M, N, O = 6
- P, Q, R, S = 7
- T, U, V = 8
- W, X, Y, Z = 9

You may assume that the input has already been case-folded, to either upper or lower case.

### Other characters

You **must** allow arbitrary use of the characters `()+-./` and space as formatting separators.  You **may** chose to allow *any* non-alphanumeric character for this purpose, if it's easier to implement.

These characters do not contribute to the pulse count.

## Example code

A non-golfed lookup table and function in Python:

```
PULSES = {
    '1': 1,
    '2': 2, 'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2,
    '3': 3, 'D': 3, 'E': 3, 'F': 3,
    '4': 4, 'G': 4, 'H': 4, 'I': 4,
    '5': 5, 'J': 5, 'K': 5, 'L': 5,
    '6': 6, 'M': 6, 'N': 6, 'O': 6,
    '7': 7, 'P': 7, 'Q': 7, 'R': 7, 'S': 7,
    '8': 8, 'T': 8, 'U': 8, 'V': 8,
    '9': 9, 'W': 9, 'X': 9, 'Y': 9, 'Z': 9,
    '0': 10
}

def pulse_count(phone_num):
    return sum(PULSES.get(digit, 0) for digit in phone_num)
```

## Example input and output

- `911` → 11
- `867-5309` → 48
- `713 555 0123` → 42
- `+1 (212) PE6-5000` → 57
- `1-800-FLOWERS` → 69
- `PUZZLES` → 48

Comment: I assume that the *Arbitrary ASCII punctuation and spaces* are restricted to those normally used for phone numbers (`+- ()*#.`) just like letters are restricted to uppercase. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Adám: I've restricted the required punctuation marks to just a few common separators.  It deliberately does not include `*` and `#`, which have special meanings on touch-tone phones and are not dialable on rotaries.

Comment: Can we use all-lowercase input instead of all-uppercase? Can we take an array of chars instead of a string?

Comment: @Grimy: Sure.  I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm a time traveller! I'm a time traveller! I'm a time traveller! Since I definitely used phones like this when I was a kid, clearly I AM MY OWN GRANDFATHER!!!!!!! Which is actually pretty icky when I think about it. Bleah!!!

Comment: I'm the grandfather.  I used phones like this in the 1950s.  And when I moved to a town in a rural location, I discovered that the phone company did not offer touch-tone service.  This was in 1985!  No kidding!  My grandmother had a phone in the parlor that had a hook and a crank.  You took the earpiece off the hook, and turned the crank to obtain a switchboard operator.  She had to replace it when direct distance dialing was set up.

Comment: Since `Z` seems to be special cased in many of the answers, a test case containing it might be useful.

Comment: Ha! I used dial numbers by hitting the disconnect button as fast as I can, sometimes it worked great

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
AÁ0ªā6+žq÷9š‡þO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8XCjwaFVRxrNtI/uKzy83fLowkcNCw/v8///P1pJW0lHQckQRCiACA0QYQQXA7M04bIFICIVRJiBCF0QYQoiDJCIWAA)

This is the first answer to use π. Why use π, you might ask? Well, the letters are associated with 22233344455566677778889999, in order. Notice how most digits repeat 3 times, but 7 repeats 4 times. You could say that each digit repeats (3+1/7) times, on average. I wonder if there’s any number that’s approximately 3+1/7 and takes fewer bytes than 22/7…

This only gives 4 7s, not 4 9s, so we still need to handle Z as a special case.

```
A               # alphabet (abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)
 Á              # rotate right (zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy)
  0ª            # append 0 (zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0)

ā6+             # range [7..33]
   žq÷          # divide by π (22233344455566677778889991010)
      9š        # prepend 9 (922233344455566677778889991010)

‡               # transliterate the implicit input with the two lists above
                # this replaces z → 9, a → 2, … y → 9, 0 → 10
 þ              # remove all non-digits
  O             # sum
```

Comment: Why lowercase instead of uppercase?

Comment: @dan04 because 05AB1E has a built-in to push `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`, but not for `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`. I could convert the alphabet to uppercase rather than convert the input to lowercase, but that’s the same bytecount.

Comment: I've edited the question to make your first two commands unnecessary.

Comment: How did you figure out the pi trick?

Comment: @Jonah I started with the idea of dividing a range by a constant to get the desired sequence, then while looking for the best way to express "slightly more than 3" in 05AB1E I remembered pi was a built-in.

Answer (score 9):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 51 bytes

```cs
n=>n.Sum(x=>x>64?(x-59-x/83-x/90)/3:x>47?1-~x%~9:0)
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to @recursive

Saved 10 bytes thanks to @ExpiredData's observation that only `() +-/.` will be in the input

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrpOZV2KXZvs/z9YuTy@4NFejwtauws7MxF6jQtfUUrdC38IYSFgaaOobW1XYmZjbG@rWVajWWVoZaP635govyixJ9cnMS9VI01Ay1LUwMNB18/EPdw0KVtLURJO2NDQECf4HAA)

```cs
n =>                     // Function taking input as string
  n.Sum(x =>             // Map each value 'x' through the following
    x>64 ?               //   If 'x' is an uppercase letter
      (x-59-x/83-x/90)/3 //     Take each char's ASCII value subtracted by 59, and subtract
                         //     one if the char is 'S' and one if the char is 'Z'
    : x>47 ?             //   Else if the char is a digit
      1-~x%~9            //   Take 1 - (-x - 1) % -10 (Maps 0 to 10, and 1-9 to themselves
    : 0                  //   Else, 0
  )                      // And sum it all up, then return it
```

Comment: `-10` is `~9`, which should work in context.

Comment: @recursive That's smart, thanks

Comment: x<91 check is redundant since the input will only consist of ()+-./ the space key and numbers which are all < 64 hence we can determine if the character is uppercase simply by checking x>64 (so -5 bytes)

Comment: Same goes for the x<58 check, since nothing in the range 58-64 will be in the input

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrpOZV2KXZvs/z9YuTy@4NFejwtauws7MxF6jQtfUUrdC38IYSFgaaOobW1XYmZjbG@rWVajWWVoZaP635govyixJ9cnMS9VI01Ay1LUwMNB18/EPdw0KVtLURJO2NDQECf4HAA "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 74 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum([(n-59-n/83-n/90)/3,1-~n%~9][n<58]for n in map(ord,s)if n>47)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYhPC4IwHEDvfYofQrBBw801dVLd7BQUdYgwD4YNB/pz@Ifo4lc3uzzee@47VC0Gs9k/57poXmUBfdKPDckIMqUZ@rFcoDn15UawCdeTzjPcqTg3bQcIFqEpHGm7ctNTawAP24jOn8rWbxCJ6ywOYIhFNw6E0tnTQngrLw4jpiTXi0ZCglIKuAjkkgJIIAIKlzRkinP@XyzmnB1P53t6vS398H4)

Does some arithmetic on the ASCII value for each character. The first option checks for letters and the second options checks for numbers. The clarification that all punctuation characters allowed in the input are ones with ASCII values less than 48 let me simplify the logic, but a new method altogether might now be better.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 84 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum(1+'1xxxx2ABCx3DEFx4GHIx5JKLx6MNOx7PQRS8TUVx9WXYZ0'.find(c)/5for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYjJDoIwFADvfsULF9sYtK9YFhMPLrgrCu7x4kZsopUIxvr1iHOameSb3Z6K53HzkN@Pj9PlCGkjfT8IVsqoC3ir3dFW1@/pen8w1GI0nmh7Ogu0M1@EkbtcrbW32e72rFyNpbqQM62J@PmCM0gFKc0/N3m/AjaSl1QZxESq5J0RSnPDQzRKhms7prCYV6iDFgghgCG3ikQgHDmFuW@bgjH2X6bLmNmbBBs/jIwf)

Uses a hardcoded lookup string, with each block of 5 characters corresponding to the characters giving each value starting with 1. Blank spaces are filled with `x`, which can't be in the input which is capitalized. Fortuitously, characters not appearing in the string produce `-1` for the `.find` which gives a summand of zero.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), ... <s>76</s> 69 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/\w/g,q=>w+=1/q?+q||10:parseInt(q,35)*.32-1|0||9,w=0)&&w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1LSwMxFIX3/orQRUnMZPIymURJRbAWQdqiiA/cDGNalGFeKc4m/306bnXK5ZzF@T643/lPHoruqzmQqv70w84NwS1C2vmmzAsP6UdP90nrFj12nLbXuI2Rs8sm74K/rw6wTaRC56kUhEcWo016x9B83g9XRV2FuvRpWe/hDs4s5zOEzv7ORmdESWanWMYlUEoBxoWc4pgDKLhAYLvURDHGpiRODGPk7mHzsnx8Oi28vr3/wv8/jAYw0xaB2816RVbP6c2ajiagFBiscTbGYjm2xhfjGSywdpkajg)

-7 thanks @Arnauld!

#### Explanation

```javascript
 q |     1/q     |  +q  | parseInt(q,35)*.32 | parseInt(q,35)*.32-1|0 | Output
---+-------------+------+--------------------+------------------------+--------
 0 | Infinity(T) | 0(F) |         N/A        |           N/A          |   10
 1 |  1.0000(T)  | 1(T) |         N/A        |           N/A          |    1
 2 |  0.5000(T)  | 2(T) |         N/A        |           N/A          |    2
 3 |  0.3333(T)  | 3(T) |         N/A        |           N/A          |    3
 4 |  0.2500(T)  | 4(T) |         N/A        |           N/A          |    4
 5 |  0.2000(T)  | 5(T) |         N/A        |           N/A          |    5
 6 |  0.1666(T)  | 6(T) |         N/A        |           N/A          |    6
 7 |  0.1428(T)  | 7(T) |         N/A        |           N/A          |    7
 8 |  0.1250(T)  | 8(T) |         N/A        |           N/A          |    8
 9 |  0.1111(T)  | 9(T) |         N/A        |           N/A          |    9
 A |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        3.20        |          2(T)          |    2
 B |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        3.52        |          2(T)          |    2
 C |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        3.84        |          2(T)          |    2
 D |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        4.16        |          3(T)          |    3
 E |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        4.48        |          3(T)          |    3
 F |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        4.80        |          3(T)          |    3
 G |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        5.12        |          4(T)          |    4
 H |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        5.44        |          4(T)          |    4
 I |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        5.76        |          4(T)          |    4
 J |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        6.08        |          5(T)          |    5
 K |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        6.40        |          5(T)          |    5
 L |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        6.72        |          5(T)          |    5
 M |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        7.04        |          6(T)          |    6
 N |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        7.36        |          6(T)          |    6
 O |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        7.68        |          6(T)          |    6
 P |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        8.00        |          7(T)          |    7
 Q |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        8.32        |          7(T)          |    7
 R |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        8.64        |          7(T)          |    7
 S |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        8.96        |          7(T)          |    7
 T |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        9.28        |          8(T)          |    8
 U |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        9.60        |          8(T)          |    8
 V |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |        9.92        |          8(T)          |    8
 W |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |       10.24        |          9(T)          |    9
 X |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |       10.56        |          9(T)          |    9
 Y |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |       10.88        |          9(T)          |    9
 Z |    NaN(F)   |  N/A |         NaN        |          0(F)          |    9
```

All of `[space]().+-/` are not captured by `/\w/g`, so they won't affect the total.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>52</s> 51 bytes

*@Grimy gets credit for -1*

```perl
y/A-Z/22233344455566677778889/;map$\+=$_||10,/./g}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79S31E3St/IyMjY2NjExMTU1NTMzMwcCCwsLCz1rXMTC1RitG1V4mtqDA109PX002ur//@PMtQ1NPiXX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNDgv24BAA)

Comment: `/\d/g` should be `/./g` for -1 (yes it still handles punctuation correctly).

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 27 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
+/'@ADGJMPTW'∘⍸+11|(1⌽⎕D)∘⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X1tf3cHRxd3LNyAkXP1Rx4xHvTu0DQ1rNAwf9ex91DfVRRMstvl/2qO2CY96@4BCnv6PupoPrTd@1DYRyAsOcgaSIR6ewf/TFNQtDQ3VuYC0hZm5rqmxgSWYY25orGBqaqpgYGhkDBbQNlTQMDI00lQIcDXTNTUwMACLGupaGBjouvn4h7sGBasDAA)

`(`…`)∘⍳` find the **ɩ**ndex* of each character in the following string:
  <sup>* elements that are not found, get the index 1+the maximum index, i.e. 11</sup>
 `⎕D` the digits: `"0123456789"`

`1⌽` cyclically rotate one step left; `"1234567890"`

`11|` division remainder when divided by 11*
  <sup>* this gives 0 for all non-digits</sup>
…`+` add that to the following:

`'@ADGJMPTW'∘⍸` the **ɩ**nterval **ɩ**ndex* for each character
  <sup>* So [−∞,"@") gives 0, ["@","A") gives 1, ["A","D") gives 2, etc.</sup>
`+/` sum that

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 39 bytes

```
1#.'?@CFILOSVZ'&I.+11|1+'1234567890'i.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBC4JAFAbv/oqPgl5iu7yn7boKUhAKgmAkFASdoqW6dPBav33rlMeZgXkGP1YajBIcZK5ps901bdcPxzMtWp2IvCUhSbO1sbkrmB76EuJopkG@0oQVPiX8GEW36/0FDypE6A/O5spkXEwmlwzGGPBvOdlEsEwljbGvrTLMPCVRjlk1XX@qDwOFLw)

A port of [Adám's APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185999/75681)

Comment: Nice use of interval index

Comment: @Jonah Thanks to Adam :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 34 bytes

```
T`WTPMJGDA`Rd
}T`L`2L
0
55
\d
$*
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qoeGe8D8kITwkwNfL3cUxISiFqzYkwSfByIfLgMvUlCsmhUtFi8vw/39LQ0MuCzNzXVNjA0suc0NjBVNTUwUDQyNjLm1DBQ0jQyNNhQBXM11TAwMDLkNdCwMDXTcf/3DXoGAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`WTPMJGDA`Rd
```

Convert the letters `WTPMJGDA` to the digits `9..0`.

```
}T`L`2L
```

Shuffle all the remaining letters down by 1 and repeat until all of the letters have been converted to digits.

```
0
55
```

Replace `0` with `55` as they take the same number of pulses to dial.

```
\d
$*
1
```

Take the digital sum.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>94</strike> <strike>89</strike> <strike>86</strike> 80 bytes

Thanks to ceilingcat, nwellnhof and Rogem for the suggestions.

```c
c;f(char*s){c=*s-48;s=*s?(c<10U?c?c:10:c-17<26U?(c-11-c/35-c/42)/3:0)+f(s+1):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc/PS8MwFAfw@/6KR2GQNA3La9cfa1qHh3kSFGV4mDuUB60BrdLIPIz@68ZkePDgJe@bvPB5CcmByDnSPaOXbootP1MbW7mutPV1y6hBtd/SlmpUNUksm7TY@2OJKGmV5X5Zp3yV1YqLnlmBvFZ6dmb8hLfOjCyEbhoogeBDHPvNicN5ARBaRi986t8nZlqlQQjThNuaw8fk@z2LlhbaK1ia5zFKgnQ6mGMCPfuNnF@EC24PR2ghuo70X9MI4d8cbP@7y2D4H7eBtQEEmBezcxtEVxWlzDO1cSVmkOc5KEwzJxBYiimH@10hc6WUQ1kpJW9u7552D4/f1L92g3Xy6wc)

Comment: [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc/PS8MwFAfw@/6KR2GQNA3La9cfa1qHh3kSFGV4mDuUB60BrdLIPIz@68ZkePDgJe@bvPB5CcmByDnSPaOXbootP1MbW7mutPV1y6hBtd/SlmpUNUksm7TY@2OJKGmV5X5Zp3yV1YqLnlmBvFZ6dmb8hLfOjCyEbhoogeBDHPvNicN5ARBaRi986t8nZlqlQQjThNuaw8fk@z2LlhbaK1ia5zFKgnQ6mGMCPfuNnF@EC24PR2ghuo70X9MI4d8cbP@7y2D4H7eBtQEEmBezcxtEVxWlzDO1cSVmkOc5KEwzJxBYiimH@10hc6WUQ1kpJW9u7552D4/f1L92g3Xy6wc) by using recursion instead of a loop.

Comment: Suggest `c<43U` instead of `c-17<26U`

Answer (score 3):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download), 44 bytes

**Solution:**

```
+/(1+(1+&(5#3),4 3 4),!10)(.Q.A,1_.Q.n,"0")?
```

**Examples:**

```
q)k)+/(1+(1+&(5#3),4 3 4),!10)(.Q.A,1_.Q.n,"0")?"911"
11
q)k)+/(1+(1+&(5#3),4 3 4),!10)(.Q.A,1_.Q.n,"0")?"867-5309"
48
q)k)+/(1+(1+&(5#3),4 3 4),!10)(.Q.A,1_.Q.n,"0")?"+1 (212) PE6-5000"
57
q)k)+/(1+(1+&(5#3),4 3 4),!10)(.Q.A,1_.Q.n,"0")?"1-800-FLOWERS"
69
```

**Explanation:**

Naive approach, likely pretty golfable. Lookup index of character, lookup score, sum.

```
+/(1+(1+&(5#3),4 3 4),!10)(.Q.A,1_.Q.n,"0")? / the solution
                                           ? / lookup
                          (               )  / do this together
                                       "0"   / string "0"
                                      ,      / join with
                                  .Q.n       / string "0123456789"
                                1_           / drop first
                               ,             / join with
                           .Q.A              / "A..Z"
  (                      )                   / do this together
                      !10                    / range 0..9
                     ,                       / join with
     (              )                        / do this together
               4 3 4                         / list (4;3;4)
              ,                              / join with
         (5#3)                               / list (3;3;3;3;3)
        &                                    / where, creates list 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 etc
      1+                                     / add 1
   1+                                        / add 1
+/                                           / sum up
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 53 bytes

```perl6
{sum +<<m:g/\d/X||10}o{S:g[<:L>]=$/.ord*.313-28+|0+9}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxNC4JAFIXhvb/iItJo0@i9DmNqFrSolVDUougDCcw2iWG0CPW3T0y7857F87q3z0jXXxhVMNfd@1MDz7I6fQSXMjj2PeHQdPv0cc7SfHGdO4HftOXYlyRFGPMeeTLo9@0LlesUHlRNa7GEiE0sFkdToSQmZk9JglIKkEJpmhO4IYUebFeRUIhoThIxoljnm8Nqt2czy7C2U0D3twfb6MCWzPfZic30Dw)

Multiplies the ASCII code with 0.313 instead of 1/3 and uses bitwise OR which rounds to zero to get [the correct bias](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBKVlBQSEPiLX0jA2NFUBA18hCQbvGQEHbUsmaC6xGFw8AqknLL1JQd1TX01OPUleo5uIsKMrMK0nTUFItVlBQNUoBEmZ6xmkICixkmBKTp6SjoBKvw8XJqZdflKKjACLBzkBiAh2DygO6DENA21LTmqv2/38A).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>33</s> 24 bytes

```
7r32:ØP«9Ṿ€ØAżFyfØDV€o⁵S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUMAvP9qZWxsef//N3IzMjrDmFDCqznhub7igqzDmEHFvEZ5ZsOYRFbigqxv4oG1U//Dh8WS4bmY//8xLTgwMC1GTE9XRVJT)

A monadic link taking a string as its argument and returning the number of pulses. Rewritten inspired by [@Grimy’s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186035/42248) so be sure to upvote them!

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 256 bytes

You can replace the `(( … ))` constructs with `let` for identical byte count.  There may be a good algorithm to reduce the case statements but not found it so far. With a bit of rework you could make it a function also (but not in same or less bytes unless you can discount the `function fname { … }` top and tail).

```bash
read p;while ((${#p}>0));do case ${p:0:1} in ([1-9]) ((d+=${p:0:1}));; ([0]) ((d+=10));; ([ABC) ((d+=2));; ([P-S]) ((d+=7));; ([W-Z]) ((d+=9));;([DEF]) ((d+=3));; ([GHI]) ((d+=4));; ([JKL]) ((d+=5));; ([MNO]) ((d+=6));; (?) d=$d; esac;p=${p#?};done;echo $d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc9LC4JAFIbhfb/igC5mkIEzVnYZSrrYvZRaBEkLcwYMoiQXLcTfbkYz2@d7F@fckiKr67dKJOTik90fCgixSyuvxkipkC9Ik0KBXeZDHPIK7k8gMWeDK2066YzM0LSiWdA4Ry2T6UyTqyViJ1P1NJ3ZxdDgRySeBwsjbR0tV2tDHU2b7c5QV9P@EBry/uRTkCNbClBFkor8d7LlV81rTyVUmr3AlnXtcCAudylEgce6iNjirI/IFrvwHBxPXw)

A better solution using the map character technique makes use of the `tr` tool:

## [Bash with tr], 173 bytes

```bash
read p;p=$(echo $p|tr A-Z 22233344455566677778889999);while ((${#p}>0));do case ${p:0:1} in ([1-9]) ((d+=${p:0:1}));; ([0]) ((d+=10));; (?) d=$d; esac;p=${p#?}; done;echo $d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY69CsIwFEZ3n@KCGRJK4Cb9sW2oxUEnQdFBUBxqE6ggNrSCQ@2zx0jxG885w3er@sa5zlQarLIFoaZuWiD28@pgxc8gpQzDMIqiOI6TJFn4pWma@TH1bu4PA5SSYW7HJTKmdAt11Rsgg80xFyPcn0AvgmdX5jsdFH/hW@UN/rnAiZQMdEG0AtNX9e/PYOflqEC3T6Oma9q5QACVQjLYrxMeI@JM8BSRb7a70/pw/AI)

Comment: One algorithm I missed of course is to do some string replacement/translation on A-Z.  This would be good.  I will amend the above to suit.

Comment: `while((${#p}))` works, saving three bytes.  `c=${p:0:1};case c in ([0-9]) ((d+=c?c:10));;` saves another 16.  With `tr -dc 0-9` added to the tr pipeline you don't need a case statement at all and the addition can be folded into the `while` condition with `&&`.

Comment: Thanks OMG. I don't often use ternary assignment so I missed that.  Interesting use of delete complement as well (but that assumes like my solution ignore any other character).  I have managed to get it down to 133 bytes as in:

`read p;p=$(echo $p|tr A-Z 22233344455566677778889999|tr -dc [0-9]);while ((${#p}));do c=${p:0:1}&&((d+=c?c:10));p=${p#?};done;echo $d`

Comment: 118: `p=$(head -1|tr A-Z 22233344455566677778889|tr -dc 0-9);while((${#p}));do((d+=(c=${p:0:1})?c:10));p=${p#?};done;echo $d` .. the last three 9's are not needed because tr will reuse the last replacement character if the second argument is too short.

Comment: 99: read p;echo $p|tr A-Z 22233344455566677778889999|sed 's/[^0-9]//g;s/[1-9]/&+/g;s/0/10+/g;s/+$//'|bc

Comment: The first example can be stripped down from 256 to 236 by removing a few unnecessary spaces. `read p;while((${#p}>0));do case ${p:0:1} in ([1-9])((d+=${p:0:1}));;([0])((d+=10));;([ABC)((d+=2));;([P-S])((d+=7));;([W-Z])((d+=9));;([DEF])((d+=3));;([GHI])((d+=4));;([JKL])((d+=5));;([MNO])((d+=6));;(?)d=$d;esac;p=${p#?};done;echo $d`

Comment: Fair comment -- I decided not to do more golf on that one as the second approach was far better.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell),<strike>109</strike> <strike>102</strike> 87 bytes

```powershell
$(switch -r($args|% t*y){\d{$_}[A-Y]{("{0}"-f(.313*$_-18))[0]}[Z]{9}0{10}})-join'+'|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0WjuDyzJDlDQbdIQyWxKL24RlWhRKtSszompVolvjbaUTcytlpDqdqgVkk3TUPP2NBYSyVe19BCUzPaILY2Oiq22rLWoNrQoLZWUzcrPzNPXVu9JjO14v///@qGuhYGBrpuPv7hrkHB6gA)

EDIT: Used @mazzy's idea for a regex switch with some string formatting to cast char -> int -> string and grab only the first 'digit'

**Original:**

```powershell
[char[]]"$args"|%{$a+=(48,(('22233344455566677778889999')[$_-65],(58,$_)[$_-ne48])[$_-lt64])[$_-gt47]-=48};$a
```

I was hoping to get <100 bytes, so I'll keep looking at it to see if there is anything else I can do. There's probably a way to remove the number string

Sorry if this is confusing as I nested arrays with boolean indexing statements but -

**Explanation:**

`[char[]]"$args"|%{` reads the input casted as a string and then explodes it to a char array and begins a for-each loop with checking `()[$_-gt47]` to see if any `()+-./` was entered (all have ascii character values <48)
Note: Powershell accepts `$true` and `$false` as `1` and `0` respectively for array indices

Then we get either `48` for the symbols, or:
`('22233344455566677778889999'[$_-65],(58,$_)[$_-ne48])[$_-lt64]`

The `[$_-lt64]` checks for a number or a letter (all assumed capital here). If it's a letter, `'22233344455566677778889999'[$_-65]` changes it to 0-25 to index into the array and output the pulse value (as a char). If the character is a number, we instead look at: `(58,$_)[$_-ne48]` checking for `0` and outputting `58` or just the numeric char itself.

Around everything `$a+= ... -=48` initializes a numeric variable $a at `0` and then adds the output. The output is the ascii char value of a number, so subtract `48`.

Note: if the input was a symbol, we get `$a+=48-48`, effectively ignoring it. If it was `0`, we get `$a+=58-48` to obtain our +10

Lastly, `;$a` just outputs our final value post for-each loop

Comment: you could save a few bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcdBDoIwEEDRq7gY0qplQTtThhhPYhrSRYOLRgk0MQQ8@4j6V@@Pz1ea5nvKWQTiNMxbdSinZatWiOerRjZaWWudc4hIRN77do@Zuz11g772FIwmNtAfv/tIyOGnXDz@NRRsQ438vkAUEdU1jfoA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Ah, yeah I had some extra parentheses and the `=` in there, left over from my previous methods of solving this, thanks for the catch! Though, I haven't seen the `t*y` before, could you explain why that works to explode the string into a character array?

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/80745 and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168174/80745

Comment: to get '< 100 bytes': [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBRS8MwFIXf@ysuIzOpayBJmzQVBV/m08AxEWFzlLFFVyluNpVN2/z2mk3tefy@czlw97uDqezWlGWHXuAGmg4Reyjq9RZoRdCqerXtEOrLr7B53jQod4sV/V42WAgRx3GSJFJKpVTqo7XOfPAC5VTJJU20Yw1nzoX0bVe84xFuC3PsXBDckgB8IoIzznEEnIf/QKuUyphlnia6pymPwQ8B4yI@GdGbEQciuAhhOlZUMsa8lmmvOdWM0bvJ/dN49uCVyno1fZzPJ2MPTzshtDCE5uyQjQCZ496sa7PxL0H5L66M/SxrDy78p5A9wwEif5yaj/4ovOrb19RXB4HrfgA "PowerShell – Try It Online") :)

Comment: good idea with `-f` and `[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>95</s> <s>85</s> 79 bytes

*inspired by [nwellnhof's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186016/80745).*

*inspired by `[0]` from [Sinusoid's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186776/80745).*

```powershell
$(switch -r($args|% t*y){\d{$_}0{10}[A-Y]{"$(.313*$_-18)"[0]}Z{9}})-join'+'|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZFrT8IwFIa/71eckOJWupp2W3cxmog6vKEgiMiQEANTMERwmwEz9ttnHbrY99vzvL3kdLVch1E8CxeLHL3AEaQ50uL1PJnMgEYaeo5e420VktoXTp@mKRpnLOUsG9bpYJRWkLZvcrOGxpS7uDJkoyxIvSzD9G05f1eJup2HmzxTlGNNAbl0TfU4V3XgHP8B13aoMJknqeWW1OEmCCGAccP8MUZpCAfN4AaGtm9TwRiTWjil5tRljDaarb7f6Uple6Vq94Kg6Uv4756f8y1hO64H9ZPTM79xfnF5dd28uW217zrd@95D/3EQqLrGGeHEICaxiCA2cYhLPCBgEKOgZmGswoqiYRetXdwi3i4YKxi2UIW0eAOKdUDhZhVOknAqx4/GOxyF8ecikWBP/gqKCyjH/ctp@FFuwgdl@5DKakXJ8m8)

Unrolled version:

```powershell
$(
    switch -r($args|% toCharArray){
        \d    {$_}
        0     {10}
        [A-Y] {"$(.313*$_-18)"[0]}
        Z     {9}
    }
)-join '+'|Invoke-Expression
```

```
key .313*$_-18 "$(...)"[0]
--- ---------- -----------
  A      2.345 2
  B      2.658 2
  C      2.971 2
  D      3.284 3
  E      3.597 3
  F      3.910 3
  G      4.223 4
  H      4.536 4
  I      4.849 4
  J      5.162 5
  K      5.475 5
  L      5.788 5
  M      6.101 6
  N      6.414 6
  O      6.727 6
  P      7.040 7
  Q      7.353 7
  R      7.666 7
  S      7.979 7
  T      8.292 8
  U      8.605 8
  V      8.918 8
  W      9.231 9
  X      9.544 9
  Y      9.857 9
```

Comment: Team effort! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
éT6T&\²|└t5φ╛│█♪√┘↑▓^
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82543654265cfd7cc07435edbeb3db0dfbd918b25e&i=%22911%22%0A%22867-5309%22%0A%22713+555+0123%22%0A%22%2B1+%28212%29+PE6-5000%22%0A%221-800-FLOWERS%22&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 113 bytes

```
{s:String->var t=0
for(c in s){val v=c-'0'
t+=when(v){0->10
in 1..9->v
in 17..42->(v-11-v/35-v/42)/3
else->0}}
t}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVjtbhu3Ev3vp5gaRb1CVrJkWXZkXAdwU6dN68ZpPpomfwp6l5L2erVUSa4V3cBAH@Tel@uL5J4ZcldaBwWaH6HIPeQM5@PM0LfGl0X1@fCQnlqtvM5pZiz5ReEoW6iy1NVcn@3h88L7lTs7PMxMruemnA2cV9mt/ggUIIPMLA//OBw9nkynY4Y/NXXlyRqv7IbyQpW0qkunHRUVKVotTKWpqpc32jI6KaqsrPOimlOpvdfW9fZ4/XlFG1NbmltV5StldeXdAeVqk8qZjI@HMTqcR2vlKOfz14Vf4PuuEmVxK1C@4JmIeGPCF62yBX7NC59CVR/kziABJ0Jnv5B9mbFWu5WpRNeFKTWjy5IKT@YOUG8aaNzrvFmlBPXJ6lIrpwEd0AUtNVuucEvGrgsckakaX7E7KIST3AqSb2BmnhTeMRTiPcteGVf4wlThbN4VjMpHMS4vXGaqSmc@Cm9nlBU2q6GwYpxb6ayYFXB8NJ@ZkS@W2qW0VLdiYTjmpgzXL4vs1g3EcN9FBwSFYTd6ASl/1AU0xE9XZwuG/fXnf4Pn//rzfykhXvTKS4y9OB/SelHA6og1rysGB2Q4/1Vwm9zK0ULdBdusrFlp6zeYKE@lsnMdrgsNHCWPU5qmNOyRV7eaSiM@8NHH2CJi3BKR3W4ZpXSU0rg3oDcc9hw@AVYsV8Z6hTiG7VyRa6vY4hwOuVVrvny9QuDYcsNwhCdsi/SA4VYu@GW92NALvab3xt7S0wJqc1DK4RC90OoONzS4djg54T3Bj7Ct7snNNGRj49x4OhodUWKqckOTaKteykYM3pEfNB2eUnJ00nynNZImBJOyTpebvkivFuqm4HS/KJW7VQO6nkH3Gog0ZL8KYXSjM7VEzFqO3ju2xXqhkQ4G7u17VjQm4g44XMgGN76Bz1omkZV3FoJTIQJHMxjnZuPhYUwQ045DLQ2hCVcj8ZeEYJnVVSYWEq@zb2VDUXGqhjj2lh2SAOwQhbrKNIcyRFuVBUaR/K28KqpAHB5X2mWi4DJTexzqGh9ts@JLMuOI0chZeF5IxcACbMWKDcuXM2Vp1pFovpNwk5/4F2Y06k/DBobL3bbymmTY2UDDgJbLj4adfLkKxCm/Xxivw3ExyI8gR6wXyYXTiYGRbSXp8e0KYQi3lCtEh2adnMkKrgqBpECnQC2ba6@1hY0tJFTw7wbeQBrnAcwZXiEYcmpKBDLiBs6STQh3iAVdSDCqFSe1LdryI05ZG5vHLJKSpD96BoOZnJrr6Hq3cV4vowXem5qWtcNqveLM5VvulBSOOGZ1Ca0dt0NI7RomuxyMTkZ88WJeLZE5DIZxmiOESdiiZ40jL1L6NqWndE5HjadSukzpGVbGceX7lH5I6TlWjuPKjyn9lNIVViZx5eeUXqR0jZWTuPIypV9SepXSayyexsU3Kb1N6VesPI4r71L6LaX3KX3A4nRrCLXha9TLGAh8uWCzBRNcCbLKNyFpkc8ZClMf4QrvpXxJDV/DQbAjx6IFka5DpWZgsPa1ILb51XWB4shHYoBkLGcNl7YQZHJKu4uS3qP@4FDcDIZC0kre2CUiJLKK02Au5Y1FvjU3yxaGa6Vp5FRylcpUfQleOFbbItvKabuaUGUsmIYpaIYUP3CgcFeEMgHKLzX7vSUvp3e1zQ2ESD0A3SCc9U7Bl2QM@Rl2X35UfJzUBFm4EA25e0Kgl8bconx4BcILUd5wXCHV5@XGI0hDnL18e/X6ksPgU3Q6HYwOzmiUttMjTFHFDi7i@G0cn8rYwsaYjrH8XRwv4/hMxhZ2jOkxlr@P4w9xfC5jC5tgOsHyj3H8KY5XMrawE0xPsPxzHF/E8VrGFnaK6SmWX8bxlzi@iuNrGVv4Y0xR7Q/exPFtHH@VsYVNMUVHcPAujr/F8X0cP8jYwods1iFP7/FfqL@Rin8X1yZCHb8jwnpnzS6rfW0r0M4yCZ4azLVPYjOJXoSDL7RIoKDt/k6QxFLWFqCGX2g6GlH/CY1GzcLjk9P@ZDyc8upxwwJ0OhrTZDKh4ehoLF8aOqJHI/QDo6Mevbw86U@GwyF/njSEghL0eDjsP7u6fnf56jV/Opk2n16@/fDh6vJ1FMSrz9o6DI74uGpaz1Itb3IVKgReApxAkmmO21ZwRsWFsUZtsGiHTT7YQ6xzec9A5kmo3Gf0WsbeGbp@j0DfI@KqqWeqLgN9eRRg6Yv/o61pCwM37gG7zfbQsMeeIG0kcecN5J2y8ahzGmLOhySdvWFfLyghR1/k/2ZW8wvdkcIEVEndQ5vZYO9UWWu@OqNjiaGlcR4lsmljixY94@K5yx0pluY1V1aulqDu7rlozSqt8wcPtagRbNKgVZ6z7QM9hfsO5BuOiUedb3f2EfjyNRjm0blM@J@0e4lsaA0S/nErJ71g1yhOFthFaRcMbdr3ARqFtnnZgjgyd6bEmfhPBIL@yXA56oJjAu7KFbqXy3ShO@3Wdh2RMBoMpg@VCtv/mV5dlJRTrqCxn@BWm9sh9I/oFTrQpuEInQi8DUdyDMX2owtOTukbmobgOu5x6K25z7vDkwXN9cOj59bUq9jvoJcbYu@oKWzSF3bQbNtGmXCwq28835EpqQN1t8WqPZgFOzTM8lhF/3Ey6IL5XeDXpj0NpOKizjn2dsHjCZQ8PoJ6VV6Gd@AxqGbb2HXh/F1u2TxhRaEm9x4ozS@WkA8qhO7Y5m0ibWGLYhaugpfjophz79OIz826@uJ2cP@8uEPIoSQHYjyRWoaLoJJ10fL5aCzFLE6OQ@eLMkXfdMGoWBEzBauCBJq/GUR3P7AcoRS5QDl/E@KngwFM@yDIQ8b3R6O@/DgcT@KP46Pe4fifZiXoCT1cB6tL6bwQyEa76qDNTenhOsgvteW9DxUdtrN7MSVU2Yu/YZtYRV6FAt0pIqIvv0sti4glXL7uye5YNKTs/Yw347Y/C8S786wN9WwJUKLs3J3RhbVq869Q0J702mJ2FcokCie4yP3NUYGhV3Qe9oxQ1@WB/PmTOwsn9p9ICTsf7mF7kknF6n0SXj/PhMn9o3M2RHLX@zTsPwGLRirDzr3W5f0nyZ04WJwbHcsm7j8Z3t/v@fvPIZTRvfNjIbyZ4/N0Zs1SFEdfb2OW7X3BFy3fDej5jPmFw4H/wBKg6BLAfnhwhL98oZKGPw/BMIPwvFgXCJYA7tZwD6U@teUs9E7nouZVUemk99VXA2/esvinEJ/0BIp2PxHogE2NDDpHA9CL8eMXFg@J5/DCXJUXdl5zE3PZ6JPsxNz@tyoPIr/aD7vxdq18WSX7XwdNEPxff1oFWb17gMIVrncumHKftCo5ruRvPvF2/DwNFKadl8eWJMA9fvpsQYm21tgz0AuU5YdDL1qh1aDVLb5p89A/uUZVaXbkcEguC@evZ8k@Wsz9lPabxnJ/W7j3d9tKxnzRTO6CO60ko2MDud9rrLy1VNAhGIp/i51i4sK7IQc5pT7/Hw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>134</s> 123 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:sum(map(int,n.translate(n.maketrans('ADGJMPTWBEHKNQUXCFILORVYSZ','23456789'*3+'79','()+-./ '))))+10*n.count('0')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1NT8JAFEX3/IrZvVfKlDcdpx8mLFSKKAUqiEB3o0I00qGBYeGvL4UFSe/unnOTW/7bn72RVbXt7XTx@a2ZuT@eCix0ib/GdoxnD9ocd9pu0HiF/ttcO8JD//l1nL0vH5PhaPK2WD0NXtLp7GM9z6EDvrxTQRjF0JYuhHFN0HG512Xg1HEFtY33tT8Zi0DgVOWhvsItQixEvWjdehSEXEmKGzAUkimlGAlfNoQrGPrCd1iWBFwRUcMKHhHxQTpdJrN5w2SLPE@TC6vO)

-11 bytes thanks to @dan04

Comment: By rearranging the letters to `'ADGJMPTWBEHKNQUXCFILNRVYSZ'`, you can reduce the string of numbers to `'23456789'*3+'79'`.