# Converting Strings to Decimals (Gone Wrong)

Tags: code-golf, string, integer, conversion

## What?

*Many programming languages, both practical and esoteric, have functions, methods, etc to convert a given string to a decimal number.* This is how the process might work:

- For each character in the given string.

  - Take the character's ASCII value and subtract it by 48.
  - Multiply the output value by 10. (The output at the first iteration is 0)
  - Add the subtracted ASCII value to the output.

Let us do this process for the string `"109"`:

1. The ASCII value of `1` is 49. Subtract it by 48, and we get 1. We multiply the output by 10, we get 0. Finally, we add 1 to 0 and get one.
2. Next, we subtract `0`'s ASCII value (48) by 48, we get 0. We multiply 1 by 10, we get 10. Nothing happens when we add 0.
3. Then we subtract `9`'s ASCII value (57) by 48, we get 9. We multiply 10 by 10 and get 100. We add 9 to 100 and get 109.

There, we successfully converted `"109"` to 109! It is just as simple!

The problem is that most languages do not like it when the converting string has non-digital characters (characters with an ASCII value not in the range 48-57 inclusive). They would most likely throw some nasty errors or exceptions at us.

*How 'bout we ignore that!*

## Task

Given a printable string from STDIN (you can assume that \$1 ≤ \text{Input Length} ≤ 10\$), implement a program or function to badly convert it to an integer according to the above steps, and output or return it back.

Strings can contain whitespace characters (Spaces, tabs and linefeeds).

For another example string `"Hi!"`:

1. The ASCII value of `H` is 72:
   `72 - 48 = 24`
   `0 * 10 = 0`
   `0 + 24 = 24`
2. The ASCII value of `i` is 105: 
   `105 - 48 = 57` 
   `24 * 10 = 240` 
   `240 + 57 = 297.`
3. The ASCII value of `!` is 33: 
   `33 - 48 = -15` 
   `297 * 10 = 2970` 
   `2970 + -15 = 2955`

This means that `"Hi!"` converted to an integer is 2955!

Standard I/O rules apply.

*Note: if your language does not support input, feel free to tell me in your answers (you can put the "input" strings in your source code)!*

## More test cases

```
STDIN                  Output
"123456789"         ->  123456789
"0123456789"        ->  123456789
"-12345"            -> -287655
"Lorem"             ->  350191
"Ipsum"             ->  321451
"AAAAAAAA"          ->  188888887
"        "          -> -177777776
"A"                 ->  17
" "                 -> -16
"
"                   -> -38
```

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "You can use Unicode values instead"? Unicode and ASCII code points line up, so there's no difference between Unicode and ASCII values

Comment: @caird I thought Unicode is a superset of ASCII.

Comment: Yes, but unless we have to handle inputs with characters outside of the printable ASCII range, the two are one and the same

Comment: Just to confirm: "-12345" should convert to -287655? We don't want the conversion to be *too* perfect, correct? :-)

Comment: @ErikF Yep, you are right! I should add this test case to confirm that. (That is also a way conversion has "Gone Wrong" :P)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to switch the first two steps and replace "multiply the output" by "multiply the previous output (if available)"? No special case anymore, a better flow and no 10*1=0.

Comment: Basically ascii string is 8 bit and Unicode is 16 bit, so there whole bunch more shit like alien crop circles you can encode. This also explain the issue with windows functions that deal with strings having two functions one with the function name with either A or W for ascii or wide character. Additionally when you need to convert, it is not a simple matter of cutting off a section, it's a more complicated matter dealing with mapping one encoding to another, and why windows does not have a basic converting function.

Comment: @Eric Duminil You just have to output the expected with the shortest source code. It does not matter how you do it. The task says "according to", not "following".

Comment: @SunnyMoon: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I was just proposing an alternative way to explain the above process, because the current explanation is a bit confusing IMHO. "Multiply the output by 10 " seems to be referring to `ASCII value - 48` even though it actually refers to the previous step. Just my 2c$, feel free to ignore it.

Comment: "The problem is that most languages do not like it when the converting string has non-digital characters. [...] They would most likely throw some nasty errors or exceptions at us."  You mean, there are compilers/interpreters out there which don't use `atoi` (or any of its friends) to convert strings to integers? Shocking!

Comment: Lorem, Ipsum, AAAAAAAA

Comment: I'd suggest to use Default I/O rules unless you have a good reason to specify your own.

Comment: Can we assume the input is limited to printable ASCII?

Comment: @Kevin Yes! That is the main point of the challenge!

Comment: @SunnyMoon Yeah, but I mainly meant no tabs/newlines, unprintable ASCII, or unicode characters beyond codepoint 126. So it's limited to the codepoints in the range [32,126]. But thanks, will finish my program and post an answer in a bit.

Comment: @Kevin Codepoints 9 (tabs), 10 (newlines) and 13 (returns) are also allowed.

Comment: @SunnyMoon If those are allowed, you probably should add test cases for them.

Answer (score 14):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), <s>258</s> 252 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to [the default](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36445/the-default).

```
,.Ajax,.Puck,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Exeunt][Enter Ajax and Puck]
Ajax:Open mind.
Puck:Is I nicer zero?If soYou is the sum ofI twice the difference 
     betweenthe product ofyou the sum ofa cat a big big cat the factorial 
     ofa big big cat.
     If soLet usAct I.Open heart
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9NCgIxDIWv8g4w9ACzERcuCoKCKxEXtZM6VScd2hR/Lj@23egikPfyJbyk@bEsnVrfzKtT@2zvpbcC3auDJabanDYvyizn04aFIioKwwMqfa6q383EmDwP7UKvEzTY2wJ/KIaVdkjhGDJ8goyElCcEpyHPwjRn8M5RJC7yQvIk4urOMQy5hAnuXZZ/mwbWCAwu/tqqqjp1xkqI3jwa8zdVLcGWBDm171RLPJKJsizbEGn6Ag)

The golfiest representation of the integer 48 is as `twice the factorial of a big big cat`, i.e. \$48=2\times (2\times2\times1)!\$.

This corresponds to

```
Ajax = 0
Puck = 0
Begin Act I
Puck = read_input (as ASCII codepoint value)
if(Puck>0){
    Ajax = Puck + 2 * (Ajax * (4+1) - 4!)
    Go to Act I
}
print(Ajax) (as an integer)
```

Comment: 252 bytes by rearranging the code to reuse `twice`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@9jgIxDIRfZR6AiwQHzTboCopIJ4FEhRBFyDqQA5xV4oifl1@SNFxhyTP@bI3TcB3Hifr5M4@J2mR7Kb0V6E5tLTHVZr96UGY57FcsFFFRGO5R6UNV3Xogxs1z3y50OkGDvS3wi2JYaocUdiHDJ8iZkPINwWnIvTDN6b1zFImLPJLcibi6Qwx9LmGCe5blz6aBNQKDoz@1qqpOnbESojfXxvybqpbglwQ5te9US3wmE2Ucv6az7/niDQ "Shakespeare Programming Language – Try It Online")

Comment: @thedefault. Nice, thanks!

Comment: a big big cat ...

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
O_48Ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98/3sTi4Y6e/4fbHzWt@f9fySNTUUlHQckRCkBsQyNjE1MzcwtLJQA)

### How it works

```
O_48Ḍ - Main link. Takes a string s on the left
O     - Convert to ordinal code points
 _48  - Subtract 48 from each
    Ḍ - Convert from base-10
```

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explaining why they cast their vote? This is a perfectly valid answer

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

As long as we're doing things wrong, why not turn a string into a polynomial?

```
48-[X]ZQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38RCNzoiNirw/391n/yi1Fx1AA)

Evaluates the polynomial

$$p_1x^{n-1} + \cdots + p_{n-1}x^1 + p_nx^0$$

where \$p\$ is the input string (minus '0') and \$x\$ is 10.

Answer (score 8):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final), 153 bytes

```
decoding a num got WRONG
I/O digits i get?converting fails,o darn
i am bummed if the I/O fails
i have a number i got based on counting it badly,i suppose
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?JY07DoMwEER7TjEHQIqSHCBllCZIaVKv8WJWwl7kDxKnJzZpZ968sTyqleBACMXDacb3M7yf3esywIqTnCBwnB@jho1jbuxEsqReYSmGTkAepnjPFjIhz4y2PZlazrTxX244NlV9MJQqrAGjlnAapYV22XtBKuuqiY/r7X7U7Ac)

Comment: I tried to run it online and it says:
{
ERROR: Unexpected EOF
Done.

Comment: Output is in the form of an ASCII byte. That is the byte with the ASCII value of 123.

Answer (score 8):

## [JavaScript (ES6/2015)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), 43 bytes

```
s=>s.map(c=>r=r*10+c.charCodeAt()-48,r=0)|r
```

```js
let f = s=>s.map(c=>r=r*10+c.charCodeAt()-48,r=0)|r

console.log(f([..."123456789" ])) //  123456789
console.log(f([..."0123456789"])) //  123456789
console.log(f([..."Lorem"     ])) //  350191
console.log(f([..."Ipsum"     ])) //  321451
console.log(f([..."AAAAAAAA"  ])) //  188888887
console.log(f([..."        "  ])) // -177777776
console.log(f([..."A"         ])) //  17
console.log(f([..." "         ])) // -16
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcy9DoIwFIbh3atomIpK4SA/ZSgJcTLxDoxDU8GfgCUtMnnvGAPSRDv4jifP@W6851qoa9t5PR0qNmiWa9LwFguWK6aWEKwEEReutvJUFh12vYiuFQvcpxqEvGtZl6SWZ1zhAyHEgXATxUlKMwcdXRf5PkLzaWHxgXn4y@@lKhsHvfv4TRxABja8a/XjG4cQxVZcTDkGAx1LbR5NGe9BOpZY9@cPs28f/oEeJMML)

**Edit #1:** -1 byte thanks to [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)

**Edit #2:** -7 bytes thanks to [EzioMercer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/116593/eziomercer)

Comment: Nice first answer! (Welcome to the site, by the way!)

Comment: `c.charCodeAt` default para 0

Comment: You can reduce bytes count by 7 if use characters array instead of string https://tio.run/##hcy9DoIwGIXhnav4wtSqrRT5HUpCnEy8A@NQK6IGKWnVyXtHDaQmZfAdT56cq3gKI/Wlu5ODOFQNadWx6k@8N7ww9CY6JHmhuZ6xYC6pPAu9/oDyjjCJsoXmAX7pvgYOBngBJ7SjlJo99jypWqOaijaqRjXyWbiK4iTNch8whuUSwC4uDX72H90qXd18@DbSVRywnLlu05mH40IWxRNXjvnWsWwodSmMWUpYOpRMXi22r9M71xCW9G8

Comment: @EzioMercer It conflicts with the assignment where is written that the function takes a string, but you gave me an idea, thanks for that

Comment: No it doesn't, There are languages where isn't string type so they must use characters array. See: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string/8964#8964. You also can use characters array just specify it in your answer

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>51</s> 48 bytes

*Edit: -3 bytes thanks to Robin Ryder*

```r
function(s)(utf8ToInt(s)-48)%*%10^(nchar(s):1-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc5dC4IwFAbge3/FMIQtGHj8nEFBl0KXXSdiakJuMZV@vkmalBzpvdt2nr1H99c8q@r0npRK5slTK1nu@6KTWVspSRtGu7YQZxXLdjhwTzBra4F9oTK7pXq42gEHhnxCTXBczw9CEZmMbMgUfiBkfjAwZmPuPzspndffTR/m@jZEgJr40XS4ccDzcXOc8sPe64kxIcqmwaXiEI4J8LLlcnPZSsvKPIfA6F8)

Multiplies Utf8 value of each character minus 48 by powers-of-ten from the length of the string minus one, down to zero, and outputs the sum.

Comment: Wow! You answered in just about 10 minutes after the release of this question!

Comment: R is usually quite bad for text-based challenges, but the vectorization helps a lot here...

Comment: Does R have a convert to base 10 builtin? That‘s essentially what the step is after subtracting 48, so that may be shorter than vectorising over the powers and summing

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing as far as I know, R doesn't have any base-N builtins, so we need to do the work ourselves.  Of course, Giuseppe will probably correct me and come up with a much golfier version...

Comment: There are no base conversion builtins, but you can save 3 bytes thanks to vector multiplication: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc5dC4IwFAbge3/FMIQtGHj8nEFBl0KXXSdiakJuMZV@vkmalBzpvdt2nr1H99c8q@r0npRK5slTK1nu@6KTWVspSRtGu7YQZxXLdjhwTzBra4F9oTK7pXq42gEHhnxCTXBczw9CEZmMbMgUfiBkfjAwZmPuPzspndffTR/m@jZEgJr40XS4ccDzcXOc8sPe64kxIcqmwaXiEI4J8LLlcnPZSsvKPIfA6F8 "R – Try It Online")

Comment: Lovely!  Thanks @RobinRyder

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing there is `strtoi` but it forces you to just use `0-9a-z` so it wouldn't be of any help here. I'm pretty sure this is as short as this can get.

Answer (score 6):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```scala
_./:(0)(_*10+_-48)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQzVWWmKOQZqUQXFKUmZeuYGun4JlXomD7P15P30rDQFMjXsvQQDte18RC838BUEVJTp5GmoaSR6aikqYmF5KIoZGxiamZuYUlmrhPflFqLpqYAohf@x8A)

Explanation:

```scala
_./:(0)(_*10+_-48)
  /:                Fold left
_                   the input string
    (0)             with an initial value of 0
       (_*10+_-48)  Multiply the accumulator by 10, and add the next character - 48
```

Comment: awesome answer!

Answer (score 6):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>35</s> 26 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{$r=$r*10+$_-48}
$r
```

Saved 9 bytes using splatting

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SpmCrUP1fJbEovbhGtVqlyFalSMvQQFslXtfEopZLpeh/LReXShlQkZKhkbGJqZm5haUSlxpQm0MZTMIAp4wuWEZJAQLQJH2A9ufC5NAlPQuKS3FKOkKBEjZJmB50tziiCyBU/AcA)

Comment: Welcome to the site and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Powershell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191/tips-for-golfing-in-powershell) page

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>46</s> <s>45</s> 42 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s>[]and ord(s.pop())-48+10*f(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCoJAFEXXzVc8hOHNlIallQkGLYP@oFoYOiSoM/hei77ecnDTXZ17Fve6D79sn4yjKdqye1YlUE6n26PsK7BDpWjtrFNaR2m22sRLo0iPXBMTFKAEbrZJutsfsiOGAuO/Fvk20dUOdTfBxdHbw3nOxDDHey9QaCGMHYCh6cG/5WLhhqZnhfK3SygVBpIClKxDMKptiBVrHVLtCrwz6vEL)

-1 thanks to Sisyphus

-3 taking a list of characters as input thanks to ovs

Comment: If you take the input as a list of characters, `s.pop` can save some bytes: https://tio.run/##VY3BCoJAFEXXzVc8hOHNlIallQkGLYP@oFoYOiSoM/hei77ecnDTXZ17Fve6D79sn4yjKdqye1YlUE6n26PsK7BDpWjtrFNaR2m22sRLo0iPXBMTFKAEbrZJutsfsiOGAuO/Fvk20dUOdTfBxdHbw3nOxDDHey9QaCGMHYCh6cG/5WLhhqZnhfK3SygVBpIClKxDMKptiBVrHVLtCrwz6vEL

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
ạ-₄₈ᵐ{×₁₀ʰ+}ˡ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/@GuhbqPmloeNXUAedWHpz9qanzU1HBqg3bt6YX//0crGRoZm5iamVtYKukoGSBzdMEcIMMnvyg1F0h7FhSXgmhHKAAyFaAAJAriKsUCAA)

For single-"digit" inputs, the output is wrapped in a list, since the fold isn't actually executed. If this isn't acceptable, two 15-byte alternatives exist:

[`ạ-₄₈ᵐ,0↻{×₁₀ʰ+}ˡ`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/@GuhbqPmloeNXUAeToGj9p2Vx@e/qip8VFTw6kN2rWnF/7/H61kaGRsYmpmbmGppKNkgMzRBXOADJ/8otRcIO1ZUFwKoh2hAMhUgAKQKIirFAsA)

[`ạ↔-₄₈ᵐ{i×₁₀ⁱ⁾}ᶠ+`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/@GuhY/apug@amp51NQBFKjOPDz9UVPjo6aGR40bHzXuq324bYH2///RSoZGxiamZuYWlko6SgbIHF0wB8jwyS9KzQXSngXFpSDaEQqATAUoAImCuEqxAA)

```
ạ                Convert to codepoints.
 -₄₈ᵐ            Subtract 48 from each.
     {     }ˡ    Left fold:
      ×₁₀ʰ       multiply the accumulator (initialized to first element) by 10
          +      and add it to the next element.
```

Brachylog's base conversion builtin actually disallows values outside the usual range, because it's actually quite useful sometimes on top of preserving proper inverse behavior, so I'm forced to implement the described algorithm directly.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
10⊥48-⍨⎕UCS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRDg0ddS00sdB/1rnjUNzXUOfg/kFIASiikKagbGhmbmJqZW1iqKyg86p2roAAX4EJSZYCkDLcqn/yi1FygOSAAVmVsamBoaYisxLOguBRViZGhiSmKEkcoUIcpMbSAAHNkVQpQAFOla2gOAWYoZsHVwcxCNQRNWtfQ7D8A)

`⎕UCS` converts string to a vector of ASCII values, `48-⍨` subtracts 48 from each value and `10⊥` converts from base 10.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
C48-I
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?s=?flags=&code=C48-I&inputs=Lorem&header=&footer=)

Wow it's actually ASCII.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```hs
n#(h:t)=(n*10+fromEnum h-48)#t
n#_=n
f=(0#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYzBjoIwEIbvPsWk7KGztAlFCmi2m@zBg4mePBpjOEjYaAspkOWw744tGA8m/ofJzPf9mapor5fbbRxNQKt1h4qaTxGFpa31xvQaKp7kGHQLE5yVWZSKRgGOuvg1oEAXzf4MTd8dOrszcIQBwhAIqG833Ebbqv6DDyhhwNnwF0OdAlQKLP7TgVn84kdKRLxMZJrlK8KeKzJKoneCTxdhPM6zVEqPdrW9aMKWMhIr4cG2aXsPYpHICfw84n7lczKP4RH3TWRz0qnuenPBmxRPp/EO)

```
n#(h:t)=       - # -> infix function taking a number and a string(head:tail)
(n*10+fromEnum h-48)#t  
                 - compute first char and call recursively on tail

n#_=n          - end condition

f=(0#)         - apply 0 to #
```

Comment: User [榨 菜](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98711/%e6%a6%a8-%e8%8f%9c) suggested [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/57377) edit to save 11 bytes

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, 46 bytes

```java
a->{int r=0;for(var c:a)r=r*10+c-48;return r;}
```

Input as a character-array.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TVDBToNAEL3zFeOeQIRQrVohmDS9aKK99Gg8jNutboWFzC6YhvDtuAvUOIeZ914mb17miC1Gx/33wAvUGl5Rqs4DkMoIOiAXsHV0FID7/Avp7R0wyKzYe7Zpg0Zy2IKCHAaMHju3SXmSHSryWyTgKQaU0@UiCXm0XGUkTEMKKOuHzDnUzUdhHWajtpJ7KG0Kf2dIqs/x2hTBGU4iGKHNBrWAFJT4gfNqx57kBbtii@ub5e3d/erB4uQ/iUZiwUtForTzudaNm@u5LIS5nOoo6wNvUnYnbUQZV42Ja3vQFMo/BwlZCixUMf9TYlNt7LfWRHjyg2D@WD/8Ag)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->{            // Method with character-array parameter and integer return-type
  int r=0;      //  Result-integer, starting at 0
  for(var c:a)  //  Loop over the input-characters:
    r=          //   Change the result to:
      r*10      //    The current result multiplied by 10
      +c-48;    //    And add the codepoint of the current characters minus 48
  return r;}    //  After the loop, return the result
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Assembly (NASM, 32-bit, Linux)](https://www.nasm.us/), <s>221</s> <s>185</s> 147 bytes

*Edit: -36 bytes + bugfix*

*Edit: -38 bytes*

```
mov edi,0
push 48
l:imul edi,edi,10
add edi,[esp]
sub edi,48
mov edx,1
mov ecx,esp
mov ebx,0
mov eax,3
int 128
mov ax,[esp]
xor ax,10
jnz l
pop eax
```

[Try it Online!](https://jdoodle.com/a/2rRk)

The result is in `edi`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array of characters.

```
£48nXcÃì
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=cQ&code=ozQ4blhjw%2bw&input=IkhpISI) (Header splits string input to array)

```
£48nXcÃì     :Implicit input of array
£            :Map each X
 48n         :  Subtract 48 from
    Xc       :  Charcode of X
      Ã      :End map
       ì     :Convert to integer from base-10 digit array
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ëk╜ΓOíU
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=896bbde24fa155&i=%22123456789%22%0A%220123456789%22%0A%22Lorem%22%0A%22Ipsum%22%0A%22AAAAAAAA%22%0A%22++++++++%22%0A%22A%22%0A%22+%22&m=2)

Explanation:

```
{48-mA|E Unpacked source, implicit input
{   m    Map over code points of input string
 48-       Subtract 48 from each
     A|E Convert from base 10
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 40 bytes

```perl
sub{my$r;map$r=$r.0-48+ord,pop=~/./g;$r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBRa4MwFIXf/RVZCEOZtsaaqg0p3dsG3dvexigbjSJME6LCpHR/3Wm0Oteet3vOl3PDlVx9kSarAYpZU1Sfp6xGimYfEimG1MJ1/PBBqKMthWQ/y8UyoUidG2pUBQevvCg3mxehODXahl3Zzsw0QKs3@JTeQTAX2wLgRYS82wODvZVP1kEYwRkz2iPoXpO3wX37mQxebV0RF0d4pJ5lUd2iPOyTiXocBOcUDnsFI3hJ56CDg17rqfH/RYbGP1U3CQdfOixqxEKZ@tTWSVtZbaI0lzbi39JiO3Sggw1QIkp2j2KdW5Od5rFgsDOB42w1Bvs0Lcxu0l225tpnZ@Mocn7oVqZ5Qptf)

Comment: 22 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlxlYlRs9A18RCO78oRcfBrbb6/3@PTMV/@QUlmfl5xf91C9wA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Nice!!! 

Answer (score 4):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

Thanks to [Gegell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80503/gegell) for -2 bytes!

```
2j@.~'0-\a*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//83ynLQq1M30I1J1NL@/98nvyg1FwA)

**Explanation**:

Initially the instruction pointer (IP) is moving right and the stack is filled with `0`'s.
`2j` skips the next two instruction (`@.`).
`~` reads one character of input.
`'0-` subtracts 48 from the input.
`\` swaps the two elements at the top of the stack. Now the intermediate result is on the top.
`a*` multiplies the result by 10.
`+` adds the new number.
After that the IP wraps around to process the next character.

If there is no input left `~` reflects the IP.
`.` prints the result at the top of the stack, and `@` terminates the program.

Animation of the code with input `Lorem`:

[image]

<sup>I'm not sure why there are black bars on two frames, I blame ImageMagick :/</sup>

Comment: Instead of using movement redirection and the newline (that is also counted as an additional byte) could you not simply inline and then jump over the `.@` part instead? So something like `2j@.~'0-\a*+`. That would save 2 bytes.

Comment: @Gegell That works indeed, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a tool to generate an animation like that?

Comment: @att There is [this interpreter](https://github.com/johanasplund/befunge-98) that uses pygame to draw the code and the stack on the screen. This doesn't create an animation though so you have to do some screen recording. For this animation I used my own tool, which is currently quite platform-specific, but uses the more complete PyFunge interpreter for executing the code.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>39</s>  38 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Shaggy*

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s).map(c=>p=p*10+c-48,p=0)|p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcy9CsIwGIXh3asImRI1bb7a3yEF3QRvosRElLYJjXXy3ivSEiEdfMfDw3k0r8bJ4W6frDdXNWkxOVGfRq3VQByNusYSKWor7Bb4TrK03FvB6dtO0vTOtCpqzY1ogiE5pFlelBVGlKI4Rsgvm4Dyn/1HL2ZQHUbfFnrIOFQQurN1Y@ASSLOVOy5h76CcK0KKljxlUMzlq1eP/ev6LjQM8ukD)

Comment: Would `map` not be shorter?

Comment: @Shaggy Not any way I can think of. You'd have to manually change an accumulator with `map`, while `reduce` has that built in.

Comment: `s=>Buffer(s).map(c=>p=p*10+c-48,p=0)|p` should do it.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>48</s> 44 bytes

Usually using a temporary variable to store the current character is shorter than doing array processing, but not this time!

```c
i;f(char*s){for(i=0;*s;i=i*10+*s++-48);s=i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU3NTsJAEL7PU4wYwm5LTYuAmHVJvGniGwgHbHdhknaXdIoHSZ@97lYT45y@@X7L7FiWw0DKivJ0aBOWV@tbQTpXCSvSlBR5mnCaZsuNVKxJ9cMtubK@VAafuKvI35228I@q6SNyQK7D5kBOfHqqJF4BMW4gvy9W672C8McthfZoOhY8R6Yv461gGWCodlL9xDBkuGtr44KWFXs92@UzNQrnNsxYMZky6i1Oq52bhPAcY4uMlh764YVuoFjcL1frh80j5H/wzbemgdczXxp4/r2xNh4ECNlohm8)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
10#._48+3&u:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DQ2U9eJNLLSN1Uqt/mtypSZn5CtoWKdpKqgbGhmbmJqZW1iqI4saYBfWBQujCPnkF6Xmooh4FhSXooo4QgGKoAIUoKpEVaL@HwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
def f(x):
 o=0
 for i in x:o=o*10+ord(i)-48
 return o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BDsIgEETvfMXKCdQm1FatTTh408Q/MN4KSqIsAZrUr0fQHpzLzJs97Lh3fKBtUhqUBs0m3hNAKQho9GDAWJh6lLisxQr9wAyv2o6AV3H0FjA9TYjySk9mQde03jTtdrfvDjmLf6i@kMMFvXplP7swFj/OyhFmlbYgvZEyIURv7L3sKK/yOJc5Ms1@B87TBw)

Comment: You can shorten this to 45 if you switch to Python 2 + a full program: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8LWgCstv0ghWSEzD4gKSks0NK0qbA0NtCq084tSNJI1dU0suAqKMvNKFCr@/1cyNDI2MTUzt7BUAgA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Sisyphus am I wrong, or does switching to Python 2 only save a single byte?

Comment: @MarkRansom You're not wrong! The full program gets you to 46, and switching to Python 2 gets you to 45.

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>43</s> 38 bytes

```
,[<[>++++++++++<-]>+++>+[<->+++++],]<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9om2k4bDmx0Y0E8O@1oG12IcKxOrI3e//9mpgA)

Thanks to JosiahRyanW for -5 bytes.

Since by our consensus, [output can be given as character code](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-the-form-of-byte-values/4719#4719), this is pretty straightforward in brainfuck. Note that the brainfuck interpreter on tio.run has 8-bit wrapping cells, so the maximum value is 255.

```
,[                  while input
  <[>++++++++++<-]  add 10 times previous sum to input
  >+++>+[<->+++++]  add 208 to it (effectively subtracting 48 by 8 bit wrapping)
  ,                 read next character
]
<.                  output
```

Comment: `,[+++<[>++++++++++<-]>>+[<->+++++],]<.` is 38 bytes (assumes 8-bit wrapping cells).

Comment: That"s surprisingly concise, if not readable.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 7 bytes

```
10/-48+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NytBAX9fEQvt/mrqGkqGRsYmpmbmFpZK1gpIBCk8XzAOxfPKLUnNBDM@C4lIwwxEKQGwFKACLgwWUNEH8/wA)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ç48-Tβ
```

Similar as some other answers.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLuJhW7IuU3//3tkKgIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w@0mFroh5zb91/kfreSRqaiko2RoZGxiamZuYQlkGyBzdMEcIMMnvyg1F0h7FhSXgmhHKAAyFaAAJAriKsUCAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ç       # Convert the (implicit) input-string to a list of codepoint integers
 48-    # Subtract 48 from each value
    Tβ  # Convert this from a base-10 list to a base-10 integer
        # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```rust
|s|s.chars().fold(0,|n,x|n*10+x as i32-48)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpNCsIwEEDhvacYu5AZTUrS1loVvYoETbBQI2YiFIxnjz8LweV7fOHOMTsPF9N7pAcMNoLbOI8zjoHkvq8r2EFOnLg8nk1gpNJdhxMqkbwYk59rtRjBMLylbDrK24lhtiEe7G2KuqqbZbvq1sJhoX5VEP0xqdsPgO9/5hc)

Takes input as an &str and outputs the number based on utf-8 codepoints.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 38 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.bytes.inject(0){|a,b|b-48+a*10}}
```

35 bytes with the new Ruby 2.7 syntax:

```ruby
->s{s.bytes.inject(0){_2-48+_1*10}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulgvqbIktVgvMy8rNblEw0CzuiZRJ6kmSdfEQjtRy9CgtvZ/gUJatJKhkbGJqZm5haVSLBdYwABDRBcsAuP55Bel5sI4ngXFpXCOIxTA@ApQAJeHSyjF/gcA)

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 15 bytes

```
0l1=?na*{68*-+!
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yDH0NY@L1Gr2sxCS1db8f///7rFPvlFqbkA)

Explanation

```
0             !         Accumulator initialisation, skipped on subsequent loops
 l1=?na*                Print-and-terminate condition
      a*                Decimal shift
        {               Next character of input
         68*-+          Subtract 48 and add
```

Comment: But some things smell fishy... (there are errors)

Comment: @SunnyMoon A common way of terminating the program. ``a*`` does double duty here.

Answer (score 4):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 41 bytes

```clj
#(reduce(fn[x y](+(* 10 x)-48(int y)))0%)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDdCoJAEIXv9ymGjWC2WnDV9Ycg6DLoDcQr3YXC1DRBn94sNUu86FwNcz7ODCdKsmtVqBZjpUG3KyxUXEUKdRrU0IS4xQ0IA2rGbQ8v6QMaxpixZi0jGGelukNQk4AK07Kl43o@3cGgPT8AfPaEGn8w/D1P/shw03MdKQk9Z4W6/fp9iCUN4QtCT3lZLQOmsGUHHAd9M/0bXi@X0HE/Z7hwezldzuzIlPMKoGG4ZHLhEMyLrsckBdRdrYy1Tw)

Or alternatively, for the same byte count with a different order of full and shorthand function notation:

```clj
(fn[x](reduce #(+(* 10%)-48(int %2))0 x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDdCoJAEIXv9ymGDWG2WnDV9Ycg6DLoDcQr3YXC1DTBtzdNzRIvOlfDnI8zw4nT/FaXqsVEadAt6ixsIixVUscKNrjDLQjTYNzx8Zo9wbAYM6FhrGUEk7xSDwgbElJh2Y50PT@gexh14EeAz55Q8w@Gv@fZnxhu@Z4rJaGXvFT3X38IsaUpAkHouajqdcASjuyA06hvZnjDH@QROu2XDBfeILfLWRyZc/oAGkVrJhcuwaLsmkwzQN0XydoX)

Answer (score 4):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
{48-}%10base
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v9rEQrdW1dAgKbE49f9/j0xFAA)

```
{   }%         # For each byte in the input
 48-           # Subtract 48
      10base   # Convert to base 10
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 88 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_top][T N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_EXIT][S S S T   T   S S S S N
_Push_48][T S S T   _Subtract][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S S S T  S T S N
_Push_10][T S S N
_Multiply][T    S S S _Add][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_EXIT][S N
N
_Discard_top][T N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Since Whitespace inputs one character at a time, the input should contain a trailing ␁ (character with codepoint 1) so it knows when to stop reading characters and the input is done.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgYsLiEE0EHJycSpwcnKC@WAOhABxgaIgRSAhMAmkIAwwB6iZC2oIFyfQnP//dQ2NjE1MGQE) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer result = 0
Start LOOP:
  Integer input = STDIN as character
  If(input - 1 == 0):
    Jump to Label EXIT
  input = input - 48
  result = result * 10
  result = result + input
  Go to the next iteration of LOOP

Label EXIT:
  Print result as integer to STDOUT
```

**Example run: [`input = "Hi!"`](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgYsLiEE0EHJycSpwcnKC@WAOhABxgaIgRSAhMAmkIAwwB6iZC2oIFyfQnP//PTIVGQE)**

```
Command     Explanation                Stack           Heap     STDIN  STDOUT  STDERR

SSSN        Push 0                     [0]
NSSN        Create Label LOOP          [0]
 SSSN       Push 0                     [0,0]
 SNS        Duplicate top (0)          [0,0,0]
 TNTS       Read STDIN as character    [0,0]           {0:72}   H
 TTT        Retrieve at address (0)    [0,72]          {0:72}
 SNS        Duplicate top (72)         [0,72,72]       {0:72}
 SSSTN      Push 1                     [0,72,72,1]     {0:72}
 TSST       Subtract top two (72-1)    [0,72,71]       {0:72}
 NTSSN      If 0: Jump to Label EXIT   [0,72]          {0:72}
 SSSTTSSSN  Push 48                    [0,72,48]       {0:72}
 TSST       Subtract top two (72-48)   [0,24]          {0:72}
 SNT        Swap top two               [24,0]          {0:72}
 SSSTSTSN   Push 10                    [24,0,10]       {0:72}
 TSSN       Multiply top two (0*10)    [24,0]          {0:72}
 TSSS       Add top two (24+0)         [24]            {0:72}
 NSNN       Jump to Label LOOP         [24]            {0:72}

 SSSN       Push 0                     [24,0]          {0:72}
 SNS        Duplicate top (0)          [24,0,0]        {0:72}
 TNTS       Read STDIN as character    [24,0]          {0:105}  i
 TTT        Retrieve at address (0)    [24,105]        {0:105}
 SNS        Duplicate top (105)        [24,105,105]    {0:105}
 SSSTN      Push 1                     [24,105,105,1]  {0:105}
 TSST       Subtract top two (105-1)   [24,105,104]    {0:105}
 NTSSN      If 0: Jump to Label EXIT   [24,105]        {0:105}
 SSSTTSSSN  Push 48                    [24,105,48]     {0:105}
 TSST       Subtract top two (106-48)  [24,57]         {0:105}
 SNT        Swap top two               [57,24]         {0:105}
 SSSTSTSN   Push 10                    [57,24,10]      {0:105}
 TSSN       Multiply top two (24*10)   [57,240]        {0:105}
 TSSS       Add top two (57+240)       [297]           {0:105}
 NSNN       Jump to Label LOOP         [297]           {0:105}

 SSSN       Push 0                     [297,0]         {0:105}
 SNS        Duplicate top (0)          [297,0,0]       {0:105}
 TNTS       Read STDIN as character    [297,0]         {0:33}   !
 TTT        Retrieve at address (0)    [297,33]        {0:33}
 SNS        Duplicate top (33)         [297,33,33]     {0:33}
 SSSTN      Push 1                     [297,33,33,1]   {0:33}
 TSST       Subtract top two (33-1)    [297,33,32]     {0:33}
 NTSSN      If 0: Jump to Label EXIT   [297,33]        {0:33}
 SSSTTSSSN  Push 48                    [297,33,48]     {0:33}
 TSST       Subtract top two (33-48)   [297,-15]       {0:33}
 SNT        Swap top two               [-15,297]       {0:33}
 SSSTSTSN   Push 10                    [-15,297,10]    {0:33}
 TSSN       Multiply top two (297*10)  [-15,2970]      {0:33}
 TSSS       Add top two (57+240)       [2955]          {0:33}
 NSNN       Jump to Label LOOP         [2955]          {0:33}

 SSSN       Push 0                     [2955,0]        {0:33}
 SNS        Duplicate top (0)          [2955,0,0]      {0:33}
 TNTS       Read STDIN as character    [2955,0]        {0:1}    ␁
 TTT        Retrieve at address (297)  [2955,1]        {0:1}
 SNS        Duplicate top (1)          [2955,1,1]      {0:1}
 SSSTN      Push 1                     [2955,1,1,1]    {0:1}
 TSST       Subtract top two (1-1)     [2955,1,0]      {0:1}
 NTSSN      If 0: Jump to Label EXIT   [2955,1]        {0:1}
NSSSN       Create Label EXIT          [2955,1]        {0:1}
 SNN        Discard top                [2955]          {0:1}
 TNST       Print as integer           []              {0:1}           2955
                                                                               error
```

The program stops with an error: no exit defined.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Razetime*

```
dmo-48c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/PyU3X9fEIvn///9KHpmKSgA)

**How?**

```
d           # interpret digits as base-10 number:
 m          # map function over each element of list (each character of string)
  o         # combine 2 functions into one
      c     # convert character to Utf8 value
   -48      # subtract 48
```

Comment: `B10` becomes `d`

Comment: Duh!  How did I miss that?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

## [mlochbaum/BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 21 bytes

```
10{+⟜(⊸×)´⌽}'0'-˜¨
```

[Try it!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=MTB7K+KfnCjwnZWo4oq4w5cpwrTijL3wnZWpfScwJy3LnMKoIkhpISI=)

The online BQN REPL does not have a method of taking input(`⍞` in APL), so append the string to the end of the program.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Ｉ↨ＥＳ⁻℅ι⁴⁸χ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwymxOFXDN7FAwzOvoLQkuAQok66hqaPgm5lXWqzhX5SSmZeYo5EJFDGx0ASShgaamprW///75Bel5v7XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   Ｓ        Input string
  Ｅ         Map over characters
      ι     Current character
     ℅      Ordinal
       ⁴⁸   Literal 48
    ⁻       Subtract
         χ  Literal 10
 ↨          Base conversion
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr`,  15 bytes

```
0&?⑷86*-⑸(
⑾⑼)⑻
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9rZWf//zAmP@KRtzg2Ki3ikbgoCuKRvuKRvCnikbv//zY5/y1ocg)

Keg is very special. Like *very* special.

Answer (score 3):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 10 bytes

```
iEh$a*+`0-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P9M1QyVRSzvBQPf/f0M3AA)

```
i           Read one char from the input
 Eh         If last char read was EOF halt and output current sum as number
   $a*      Else swap new input and current sum, then multiply sum by 10
      +     Add the new char value to current sum
       `0-  Subtract 48 (value of '0') and wrap around implicitly to loop
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```
&List.foldl&1,0,fn x,y->y*10+x-48end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7LCoJAFIb38xQDgaM1Ix51vCwSWrQQhB6gWgQ6IHjDC@jTm6VmiYv@1eH8H985URK3cdmLYy8FcVWrIk/CRAKqUZHhlnbM6/agHVpmOlEW9uesSdX0UeAbuhLQDZNbtuMSiqfsmIfxZ4@I9gfD3vPSzwzTHdviHJEgL6P0tx8lBtfABUT8omq2AR1MPgCnKd/M@IYzxkZk3q8ZBvYYa/Csjiyel4Dc6VbJwEKS7F/UoqkrLFRZAkXpnw)

Anonymous function that performs a simple left fold over its argument (`&1`) using the specified accumulating function. Relies on the fact that Elixir charlists are the same thing as the lists of integer codepoints, so that the transformation can be applied directly without any conversions.

Answer (score 3):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 84 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
N	I LEN(1) . C REM . I	:F(O)
	O =O * 10 + ORD(C) - 48	:(N)
O	OUTPUT =O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NTwdbTLyA0hMsPyPRx9dMw1FTQU3BWCHL1BdKenFZuGv6aXJz@Crb@CloKhgYK2gr@QS4azpoKugomFpxWGn6aXP6c/qEhQDOAarhc/Vz@/1eAAgA)

Answer (score 3):

## Rust macro, 121 bytes

```rust
macro_rules!f{($a:expr;)=>{$a};($a:expr;$c:tt$(,$r:tt)*)=>{f!($a*10+$c as i64-48;$($r),*)};($($c:tt)*)=>{f!(0;$($c),*)};}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU/RaoMwFH33K64sYNJZ0Nba1mBhD/uBdW@lSCYWZDZpE6XdxG/vbrQIG6M3HBLuOfecXN2Y@nY7ilyrTDdVYdxDS4lIiutJc5ZuWiI6PjZIntQ1oT7ReLOJ5Q8uspMweCY5CANlHE2jFSeUaOZPmJ2l/dSoDiyZD2T3KxlyJU2dCWMKXWfFGVoHsCi59uk@kK/@wSDd3DlbTztRVepCG/kp1UVmVSlr40NxztSJ7UdZbw5ZAjvKOAQwBbe9N1@229e39wQ@lKogtYGQppiGuoGCzu7WmPK72KNgt@e9bcedzjlIOIpSUnb/0p8lXBrO5tEiXq7WPuD6XuCBFyJmiDkiQiwQMWKJWCHWHmP8f7dpGA8@8EizHGqUPjrWpnNuPw)

This is a macro that takes a sequence of characters and returns an expression like `((0 * 10 + '1' as i64 - 48) * 10 + '0' as i64 - 48) * 10 + '9' as i64 - 48`.
The expression `$a` is used as an accumulator: The macro expands to `$a` if all characters are consumed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 55 bytes

```lua
i=0(...):gsub('.',load'i=i*10+(...):byte()-48')print(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFda4MwFIavm1@RZYjJ2ohp60cLFnYx2GDscjfihvWjE6zpTByMsd/ujtp2uPVcaM77nvNEfMsmbkuZxCXOcYBLGadh2BaBTS3LYuudarbUtMxZZ5hFUNwIezpY20@dUcaXvskOdVFpWrA2ihAaYL0EwP591D7iEqHXu6dn6@TmTZXoQlY9EU1ipbJa0@svaL9xEGABImzBJCgoq1KEdKa0AiEMERHzxdJxPX9F8Kn4BuOzjIj9f@TPBO/Pv4Bhgs99z3UcRB5lne1Hbg9YOLZYCUQeDqq5ZM/F0gH79lhkbAt/KA@djfEEF95QLjDG@DOjW75oceF2OeSyxkV1mGHZaDjg/setd/tYJ280DAkNX0jEGTEUN/gGnjQ0UoNHUxZFDKcSTXIK@5DAEC81jfcObyhME1nXWaLX0DCTreEqwNL@NohrhrVUGpZ2FDrWBQnfwFgXYNveF1c/)

Fairly simple: executes given algorithm for every character in given string, then prints the result. TIO includes test suite.

Note: input is taken as an argument. This doesn't conform to question as currently written, but is an input method allowed by default I/O rules.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 23 bytes

```haskell
foldl(\a x->10*a+x-48)0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BioMwEIbP@hSD9JDsmsWo0bSgsOxeCvsGtYdQI5XVGNIUfHs3Rultf0iY/5t/huQuHr9yGJZ@1JOx8C2s@Pi6CxN2p9PlrOyV1O5euqqbhnZAjYCZ1DR5E@8zyTlOllH0qtKmVxYOYTAKHQYBalCv9NPGIGctb1a2GEj9MlBVgDo4gEvDZFrwYYzd5MWdAEU0zXJWlPwYxfCqcQwoSv5vEW8dJikvC8Y8/JmMHB3LWEKP1KOzfjw9SmnONvS5a93JN5W@AbvWrbTcVOB4e6WP7zkfKHzdqNVkfP3PdfkD)

A simple fold.

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 35 bytes

```
explode|reduce.[]as$x(0;.*10+$x-48)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@1oiAnPyW1pig1pTQ5VS86NrFYpULDwFpPy9BAW6VC18RC8/9/JZ/8otRcJQA)

This is pretty much a direct translation of the rules to `jq` syntax...

```
explode
```

Splits the input string into a list of codepoints.

```
reduce.[]as$x(0;.*10+$x-48)
```

Initializes the accumulator variable `$x` to 0, the for each codepoint computes 10 times the current accumulator value and adds the current codepoint value less 48.  The result is a single number with is displayed to STDOUT by default.

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), <s>75</s> 48 bytes

```
wi.hn$}'0-!]K@ O Q \{
      {;e(w]?. h n ${~a*+K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/788Uy8jT6VW3UBXMdbbQcFfIVAhpppLAQyqrVM1ymPt9RQyFPIUVKrrErW0vf//9ywoLs0FAA)

```
w .hn$      K                While there is characters left in the input
 i    '0-!]                  Read one char - 48 and put it on the tape
      }                      Otherwise go south
      {;e(                   Go east and rewind the tape
          w]?. h n $     K   While there is more to read on the tape
                     ~a*+    Multiply the current stack value by 10 and sum the tape value
                    {        Then go north
                   \{        Go west, switch to ordinal mode
             @ O Q           Convert the stack to string, print it, bye
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `project-euler.common`, 31 bytes

Thanks to @chunes for pointing out that there actually *is* a function to convert a list of digits to a number, it's just hidden under an extension of the standard library.

```ruby
[ >array 48 v-n digits>number ]
```

- `[ … ]` Quotation (anonymous function) taking a string on the stack
- `>array` Convert string to list of code points
- `48 v-n` Subtract 48 from each
- `digits>number` Convert list of numbers to base-10 number

The `>array` is necessary because if you subtract a number greater than a character's codepoint from a character, it goes around to some really big number instead of being negative.

[image: Screenshot of test cases passing]

---

Without using extra vocabularies, the program is only 2 bytes longer:

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 33 bytes

```ruby
[ 0 [ 48 - swap 10 * + ] reduce ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBCoJAGITv@xSD4KUQ1Ky0KPAUQnSJTuZB1t@UdHfbXYme3hbnNAzffG3NrdTz417cLge8SQsaMNa2Qy9h6DOR4GTQSu1G24sXlCZrf0r3wuI4lwhRIkkRwHxrhSjECmtU0NRMnFDNQy@coJkUtLROrRzv@UFmcDrDb57CwyJr3SmmmndzFG@S7W6fZixYKrtKTSMrlJlGli9h@R8)

<s>I feel like there’s probably a built in to convert a list of digits to a number, but if it exists I can’t find it.</s> @chunes pointed out that such a function exists under an extension of the standard library, thus the above solution. I decided to keep this one since it's almost as short with a different approach and doesn't use any extra vocabularies.

#### Explanation

| Code | Explanation | Stack |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[ … ]` | Quotation (anonymous function) taking a string (equivalent to list of code points) | `"-12345"` |
| `0 [ … ] reduce` | Reduce body, taking previous then current, with 0 as initial | `0 "-"` |
| `48 -` | Subtract 48 from char | `0 -3` |
| `swap` | Swap so accumulator is on top of the stack | `-3 0` |
| `10 *` | Multiply by 10 | `-3 0` |
| `+` | Add | `-3` |
| This repeats until string ends | -3 → -29 → -288 → -2877 → … | `-287655` |

Comment: "I feel like there’s probably a built in to convert a list of digits to a number, but if it exists I can’t find it." `digits>number` in `project-euler.common`.

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 36 bytes (9 instrs)

```
00000000: e3010000 83ff0000 e7000001 42ff0005  ẉ¢¡¡³”¡¡ḃ¡¡¢B”¡¦
00000010: 2a010101 280101ff 21010130 f1fffffa  *¢¢¢(¢¢”!¢¢0ȯ””«
00000020: f8020000                             ẏ£¡¡
```

Disassembly:

```
atoi    SET   $1,0          // n = 0
0H      LDBU  $255,$0
        INCL  $0,1          // loop: v = *a++
        BZ    $255,0F       // if(!v) goto end
        4ADDU $1,$1,$1      // n = (n << 2) + n
        2ADDU $1,$1,$255    // n = (n << 1) + v
        SUBU  $1,$1,'0'     // n -= '0'
        JMP   0B            // goto loop
0H      POP   2,0           // end: return n
```

Note the one trick I used: `4ADDU x,x,x; 2ADDU x,x,y` takes no more space than the obvious `MULU x,x,10; ADDU x,x,y` and executes faster (multiplication is much more expensive than addition or shifting).

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 14 bytes

```
10⊸×⊸+˜´'0'-˜⌽
```

Anonymous tacit function that takes a string and returns a number. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgMTDiirjDl+KKuCvLnMK0JzAnLcuc4oy9CgpGwqggIkhpISLigL8iMDEyMzQ1Njc4OSLigL8iLTEyMzQ1IuKAvyJBIuKAvyIgIuKAvyIKIg==)

#### Explanation

```
10⊸×⊸+˜´'0'-˜⌽
              ⌽  Reverse the argument
         '0'-˜    Subtract character 0 from each character
        ´         Right fold on this function:
       ˜           Apply this function with arguments swapped:
     ⊸+            Add the right argument to
10⊸×               10 times the left argument
```

For example, with an argument of `"109"`, `'0'-˜⌽` gives `⟨9,0,1⟩`. Then the fold proceeds as follows:

```
0 (10⊸×⊸+)˜ 1  →  1 (10⊸×⊸+) 0  →  10 + 0  →  10
9 (10⊸×⊸+)˜ 10  →  10 (10⊸×⊸+) 9  →  100 + 9  →  109
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org)

### 36 bytes

an `evalpoly` version:

```
!s=evalpoly(10,[reverse(s)...].-'0')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZE9CsIwGIZxzSliEW2hKU1r2jhEdFPwBuoQMIJSrSSt4FlcungoPY1J4w-1vkvI9zzfmyHX277Mdrx6dGYbXnC2BA6O4iFJUjpy4DtsDOFn7AMnbDu_Cqov3wqroIimCSGaL3IpDg1cV8QkxCOs-fykyn88wkNi-PQVp8kxtUm18p43FYRTm8S0NF_4tNTrfxnCZm91bEHDYuqD9a0stojee13FxJlnpzy7uDj0l1KchVTCVV4QBOsADcKB93L721xCV_lSKI-ZfwAQTrhSQhZQ1zA9B-K4sXZV2fMJ)

and a `fold` based:

### 35 bytes

```
!s=foldl((x,c)->c-'0'+10x,s,init=0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZExboMwFIbV1adwidSAYiMbYiCDo3as1BskGaxgJCoHIhui9CxdWHKo9jS1oaSiyRts-X3f-9_gz8t7q0rRfT80uWgE3wCPRvGSJWm28uBYfA3htY2AR26d_wruH38Rg4KjLE0Ys_yt1vIwwX1EzAhdUctfj6a9xyO6ZI6__JY35TQbKrXK2J8qmKZDJS5luuGa0o_fZZi6uW11Ax2LMwR2YAbjxB6PhsuTUMdaffiUoI2WJ6mN9E0QhuEuxHMyDy5tU-Dsa2bdola58v0z2gd4vXd0QckZGVRWZcPJqD4VtYa-QVqagLsvAxA-C2OkbtxGbvtAVvlgd91w_wA)

and here are two more variants:

### 36 bytes

`foreach`:

```
!s=(x=0;foreach(c->x=c-'0'+10x,s);x)
```

### 34 bytes

```
!s=(x=0;[s...].|>c->x=c-'0'+10x;x)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
O48-ZD
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbL_E0sdKNcIJwFMMonvyg1F8IBAA) or [verify all test cases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wQbPascKpZgSXV07BSXtKJ-KpaUlaboWy_xNLHSjXCCcRVHeEMbSaKUUpdibIUqGRsYmpmbmFpZKXEoGyBxdMAfI8MkvSs0F0p4FxaUg2hEKgEwFKACJgrhAHJOnBLEBAA).

Port of [caird coinheringaahing's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/212307/114446).

##### Explanation

```python
O48-ZD  # Implicit input
O       # Ordinals of input
 48-    # -48 to each
    ZD  # Convert to base-10
        # (from a list of digits)
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Opcode (x64, Linux), 17 bytes

```
f:	xor eax, eax
f0:	imul rdx, rax, 10
	xor eax, eax
	lodsb
	lea rax, [rax+rdx-48]
	loop f0
	ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHBasMwDD1bX6HBoIe2kLRlhNx22NhhfzDGcGK7y3AWY7kl3c9nsmNKusMMsdHTe9KTIol039jL1kjqp8kMvpcBn16fHw6oR92egmysxj3ABwXpQw2iH87oqdtgT8dyDnU7bpgjWmktmvw6332Hxt8KdgtB9Z9AS2aUgPkkqGGouEJMxmKsGIDoBFWDq5fubhWjXYoe81kBmFqMg5@r8gWmqEXXnyx6xYhPzQq45Qg7KGr40XJmvPG9ZsH2UL3H7ODQsMjrAEJ15Ky84P3WrPc7gDxMvZwNhDvRJxapFV0oZhjjMr4d4zfXStx6sahIT4FKC@Be55ktlUJlN3iocmk2ByJoCrNhH6f4@kFX3thwZb3cca7d5amvv8uTW/RNub@mk@Fp@gU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 4 bytes

```
`@~+-48
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWyxMc6rR1TSwgPKjg6milGCWPTMUYJaVYqBAA)

```
`@~ Convert from base 10
+    add [vectorized]
-48   -48
      input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 14 bytes

```
FiaYy*t+Ai-48y
```

How?

```
FiaYy*t+Ai-48y  : One arg; String
Fia             : For each character in a
        Ai        : ASCII value for char
          -48     : Subtract 48
    y             : Previous result
     *t           : Multiply by ten
       +          : Add together
   Y              : Yank
             y  : Return result
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJGaWFZeSp0K0FpLTQ4eSIsIiIsIiIsIkhpISJd)

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 48 bytes

```cpp
int f(char*s,int r=0){r=*s?f(s+1,r*10+*s-48):r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5BTsMwELzvKwxc7DRBCRQoaRLEDaT@oYo2brpSYke2A4cqbw@2W4k9rGfWM7uD05T1iOtKyrETx3NrEpsGYupcXEyd2I8Tt5siNUmRbxKbbXeiNPtlfSCFw9xJVpG2zsh2bACCcWxJ8R9NnWAXYMy6riy9gFTPBlJy72e/Zxokjz@9dGF6JUgqDUxcrTcz6tmxqoru8N6zuvHNIx9YK@uO2FpXxewND6pHPPqLXPg9XhWXSNUN4fQCy/pFd1A8PW9fXt9275D/w4M2coTvyc4jfN4q5ggFHkIWxfAH)

**Edit #1:** -4 bytes by removing `return`

Answer (score 0):

## [C#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 34 bytes

```cs
x=>x.Aggregate(0,(y,z)=>10*y+z-48)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLdb5swEH/nr7iiPZgVGOSTNk0m1jZStUibFml7yQsDQ60xnGGThlL@9uxMkqauOu0ejH2/j/OdiYUTC7abV0V8JWTJiswGVsgZpDCF3XY627phlpU0iyQlnk1q@9GaznzvfX3@6AwCazcxjBsWS8aLqKx1C0mFRJeCPsA/KMSaGIrlhklCTL/XHwxH4@DCtOF5rzG8/1OcLo2w0wvGo@FQAxe8pL8R6w89/8LXoLu1qDqo5w@GOhQeQtUM9jHWCHAIVdUf72OkWyjtK1HH1mmrQiX7ASYxvlSSpHY3RlzLimL6mheC59T9RqNkwQqqJmgIGUkWw4azBFB0FdqfZqR7UrUD9Hgx/y6V2PCT8xx4kdfLe/4wj1guLGgM1cYmKmEdCUETfD1v0uVSnFwU3wNR4K/NGp8PkqPgKKLbNSoQdb9HeUUnGphx9TOkRMGfaW3pqKqHMJLc2z9VlAuCZhZ8BPNruFyacAnmPLxbmNjtUXa44vlbKh8F3qnC84alQM60puHpCc5eGWBfJ4mK49R/lEzSbuzvzJQ0h1ZaCxxo1HVaIGh1CSuzwW@7wtdEv@6MXzxb5ou@W@O0vlVBdX57s3emSfuhSdxrXhWyVSbt7i8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `B`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
48-Tḋ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpNS7IKlpSVpuhbLTSx0Qx7u6F5SnJRcDBVbsEJJ19DI2MRUCcIHAA)

##### Explanation

```python
48-Tḋ  # Implicit input
       # Cast to codepoints
48-    # Subtract 48 from each
    ḋ  # Convert from a list
   T   # of digits in base ten
       # Implicit output
```