# Based Palindromes

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion, palindrome

A palindromic number, as a refresher, is any number which reads the same forward as backwards. However, what about palindromes in other bases?

### Input

Any integer `b` where `b > 1`.

### Output

All integer base 10 numbers from 0 to 1000 inclusive that are palindromes in base b. The output can either be a list of integers, or integers separated by a delimiter such as a comma or a newline.

### Test cases

`Input->Output`

`10->{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,101,111,121,131,141,151,161,171,181,191,202,212,222,232,242,252,262,272,282,292,303,313,323,333,343,353,363,373,383,393,404,414,424,434,444,454,464,474,484,494,505,515,525,535,545,555,565,575,585,595,606,616,626,636,646,656,666,676,686,696,707,717,727,737,747,757,767,777,787,797,808,818,828,838,848,858,868,878,888,898,909,919,929,939,949,959,969,979,989,999}`

`2->{0,1,3,5,7,9,15,17,21,27,31,33,45,51,63,65,73,85,93,99,107,119,127,129,153,165,189,195,219,231,255,257,273,297,313,325,341,365,381,387,403,427,443,455,471,495,511,513,561,585,633,645,693,717,765,771,819,843,891,903,951,975}`

`9->{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,82,91,100,109,118,127,136,145,154,164,173,182,191,200,209,218,227,236,246,255,264,273,282,291,300,309,318,328,337,346,355,364,373,382,391,400,410,419,428,437,446,455,464,473,482,492,501,510,519,528,537,546,555,564,574,583,592,601,610,619,628,637,646,656,665,674,683,692,701,710,719,728,730,820,910,1000}`

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20572/96079)

Comment: Is there an upper bound for `b`?

Comment: Although not golf'ed, I already answered this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482735#44491340 But I made it more general -- you can search for numbers that are simultaneously palindromic in >>several<< bases. For example, 749470(base10) = 1102002002011(3) = 2312332132(4) is a palindrome in >>both<< base 3 and base 4. So can somebody golf that more general question???

Comment: @JohnForkosh If you’re willing to write up a quick draft in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/66833), I’m sure people will be happy to help you turn that into a full spec

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing The code's all there in that stackoverflow answer, if anybody's curious. It's trivial enough -- just wrap the palindrome function in a loop over several bases. I don't personally care to golf it; just mentioned it here due to the coincidental similarity. And just wrote it to begin with due to its more mathematical curiosity -- There are lots of numbers in GioD's output. But (excluding one-digit numbers) there's only one unique number between 1 and one-hundred-million that's a palindrome in bases 9 and 10 and 11: 3360633(base10) = 6281826(9)  = 3360633(10)  = 1995991(11).

Comment: @Shaggy I guess for b > 1000 all numbers will be palindromes, so no upper bound should be needed.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 78 bytes

Outputs the numbers in decreasing order `1000 -> 0`, and short-circuits with a `ZeroDivisionError`

```python
def f(b,n=1000):
 r=0;m=n
 while m:r=r*b+m%b;m//=b
 n==r==print(n);f(b,n-n//n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvLDgIhDEDRPV/RjQn4AnXlkP4MCpkm0zIpGDNfj4@bnOVdtz5XuQ3itWqHtjXzdW65a368tFGVhZi6vf9y45kLFJuOgpcQgpsMKIbIKAbeMy0ZeFLUfTrwLkX2HpMBQVTEVUm6FRf/@0m8FzeKvbrxAQ)

The `f(b,n-n//n) -> f(b,n-1)` recurses until `0`, and errors because dividing by zero is undefined.

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 76 bytes

We can shorten the answer by 2 bytes if a floating-point output is allowed.

```python
def f(b,n=1e3):
 r=0;m=n
 while m:r=r*b+m%b;m//=b
 n==r==print(n);f(b,n-n/n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvLDgIhDEDRPV/RjQn4Qp2VQ/ozKGSaTAspGDNfj4@bnOWtW1@KTIO4Fu3Qtma@zi11TY@XNiqyElO3919uPFOGbONR8JomNxtQvARGMfBeaE3As6Lu44F3MbD3GA0IoiJWJelWXPjfJ/HiRrY3Nz4)

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
₄ÝʒIвÂQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVPL4bmnJnle2HS4KfD/f0MDAwMA)

### Explained

```
₄Ý	"Push the range [0, 1000]"\
  ʒ	"and keep the items where:"\
   Iв	"After being converted to base (input)"\
     ÂQ	"have its reverse equal to itself"\
```

Comment: This answer is not correct for `b = 1000`. The output should be all integers from `0` to `999`.

Answer (score 10):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) forwards, <s>118</s> <s>117</s> 115 bytes

```c
b[11],*p,*x,i,m;f(n){for(i=-1;i++<1e3;){for(p=x=b,m=i;m;*p++=m%n,m/=n);while(p>x)m|=*--p-*x++;m||printf("%d,",i);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcvNCoJAFIbhvVcxGML8lmOrOI03Ui3KnzzgTEMZCeq1m1gtpLN6@XhOpq5ZNo6Xg9Ynyb3krURpoaSOdeXtTtEoDSjEXhdb@EzetOYirUGwwL0QxkZO2o1xDF4V1gX1actsb7hSXvFWCLB97@/ompKGUS5DiQyGYVyhy@pnXpD9o8nxtq7SIJgQsWd0lAVdQKb7/emYmJSEDOa1pDr@5g8cXbIUyR/YLcFuqmHu8Q0)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), backwards, <s>115</s> 113 bytes

```c
b[11],*p,*x,i,m;f(n){for(i=1001;i--;){for(p=x=b,m=i;m;*p++=m%n,m/=n);while(p>x)m|=*--p-*x++;m||printf("%d,",i);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcvLDoIwEIXhPU/RYEx6VcrOjOVF1IUUkElsbbzEJsKzI1FZEGf15@Qbq07WDkO50/ogeZA8SpQOGurZq7lcKRqdZRpQKfgOwURTSmcQHPAghHFLL93aeAbPFs81DUVkrjNcqaB4FAJc14Ur@ntD02UlU4kM@n5YoLfnR1WT7e1e4WXVFkkyIuKO6ClLXgkZb/rTGTEFSRl81obq7JcT2Pt8LvI/sJmDzVj9p4c3)

### Explanation

C signature:

```c
// Technically implicit int with a void return
void f(int base);
```

Loops through all numbers from 0 to 1000, converts them to base `base` by hand, then checks if it is a palindrome.

The backwards version does the same thing, but backwards.

Prints matching numbers, comma separated, to stdout.

Ungolfed version

```c
#include <stdio.h>
// A buffer to hold our converted integer.
// It is large enough for 1000 in binary.
int buffer[11];
// Start and end pointers for buffer
int *start, *end;
// Loop counter
int i;
// Temporary
int tmp;

void f(int base)
{
    // Loop for 0 to 1000
#ifdef BACKWARDS
    // Loop backwards
    for (i = 1001; i-- != 0;) {
#else
    // Loop forwards
    // for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
    for (i = -1; i++ < 1e3; ) {
#endif
        // Convert to base in buffer, tracking the length in end.
        for(start = end = buffer, tmp = i; tmp != 0;) {
            *end++ = tmp % base;
            tmp /= base;
        }

        // Check if it is a palindrome.
        // Loop while our starting pointer is less than our ending pointer.
        // tmp will zero at the start thanks to the loop condition.
        while (end > start)
            // Assembly style comparison using subtraction.
            // If *end == *start, tmp will still be zero.
            // If not, it will be permanently set to non-zero with a binary or.
            tmp |= *--end - *start++;
        // If tmp is still zero (meaning it is a palindrome), print.
        tmp || printf("%d,", i);
    }
}
```

Thanks to Arnauld for the -1 bytes!

Thanks to Toby Speight for the -2 bytes!

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ȷŻbŒḂ¥Ƈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//yLfFu2LFkuG4gsKlxof/w4figqz//zEwLCAy)

### How it works

```
ȷŻbŒḂ¥Ƈ - Main link. Takes a base b on the left
ȷ       - 1000
 Ż      - [0, 1, 2, ..., 1000]
     ¥  - Group the previous 2 links into a dyad f(k, b):
  b     -   Convert k to base b
   ŒḂ   -   Is this a palindrome?
      Ƈ - Filter [0, 1, 2, ..., 1000], keeping those k that are true under f(k, b)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using it wrong. When I use the provided TIO link and input "10" it returns me ten lists, A list for each number up to 10 with the palindromes in the base.

Comment: @GioD The code in the Footer section (`Ç€`) runs the above code over all provided inputs (10 and 2 in my link). If it's just passed a number, `€` turns that into a range. If you just want the result for 10, either delete the Footer, or put the input as `[10]`

Comment: Oh alright, Thank you! In that case, this answer is fine. I didn't notice the footer at first.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 44 bytes

```
Pick[r=0~Range~1000,r-r~IntegerReverse~#,0]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277PyAzOTu6yNagLigxLz21ztDAwECnSLeozjOvJDU9tSgotSy1qDi1TlnHIFbtf0BRZl6JgkN6tKFBLBeEE62kBGMCxY2wC1vG/v8PAA)

-13 bytes from @att

Comment: When I use the test case of 9 it doesn't output 1000 as it should

Comment: [because the 1000 needs to be changed to 1001](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277Pzg1JzW5JDooMS891cHQwMBQ11Cn2FbZOiAxJzMvpSg/NzXQwTOvJDU9tcglMz2zpDhaWac4Vi1W7X9AUWZeiYJDerShQSwXhBOtpARjAsUtY///BwA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: @GioD fixed.....

Comment: @Lyxal nice....!

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277PyAzOTu6yNagLigxLz21ztDAwECnSLeozjOvJDU9tSgotSy1qDi1TlnHIFbtf0BRZl6JgkN6tKFBLBeEE62kBGMCxY2wC1vG/v8PAA)

Comment: ah Mathematica, you cray ... `IntegerReverse` allows us to select a base, but `PalindromeQ` doesn't

Answer (score 6):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>62</s> 87 bytes

- Fixed after Siu Ching Pong -Asuka Kenji- pointed out `BigInt`'s `toString` only works for bases up to 36.
- Saved 1 byte thanks to [@cubic lettuce](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74778/cubic-lettuce).

```scala
b=>0 to 1000 filter{x=>val y=Seq.unfold(x){q=>Option.when(q>0)(q%b,q/b)};y==y.reverse}
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zTFJgi3VQ3e8ZrLa3yrPLQ)

This is pretty straightforward. It makes a range from 0 to 1000, then filters by checking if they equal their reverse in base `b`. To convert to base `b` (as a string), `BigInt`'s `toString` method <s>is</s>was used, but now `Seq.unfold` is used to create a `Seq` of digits.

Comment: I was just about to post `b=>(0 to 1000).filter(x=>{val y=BigInt(x).toString(b);y==y.reverse})`, which is the same solution as yours (incl. same variable names!), but still 6 unnecessary bytes longer :) Thanks for showing (again) how to tweak Scala to get rid of dots and braces!

Comment: @cubiclettuce I guess great minds think alike :) As a matter of fact, I'd started out with something similar.

Comment: Well, I don't think this is correct since `b` is unbound in the question other than `b > 1`. However, the `toString` radix cannot be greater than 36 as stated in the API documentation.

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- You are absolutely right, I will fix that when I’m on my laptop.

Comment: Great "fix"! And you can save 1 byte when replacing "->" by "," (still treated as a tuple in this case) :)

Comment: @cubiclettuce Thanks! I forgot about auto-tupling and thought I was being smart by avoiding double parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>87</s>  86 bytes

Returns a comma-separated string.

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>--k&&g(k)+((h=k=>a=k?[k%n,...h(k/n|0)]:[])(k)+''==a.reverse()?[,k]:''))(1001)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcqxDsIgEADQ3f@w3MWC1M0m134IYSCVUr0GDJhO/jva0bi@vIfbXJny/fmSMd18nalGGiAQ0yAlN00AxhPAsoMjHg0fY6uUWoDP8a3R9sbifoQgcir7zefiAUfTsu2FQIRO6w7rlGJJq1drCjB/DfHwS5c/uSLWDw)

#### How?

```javascript
n => (                        // n = input base
  g = k =>                    // g is a recursive function taking a counter k
    --k &&                    //   decrement k; abort if it's equal to 0
    g(k) + (                  //   otherwise do a recursive call and append the ...
      ( h = k =>              //   ... result of the recursive function h
        a = k ?               //     which builds an array a[]
          [ k % n,            //     consisting of each digit of k in base n,
            ...h(k / n | 0) ] //     dividing k by n and taking the integer part
        :                     //     for the next iteration until k = 0
          []                  //
      )(k) + ''               //   invoke h with k and coerce the result to a string
      == a.reverse() ?        //   if this is palindromic:
        [, k]                 //     append a comma followed by k to the output
      :                       //   else:
        ''                    //     just append an empty string
    )                         //
)(1001)                       // initial call to g with k = 1001
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
A³ô fÈìU êê
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QbP0IGbI7FUg6uo&input=Mg)

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to LegionMammal978*

```
foS=↔B⁰ŀdḋ9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Py0/2PZR2xSnR40bjjakPNzRbfn//38jAA)

The actual 'based palindrome' code is 7 bytes (`foS=↔B⁰`), but specifying 0...1000 costs <s>5</s> 4 (thanks to LegionMammal978) more bytes.
We could save a byte if it's Ok to output a few more based palindromes with values up to decimal 1024 (`foS=↔B⁰ŀ□32`).

```
f               # output the truthy values of
       ŀdḋ9     # series from zero up to one less than 1001
                # (decimal interpretation of binary digits of '9')
 o              # based on combination of 2 functions:
  S=↔           # 1. is it equal to reverse of itself?
     B⁰         # 2. digits in base given by argument
```

Comment: Would something like `concat(range(1000), 0)` save bytes? As the output can be in any order, something that generates `[1,2,3,...,1000]` then either pre/appends `0` could be shorter

Comment: Would filtering the natural numbers (and also checking they're less than 1000) instead of a range help?

Comment: -1 byte: `ŀ1001` is equivalent to `ŀdḋ9`.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 - Wonderful!  Thanks!

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing - Sorry for late response: the problem was expressing the number ```1000``` or ```1001```, which seemed to always cost 4 bytes (since Husk doesn't compress numbers).  LegionMammal's clever/sneaky trick saves a byte here.

Comment: @user - See above.  The problem was the number ```1000``` itself, rather than how to use it.  Your solution would have worked, but not saved bytes.  Thanks anyway, though!

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
ＮθＩΦ⊕φ⁼↨ιθ⮌↨ιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDObG4RMMtM6cEKOqZl1yUmpuaV5KaopGmqaPgWliamFOs4ZRYnKqRqaNQCBQKSi1LLQJyEWJgYP3/v@V/3bIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ              Input the base `b`
     φ          Predefined variable 1000
    ⊕           Incremented
   Φ            Filter on implicit range
        ι       Current value
       ↨ θ      Converted to base `b`
      ⁼         Equals
            ι   Current value
           ↨ θ  Converted to base `b`
          ⮌     Reversed
  Ｉ             Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Comment: This answer does not output 1000 as one of the palindromes with an input of 9

Comment: @GioD Sorry, I overlooked that 1000 was included, as it didn't appear in any of the provided test cases.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

Thanks to [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime) for -2 bytes!
A bug fixed thanks to [Siu Ching Pong](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74641/siu-ching-pong-asuka-kenji)!

Requires index origin `0`.

```apl
⍸⎕(⊤≡∘⌽⊤)¨⍳1001
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97f@j3h2P@qZqPOpa8qhz4aOOGY969gLZmodWPOrdbGhgYAhS9R@owtP/UdsEAy4ukJiCAoZ6S0tLLi51BSMrda40LiMurke9a7jUDQ3AXEMDKN8SzLWEyxoYQuUNDAE)

```apl
                 ⍝ tradfn taking the base as input
          ⍳1001  ⍝ the indices up to 1000
 ⍵(     )¨       ⍝ apply a function to each index as a right argument and the input base as a left argument:
      ⌽⊤         ⍝  the reverse of the index converted to the input base 
    ≡            ⍝  does it match 
   ⊤             ⍝  the index converted to the input base
⍸                ⍝ all truthy indices
```

Comment: You can use a tradfn for [-2](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97f@j3h2P@qZqPOpa8qhz4aOOGY969gLZmodWPOrdbOhqDFL0H6jA0/9R2wQDLi51BSMrda40LiMurke9a7jUDQ3AXEMDKF/BEsy3BAA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Comment: This answer is not correct for `b = 1001`. `1000` should be included in the output for `b = 1001`, but it is not.

Comment: @SiuChingPong It turns out `⍳` is not inclusive with `⎕IO←0`, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

## C - [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU/basQgEH3PVwxZFtQYkvStiP0XtSY7sDWLMS24m2@3mtCSgWFmzgXOmHYyJiWUQ98PXPEoRqLpc5w9Edi2uePr9fDowkjq6yfUHCktrJLIo@yFEqqTmkYZmW7UVYstZTF8KXSkLMpPhoO5KQ@M5eObVs8Kcv3c8G6BsKbZUTjQUsWmQYIKM5LDI/7JvyyXC@Q48iMnAn3iS/yTeg0LqesTcnwqoGPg7WIDLOimu23XxcK4OhNwdsC6Xb9V2z5TGvr0lt5/AQ)

```c
i=1001,a,z;f(b){for(;i--;i-z||printf("%d ",i))for(a=i,z=0;a;a/=b)z=z*b+a%b;}
```

## Explanation

Sufficiently different from [my earlier answer](/a/216970/39490) to warrant posting separately.  This time, we completely reverse the number, then compare to the original.  So we don't need to eliminate trailing zeros, or special-case `0`.

```c
void fun(int b)
{
    for (int i = 1001; i--;) {
        int z = 0;
        for (int a = i; a != 0; a /= b) {
            z = z*b + a%b;
        }
        if (i==z) {
            printf("%d ",i);
        }
    }
}
```

This method works reliably for `i` up to `INT_MAX/b` and `b` up to `INT_MAX`, or the appropriate equivalents if we change the integer type used.  For unsigned types (or with `gcc -fwrapv`), it should work for the full range of `i`.

Comment: And here I was thinking my answer was clever...nice job!

Comment: Thanks @EasyasPi - I did take inspiration from you, replacing the `if () printf()` with `||printf()`, so thanks for that.

Comment: [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU/bDoIwDH3nKxoIycYlgj6ZZf5LN7k0UTCImgz49rmBGs9L23NJTnXeaG0tZZgZUTPFp7ofGMmyOgiUJCiXlJt5vg3UjTUL4zOEGXHuXUYWAgXupOJGmkSlGCuxWGeEK1LH/IJDozPQLQ6QJO548mAKwOHV0qUClqTpysLGeviYAgk49sS2jPiJ3x5RBK6KPLk2oP50/8Kf@zHeWRh@mCVY1mltWdi9Pb4B "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 63 bytes

```hs
f b|let 0%m=m;n%m=div n b%(m*b+mod n b)=[n|n<-[0..1000],n==n%0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYgxDsIwDAB3XuElUgO0ctkQ@CVVh6RpICJ2I1ox9e2YMsINJ93d3fwYc1aN4Nc8LoCGiS@yOaQXCHhT8d4feArfsNTJKte6w6ZpEbE/CpEY7JVdEiAI0w42yjPJAlWEFu3vOP312ep7iNndZq2HUj4)

Based on a nice idea from [dingledooper's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216981/20260): to check that `n` is a base-`b` palindrome, don't generate the list of base-`b` digits, but reverse `n` as a base-`b` number by running a base-conversion reading digits from the end, and check that the result still equals `n`.

The code `|let 0%m=m;n%m=div n b%(m*b+mod n b)` recursively defines an infix function `%` that reverses base `n` (given `0` as an initial second argument). Defining it inside of a `let` guard lets us access the argument `b` to the main function, whereas a standalone function would need to keep passing it with each recursive call.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>92</s> 85 bytes

```python
lambda b:[i for i in range(1001)if(f:=lambda n:n*[0]and[n%b]+f(n//b))(i)==f(i)[::-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBCsIwEEX3niIbYUYpTXSjAzlJmkVCnTig0xC68fSxiwpuPu/B49fP@lz0equtFz/1V3rnOZlMQQwvzYgRNS1peYCz1qEwMPm9UtJTsDHpHPSY45lBxzEjgqD3vG0gGlyMvTbRFcp2gXj4yeWP74j9Cw)

Thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper) for saving 7 bytes!

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYxBCsIwEEX3niIbYUYpTXSjAzlJmkVCnTig0xC68fSxiwpuPu/B49fP@lz0equtFz/1V3rnOZlMQQwvzYgRNS1peYCz1qEwMPm9UtJTsDHpHPSY45lBxzEjgqD3vG0gGlyMvTbRFcp2gXj4yeWP74j9Cw)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 27 bytes

```
((-:|.)@(#.inv)"0#])i.@1001
```

### how

- `(...) i.@1001` - The whole thing is a J hook, meaning that the argument will be the left arg to everything in the parens, and the right arg will be the integers from 0 to 1000: `i.@1001`
- `...#]` The phrase inside the parens uses copy `#` to filter the right arg `]` by the boolean mask resulting from the phrase on the left of `#`:
- `(-:|.)@(#.inv)"0` - The rank 0 `"0` ensures the phrase applies to each individual number of the right arg.  The phrase itself first converts each of those numbers to a list of digits in the base given by the left arg  `(#.inv)`, and then checks if that list equals its reverse `(-:|.)@`.  The entire phrase will thus return 1 when this is true and 0 otherwise, and this boolean mask will filter the right arg as desired.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZJBbxQxDIXv8ytCi7S7kncUx3EcrwSqQOKEOPTeE6Jqe4AbF@hvX77ZhRMjfcrIk7Hfe8nLOd@cLMpD6eVtqSW3Z1lu1t1jeXcquyIUT3Bcy8f7z5/O@/3x9Hs93O1v1@fvPw839fbh8Lzeaa16PizLt69PP8pjadeX3e5fQev/lVqX5cuHtbTj@19VVExcQlLURUOaSgsxyibdxVWGyWCHyXRJk2RnDVFlZae27U8TZY9O3tPpkdJo0Zx3pyc/t9y6mlhzsU579ttknSG9MotevW8zXXqo9NyGK6BvsDJ9oGkgaiAj0BqbLvZO5k3@namS9EpUZ/jr1afWv0YbVjtmB3bnZphSu/ikSpk6H@bVofIZiENxoihWuipKlImKcmVaqw23QKNm0MFhQMCEZAiqru6BiYZaIzUjXCMdm4CrXrt0hQYGSOsOAwImJHLrlg6QphtsR4UHJxEPv6TlJDjqkKHQwKCDA2ZHwITEOCd6SZRTCIMOviUMpBKcUnCCs07ShgYGHRwGBBDfTCKsKcmpJLcjDTo4DAjgpnDjX89/AA)

Comment: If the output is too long, it would be clipped by `...`. Please check your output for `each f 10`. :)

Comment: It's correct.  That's just J's default output control truncating a long line.  I updated the TIO link so it will display the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks! Still truncated for `b = 1000`.

Comment: Updated again :)

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Comment: @Steve Sure, explanation added.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 100 bytes

```c
i=1001,a,z;f(b){for(;--i;)for(a=i,z=0;i%b*a;a/=b)if(a==z||a==(z=z*b+a%b))printf("%d ",i);puts("0");}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TU9db4QgEHz3V2y8mABi1L41hP4XoOBtcsWLYptw52@noOnHPuzOzuxksqabjEkJ5TgMI1c8Ckc0fbh5IaLrUNCClEQe5SCw0UwJ1UtN0WVWxuczdxJlZLpVjab0vqAPjtTNO9QcqbhvYSX1UFOxp6zAh0JPClDLZDiYq1qAsbx80upRQa6vK94sENa2BwsnW6rYNEhQYUZyesSv@BN8uUDOlm85HvQ/vbz1t53/CugZLHa1AVb0081222rBbd4EnD2w/rjfq/2YKY1Dekmv3w)

### Ungolfed code

```c
void fun(int b)
{
    for (int i = 1001; --i;) {
        if (i%b) {              /* no leading/trailing zeros */
            for (int a = i, z = 0; a != 0; a /= b) {
                if (a==z) {
                    printf("%d ",i);
                }
                z = z*b + a%b;
                if (a==z) {
                    printf("%d ",i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    puts("0");
}
```

### Explanation

This outputs the numbers highest first, since no particular order was specified.  For each candidate number, we reduce it (as `a`) by successively dividing by the base, using the remainder to build up the reverse number (in `z`).  If `a` becomes equal to `z`, then we have a palindrome.  Ordinarily, we'd stop there (`a >= z` in the loop condition), but for golfing, we continue all the way to `a==0`.

We need to test the equality both before and after transferring the remainder to `z`, to accept both odd and even length palindromes.

Finally, we print `0`, which is always a palindrome, and is easier to special-case than include in the loop.

The method works for integers up to `INT_MAX` if we ungolf the condition `i%b*a` back to `i%b&&a`, and would also work for other integer types.

Comment: Very creative answer! I like it :)

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 18 bytes

```
{&{x~|x}'x\'!1001}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlqtuqKupqJWvSJGXdHQwMCw9n@auqGBgpGC5X8A)

- `x\'!1001` convert each of 0..1000 to base-x representation
- `{x~|x}'` check if each representation is a palindrome
- `&` get indices of trues

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 67 bytes

```haskell
b&n=take n$mod n b:b&div n b
f b=[n|n<-[0..1000],reverse(b&n)==b&n]
```

`f` is the function of interest. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0ktz7YkMTtVIU8lNz9FIU8hySpJLSWzDMTiSlNIso3Oq8mz0Y020NMzNDAwiNUpSi1LLSpO1QBq1LS1BZKx/3MTM/MUbBVS8rkUgKCgKDOvREEjTcHQQBNVwAiNb6n5HwA)

Perhaps the only clever bit here is the use of `take n` to make a base case for the digit-expansion function. When `n=0`, `take n` ignores its argument and so the recursion stops via laziness; when `n>0`, there certainly won't be more than `n` digits so it's safe to keep only the first `n`. The following definition is equivalent (and equally long):

```
b&0=[]
b&n=mod n b:b&div n b
```

...but the `take n` version is more fun because it's more confusing. ^_^

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 74 bytes

```ruby
->b{(0..1e3).select{(a=(g=->k,r=[]{k>0?g[k/b,r<<k%b]:r})[_1])==a.reverse}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6pWsNAT88w1VhTrzg1JzW5pLomr0Yj0VYj3VbXLlunyDY6tjrbzsA@PTpbP0mnyMYmWzUp1qqoVjM6L1bT1jZRryi1LLWoOLW29n@BQlq0oUEsF4g2glCWUMoy9j8A)

TIO uses an older version of Ruby, whereas in Ruby 2.7, we've numbered parameters, which saves two bytes.

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```ruby
->b{(0..1e3).select{|k|(k=k.to_s b)==k.reverse}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6pWsNAT88w1VhTrzg1JzW5pLomu0Yj2zZbryQ/vlghSdMWyCxKLUstKk6trf1foJAWbWgQywWijSCUZex/AA)

Doesn't works for bases over 64, due to the limitation in `.to_s` method.

Comment: This doesn't work for bases over 64, does it?

Comment: @Sisyphus - Hm, I didn't noticed that, thanks I'll mention this.

Comment: You may take a look at the answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216938/74641). Scala has similar limitations and he solved by another algorithm.

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- Hopefully, now it works for bases > 36 :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>82</s> 81 bytes

(or [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##Zc1BCsIwEAXQq9RF4H8QrLiykKsoGZvoQMxIUnXTu6cH6LvAq11Ci/P9E7KWudo7Nt/TtzwWtQJhsgodtAzjdI4XasJB1zXkDASv7uTkhnHK9oQehXRO6H2NPwSS7WV/KPcFruwb) using the rather-complicated delimiter of "`\n[1]` ")

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to caird coinheringaahing*

```r
function(b)for(i in 0:1e3)if(!i||all((a=i%/%b^(0:log(i,b))%%b)==rev(a)))cat(i,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc1BCsIwEAXQq9RF6P8gWHFlIVdRZtpEBmIiaXXVu6fdu32bV5vKEubnR5LluZZ3WHyL3zytVjKUsVRYZ7kbxmu40SJOtm2SEiDe3MXpA8OYygt2VtI5pfc1/CAkJ1kP7nv@J7iz7Q)

Manually calculates digits in new base representation, and checks whether they are the same as themselves reversed.

```r
function(b)
 for(i in 0:1000)               # loop i through zero to 1000
  if(!i                         # if i is zero (always a palindrome),
   ||                           # or
   all(                         # if all the digits of
    (a=i%/%b^(0:log(i,b))%%b)   # a = the representation of i in base b
    ==rev(a))                   # are the same as themselves reversed
  )cat(i,'')                    # output this i
```

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##Zc1BCsIwEAXQq9RF6P8gWHFlIVdRZtpEBmIiaXXVu6fdu32bV5vKEubnR5LluZZ3WHyL3zytVjKUsVRYZ7kbxmu40SJOtm2SEiDe3MXpA8OYygt2VtI5pfc1/CAkJ1kP7nv@J7iz7Q)

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##Zc1BDoIwEAXQq@CiYX4CEcMKQq@CmYHWTFJb06Ir7l7du32bl6twcfv9xUHjntPTFVv9O26HpkgCnzJpo7EZ5psboZ4uep4cAmX3IV56NVcjKw1zSA/STgBjBNYysPHxk7bF/0ET6hc)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>77</s> 89 bytes

Fixed for bases greater than 36.

```javascript
b=>{for(i=-1;i<1e3;){j=[],k=++i;while(k|=0)j.push(k%b),k/=b;''+j==j.reverse()&&print(i)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcRBDsIgEADAu/@w3Q1tLXqxoetHjIdiIF0wSqDiofbtGOcwbspTukcOS5vPxVLRdFntKwJTKxWP0pwUro6ut8aTEKw@Mz8M@C/16LrwTjP4vcbGH0iruhaOyHXRZBOTAayqEPm5AOO2FQuyx52F478Byw8)

Comment: Well, I don't think this is correct since in the question `b` is unbound other than `b > 1`. However, the radix parameter of `toString` cannot be greater than `36` as stated in the API documentation. You may take a look at the answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216938/74641). Scala has similar limitations and he solved by another algorithm.

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji-, Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>102</strike> <strike>100</strike> <strike>98</strike> <strike>95</strike> <strike>87</strike> 75 bytes

-14 bytes thanks to mazzy!

```powershell
param($u)0..1e3|?{for($b=@();$_=($_-($b+=$_%$u)[-1])/$u){}"$b"-eq$b[11..0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBToQwEIbvPMWEzJo2CFI9qWkkevHEycQDIQTMbCRhAduSPbB9dizguptsjHPpPzP/fDNp3@1J6U9qmgm3Q/th6q6VHrgYp75U5Y7hwOMoEnR3eBq3nWJYyYTxRywkwyJ0aSCx2DhXFoqc3zgxWh8rP6QvrDIhoijO7TQTrYeGtHkpNWmQkLBlTzIuzxx12w9mFnPzni91e/2X4fY/g4h/HB4/33yADYxLng67ipQUdgXgOi0Bi2iRa1WRHpq5fPX7Q5Cc@u@qNhS@dtqAn705Kpyx8@zZ7QRkRyTPfbiMMO1S2jd1SxfIh@MB/nrNiR0Enp2@AQ)

Comment: You can use `?` instead `%`

Comment: @mazzy a maddeningly simple change for so many bytes! Thanks again! Updated my tio code to be more compact, per your recommendation

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBNa4NAEIbv/opBJmUX61bbU1uWSnPpyVOhBxGJZUMF49r9IAezv92u2jSBUDKXfWfmnWeG7eVeKP0l2nbEre0@TSM7HoCPYew3arMjaGnCWCoeDi/DViqCNc8IfcaKE6xin0Ycq5V3FXFa0jsvBhdiHcbiG@sCa7aWtjOMJaUbJ64L0Aht1hstNHDIyLwtG@ZniqbrrZnE1Hykc93d/me4v2ZIk19HQM83H2AFw5zndlcLxVO3AHCZ5oAVm@VSVULbdirf/P0TZKf@h2qMiN@kNhAW754KZ@yyePU7AckRScsQLiPOZS72bdOJC@TT8YBwuebEjqLAjT8 "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy clever getting rid of the temporary variable; hopefully one day I'll catch those on my own! :P Thanks! Also, found another trick in the [Tips for golfing in PowerShell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191/tips-for-golfing-in-powershell) to cut another 6 bytes!

Comment: It's clever! ٩(^‿^)۶

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `M`, 7 bytes

```
k1'⁰τḂ⁼
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJNIiwiIiwiazEn4oGwz4ThuILigbwiLCIiLCIyIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 66 bytes

```
. as$a|range(1001)|select([while(.>0;./$a|floor)|.%$a]|reverse==.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/19PIbFYJbGmKDEvPVXD0MDAULOmODUnNblEI7o8IzMnVUPPzsBaTx@oJC0nP79Is0ZPVSUxtqYotSy1qDjV1lZP8/9/SwA)

### Explanation

````
. as $a |                # Assign the input to $a.
range(1001) |            # For every item in [0..1000]:
select (                 # Filter out all items where:
  [ while(. > 0;         #     The list of quotients from repeatedly
     . / $a | floor)     #     short-dividing by $a

      |. % $a]           #     And then modulo-ing by $a
  | reverse == .)        # is equal to its reverse
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
f_IjTQUh^T3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Py3eMyskMDQjLsT4/38jAA)

---

```
f_IjTQUh^T3 | Explanation
------------+---------------------------------------
f           | filter
      Uh^T3 | the range [0, 1001)
   jTQ      | on whether each number in base <input>
 _I         | equals itself reversed
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, 118 bytes

```java
b->{for(int i=-1;i++<1e3;){var s=b.toString(i,b);if(s.contains(new StringBuffer(s).reverse()))System.out.println(i);}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVA9T8MwEN37K06dbCWxCEw0hAGmDpShY9XBcS@VS@pE9iUIRf7twfkoE0gsJ927d@@9u4vsZHI5fQyqks7Bm9SmXwFoQ2hLqRB2YwvQ1foEim0DfkYLBc8C7FehOJKkFezAQD4UyXNf1paFfdB5kmY6ip5SfMh430kLLi8E1Xuy2pyZjoOKLpkTqjYUjB0z@Anz9KUtS7TMcWGxQ@uQcc73X47wKuqWRBNIVBmmeeb9kI1BmraoQpAlzxT4GlTZLHg4guTzLbeAhI5epUPYwGgcoMOxT@/i@/jRL1SAXzzXW9O0tIF1dFOYvvEX@72lmf7DMkKx/6wuMz@92g/f)

**Explanation:**

```java
b->{                           // Method with Integer parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=-1;i++<1e3;){      //  Loop `i` in the range [0,1000]:
    var s=b.toString(i,b);     //   Convert `i` to base-`b` as String
    if(s.contains(new StringBuffer(s).reverse()))
                               //   If this String is a palindrome:
      System.out.println(i);}} //    Print `i` with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```factor
[ 1e3 [0,b] swap '[ _ >base dup reverse = ] filter ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY4xC8IwFIR3f8VtLhJanVQUN3FxEadSJI0vNdgm8SVV@uvrAzdv/O6OO6tNDjxdL6fzcYNe54di7VtKeBJ76mB5/OGoOREj0WsgbyQQmXIeIzuf4XVPKeo/rEzw1rVwAdvZrCywxHqqUNIKVbFoaqSPjphXuGHf6ES4DxFMb5Il7FDDui7LZi0lpRR8J8yEPgbxy0Ik17h1Xl5lZHaH6Qs)