# Make an array of random 128 bit integers

Tags: code-golf, integer, random

Given an input value \$n\$, construct an array of \$n\$ random 128 bit (unsigned) integers.  The integers should be uniformly random.

Your code can use any in built random number generation function it has or you can implement your own. Clearly this challenge is harder (and more fun) in lower level languages.

Comment: Can we assume \$n>0\$?

Comment: @ovs Yes you can.

Comment: Do we have to allocate the array ourselves or can we have it passed in?

Comment: If we decide to implement our own RNG, how good does it have to be? (returning the same number repeatedly is technically uniform, if the input seed is)

Comment: @thedefault better than that :)  any rng you find on the internet will be fine

Comment: Well, @thedefault.'s rng [can be found](https://xkcd.com/221/) on the internet...

Comment: Also, what can we do if language lacks 128-bit integers? Is returning array of 64-bit integers that's twice as long as requested and uniformly random allowed?

Comment: You can still print out 128 bit integers in decimal as some of the solutions are doing. It's not ideal but better than nothing.

Comment: not necessarily harder in lower level languages as newer x86 processors have a builtin rng instruction

Comment: @qwr I was thinking about C really. Are the posted answers in C correct?

Answer (score 13):

## x86-64 machine code, 10 bytes

Fortunately, there is a built-in RNG. Requires the RDRAND instruction.

```
00000000: c1e1 020f c7f0 abe2 fac3                 ..........
```

Disassembled:

```
shl ecx, 2
label:
 rdrand eax
 stosd
 loop label
ret
```

Outputs to a pre-allocated buffer in `rdi`. `n` is passed in `ecx` (arrays with 2^30 elements and more are not supported).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLBTuMwED3HXzHLCpSSNKQsWqFttjf2uh@AqspxnMaVY0e2AxGIby8zDiAoJ3vezHvzZuya@@54FDzABurCQ1XB3f9/zHHT2P4PA99pkGLK4ZqB5rXUiIFrKA@STxj4YH2DSWuHuYI5GRjba1tzDbPQ7tHxYZCOfQ1Rq7cPs770isGhH94YjFzMtngh3m39VEbosZFQ@dAoE4puc4LZb5BWNWFyCtIZeLCqOTGV7nYjaq2ub3fhEgJ3exlyQATMYs0iYXAYfq6DacGeWSI67sCM/f2vcrtmCXEO8BdKurfpj2kRw1Uea8ot3m9uMffYKS1TlEhQI6HcIcsoO8E5rErI5rJkgitkk9rLO@kAy@UGSqQmwxiofxr5W7T6gaxKjF4Y2em5Mmn0GgdagxfctOnZeXOWwwUNmHwZvx5b9NFzra1IzaVXT9K2nydfEOVkgUjK47KS1rqUGqm4BTwq6qmyLBqOW8TiexXttk5KCqNZel7DfQ/LFqRuf9/Qd2R7IeL714VlxRUv7BjwL1S4lOPxFQ) (a helper function is needed because of the unusual calling convention)

Comment: It's worth noting explicitly that it outputs to a pre-allocated buffer at `ES:RDI`! Common modern operating systems use a flat segment model, but x86-64 doesn't require/guarantee that. For one byte extra, you can optimize the performance of the code by generating and storing 64-bit values (`RDRAND rax; STOSQ`). This also allows switching from `SHL ecx, 2` (which is 3 bytes) to `SHL ecx, 1` (which is 2 bytes), or even `ADD ecx, ecx` (still 2 bytes). Unfortunately, the 64-bit version of `RDRAND` is 1 byte larger, as is the 64-bit version of `STOS`, so it's a net change of +1 byte.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention in my previous comment that the `RDRAND` instruction is an *optional* part of the x86-64 ISA. It is supported by Intel Ivy Bridge and later. This is not an issue for Code Golf, of course, but whenever I've used it, I've preferred to call out that requirement in the title, since that's a stipulation of what environment I'm targeting with my submission.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't know very much about segments, but Google results say that the cs/ds/ss/es segments always start at zero and end at 2^64 in long mode (and these results don't seem OS-specific). I tried using 64-bit rdrand/stosq, but I also saw that it was 1 byte longer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
ƛ₇ƛ₀℅;B
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9B%E2%82%87%C6%9B%E2%82%80%E2%84%85%3BB&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

```
ƛ       # Map...
 ₇ƛ  ;  # Map 128 to...
   ₀℅   # Random choice from digits of 10
      B # Convert to base 10
```

Or if it's allowed not to complete within the lifetime of the universe, 5 bytes:

```
ƛ₇Eʁ℅
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9B%E2%82%87E%CA%81%E2%84%85&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

```
ƛ     # Map...
 ₇E   # 2 ** 128
   ʁ  # Range (0...x)
    ℅ # Choose a random item
```

It's trying to generate a 2<sup>128</sup>-item array, do you think it's gonna finish any time soon?

Comment: So `₇E℅` gives you a random digit from the decimal value of `2¹²⁸`?

Comment: @Neil Yeah, although I'm trying to change that - see the second-to-last item of [this tasklist](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/issues/160)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>72</s>  70 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [@RedwolfPrograms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79857/redwolf-programs)*

The helper function `g` builds a 128-bit integer, one bit at a time. This seems a bit long...

```javascript
n=>Array(n).fill(128n).map(g=k=>k--&&BigInt(Math.random()<.5)|2n*g(k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoMwEADA38huIQEthR6MoDcPfcSiJo2JuxJDQfDvqbdhVvrRMSW/Z8UyL8WawqbrU6ITGLX1MULdvG9utIMzwXRBqaoavBs5w4fyVyfiWTbAVr/wavjhICCWSfiQuOgoDiw87/kD)

Comment: I think this saves 2 bytes, by using `Array` and `fill`: https://tio.run/##DchBCoMwEADA38huIQEthR6MoDcPfcSiJo2JuxJDQfDvqbdhVvrRMSW/Z8UyL8WawqbrU6ITGLX1MULdvG9utIMzwXRBqaoavBs5w4fyVyfiWTbAVr/wavjhICCWSfiQuOgoDiw87/kD

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), <s>57</s> 37 bytes

```
&'wa+0> #;\1-:9j;+1?;#*2\_$.1-:!#@_1j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XUy9P1DawU1C2jjHUtbLMstY2tLdW1jKKiVfRAwooKjvEG2b9/2@sAAA) Note that the input has to have a trailing space because of a bug in the interpreter.

The part generating a random 128-bit number bit by bit is explained below:

```
'wa+0> #;\1-:9j;+1?;#*2\_\.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XL0/UNrBTULaOMdS1ssyy1ja0t1bWMoqJj9Fz@P8fAA)

```
'wa+                           push loop counter, initially 129
    0                          push initial number 0
     >                         if the IP is coming from the right, turn it around
       #;                      # skips the next instruction
         \                     swap to the loop counter
          1-:                  decrement it and push an additional copy
             9j                skip over the next 9 instructions
                        _      if the loop counter is 0, go right:
                         \.      swap to the number and print it
                           @     terminate the execution
                        _      else, go right:
                     *2\         swap to the number and multiply by 2
                  ?              go into a random direction, if up or down is selected, ? gets executed again
        ;          ;             if right is selected, jump to the next semicolon and continue with the next iteration
     > #;      ;+1               if left, increment the number and go to the next iteration
```

Animation with 9 instead of 128 bits:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>68</s> 42 bytes

```c
f(n,a)char*a;{for(n*=16;n--;)a[n]=rand();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRdT9swFH3Pr7gKQrJDSRMWWlAoEmIIVeJLBbRpgKKQOGAtdZDtABvqb@@undImg0nzgxvde87xucdpss2HLJvPCyJ6Kc0eU@ml8VtRSSK8UTiIxeZmTNMbcTeSqcgJjWfzNS6yss4Z7Cmd88p/3HcAV6dc8ntTX9W40PrXE1Om6vQ9x/PgWnHxAHmV1VMmNMvh@PAQDAhqofiDwEqSIC/c2gEulGZpDlWBzRXFyFT3qiqZyrBg2TkrQKRThuS6YSfaB/hWyZ8KXrh@tOdE/tAP4b7WICptZJpi6G8BMdUWGV7@piKKQiXgNM3g/BK@QxigXOQ7Xt95t/BxhqVgbBIAu67HZ1eDKDk9QI2dKBoMoygYfhkGu9vb4SDcvj45AdRcQ0EuGFyEQdIw8MSPy6ABUDrchd9MVky1yUct8q6zLF9eTcZnx@MfRxPySs01wuuyd3WeNO2m1cU6jtKp5hnejYYniXtSm/FqskrOFKjzZt8PA5NZ3DwXQEwP9lsJUNtqwGatZEq8evOuwMgqQr@VRNzBo5IG0DLlpSEs8Ouf4mWG/Y7xxTm0g9lYgArirvtuK5NVoBQuJuN6EPWWJy8kZnZnpWKfzGa9Imvh8jNj5kx3KY5bR1cyXUthQ505jsl3mnJBniue29CV/cuC5lNGIAAKht1@sVMpb8LgbvQWzLBTkDDoYcmg8AMAxF4ZHwUx3wuDeGODUzNAJzGjwO@sq6daK@K65hntNfYB/edub3Jw9tXecOO@ZZ4E1JrHL8K7fyD0f71HK@vRv5xH1vi7bxNoWb7eCjA/cCvcXjNCbznJzOvP/wA)

- takes an 0 array and the number requested as input
- the array I taken as *char to be manipulated byte by byte so that we set every 8bit to rand() which is RAND_MAX e.g. At least 32767 and thus guaranteed to affect every bit
- numbers printed as decimal thanks to [this good answer on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11660651/7699953) I copy-pasted-adapted

Comment: The upper halves of these random numbers are always very small (and not printed in the TIO link). I think you can replace 64 with 128 and remove the %4.

Comment: It still doesn't work (and the upper halves still aren't printed in the TIO link)

Comment: Seems to segfault on TIO

Comment: @Anush yes I operated on 32 chars exceeding a little bit the array lol

Comment: try this `f(n,a)int*a;{for(n*=4;n--;)a[n]=rand();}`

Comment: @Johan du Toit your suggestion would put me to 35bytes (using `f(*a,n){..`. Unfortunately with int* the last bit(or first) every 4 bytes is not set and remains always 0.. Look at RAND_MAX printed at the end, that's why I used char* instead.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 18 bytes

```julia
!n=rand(UInt128,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHPtigxL0Uj1DOvxNDIQidP87@ioYGBQo2dQkpmcUFOYuV/AA)

sorry, <s>boring</s> useful built-in

Comment: A great advert for julia. But why such an ancient version?

Comment: that's the latest version available on TIO, this will of course work for any 1.x version

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/)

**<s>54</s> 53 bytes**: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjexQKMoMS8FiNNTdaJNtLTMTGK18jS50orycxVAMkAqM7cgv6hE639BUWZeiUKahqnmfwA)

```python
lambda n:map(randrange,[4**64]*n)
from random import*
```

**69 bytes**: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCoAgEADAe6/YWxohFNQh6CXVwVJpIXdFDer11twnvPlk6oub13JpvxsNNC1IWXBSd9Rk2AuUytLBxor6tE8tW5SOIyAgLd24NbRV6APHDJxKiP8GJwZZPg)

```python
lambda n:[int(os.urandom(i).encode('hex'),i)for i in[16]*n]
import os
```

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/)

**54 bytes**: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKlorN7FAoygxLyUps6RYJ9rQyCJWK08zliutKD9XoTg1uSi1pFghM7cgv6hE639BUWZeiUaahqmm5n8A)

```python
lambda n:[*map(randbits,[128]*n)]
from secrets import*
```

**<s>57</s> 56 bytes**: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKlorN7FAoygxLwWI01N1ok20tMxMYrXyNGO50orycxVAUkAqM7cgv6hE639BUWZeiUaahqmm5n8A)

```python
lambda n:[*map(randrange,[4**64]*n)]
from random import*
```

**70 bytes**: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCoAgEADAe6/wlkYEEXUIeklJKGUt5K6sdvD11twn5HQTDsUtW3mMt4cROK@AqXNMfrc5nVFS7F42eJCXoNrawlUrRyxAAK79pBvUFfhAnATFEvjv0slRqfIB)

```python
lambda n:[int.from_bytes(os.urandom(i),'big')for i in[16]*n]
import os
```

Comment: `1<<128` can also be `4**64`, which saves a byte.

Comment: You might also want to add `eval('uuid.uuid4().int,'*n)`; it works in both versions of Python as far as I can tell.

Comment: Is uuid random? Isn't it the same every time?

Comment: @Anush `uuid4` is a function to generate a random uuid ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4))

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that.

Comment: Type 4 UUIDs aren't uniformly random; some bits are fixed.

Comment: @thedefault. thanks for the info, I don't know anything about UUID's. Removed from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <sup><s>33</s></sup> 31 bytes

```
[ [ 128 2^ random ] replicate ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcrBCkBAEAbgu6f4n0BRSjyAXFzkpFXTGpG11hgHT79OvvO3kNVT4tC3XVNhZ/HscJCuCMKqb5DNK4T8fB64@XrYW75RJ0kRR4zI8hL59AcD4eA2S8ow0ZJzSOMH)

- `replicate` Create a sequence given a number of elements and a generating quotation.
- `128 2^` 2<sup>128</sup>
- `random` Return a uniformly random number (via Factor's default Mersenne Twister PRNG) from 0 to whatever number is on top of the data stack minus one.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>24</s> 22 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to pajonk*

```r
runif(scan())*4^64%/%1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v6g0LzNNozg5MU9DU1PLJM7MRFVf1fC/ocF/AA)

Output is an integer uniformly selected from the range `0`...`2^128-1`.
[R](https://www.r-project.org/) does not natively support 128-bit inteters, so the data type of the output is a floating-point representation ([click here](https://tio.run/##RYzNCsIwEITvPsVSKSRSfwrFi/RVhFi7ZSHdhOwGKeKzx3jyNsw336SCI2aelAIbsm@ZHP8LSzfYg86i8EouxjmVlJnQ/GbG2sNwvw7tue3LZyeV@82g6S@2k5iIFTtcdWzaEza2/jxJoncbOO9rXkgFAgL64JR4OcZQFeC8PuYkUL4) for a TIO link that dispays all the digits, instead of displaying in scientific notation).  Note though that although 128-bit numbers can be represented using floating-point variables,  [rounding inaccuracies can occur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848762/13432336) when more than 53 bits are required.

If floating point output (with its associated rounding inaccuracies) isn't Ok, we can output the exact value in the form of a vector of binary digits for **[35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyexoCCnUsPQqjg5MU9DU6c4MbcgJ1WnwtbAylCn2NbQyELzv6HBfwA)** (or flattened into a string of bits for [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVozgxtyAnVcPAylDH0MhCqzg5MU9DUydEUwfM19FRUtL8b2jwHwA)).

If neither floating point nor binary output are Ok, then base-[R](https://www.r-project.org/) will struggle a bit, but we can still manage by constructing string of random `0`-`9` digits (so including leading zeros), and checking that its lexicographically smaller than `"340282366920938463463374607431768211456"`, for a whopping **<s>117</s> [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##DchBCoMwEADAr4inXchhk003iWIfUfqBYFMMtCqmxYP07akwp9lqfS4b5CbPje7KGGdALNOyw7FP@ZUA4nBLj@@YYI3lk0iV@F7Ppy4oDuqOiNeWLRlvWCQYCuyt8ImdFXKWtRNvtLYXaZH6@MOqqf4B)**:
`for(i in 1:scan())show({while((a=Reduce(paste0,sample(0:9,39,T)))>"340282366920938463463374607431768211456")0;a})`

Comment: How do the floating point numbers have enough precision for 128 bits?

Comment: @Anush - They don't.  It wasn't clear to me from the challenge whether this was a requirement (if it is it should probably be specified explicitly, [see here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20533/95126)).  However, I do realise that this was an obvious limitation of the approach: hence the two other versions.

Comment: Thanks. It's a very nice set of answers all in. My thoughts were that the uniform requirement would already imply full precision. Is that wrong?

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##K/r/v6g0LzNNozg5MU9DU0fHJM7MRFNVX9Xwv6HBfwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk - Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>57 bytes</s> 41 bytes

```powershell
@(1..$n|%{(Random 1.0)*("2*"*128+1|iex)})
```

**Explanation:** `1..$n` enumerates integers from 1 to $n, `%` is an alias to `ForEach-Object`, `Random` decimal between 0 and 1.0, multiply by 2^128 through [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15368) clever obfuscation. `@()` encapsulates the result in an array, save 3 bytes if a actual array isn't needed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmdr@t9Bw1BPTyWvRrVaIygxLyU/V8FQz0BTS0PJSEtJy9DIQtuwJjO1QrNW8/9/AA)

**Original (57 bytes):**

```powershell
@(1..$n|%{(Get-Random -Mi 0.0 -Ma 1)*[Math]::Pow(2,128)})
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Powershell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191/tips-for-golfing-in-powershell) page for ways you can golf your program

Comment: Hi @ssh2ksh! Nice first answer! Make sure you get the `$n` parameter as an argument. For example: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVP01BPTyWvRrVaIygxLyU/V8FQz0BTy7AkCYyNTM1Kkmr///9vCgA "PowerShell – Try It Online").
I also changed the power calculation, and removed the `@()` that is not needed in this context

Comment: Rearranged to have less `tb` digits and less stuff after `Random` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVP01BPTyWvRrU6KDEvJT9Xw6QkScsCgjVr////bwoA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

*–1 byte thanks to Bubbler!*

```
RandomInteger[4^64-1,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PygxLyU/1zOvJDU9tSjaJM7MRNdQRzlW7X9AUWZeSXRatGls7H8A)

I wrote this and even I can't find anything interesting to say about it

Comment: Change `2^128` to `4^64` to save a byte.

Comment: The shortest answer containing the word random? Everything is interesting in at least one way :)

Comment: @Anush I applaud your glass-half-full attitude :)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (Browser), 99 bytes

```javascript
n=>crypto.getRandomValues(a=new BigUint64Array(n*2)).reduce((r,v,i)=>i&1?[v<<64n|a[i^1],...r]:r,[])
```

This feature is introduced eailer this month by [this post](https://github.com/w3c/webcrypto/issues/255). And it currently requires a recent version of Firefox / Chromium Nightly build to run.

It is a sad story that words `crypto`, `getRandomValues`, `BigUint64Array` are too long for golfing.

```js
const f=

n=>crypto.getRandomValues(a=new BigUint64Array(n*2)).reduce((r,v,i)=>i&1?[v<<64n|a[i^1],...r]:r,[])

{
let len = 5;
let arr = f(len);
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i] + '')
}
}
```

Comment: No TIO possible?

Comment: @Anush No, this feature is added this month while TIO is outdated yearly.

Comment: Which feature exactly was added?

Comment: `crypto.getRandomValues` only support `(U)Int(8|16|32)Array` but not `Big(U)Int64Array` before. Try to passing `BigUint64Array` to `crypto.getRandomValues` will cause an exception before.

Comment: @Anush Also, `window.crypto` is only available in browsers. If you are using Node.js 15+, you may need to write `require('crypto').webcrypto` instead of `crypto`.

Comment: Could this perhaps be demonstrated as a Stack Snippet instead?

Comment: @Neil A stack snippet had been added. Although it only works on nightly builds browsers.

Comment: Worked fine for me in Firefox Beta 91.0, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 62 bytes

```
=MID(CONCAT((RANDARRAY(A1*128)>0.5)*1),SEQUENCE(A1,,,128),128)
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnFlcN6djVEpskqbo?e=YNT6va)

Excel doesn't handle 128 bit integers. What this returns is technically n strings of 128 random 1s and 0s, which could be interpreted as n 128 bit binary integers.  If Excel did handle 128 bit integers, then answer would be `=RANDARRAY(A1,,,2^128-1,1)` which is 26 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LεžyoÝΩ
```

No TIO, since it won't finish anyway.

**Explanation:**

```python
L        # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 ε       # Map each to:
  žy     #  Push builtin 128
    o    #  Pop and push 2 to the power this 128
     Ý   #  Pop and push a list in the range [0, 2^128]
      Ω  #  Pop and push a random item from this list
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
É♣ów]
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9w56OZiw9vLo/9/98UAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
É      # Loop the (implicit) input amount of times,
       # using the following three characters as inner code-block:
 ♣     #  Push builtin 128
  ó    #  Pop and push 2**128
   w   #  Pop and push a random integer in the range [0,2**128)
]      # After the loop, wrap the entire stack into an array
       # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 29 Bytes

```
->n{n.times.map{rand 2**128}}
```

## [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BB1y6vOk@vJDM3tVgvN7GguigxL0XBSEvL0MiitlYvOTEnRyM9taRYryQ/PlPz/39jAA)

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNQTy9PUy83saC6KDEvRcFES8vMpLb2f4FCWrRJ7H8A "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 17 bytes

```
{roll ^4**64: $_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/uig/J0chzkRLy8zESkElvva/XnFipUJafpFCmoahgeZ/AA)

`^4**64` is the range of numbers [0, 2¹²⁸).  The `roll` method returns randomly selected numbers from that range, in the quantity of `$_`, the input argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 49 bytes

```scala
def f(n:Int)=Seq.fill(n)(BigInt(128,util.Random))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcmxCsJADIDh3afImIAUWhBEqKCbg0t9gtjLSSRNT3uCID77eZPbz/cvIxuX@XqXMcOZ1UHeWTwscEjpU4JEiOi7k2fqL/JoopqhEx71Vg3bbrt@ZbVmYA/zRFQithuCiROCeq4f@j2kZ23zPxHQ6lt@)

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/) `srfi/27`, 45 bytes

```lisp
(for/list([i n])(*(random-real)(expt 2 128)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcfBCkBAEADQu6@YcplRkr3gW@SwMavJGoxV/n6Vd3vm541TLqPXFexPgcbXI8ZwW5DGdVTgwkGUQWGgjOGwJsqdcBTQibBC87oce23sIyG/ZwIHreuJKOcP)

depends on `srfi/27` package

Comment: Welcome to code golf, and nice answer! Just so you know, when a submission uses a certain package, it's common practice to put those next to the name of the language, e.g. "[Racket](https://racket-lang.org/) `srfi/27`, 45 bytes"

Comment: @AaronMiller I don't think that's common practice. I'd probably assume the string next to the name is a command line argument. And a note in the post is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 59 bytes

```c
f(n){int*a=malloc(n*16),i=0;for(;i<n*4;)a[i++]=rand();n=a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJha4MwEP3urzgKhUQd066MgfWXdEWCJt1BjSWJY1vpb3cXo3UdvS8h757v3jtTPx3rehgU0/yC2sWibMXp1NVMx/krT7HMCtUZVuBOx9uCiz0myaE0QjeMF7oUxXVw32fZSAW9tnjUsoGqIqV88wZ9OIso@uywma@V6yrrTIVOGjZhoFOoP4SJoetdCgSCQmOd53C4REBlnXBYj71OKSsdlJAVYwsVsIU/Qr4e0TSUdF84Rrre6NB/ZFDDM@RZGnxlPBDpsg/itA3S17AmEiSQfb3QrGsUhTD3gkvYOdItMmnUYe8Wf2SnmO/wFLbzxIfWJlf5xAlRPDZa8ItqBWp2W@D42xy2kmV8@saTMAVvYJPdjYpBEKiYm5j0DIDhuExA2IGjI0lm7SWNJcq/3PRqDpOKr7OhtmKr9aYh7tq@61XqTdg/HGWkZDNwjW6QuM/qlz38Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda n:eval('randint(0,4**64),'*n)
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoAgEEX3nWJ2OeLCKCKCbtLGqGwgRxkk6PSWf/PgPfjpzVfkfkpS/LKW24Vtd8Dz8bhbteJ4J87KmkHrcUDTasbmlBigph8UUpSsyxkFCIir94fqTGdxbuBfkvrgFSGWDw)

Doesn't work for `n=0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://rust-lang.org) with [`rand`](https://crates.io/crates/rand), 59 bytes

```
|n|->Vec<u128>{vec![0;n].iter().map(|_|random()).collect()}
```

[Try it on Rust Playground!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6baa193bba2a72891f76985853c5b701)

`vec![0;n]` is a built-in macro that generates a `Vec` of length `n` with all values initialized to `0`. While this macro does accept an expression as the first argument, unfortunately it only evaluates it once, not for each item. Otherwise everything from `.iter()` to the end wouldn't be needed.

I was excited when I realised Rust has native support for 128-bit integer primitives through `i128` and `u128`, but then I realised Rust's stdlib no longer includes RNG features, meaning we need the [`rand`](https://crates.io/crates/rand) crate to handle RNG. `random()` is from the `rand` crate. Specifically `random()` is an alias for `thread_rng().gen()` and generates a random value of the given, or inferred type.
Thankfully, rust's type inference is good enough that, even though we only specify `u128` in the return type of the closure, it figures it out and calls `random::<u128>()`

Comment: Another reason to love rust! And that you can print them out easily, unlike in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Ø⁷2*X’)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjEeN2420Ih41zNT8//@/KQA)

A monadic link taking a single argument and returning a list of random 128-bit unsigned integers of that length.

### Explanation

```
      ) | For each value from 1..n
Ø⁷      | 128
  2*    | 2 ** that
    X   | Random Int from 1 to that
     ’  | Subtract 1
```

If the output can be from 1 to \$2^{128}\$ rather than 0 to \$2^{128} - 1\$, which for practical purposes is almost the same given how unlikely it is to generate the extremes, I can shave off a byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 bytes

```perl
sub{join('',map chr rand 256,1..16*pop)=~/.{16}/sg}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDfaoMwFIfvfYozJ6u2rjaFyqhklN3tYm8wEK2JnqGJJClDuu7VXaIdbGyBhPz5fl9O0jPV7sZuCDgd9ak8v0kU4WIRd0UPx0aBKkQF210ak/WapMte9hH9TNZnkl4SXV/G7KQZvBSm2e@fsH4WJvO6AQJBdYPcZPBfu4Wj7DonblEwEKeOKTxCoWo7E8YJDoVSxZBLnoscyfYBKNwFPLRiiLKrZEJAcrdpkfsSDaAwrGZKe1wqcIVM4fCvL4Kz5zSOKZH@fMH9o2Dv4SbKvoFDORimqfsSqaoYdN@iSZJ4ks@Uc9i@tD@1CnJwt8@p@bhXtjDwK6zR6D34MbRM1KYJbSaKwYcPZ7AjSWGK2ffOef@X4FVc1xUy2KxmBJBf4RtK0sy7jCPZfQE)

Creates n random 128 bit integers. Or n strings of 16 random 8 bit chars. How to print the array elements as decimal numbers can be seen by clicking the "Try it online" link.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
ÇMq2pIÑ
Ç       // Create the range [0..U) where U is the input, then map each value to
 Mq     // a random non-negative integer smaller than
   2    // 2
    p   // to the power of
     IÑ // 64 * 2.
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=x01xMnBJ0Q==&input=NQ==)

Comment: I don't think the output format has enough precision to represent all integers between 0 and 2^128-1.

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
ri{L{2mr+}128*2bN}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyiz2qDaMNfGKLdIu9bQyELLr1br/39DAwA)

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>27</s> 24 bytes (Old method)

```
ri{8,{G*YG#(mr\m<}%:+N}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyiz2kKn2l0r0l1ZI7coJtemVtVK269W6/9/QwMA)

**Edit:** had a better idea using the "repeat N times" operator. Saved 3 characters.

**Edit 2:** tried a completely new algorithm. Saved 4 characters.

**Edit 3:** went for the string manipulation side of things. Saved 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
ＩＥＮ‽Ｘ²¦¹²⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQMMzr6C0xK80Nym1SENTRyEoMS8lP1cjIL8cyDfSUTA0stAEAev//03/65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  Ｎ         Input integer
 Ｅ          Map over implicit range
    Ｘ²¦¹²⁸  2¹²⁸
   ‽        Random integer (0-indexed)
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```